# Is it OK to repost deleted answers as new answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23231123/456814) had 2 downvotes and was deleted ([you'll need 10k rep to see it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)). But then the answerer posted the same answer (with a slight edit) as [a completely new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23231237/456814), and it removed his/her downvotes.

Is this allowed/fair? In this particular case the answer is still wrong, but I'm just curious if this is a legal move to delete and repost answers to eliminate downvotes?

#### First Answer

> Something like this should work:
>
> Raw:
>
> ```
> function modify()
> {
>     var el = document.getElementById("divId");
>     e1.firstChild.nodeValue == "changed content.";
> }
> var el = document.getElementById("divId");
> el.addEventListener("mouseenter mouseleave", modify, false);
> ```
>
> If you're using jQuery for already existing functionality it can be smooth to
>   use:
>
> ```
> $("#divId").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function()
> {
>     $(this).html("<p>New content</p>");
> });
> ```

#### Second Answer

> Something like this should work:
>
> ```
> function modify()
> {
>     var el = document.getElementById("divId");
>     e1.nodeValue == "changed content.";
> }
> var el = document.getElementById("divId");
> el.addEventListener("mouseenter", modify, false);
> ```

Comment: The user will end up with an answer ban at the rate they are going. Second answer has been deleted as well.

Comment: lol well that's not good

Comment: you'll need 10k rep to see it -- My rep is lower than 10k, perhaps upload the screenshot so we can see it?

Comment: I don't have 10k rep either, we'd need a hand from a higher rep user.

Comment: @RUJordan so wait a minute, if you can't see deleted answers, how did you know that the guy had posted two instead of editing his first one?

Comment: @Cupcake because when I tried to comment -- the answer no longer existed. Then a bit later a new one popped up. Edits wouldn't remove my comments nor the downvotes either -- pretty easy to notice that, no?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are two things wrong with re-posting a previously deleted answer that has basically the same content:

1. The new answer doesn't reflect the downvotes that the previous one received, so it's basically as if you removed all the downvotes.
2. You clear the reputation loss of downvotes by deleting the answer.

**Re-posting the same answer instead of editing and undeleting the old one is thus basically abusive behavior.**

Maybe it was an honest mistake? You should ***politely*** mention in a comment that instead of re-posting the same answer, the old answer should be edited and undeleted.

If the poster doesn't comply, then I would flag a moderator about it.

Comment: _Maybe it was an honest mistake_ - for new users especially, or those not as familiar with the voting system, this can definitely be the case. **Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by ignorance.**

Comment: @Chris, the security zealot in me chuckles mightily at your bolded phrase!  ;-)  (Treat all externals as hostile.)  I also might grab the wonderful house idiom, **Everybody lies.**  Just trying to keep it light...

Comment: What about if the content has changed? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297104/is-it-ok-to-repost-deleted-answers-as-new-answers-when-errors-have-been-correcte