# Is deleting a question and posting a new one with issues fixed acceptable?

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-questions

Let's say someone does the following:

- Post a question,
- Possibly have it downvoted and/or closed,
- Delete it
- Repost it with the problems fixed

Is this acceptable?

The 'correct' behaviour would be to edit the question and wait for it to be reopened instead, would it not?

I had a specific example ([deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445282/cutting-an-array-into-pieces), [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446276/subarrays-allocation)) where the user did the above, with the exception that I don't think it's too likely that any of the changes made would've changed any of the downvotes and/or close votes, and the edits were actually made on the original post after closure, prior to deletion (not sure if this changes it).

This appears to either stem from a broken system, lack of knowledge as to how the system works, or an active attempt at gaming the system.

Comment: Meh they're just pushing themselves closer to an automated question ban...

Comment: @animuson If the net result is that SO loses a "bad" question and gains a "good" one, where's the down-side?

Comment: Related: [Is it OK to repost deleted answers as new answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251724/456814).

Comment: @ClickRick the 2nd question is still very much [`plzsendmetehcodez`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19780/163250).

Comment: It's ok for me, as long as it's improved, and at least, he followed/try suggestions in comments (which are sometimes specific by guess of the issue, and not: "Give more details"). I often ask for more informations in comments (did you check if there was something null? Did you find which line exactly was causing the crash?, etc.)

Answer (score 97):

If the new question is reasonable enough, who cares? In some cases the OP might even be better off by giving the question a fresh start. If you're downvoted into oblivion, you can make it a great question through edits, but it's still pretty unlikely that you'll recover. No matter how wonderful the system and community in theory are with reversed downvotes and all that.

If they were to proceed to ask the same question in the exact same terrible state again, they'll find out pretty soon that that's not going to work in their favour. If however the OP has understood and addressed what the problem was, and the site ends up with a reasonable or even great new question, I'd say that's a win-win.

Comment: This.  To me, the mission of Stack Overflow is not to be "as fair as possible in distribution of rep".  And certainly not "as strict as possible in enforcement of policy".  Rather, it's to have as high-quality questions as possible and as high-quality answers as possible.  If the net effect of the delete-and-repost is that we lose a bad question and gain a good question, I am 100% for that.

Answer (score 33):

If a newbie (or anyone else, for that matter) asks a question, and it starts getting downvoted like crazy, then the most natural reaction in the world is to delete it to save face (and rep).

However, that user still wants their question answered. If they think they understand what was wrong with their first attempt, then the most natural thing for them to do is to try again afresh.

Editing the closed question and waiting for re-opening is not appealing to the user since they have no idea if anyone will even look at the old question, and no confidence that anyone will see through the original downvotes. And anyway they have already deleted it in embarrassment.

If the 'correct' behaviour is to edit the question and wait for it to be reopened, then what is the incentive for the user to do this, rather than starting again?

Comment: Not simply whether people would look past previous downvotes, but whether anyone who downvoted before would take the time to reconsider, let alone reverse their vote. As you say, new users only need to see things going south once before they change their tactic.

Comment: +1 for the implication that whatever we decide is the desired behaviour should be matched by the incentive structure

Comment: +1. Getting a revised question reconsidered is *much* harder than getting downvoted in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot depends on whether the original question was a good one.  If the original question was a good one, then deleting the question serves future users of the site poorly since they won't be able to find it.  If the original question was poor enough to be closed, deleting it improves the site.