# Effectiveness of editing a question to bump it up to the homepage

Tags: discussion, support

I recently asked a question that has (as of now) 30 views, 0 comments, and 0 answers. It has not been flagged for anything and, in my opinion, is a [good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

My problem is this: I would not like to offer bounty on the question because I don't use Stack Overflow that much so my rep is very low. I then looked at What should I do if no one answers my question? on the Stack Overflow help page, which says, "Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question to the homepage and get more people interested in it." My question is: How effective is this?

Comment: It's probably a tl;dr for most people.

Comment: @Mysticial that's what I thought. I was just trying to be thorough because I've asked a few questions where people have asked for a particular file or to see more. Should I have not provided some of the files and given them upon request in an edit?

Comment: You should check out sscce.org for tips on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Following up on Wooble and Mysticial's comments - you should absolutely try to post a **short**, **complete** example, i.e. an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), or an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - I'm not too familiar with Android coding, but that seems **a lot** longer than it needs to be. And no, don't just omit some files. Construct a **new** program focussing on this issue and post **the entire** program, which should be **short**.

Comment: @Dukeling thanks for those resources - it is longer than it _needs_ to be. I generally err on the side of giving too much information when posting, which might scare off some people. Is the best course of action to edit the question down and hope people answer it or to delete it and ask again in a briefer version?

Comment: [Either is fine](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253438/is-deleting-a-question-and-posting-a-new-one-with-issues-fixed-acceptable).

Comment: If people end up having to vertically scroll through a lot of code, you should take that as a sign that you need a smaller example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't participate in the android tag, but when I browse my favourite tags and see a question like this, I usually run away as fast as I can:

- On the first line, it says that it is about a tutorial. I personally don't consider tutorial problems "real" problems, and don't want to spend time having to find out what the tutorial is about.
- When I scroll down, my scrolling gets hijacked by the embedded code window which has its own scrolling and seems to contain about half a kilometer of code.
- The large code "snippet" starts out with something that looks like 20 *import* statements. That tells me that you have not done much (any?) editing to help me zoom in on the problem. I basically have to find it myself.

I normally presume that the gist of the question is summarised in the last paragraph of the post - hence the scrolling - but in a case like yours I often don't even reach the end of the post before my pattern matching algorithm tells me to just forget about it. Too much work on my side to help someone who appears to have done too little on their side.

I am sorry if this last impression feels wrong and unjust (could well be, I spend just a few seconds to form it), but with the flow of questions, I am afraid that that is how things often go.

So my advice would be to find out what the core of the problem is, write a small example that reproduces it (ideally about 10 lines of code, but more if needed) and maybe tell people what you have tried so far. [This post](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert also contains some really good advice.

Then I am sure a lot more people will be willing to help.

Answer (score -1):

Whatever the question is about, it's far too long. Shortening it to an SSCCE as recommended by others would be the perfect solution.

Sometimes it's not possible, so leave only the relevant pieces there and post the whole code somewhere else for those who get interested enough to run it ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702939)).

Comment: I'm curious what's wrong with this answer? I intentionally left out everything already stated by Monolo.