# Is adding a reproducible example enough change to warrant a delete/repost?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question which received no attention except for a comment that without a reproducible example I was unlikely to be helped. I added one since then, but it was ~15 hours later. Now my post is buried, and although it is a higher quality question now, I feel as though it needs to be bumped. Is it acceptable to delete/repost, bump in some other way, or should I just give up?
If the answer is "edit it, and if you still get no responses, repost" What is the approximate amount of time I should wait after the edit before doing this? I was thinking 6 hours should be ok...?

(I read [Is deleting a question and posting a new one with issues fixed acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253438/is-deleting-a-question-and-posting-a-new-one-with-issues-fixed-acceptable) already and this question isn't quite answered since my post didn't get any downvotes or answers at all, but was simply ignored)

Comment: You could wait 48 hours then burn half your rep in a bounty...

Comment: Edits bump.  Re-posting is not necessary.

Comment: oh nice, didn't know that. That pretty much answers my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posts that are edited are bumped, which means that they appear at the top of the question on the active tab of the tags on the question. That guarantees that at least some users will take another look at the fresh edit. Deleting and re-posting is not advised, regular watchers of the tag might even notice that you re-posted and I personally find that very annoying.

You can edit your post as many times as you like so you can add new information to it when asked for in comments or when your own research pays off and warrants sharing that information.

Make sure that your edit is substantial enough to be found valuable by the users that revisit. Only changing 6 characters to make the post bump is not a much appreciated way of *using the feature*.

If your question doesn't get answered consider the possibility that something else is wrong. Maybe you have added too much code/context, maybe you structured the question wrong, maybe you missed a crucial tag. If you need direct feedback you could consider heading to a [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) that is open for assisting users with their questions.

As a last resort you can place a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on your question. That advertises your question for seven days on the [featured](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) tab.

Comment: As long as the chatroom you post your question in allows that sort of thing. ;)