# Can downvotes for "unclear" questions sometimes be misleading?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I've read on SO that the downvotes purpose is :

> how the community indicates which questions and answers are least
>   useful.

But do you deal with a situation when a question has been significantly downvoted because of being unclear, but then it has been edited by the same user or by another user and now the question is quite meaningful. Won't the existing downvotes in this case be misleading ?

Comment: Related: [Is deleting a question and posting a new one with issues fixed acceptable?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253438)

Comment: Thanks, so the suggested answer in the link above is to ask the edited question in a new post to get a fresh start.

Comment: I'd suggest first fixing the question before doing anything else. If it's answerable, there's still a pretty good chance that you'll get an answer even with the downvotes.

Comment: Re-asking the question risks you receiving the same downvotes if the changes you make don't actually improve the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you submit the question, the question should be as high a quality as possible.

Once you press that big "Post Your Question" button, you are effectively saying "I put as much effort into this question as I believe is needed and I am now giving the community the opportunity to openly judge it." If your question is unclear in any way, that if your fault and you deserve all the downvotes that you get.

I definitely do not think that there should be a way that you can just undo pressing the "Post Your Question" button and get a fresh new start. What you can do is delete that question and make a new question if the question was only downvoted for clarity. However, the quality of the deleted question will still count toward a question ban. The deleted question is, therefore, not a "get out of jail free card." If you post unclear questions too often, you may be question banned because of the quality of your deleted questions.

Comment: Question bans have more to do with posting bad questions than they do with deletion.  Deleting bad questions doesn't seem to have much to do with the banning algorithm, except insofar as early deletion can prevent massive downvotes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you for the information. I believe it is correct now.