# How to best deal with very similar reposts of a deleted question?

Tags: discussion

First there's this now deleted question:

*[Crop and resize the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809384/crop-and-resize-the-image)*

Which is followed by:

*[Crop the image using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53810434/crop-the-image-using-javascript)*

And then:

*[Image crop and resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811160/image-crop-and-resize)*

The OP seems to be asking the same question every time: *Please help me write an application that crops and resizes an uploaded image using JavaScript or Angular*. That said, each question provides different pieces of non-working code. Is the context provided on each of these different enough to warrant posting anew or should the OP have simply edited their original question?

Comment: Thanks for the links and yes, i've read those, as well as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253438/is-deleting-a-question-and-posting-a-new-one-with-issues-fixed-acceptable) which is good reference as well.  As someone who has just recently gained +10k rep I am now observing a world of users delete / post habits that I couldn't see before.  This has left me a bit confused about *exactly where* to draw the line when it comes to re-asking the same or very similar question.  The OP definitely gave some new context but is it different enough?

Comment: Both of those are at +3, too; is that a typical score for a question like that in [javascript]? I'd be suspicious if I saw that in [swift] or [objc].

Comment: @JoshCaswell - seem legit given the interest.  The second question garnered three answers and it wouldn't surprise me if each of the answerers give an upvote.

Comment: Fair enough, then.

Comment: It is legit.  Seems the [javascript] tag is in need for some half-decent questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not seeing enough to make me think that we need to take authoritative action and remove/close/downvote these posts.

What I *do* see is:

- Poor grammar
- Poor sentence structure
- Reliance on a third party service to post their code snippets (grr!)

...most, if not all of which, can be rectified by some edits to the questions themselves.

The requirement to not rely on any other libraries is odd given that they're using Angular, but...constraints can be artificial and capricious and are not an immediate disqualifier for a question.

If the OP had edited their original question with these posts, they'd have been *flayed alive* behind them having written a chameleon question.  They've done what we wanted them to do in the framework we presented; they had a different question about related code, so they *asked* it.  Let's not move the goalposts here and suggest that they are, somehow, not following proper protocol.

Comment: thanks, that all makes sense.  for the record, I didn't downvote any of it, but did vote to close the third post as a dupe of the second, since I felt they were basically asking the same question.  I'm still on the fence about my own close vote here and remain open to retracting it pending feedback like what you've offered.

Comment: It's *similar* but it isn't the same question from what I can see.  I see something similar between two different components but that's not enough to convince me that they're close *enough* to be marked as the same.  I maintain that the grammar is fairly poor so it's easy to mistake it but it likely could be rectified with an edit.

Comment: @billynoah: I haven't looked at the questions themselves, but consider closing the 2nd as a dup of the 3rd, so the one that's still open is their most recent version of the code.  (Unless the 2nd one was in some way a better question, or already had answers or something.)