# Are jokes that center around code on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

So please don’t call me a snit! Please! I am not humorless!

But where does a “question” like this belong? This really seems a bit too `133t` for Stack Overflow.

- [Can someone explain this regex joke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23643737/can-someone-explain-this-regex-joke)

Okay, I get it. Coding humor! Ha! So funny! Hilarious! Before the ambulance comes to take me to the hospital because I am laughing so hard one question: Is this something so semantically high quality that it needs to be on Stack Overflow? Let alone pumping up the profile ratings of the original poster & the question answerer?

**EDIT:** So I see the question is “on hold” as “off-topic” but my new question is what happens to the up vote reputation of the original poster & anyone who answered the question? So someone—as of right now—scored 70 reputation points answering a joke question? How fair is that to someone else who is putting real effort into real questions?

Comment: [main] questions are supposed to involve [actual, practical problems](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): `practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development`. Trying to understand a joke doesn't fall into that category, even if it involves regular expressions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke

Comment: @apaul34208 you're bringing that question up because?...

Comment: @Cupcake Just being a little subversive and trying to put things in perspective.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not high quality and definitely doesn't belong on Stack Overflow (or any Stack Exchange site for that matter). It should be closed as off-topic (which George Stocker did already).

The question can be rephrased to be on-topic, but I personally don't see much point in an "explain teh regex" questions. I think it should just remain closed.

Comment: @AmalMurali that should be closed and deleted. You know, because of the whole setting a bad example/precedent thing.

Comment: I agree with you Amal, but when I voted on close for a joke question, the moderators even removed my closure reasoning [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261505/is-it-true-that-if-someone-reaches-200k-reputation-he-she-gets-a-painting-with-a). Now, it is possible that it is not a joke, and I only handled so, but why my opinion got removed which is not offensive, not spam, nor anything, I do not know. IMHO, moderators are mostly dictators lately towards my activity, so it may not be a valid reference.

Comment: @FinalContest: The close-reason is removed once the question is closed. As for the question you linked, I don't see a moderator involved in any closure/reopen activity. See [the revision history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/261505/revisions).

Comment: @AmalMurali: ah, ok, thanks, so I should suspend my moderophobia!

Answer (score 5):

No, they're not particularly on-topic, but that one was on the verge.  If someone's really trying to understand a regular expression, we answer much, *much* worse questions around here on a daily, hourly, *minutely* basis.

Honestly, the thrust of your question sounds like a complaint/rant that "It's not fair that these people are getting reputation points when I'm putting in tons of work to *earn* mine!"

I don't think that giving someone 70 or 80 reputation points breaks Stack Overflow or the reputation market.  Try to [assume good faith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Assume_good_faith) for the asker and the answerer.  And even if one or the other really is just having a bit of fun, I think that's probably a net positive for the world.

If you disagree, you're free to downvote.  Just like other people are free to upvote if they find any of it informative, or even entertaining.  As someone who isn't intimate with regular expressions, I actually *do* find that answer informative and helpful as he breaks it down, piece by piece.  Except for rare cases of voter fraud, every user is free to vote however he pleases, without question.

I think it's going to be okay.

---

We gave away *thousands* of reputation on [this Unicoins question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789277/unicoin-mining-and-canvas-clicking) alone.  Are you outraged about that as well?  Or is that one in good fun?

Comment: [It's important to assume good faith](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251732/456814). We start crossing a very dangerous line around here if people start taking accusatory attitudes.

Comment: @Cupcake I agree with you.  Unfortunately, the OP sounds quite angry and spiteful, so that might be lost advice.  One must always be very protective of their fake Internet points. :)

Comment: @JakeGould I'm not sure how what I said could be interpreted as "projectng", so I'll assume you meant "assuming". And I don't think they're really assumptions, considering the tone of your text. e.g., `Okay, I get it. Coding humor! Ha! So funny! Hilarious! Before the ambulance comes to take me to the hospital because I am laughing so hard one question: Is this something so semantically high quality that it needs to be on Stack Overflow?` being fairly caustic and hostile, and `“Once they're deleted, none of the reputation will matter anyways.” Bingo!` being pretty indicative of reputation envy.

Comment: An upvote it's 10 rep.  A downvote is 2 rep.  So if 75% of people downvote, that's a net positive.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to engage yourself in humorist activities, request such a site. You could start off with this image which is my favourite:

[image]

Joke aside, the problem with joke is that:

- It increases the noise.
- Relative based on the culture, personal, national, sex, age and so on differences. It might be offensive to someone and I would assume that you do not wish to hurt anyone.
- It becomes more difficult to decide whether a basic question is joke or not.

I am very sorry to spoil your fun and this is not a joke answer either, albeit I am trying to express this visually in a bit funny format now ;-)

[image]
<sub>(source: [roselawgroupreporter.com](http://roselawgroupreporter.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/no-joke.png))</sub>

Disclaimer: I am merely referring to questions and answers. Sometimes, a little funny, but useful technical comment might be OK. It is probably more frequent at conferences, contributor summits and such events over a drink or so.

Comment: Related: [xkcd 208](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/208:_Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score -4):

Jokes shouldn't be **closed/deleted** but **moved** to..**?** Maybe every SE site should have a **Misc** slot with an auto-deletion for anthing with less than n upvotes? But then maybe not, we're so damn serious here!

PS: Great RegEx image!! Where does it come from? Are there more?