# Is it true that if someone reaches 200k reputation they get a painting with a unicorn on it?

Tags: discussion, reputation, unicorns

I've seen a blog post with Jon Skeet on it holding a painting of a unicorn with the title "What happens if you reach 200k reputation?"

Comment: [What Happens When You Reach 200k Reputation?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/).

Comment: I've yet to see Jon Skeet be wrong. As far as truthiness goes, he has it.

Comment: I've heard that you get super downvote and upvote powers, as well as access to the secret V.I.P. room, but they don't publicly admit that anywhere.

Comment: I'd like to receive a number of upvotes where `nrOfUpvotes = Unicorn.circumference();` in centimeters.

Comment: duh, just try it and see, whats so hard?

Comment: Oh. I guess I have to start again with the whole reputation thing, then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree. At least I gave you some work so you can get some rep for the tag editing. :)

Comment: Jon Skeet is nearing 700k now. You should actually be asking the question *"what happens when someone reaches 1m?"*

Comment: I hear that going forward you'll just get emailed an stl file, soes you can 3d print, a wee Jon Skeet, holding a painting of a unicorn

Comment: Not bad. Do I have to paint it myself?

Comment: I heard that when you reach 200 million, you get an actual unicorn.

Comment: I wonder if that's 200k SO rep or 200k network rep.

Comment: it's been rumoured that Vincent van Gogh comes back from the dead to paint you naked in a field of clover

Comment: Well if *YOU* reach 200k reputation, Stack Overflow will look into how you got there, notice garbage questions like this one that people vote on because they're fun rather than important, and then change the rules so that these don't count, and you'll no longer have 200k reputation.  :)

Comment: This was discussed in Stack Exchange podcast [episode #60](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/07/podcast-60-are-we-that-predictable/), 2014-07-16, about 46 min 23 secs - 49 min 24 secs ([direct download URL](http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/158893545-stack-exchange-stack-exchange-podcast-episode-60-are-we-that-predictable.mp3)).

Comment: They'll give you [UNIKONG](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320189/whats-with-the-stack-overflow-unikong-game) instead

Answer (score 193, accepted):

I got a *T-shirt* with a unicorn on it when I reached 200k, plus some other swag. Does that count?

The shirt is black, with the text from [Bobince's famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/100297) re-flowed to fit a Unicorn outline, in white. It is **AWESOME**:

[image: unicorn]

Note the red hand drawn circle.

But no, the painting was a one-off because Skeet was the first to reach the milestone. We now have nearly 50 users with that many points, unique paintings don't scale to that extent. You *are* offered some swag when you reach 200k, until such time too many people have reached that milestone; I believe the first 100 people or so to reach 100k got swag too, for example, but I was never offered any when I reached 100k as number 180-and-something.

I suggest you double up on your C# and Java, and beat Jon to 1 million, and see what the SE team will do to celebrate that milestone! Shouldn't take you more than 8 years. You'll have to answer every question he ever answered *better* to make sure he doesn't get more points for all the upvotes he gets from old answers, though, because he'll be there in about 4 years, tops, otherwise.

Comment: I have that shirt too, but I received it some time before I reached 200k. Come to think of it, I don't remember why I got it...

Comment: If someone beats Jon Skeet the universe will implode into a black hole and disappear into oblivion.

Comment: I remember now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108395/stack-overflow-t-shirt-3rd-anniversary-edition

Comment: @BoltClock that's the one!

Comment: The link to the answer printed on the shirt. Its awesome and hilarious. [http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732454](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732454)

Comment: @LoneRider: it's the first link in my answer. :-)

Comment: Opps.. missed that

Comment: _Bobince's famous answer_ OMG, I wouldn't have thunk I'd ever even try to upvote a 4000+ answer. ROFL

Comment: A shirt of a demeaning, **wrong** answer that breaks the site's own restrictive rules so that the site could celebrate its oppressive closed-mindedness? No thanks...

Comment: I want to be able to buy this shirt now. :(

Comment: **I want this shirt**

Comment: I am eternally disappointed that I never had the opportunity to obtain that shirt.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky You're no fun.

Comment: Can I buy the Tshirt somewhere? Or can I buy enough rep to get it? I'd rather pay money instead of starting to spam SO.

Comment: @Camilo Martin: He's probably dead by now. Nobody insults Ź̼̺͓̘ͥ̓ͯå̦̗̝̜̗̫̿͝l̻̻͐̐ͣĝ̜ͤͦͧͯo̜͉͇̗̻̿̈́̐͛ ͍͖̮̘̖̓͑̓ͧ̀ä̶̻͇̯̙́͗̇ͦ̃ͅͅͅn̘̩͔̱͖̂̕d̉͛̍̃̎ͮ͊ g̹̪̺̣̰͔̳ͤ͐e̷̥͙͕̳̣͔̪̓̈́ͮ͑͛̓͂͜ṫ̲͔̪̪̮̠͈̘̟ͪ̂̕s̷̥̤̖̱͔̬̻͎̱͆͂̀͠ ͔͇̫̜͈̖͉͌̊̈́͋ͧ͟a̧̯͕̺͔̼ͨͪ͗̍͜ẅ̢̓̀ͨͫ҉҉̤͙̝̝̗̥ͅą̢̺͗͒ͥ̈͒͛̊̊̔ẏ̷̛͓͓͍͖̓́̔ͯͯ̃ͩ͠ w̨̱͚̻͉̩̮̜̯̭̤̗̝̱̻̖ͧ̉̑ͤ͐̈́ͩ̆͊͒͒̐̑̄̒ͫ̍͝͡iͣ̏͊ͥ͌ͪ͋͏̷̢̫̹͈̦̯̲̖͞t̷̜̖̲̟̘ͫͣ̋̔ͤͨͪ͡hͬͣ̌͂͗̃ͨ̔͒̄͋̆ͫ̇҉̤̥̤̹͚̲̗̬̪͔̖ͅ ̵ͤ̂ͩ̃ͧ͑͛̔̒͒ͯ́̚͞҉̭̭̦̜̮̤̙̥̻̺͎̟iͬ͌̾̍̔ͪ̌ͤ̾ͪ̆̃̌͑͒͏̷͝҉͇̖̝̪̮̫̖͔̯͍͞ẗ̶̛͖͙̭̳̣̬̫̘͇̝͇́̅͊̌ͅ.̶̵̜̳͔̲̺̫̝͖̹̦̹̦̼̯̮̺͉̿̓ͯͤ̓̉ͭ̏͗͘͘͘

Comment: @JustSid: You can't. There is no store, all swag is earned through site contributions instead. You certainly cannot buy reputation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Bummer... Well, only 185k rep to go! I wasn't planning on doing anything this summer anyways.

Comment: Is the shirt for sale?!

Comment: @SomeNickName: sure, deposit $50.000 in my account and we can talk about delivery. Or did you not mean *my* shirt?

Comment: @CamiloMartin Actually, it's SO that's explicitly not fun. Furthermore, it seems the only exceptions are made, apparently, for mean-spirited, ignorant fun. The stickler is that the OP question had working, correct answers. That this was tolerated is bad enough. But to emblaze it on a trophy for the site's elite? That's... a bad omen, perhaps.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky its the most upvoted question on the site, ever. And its really funny. I point people to it at work whenever someone gets the idea to parse HTML with regex instead of a DOM parser.

Comment: @chiliNUT: I'd not push this, if I were you, I don't think Aleksandr is in the mood. Besides, it is no longer the highest voted answer on the site; it has been surpassed by Mysticial's [branch prediction answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902).

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know that. I forgot about that one, I know I upvoted it at some point.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky No shirt for you. (Plus, the only redeeming quality of that question was that answer...)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'd be tempted for $50, though I don't know why you had to specify it out to a 10th of a cent (yes, I do know... silly decimal ***points***).

Comment: @BoltClock: *How on earth do you do that crazy text stuff???*  I want it! (P.S.  I *so* want that shirt!)

Comment: @SuperScript this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16051344/213246) has some information about using Unicode Combining Characters in this way. The key word is "Zalgo."

Comment: It bothers me that the only remaining mistake of that post is front-and-center on that t-shirt (transgession).

Answer (score 92):

The first rule of unicorn paintings is you don't talk about unicorn paintings.

Answer (score 51):

As a user with 200k reputation, no, I did not get a unicorn painting, unfortunately.

I did, however, receive a Stack Overflow mug, as well as some miscellaneous swag. It's nothing special, but I suppose it's better than nothing at all.

Comment: Maybe you just didn't deserve one :-)

Comment: As you are a unicorn they should have just sent you a mirror.

Comment: What about newly elected moderators? :)

Comment: Hey, it could have been worse. They might have given you unicoins.

Comment: is there anything that SO gives after 100k?

Answer (score 22):

There are now 49 users with more than 200k reputation - https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=2&tab=reputation&filter=all.

I don't recall hearing that any others got a unicorn painting when they achieved that milestone.

I suspect that it was a one off occurrence.

Comment: Now I'm disappointed.

Comment: @AdamArold - In a sense I am too, as I've nothing to work for :)

Comment: I do agree with that. :)

Comment: @ChrisF - I thought you were already working for nothing... isn't that kind of the point of SO?

Comment: @Floris well exactly. I wasn't being entirely serious with my previous comment :)

Comment: "...I wasn't being *entirely* serious...", oh really?

Comment: What would have been REALLY cool would have been if the second person to get 200k had got a painting of a bull, the third person had got a painting of a triceratops, and so on; with one additional horn on each depicted animal.

Comment: @DavidWallace But how many horns can be on an animal?

Comment: @Wyatt we are programmers! We can just code some more on. StackOverflow has all the genetics programs we need for this.

Comment: Subtract the upvotes on common git questions and I suspect there will be very few 200k + reps... If only I had posted the question on how to undo the last commit!

Comment: With inflation, we are now down to [duocorns.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRwD0.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

Eric Lippert stated on the Stack Exchange podcast that he had gotten a sweater. He also stated that he was unaware that he had accumulated 200K points until had received the sweater at the 28 minute mark of episode 45.

http://www.developerfusion.com/media/150455/podcast-45-keeping-it-sharp/

Comment: Stack Overflow is like Whose Line: it's all made up, and the points don't matter.

Comment: ...unless you want a t-shirt:) For the record, I do.

Comment: So Stack Overflow had his delivery address without asking him?