# Where is my box of Stack Overflow swag?

Tags: support, email, swag

That question title isn't intended to sound demanding, I'm just unsure how to word it better.

So a while ago, I received an email from Robert Cartaino titled *Stack Overflow — You're killing it*:

> It's not often I get to reach out and thank someone individually for their contribution to a site, but I wanted to congratulate you personally for reaching 100,000 reputation on Stack Overflow! To be in the top, top rankings among the millions of Stack Exchange users puts you in some really elite company.
>
> Hitting a milestone like this is a great opportunity to take a step back and remember what the points are really about. It's not just the tens of thousands of community members who took the time to up-vote your posts; it's the uncounted millions of people — yes millions — who have also learned (and will continue to learn) from what you've given so selflessly.
>
> Words cannot express how much I appreciate what you've done for this community. You've worked hard, and you deserve a lot of credit for what you accomplished. I hope you've found the experience rewarding in your own way. But getting a big ole box of cool stuff from our sites is also a fun way to mark the occasion, so I put together a collection of swag for you. It's just a small token of our appreciation for everything you've done.
>
> Click here to tell us where to send stuff.
>
> Once again, thank you for generously contributing your time, your passion, and  your knowledge. You've made the Internet better for all of us.
>
> And for that, you should feel incredibly proud.
>
> Robert Cartaino
> Community Manager
> Stack Exchange Inc.

This was really nice and, honestly, I didn't really do it for any reward.  I think I learned more participating on Stack Overflow than I ever have in any other learning environment in my whole life.  Even answering questions  can teach you a lot.

Alas, I never received anything after filling in the form.  I replied to Robert twice via email (one at 8 weeks later and another at 10 weeks) but all was silent and I was unsure who else I could contact.  I'm sure there's a reasonable explanation for it, my mail got junked maybe?

As a last resort, I'm asking here.  I'm hoping to share some of the stuff with my colleagues, so it would be nice if I could find out if the stuff was sent, if it got lost, if the form I completed failed submission, or what else could have gone wrong.

Comment: Nobody on meta can help you with that, except for any SE employees that happen to swing by. I'd suggest using the [contact form](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) to contact SE directly.

Comment: I passed 100k a long time ago and never got such an email, so I guess you're lucky to begin with. :-)

Comment: Carl's conundrum was later sorted out [here.](/questions/321681/do-users-still-get-the-package-when-their-rep-reaches-100k#comment337004_321686)

Answer (score 317, accepted):

We had a baby. A month earlier than expected, my wife had a baby, and that's why it's late. As the resident 'lord of the swag', certain things collect and ping in documents that only send *me* alerts, thus a whole lot of stuff didn't happen while we spent nearly 45 days in the neonatal ICU waiting to bring babby home.

tl;dr - [babby was formed](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/how-is-babby-formed), but not formed enough, and stuff got way behind. The good news is, it *has* shipped or will within the next few days, so you can expect it reasonably soon.

We've fixed this, as it is a bit of a bus factor for us, Abby is now helping to get everything caught up.

Sorry about this, I've been e-mailing people who have been replying to Robert asking where stuff is, but I'm sure I missed a bunch. I hate it that this happened just as soon as we *finally* made the gesture of swag at certain levels more meaningful and fun, but life is what happens when you're making other plans.

Comment: I think you need a **lord of the swag** hat, maybe Winter Bash 2015?

Comment: +999.  Wow, I feel terrible for wondering what  became of that shipment last month.  Congratulations to you & your wife, and continued health for your new baby!

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Don't feel terrible, a big mistake I made wasn't just writing a post (that could have headed off a bit of confusion), I just kept saying "I'll have that done mid-week" as weeks just kept .. going by. It's my fault.

Comment: This is what I love about the Stack Exchange network. If this were any other site of this size you'd expect to see a robotic copy-paste response loosely apologising for the delay and/or making some generic excuse. But here we have a human giving a human response. It's friendly and heart-warming. I had no reason to ever click into this post, but I'm so glad I did. Congratulations, and I wish you and your family all the best!

Comment: A new baby brings chaos to most lives, I can only imagine how much that is amplified when they come a month early.  No apology necessary, when you have as much on your plate as all that!  Thanks for clearing things up, and congratulations, best wishes for you and your family.

Comment: "It _has_ shipped". For a moment I thought you were talking about the baby.

Comment: TL;DR: The baby shipped early, so the swag is late.  Priorities and stuff :)

Comment: I said a prayer for your little one. Best wishes!

Comment: Have you worked out what you're going to send Mr Skeet when he hits 1M? Better be good...

Comment: @chiastic-security *lots of hats*

Comment: @Compass and then take them all away on Jan 5th? Seems a bit mean.

Comment: Anyone else interested to know what's in the box?  I'm curious as I'll likely never find out myself :)

Comment: @Jeff: It's a secret :-) [Less than this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261505/1048572), though.

Comment: Hope your babby is fully formed now and will continue to form well. Congrats to you and happy parenting. My wife's in the process of forming second babby here, chaos will ensue again in our lives next year... ;)

Comment: Having spent the longest 10 days of my life in the neonatal ICU with our youngest, I still cannot imagine what 45 days must be like.  Hope you and your family are okay now!

Comment: "It has shipped".  How is babby mailed?  How UPS get package?

Comment: As a veteran of a month in NICU with premature triplets, I totally sympathize. It's stressful beyond belief, to the extent that it felt like a vacation to be at home dealing with three neonates.

Comment: Wow another triplet parent.  Ours spent about 45 days in NICU.  Grats on the baby Tim.

Comment: Hopes and prayers that baby and parents are doing well.

Comment: Delays for a baby are fine - https://www.markturner.net/2015/05/10/yes-coca-cola-ceo-brian-dyson-really-did-give-that-five-balls-speech/

Comment: @TimPost: Just wanted to say thanks for the 100k swag. :) Please thank the rest of the team as well! (Edit: and obligatory congrats on the baby, but it seems weird congratulating more than a year after the fact! =P)

Comment: As a brief update, I got the same message a couple of weeks ago, minus the "words cannot express" paragraph and (somewhat more crucially) the "click here to tell us where to send stuff" paragraph.

Comment: There was a brief moment when I thought "am I really *killing* Stack Overflow!?" but it quickly passed. Perhaps the wording could be tweaked to avoid misunderstandings by people for whom American English figures of speech are not always entirely transparent?

Comment: Belatedly [swag is allegedly being revived](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403782/874188) but I'm still waiting.

Comment: @tripleee Make sure you reach out to them if you're expecting something, I left the company last November, so I'm no longer in any of the loop(s).

Comment: @Tim Thanks, I guess you mean via the "contact us" form? The linked answer sort of implies that Cesar M is doing something, and I interpreted it to mean he was following a process where he would eventually reach out to me.

Comment: @tripleee You can comment there too (or contact them using the form to follow up) - this thread is from 2014 when swag got backed up due to me taking Paternity leave earlier (and longer) than expected, so I don't think anyone still there is going to be monitoring this.

Comment: Thanks, will do. I sent a "contact us" form yesterday [but I'm not entirely convinced the form is working.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406802/no-email-received-after-filling-in-contact-us-form)

Comment: I got a response now: *"We do not yet have any updates on when the swag will start going out. You do not need to provide any information at this time, and we will reach out to everyone who is eligible for swag to collect shipping information when we are ready to send it out. We will publish an announcement once we have done this so that anyone who qualifies that does not receive our messages can reach out directly."*

Comment: (FWIW [I have now received the 100k swag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411242/874188))