# What do I get with 100k reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, swag

What do I get once I hit 100,000 reputation? I'm getting close.

I remember Telerik was handing out licenses at 10,000.

Comment: A 6 digit reputation...

Comment: In the past the community managers have offered some swag to people reaching astronomical numbers. I don't know if 100k still qualifies.

Comment: You get a dotless reputation. No more dabbling in small amounts, just whole multiples of a k.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this should be documented somewhere.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: not sure it should be; that'd change the motivations why people participate. Are you answering because you want a T-shirt and a few stickers, or because you want to answer?

Comment: You get to stop for a few moments and think about just how people you helped !

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was referring the "6 digit reputation" comment ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun, Well, It's pretty obvious that once you have 100000 reputation, you'll have a six-digit rep figure :-)

Comment: I want a T-SHIRT!!!!

Comment: how about a hat, no wait...

Comment: Permanent access to the Christmas Hat features? I want my crab face back!

Comment: why don't you hurry up with the last 1.3k of points and let us know!

Comment: One silver badge from me by up voting at 24.

Comment: @MrLister "You get a dotless reputation."  Until you cross the 1m mark, and that stupid dot comes back.  Down with dots!  (Or should that be, "Down with dots|")

Comment: People starring this question desperately need a cup of coffee...

Comment: Your rep becomes .130 * [Jon Skeet](https://ideone.com/FLi5va)

Comment: You get what I will get 285 years from now if I keep not participating seriously.

Comment: @NathanOliver Huh! Are you suggesting Jon Skeet's rep will stop at the mere 771k he has as of today?

Comment: @LuisMendo No the .xxx will change with both of their reps.

Comment: `#if JONSKEET                                                   long int reputation_score;                                      #else                                                           int reputation_score;                                            #endif          `

Comment: you'll get job offers.

Comment: Even more KARMA! :)

Comment: @codeMagic what a conincidence to bump into you here.

Comment: @JohnnyCoder ? Probably not much of a coincidence. I'm around here quite  abit :P

Comment: @codeMagic: and I want a unicorn. A real, live, breathing horn wielding unicorn. Doesn't mean we deserve one however. :-)

Comment: Looks like you asked this question, to get additional points, to get you to 100K huh?

Comment: @Kairan , Reputation isn't affected in meta.

Comment: @JonasCz, you reminded me of [this](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/1989-06-11/features/8902080413_1_impaired-mister-language-person-humor-column) (Translation: It was a joke ;-)

Comment: @alexis, I must be Humor Impaired then. Uh-Oh.. :-)

Comment: In that case, I think Dave Barry's test proves you are not! :-)

Comment: A free potion for the callus on your fingertips due to all the keyboard hitting you've been doing on your way to helping out a metropole-sized quantity of knowledge seekers

Comment: A warm fuzzy feeling inside!

Comment: The link to the Stack Overflow Premium site.

Comment: @MrLister - Ok, I give up, how'd you do it?

Comment: Telerik is giving out licenses at 10k? Where do I go to get my schwag?

Comment: @JustinMorgan Nonbreaking spaces. The gray areas are runs of them, separated by one normal space each, essentially being treated as words.

Comment: **Who done got swag???**  I made a data query for this  http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/310972/100k-rep-users-eligible-for-swag

Comment: is there any kind of acknowledgment can I get if I reach 25K? at least a t-shirt, mug or anything?

Answer (score 255, accepted):

One [email](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/where-is-my-box-of-stack-overflow-swag) , a T-Shirt *(with stack overflow logo)*, one coffee cup, few Stack Overflow stickers....**and of course six digit rep**

By the way, this is what the coffee cup looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can I exchange the T-Shirt with a cruise ship?

Comment: Yes, if the cruise ship owner agrees ;-)

Comment: I want! Give me teh reps!

Comment: Damn, I have a long way to get this cup.

Comment: Damn! I need someone to offer me a bounty of 100,000

Comment: @BhargavRao , Why do you need 111K rep? You already have 11K ;-)

Comment: @CoolGuy 111,111 looks cooler than 100,000

Comment: I'm now curious to see what other goodies you may get for other milestones but then the surprise will probably be better! :) Jon Skeet must be getting close to a key to the offices.

Comment: @Sayse, here is what [Jon Skeet got on 200K](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/)

Comment: 99K to go, but hell i'll get that cup !

Comment: I want that cup! 90k more rep to go!

Comment: @Habib I thought I had seen a topic on MSE asking if everybody was getting a unicorn painting at 200K, and they said that was a one time thing. But I haven't been able to find it anymore. I think there are people here who might be able to confirm or deny that. :)

Comment: @RetoKoradi, I remember seeing that post as well, It was a one time thing, since Jon Skeet was the first person to get 200K. They *(Stack overflow)* don't do it any more

Comment: [It was an old SO blog post :)](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/)

Comment: the code on the mug should be recursive without proper TCO for kicks ;)

Comment: I wonder what Jon Skeet will get when he reaches 1 million rep..

Comment: @TravisJ It was this post I had been looking for: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261505/3530129. It was on MSO, no wonder I couldn't find it on MSE.

Comment: I was highly torn by the mug. On the one hand, it's in JavaScript (and I only have something like 176 rep in that language), and the indentation sucks, and it's clearly designed around a clumsy object model. On the other hand, it holds coffee, and it has a normal (but nicely-designed) coffee mug shape that doesn't stop me from dunking unlike most of the other swag mugs I've gotten, and it means one more day between doing dishes.

Comment: Also, how is your mug larger when seen from the code side than when seen from the logo side? If mine did that, I'd be ecstatic!

Comment: @abarnert, obviously it is a feature.

Comment: They chose Java for the Mug!

Comment: If I ever get there, I'd prefer a functional cup! Make it return an `IO[FilledCoffeeMug]` !!!

Comment: 75k more to go for me.

Comment: You forgot to mention the ever-encroaching sense of "am I wasting my life?" that comes with 100k rep the same as it comes with any other time-consuming Internet activity.

Comment: Damn... I want that coffee mug. WTB Reputation!

Comment: I only need 99893 points to get the mug, the T-shirt and the email :'(

Comment: I want that cup, lmao

Comment: @pulp_fiction: I thought that too at first, which would be a clever pun… but `'coffee'` isn't valid Java.

Comment: @Chirlo: I'm fine with OO if they really think the problem needs it, but in what kind of object model is the `mug` object responsible for filling itself with coffee? Unless they really do have mugs that can do that on their own, in which case… why didn't they send me one of _those_ mugs? Do I need 200K?

Comment: @JonasCz Jon Skeet will unlock a hidden privilege -- acquire a giant "M" with which he can protect himself when [opening a pluralization bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/203888).

Comment: I would definitely reach there..... 50k more to go for me....

Comment: need 30k more :D :) ;)

Comment: just started and need 99.5k for mug :)

Comment: the biggest aspiration of my life is now to get that cup, only 99.4k left.

Answer (score 27):

### A congratulations email and nothing else

Some months ago I was hoping to reach the 100k barrier, and yesterday i realized that received the ["You're killing it" e-mail](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/where-is-my-box-of-stack-overflow-swag) similar to that described by Andy E.

> It’s not often we get to reach out and thank someone individually for
> their contribution to a site, but we wanted to take this time to
> congratulate you for reaching 100,000 reputation on Stack Overflow! To
> be in the top, top rankings among the millions of Stack Exchange users
> puts you in some really elite company.
>
> Hitting a milestone like this is a great opportunity to take a step
> back and remember what the points are really about. It’s not just the
> tens of thousands of community members who took the time to upvote
> your posts; it’s the uncounted millions of people — yes millions — who
> have also learned (and will continue to learn) from what you’ve given
> so selflessly.
>
> Once again, thank you for generously contributing your time, your
> passion, and your knowledge. You’ve made the Internet better for all
> of us.
>
> And for that, you should feel incredibly proud.

but without including this part :-( :

> Words cannot express how much I appreciate what you've done for this
> community. You've worked hard, and you deserve a lot of credit for
> what you accomplished. I hope you've found the experience rewarding in
> your own way. But getting a big ole box of cool stuff from our sites
> is also a fun way to mark the occasion, so I put together a collection
> of swag for you. It's just a small token of our appreciation for
> everything you've done.
>
> Click here to tell us where to send stuff.

**Well now I just can say that I am very proud of this achievement**, but missing to show to my colleagues a coffee cup of this great site that helps everyone around the world to build extraordinary things!

---

**Update:**

Well today I wrote to Stack Overflow's community support, mentioning that I hit threshold, expecting big news :-)

Comment: I think the lack of swag may be due to them being between be vendors

Comment: Yep, I got the same email as you when I got 100k around July

Comment: Don't hold your breath. I got an e-mail at the end of February, and it mentioned the swag. I filled a ticket, and nada. I daresay there's a reason they removed that part.

Comment: @StoryTeller ok there goes my motiviation.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - All part of the longtime-contributer depreciation that happens at SO headquarters. I don't mean to bum anyone, but it sure feels like it given recent history.

Comment: this is really disappointing :(

Comment: Just reached 100k rep yesterday, in my birthday. Got the that email too. I was waiting for 7 years. I felt a bit sad.

Comment: Ah, boo. Just hit 100K (after about five years of active use, 10 of "having an account"), got the swagless e-mail. Sadness.

Comment: @Jorgesys did you ever hear back from community support?

Comment: @mikemaccana sadly no, in fact I will be the first user to reach 100K in SO in Spanish  https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all but probably I will not receive anything :-(

Comment: Note: for 1M rep, you get directly to the "nothing else" part ;)

Comment: March 2023, I haven't received anything and probably won't receive anything :( haha!

Answer (score 15):

### As of 2021, 100k swag is <del>(allegedly)</del> back

[This answer by a CM](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403782/874188) states that the swag queue is slowly being backfilled.

Personally, I got an email on August 5, a bit over a year after reaching 100k reputation on Stack Overflow, inviting me to fill in a form with my preferred delivery address, T-shirt size, etc.
<del>Still waiting for the actual delivery, though.</del> [I hear they are collecting a pile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401435/can-we-definitely-say-goodbye-to-swag/403782#comment865034_403782) which will eventually be delivered.

The current offering does not include the mug (drats) but there are socks, and a 250k swag set to look forward to.

---

Update: Arrived on Sep 28.

[image: Cheesy photograph]

Comment: Well, they keep this in effect for about another half-year or so, maybe I'll get that too... something to look forward to I guess.

Comment: The key to getting the mug is waiting until it's back ;)

Comment: Quite frankly I'm guessing they are focusing on gifts which can be sent in a package which fits through a standard mail slot and also want to avoid shipping anything heavy and/or fragile.

Comment: Perhaps they'll come up with an IKEA type mug: Clay, a suitable sticker, and an instruction manual ;)

Comment: The 100k swag I (finally) received came by FedEx in a brown cardboard box 90% filled with air, so my speculation about fitting the stuff in a regular envelope was refuted.

Comment: At least your new socks are not broken :)

Comment: For a split second there I thought you were commenting in reference to my _other_ socks. Now I won't need to buy a new pair just yet.

Comment: I hope the socks don't upvote your posts or you might get banned...