# Can I have "real world" badges?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

Some of the badges on Stack Overflow denote some significant amount of effort. 
It'd quite like to be able to discreetly brag in the real world.

Has the possibility of little enamel pins or similar been investigated, and is it feasible?

I'd be thinking the "golds" and perhaps certain rep milestones.

Is this feasible?

Comment: I bet they could make a decent amount of money if SE made "official" merch for the sites. They'd have to hire people to handle that though.

Comment: could always link your SO profile in your resume ;)  I think badges are public info.  Applying for a job seems real worldy.

Comment: There already is [swag for a certain rep milestone](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291791/1048572).

Comment: How about some stickers, everyone loves them! I hope SE is listening to this and give us some good stuffs to stick on our lappy

Comment: Bluetooth enabled micro controller + tiny OLED display and badge pin housing.  Write an app for your phone to query your [flair image](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair) and push it to the micro.  Voila - real-time updating flair.

Comment: Reminds me of this [deleted question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291842/how-to-get-the-badges-in-real-metal)…

Comment: The problem SE had with merchandise was handling the tax filings from accepting international payments. It was more trouble than it was worth at the time.

Comment: If you think this'll get you "all the chicks" you're wrong...

Comment: Only the ones worth having! (stack exchange personals anyone? Gsoh, no javascript programmers, likes perl for kinky fun). But no, I am thinking programming related conferences, so the perl gurus can meet up and complain about the rise of the python

Comment: There used to be an SE store where you could buy swag, but [those days have come and gone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store).

Answer (score 29):

Yes, you can, but you have to pay for them yourself.

And of course anyone can buy this item and *pretend* they earned it.

http://www.nerdmeritbadges.com/products/stack-overflow-gold

Comment: Jon Skeet would only have to spend $2,258.23 to cover [all his gold badges](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=badges&sort=class).

Comment: Whilst a nice thought, if I can give my money to Stack Overflow,  I would rather do that. Or at least start fabricating my own with explicitly permission.

Comment: @Sobrique If you want to give money, you could also give money to the charities that [SE and the moderators care about](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/12/stack-exchange-gives-back-2014/).