# What are the incentives for gaining reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I understand how different privileges unlock, and how you can gain access to different parts of SO with more reputation. However, is there any other incentive to gain reputation other than the SO unlockable privileges? Can employers see reputation, or is it something an experienced SO user can use on his/her resume?

The highest privilege (that I know of) unlocks at 25k reputation, but there are many users on SO who have over 100k reputation. What are the personal incentives to keep earning it? Simply because a user enjoys answering questions and helping others? Are there any personal incentives outside of work that cause someone to continue answering questions past the 25k reputation mark?

Comment: You keep gaining more [delete votes](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) until 35k rep, so people who vote to delete a lot of things might have incentive to keep going until then.

Comment: This question isn't specifically about professional incentives. While that may be someone's personal incentive, I was more asking about what personal incentives there are

Comment: we get free cookies after 21k

Comment: [OP right now...](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/83/839cc283bf374a478ebc2d132c2b5e1dcec318a9065272c5fb025c878633dbcb.jpg)

Comment: [Increasing a counter is its own reward](http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=3259).

Comment: You get a Mug with a programming Joke.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist if I could select comments as the best answer I'd pick this one

Comment: @zzzzBov is worthy too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I understand how different privileges unlock, and how you can gain access to different parts of SO with more reputation. However, is there any other incentive to gain reputation other than the SO unlockable privileges?

That's about it, really. Badges are another incentive, but they're not really something you unlock with more reputation, just something you earn along side it.

> Can employers see reputation, or is it something an experienced SO user can use on his/her resume?

Everyone's reputation is publicly viewable. I wouldn't put my reputation on my resume, but I might mention it if I were one of the top contributors to a particular tag that was relevant to a job that I was applying for.

> The highest privilege (that I know of) unlocks at 25k reputation, but there are many users on SO who have over 100k reputation. What is the incentive to keep earning it? Simply because a user enjoys answering questions and helping others?

Yes, that's about all. I'd add the fact that you keep earning reputation on old posts that you answered years ago (so you don't really need to keep answering if you don't want to).

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any personal incentives outside of work that cause someone to continue answering questions past the 25k reputation mark?

Yes! When you reach 100k [you receive a swag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291791/1529630).

Comment: Only 15k remaining to get mine!