# Where's my quarter-million swag?

Tags: discussion, swag

On August 25th I reached the milestone of 250,000 reputation on Stack Overflow, and received an email offering swag. I filled out the form, but it's been six weeks and I haven't received anything.

I was just hoping someone could let me know what's up, and hopefully I can get some awesome stuff to show off my excessive use of Stack Overflow ;)

Comment: It can take months for swag to arrive.

Comment: Does the new CoC even allow offering this swag? It can be seen as off-putting ...

Comment: @rene If you want to go that route, the CoC also tells us to be patient. :o

Comment: so you previously received the 100K stuff in less than 6 weeks?

Comment: Maybe the time it takes to deliver it is directly proportional to your reputation. (Good luck waiting another 9 weeks!?)

Comment: You could have at least waited [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/261748)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Come to think of it... I don't think I ever received the 100k stuff - I must've forgotten about that one!

Comment: It's delivered manually by unicorn from the SO headquarters. In case you live in Europe, it usually takes 6 to 8 weeks for the unicorn to swim across the Atlantic alone. And then because of the gulf stream, it typically ends up somewhere in northern Norway. Expect another 6 to 8 weeks from there, until it has found its way to the UK.

Comment: Oh, so you don't have the SO mug ?!! how are you still contributing without the mug!

Comment: There was a mug? Nooooo! I need it now :'c

Comment: yes, a big one! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291791/what-do-i-get-with-100k-reputation/291797#291797

Comment: Sorry, I copped it. *whistles in half-million*

Comment: (why don't you contact support instead?)