# Does SO still send swag on reaching 100k reputation?

Tags: support, swag

After reading some recent meta posts, it's not clear to me if users still get swag when their rep reaches 100k. Can someone confirm or deny this?

Comment: I was unaware this was a thing, if they no longer do what did the send to those who did hit 100k? It would be nice to know.

Comment: @Matthew: check this other [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291791/244297).

Comment: I contacted the support when I reached 100K and I have to wait : *Because we are in the process of setting up with a new swag vendor, we are not currently sending out swag. Once we've completed that process, you'll receive an email with instructions on retrieving swag so long as you are still subscribed to the Community Milestones email bucket in your email settings.*

Comment: Delay your 100k until stackoverflow finds a new vendor x)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you consider a (most likely: automated) "congratulations" email "swag", then yes. Otherwise: no.

I reached 100K earlier this year, and not even a T-Shirt that says "I reached 100K and all I got wasn't even a lousy T-Shirt".

And I just checked that email: no, there is no link in there, pointing to somewhere to get yourself some swag.

Edit: there was also no mentioning of "we are looking for a new vendor, you will be notified about *swag* later on*.

And in retrospect: I really don't mind that, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341253/285661).

Comment: I've gone from excitement on something I knew nothing about to disappointment on something that'll likely never impact me, a bit of a shame.

Comment: @Matthew I reached 100K *before* I learned that there was more than an email. Which again gives evidence to: nicely managing your own expectations is a corner stone of living a happy life.

Comment: *Edit: there was also no mentioning of "we are looking for a new vendor, you will be notified about swag later on*.* I had to email them to get that response.  That was over 6 months ago and I'm still waiting.

Answer (score 20):

I didn't get either my 100k or moderator swag. I wrote to SE team to ask about the moderator items at least and here's the reply from september, 30th, 2019:

> Hi,
>
> Unfortunately we still don't have a clear timeline on when these items are going to be available again. We do still have your original election swag request sitting in our system waiting to be processed, and it will be as soon as our team receives word that the mod items are available again.
>
> Regards,
> Stack Overflow Team

So that's ... good news. I suppose the problem is the same for 100k items, but we'll get some goodies, eventually.

I wouldn't hold my breath, though... Better draw a SO logo on a blank cup or start knitting a woolen cap if you're in a hurry.

Comment: FWIW, I can't imagine the company being able to prevent all custom swag printing services from using their logo. My colleagues gifted me a T-shirt with the Stack Overflow logo.

Comment: You're lucky. I only got one with "ATARI" written on it.

Comment: To heck with this Stack Overflow swag; where do I sign up for the "ATARI" swag?

Answer (score 20):

In case you're still wondering, I received my mail last night, and no, no link to swag order. All I got was just a personal email from [the dedicated Robert Cartaino, Community Manager Emeritus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392867/in-case-you-missed-it-shog9-and-robert-cartaino-are-no-longer-staff-members-at?cb=1), signed in Arial.

Comment: A "personal" email, sent by someone who is no longer on staff?

Comment: @codygray I was amazed too. Truly dedicated to the cause!

Comment: Probably an automated mail where noone thought about changing the signature

Answer (score 13):

According to SE employee animuson on Meta.SE over the last few months they've been the process of setting up with a new Swag vendor and trying to integrate the vendors process into SE's.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329071/136100

Comment: That sits in the 6 to 8 weeks queue ....

Comment: @rene the one where new items are started each year on Nevember 32nd?

Comment: Not that I would care, but: thanks. So I should probably wait for that to happen, before focusing on getting to 100K on another site here ;-) ... you know, to keep the motivation high.

Comment: @GhostCat maybe by the time you hit 250k they'll finally have everything sorted and will be able to send you a double set of swag.

Comment: Given my current reputation gain speed, that will be at least 5 more years. I honestly do not want to commit to that goal at this point in time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I made 100,000 last week, and got nothing. I mean, theoretically, swag could be on its way, but I didn't get an email nor a personal message.

**edit:**  It's on me... T_T   apparently you need to have a "community milestone" toggle enabled in your email setting. I didn't even know that existed. Turned it on now, let's see if a leprechaun appears somehow.

Comment: Well I've never always had the community milestone toggle set to on and so far no leprechauns so it can't just be that.