# In case you missed it: Shog9 and Robert Cartaino are no longer staff members at Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, community

<sup>Today on "In Case You Missed It"…</sup>

**[Shog9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9)**, a veteran Stack Overflow member and long-time Community Manager for Stack Exchange, recently [Tweeted](https://twitter.com/shog9/status/1216752358933184512) that he is no longer working for the company.

An [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342031/thank-you-shog9) was posted on Meta Stack Exchange to this end, thanking Shog9 for his years of service and wishing him well. If you'd like to share your thoughts, please do so there. Note that [Shog9 himself has also replied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342059).

In addition to Shog9, it has been noted that **[Robert Cartaino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino)**'s diamond has been removed as well, suggesting that he is no longer on staff, either.

These apparently inscrutable decisions on the part of the Stack Exchange management have led to [some further discussion on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342039/firing-community-managers-stackexchange-is-not-interested-in-cooperating-with-t):

> Today, we are seeing a new wave of SE actions targeted on work with the community: firing/letting go/agreeing to separate (the actual term is unknown and can remain an unknown forever) two very knowledgable and very trusted community managers: [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) and [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino).

This question has drawn [an official answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342045) from Stack Exchange management.

Comment: Oh, Shog9 is gone??!!

Comment: Wow. I would just like to say that, from my perspective as a cold, unfeeling, selfish person who honestly hasn't cared much about any of the various controversies so far and has mostly just been annoyed at people for being upset, I find this extremely upsetting.

Comment: Well, good for them.

Comment: I shall miss @shog9.  A lot.

Comment: And so the purge continues. Salyut, comrades.

Comment: Many thanks to Cody Gray for editing this question, and making it worth to be "featured". When I wrote it up last night, I was already tired, and in the process of logging of. I am glad that you stepped up and added all that content, and a more helpful title!

Comment: I think it's time for me to also leave SO. I can no longer support this company.

Comment: @Arulkumar I have a follow up to that  bug report. Hold the press. Breaking News. We have evidence that someone recently visited Area51.

Comment: SO Corp are out of their minds, its almost as if they're getting ready to replace anyone actively moderating or providing community insight with their own shills

Comment: @Sayse Yes, that is the impression I get, too. Which is one of the few reasons to stay around here, just to lean back, get some popcorn and watch that clown show. It is almost like watching the current US White House TV show, just without people dying and such.

Comment: "Clowns led by monkeys" is the latest fashion in companies, isn't it?

Comment: I think the first sentence could be clearer if you stated that Shog9 tweeted that he is no longer working for the company *and looking for work*; the second part clearly indicates that it wasn't his decision.

Comment: @HansOlsson it's ambiguously worded, "looking for work" does not necessarily mean Shog was fired that would be too horrible a thing to have to say or place in a résumé. It could well be he had expressed grievances and reservations on the handling of certain issues and management offered him the opportunity to "resign" Perhaps, perhaps... Shog felt confident about his stature and record on SE but management called his bluff. Pure 100% conjecture on my behalf.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I didn't write "fired"; merely that he hadn't found a new job and resigned for a better opportunity.

Comment: @HansOlsson  https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6815/i-am-stepping-down-as-moderator it seems  Shog9 and Robert  Cartaino were indeed both fired

Comment: Do we really need to duplicate this across multiple meta sites? It's getting hard to keep up there are so many of these posts on the same topics, which is exactly what the SE system is supposed to prevent.

Comment: @Mr.Boy When I came to MSO yesterday, **nobody** seemed to be aware. By now, this question received 166 up and 3 downvotes, and was viewed 3K times. So I think people do care. Strangely enough, when a house is on fire, most inhabitants really only care about that, and it doesn't matter to them how often the topic comes up. Err, 169 upvotes.

Comment: @Mr.Boy - Yes, I find it useful to see what the [so] community has to say seperate away from the noise

Comment: I was a little confused as to why this happened all these years later

Comment: Is asking a question about Stack Overflow alternatives allowed on Meta? Because it's time to find an alternative.

Comment: @MattR That is probably subject to discussion. But well, plenty of people that were active on other stack exchange sites are already moving. See https://writing.codidact.com/ for a first community "on the move", and https://codidact.org/ as a potential new place. Albeit, make no mistake: it is one thing to get the main readers and writers of a small community to relocate. But for the millions of people that use stack overflow ... very different story.

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC.I agree. But hey - we can learn from what made this site great, and what didn't work. It'd be *much* quicker to launch a second go-around. And we can focus on the stuff that made Stack Overflow great in the first place!

Comment: @j08691 It could be deliberate. A semi-common tactic among companies is to bring in a new CEO to make unpopular changes they want (layoffs, restructuring, direction changes, etc), then you "fire" (golden parachute) them, letting them take the heat for stuff you wanted to do anyways. Between the older layoffs, newer ads, and "welcoming" (aka "we desperately need new user numbers to keep climbing"), I strongly suspect SE is trying to position itself for an IPO or buyout.

Comment: @mbrig But it is not like we see the new CEO "taking much heat", do we.

Comment: F**k me. I'm surprised there's any space left for new nails on StackExchange's coffin. I didn't always agree with Shog9's point of view, but I always respected him because it was clear he cared deeply about the community. It was also clear that it was unsustainable for him to care so much and to be this competent amid so many mediocre new colleagues. I hope he'll find better projects in which he can grow happily.

Comment: Anyone want to make a prediction how long until they shut down Meta altogether?

Comment: @SteveBennett Well, *if* they have that in mind, then according to the timeline in that blog post, I would think it will happen within 1Q or latest 2Q2020.

Comment: It's hard to call that an official response. It's basically just saying "We can't talk about this. Deal with it."

Comment: @javadba Not naming anybody, but two important positions right now are held by people that have no knowledge of social relations.

Comment: The sociopathic corporate machine rolls on.

Comment: @mbrig: They are going to be very busy [doing a 10x](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY&t=15m57s) in less than 3 years. I don't see how this is possible, especially as the original reason to take VC money was to grow sites other than Stack Overflow, and this has failed. Stack Overflow is already saturated. They will have to come up with some completely new ground-breaking and revolutionary ideas and software to appeal to beginners (in software development) - that can handle the Eternal September. The recent events are also unhelpful.

Comment: [Interview with Shog9](http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/15494022-stack-exchange-sta.mp3) (second podcast series, episode 5, 2011-05-18). The interview starts at 11 min 05 secs. (This interview is strangely practically unfindable using a search engine.) *"...kind of got frustrated with the problems inherent in forums once they reach a certain traffic level."*

Comment: Well. A few months ago this post would have probably had 1500 votes by now. I think all the users deleted their profiles today before they even had a chance to vote this time.

Comment: @Keiwan There is an indication that Shog9 himself actually posted that tweet https://twitter.com/shog9/status/1217245698908778497

Comment: @dustytrash It was about official SO Twitter account that quote retweeted this https://twitter.com/shog9/status/1216752358933184512 with something like "Finally got it done."

Comment: How about a compromise instead @TimPost?  Give us a week.  These two individuals meant a *lot* to this community.

Comment: @DavyM Actually, the team [*did* post in a private room why they were removing the tag](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8174309#8174309) (link is public).

Comment: At this point after reading [Shog9's comments](https://twitter.com/shog9/status/1217557293518196736?s=21) participation on meta seems pointless. This is particularly telling - *"I don't believe anything posted to meta registers at this point, regardless of tone. The people you might hope to reach are not reading meta."*. Feel bad for Shog9 but they are probably best out of it and feel they'll have no trouble finding a greener pasture to move on to. Good luck Shog9.

Comment: Added to the timeline I've been working on: [stackexchange-timeline](https://stackexchange-timeline.webflow.io/#community-managers-shog9-and-robert-cartaino-fired-from-stack-exchange-inc)

Comment: @SamuelLiew Wow, very impressing technology, mostly depressing contents though ;-(

Comment: @SamuelLiew has anything substantially changed as a reason for re-featuring this post? I'm generally in favor, but I'm not holding out that SE will let it be featured considering what they said about legal concerns.

Comment: Yeah, here are my reasons: this was unfeatured previously to grant slots for CEO's and a sponsored tag merge post. Also, I miss Shog.

Comment: Can't argue with that. Godspeed.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Make that timelime a question (e.g. "Is anything missing?") and feature that question. That thing is so impressive (in either ways) it needs to been seen!

Comment: @OcasoProtal no, I am not going to advertise my personal project as a Meta post. You can however, feel free to share a link on social media or elsewhere.

Answer (score 314, accepted):

I'm shocked. The site is unidentifiable to the site I took a break from a few months ago.

Many moderators are gone and now Shog and Robert.

It's undeniably the end of an era. If we, the community, feel sad, I can only imagine how Shog, Robert and the rest of the team feel.

I wish you both the very best. You will be missed. Who will get our statistics and create our colourful graphs Shog? In seriousness, **thank you for all your work on here Shog**. You've been a backbone, a great supporter, a voice of reason and you understood what makes this site tick. How vital the community is, where we are strong and where we flail. Irreplaceable.

A sad and somewhat empty site today.

Comment: *The site is unidentifiable to the site I took a break from a few months ago.* Do you mind giving just a few thoughts how exactly that manifests for you? You see, for those who staid, we probably already accustomed to the daily amount of decline, so an "outsider" perspective" would be really helpful.

Comment: *I'm shocked* ... more like *we're [Shogged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315412/158100)* ...

Comment: @GhostCat Well, for one, Shog9 is gone...

Comment: @rene Well, being "shogged" was something good, wasn't it. It meant you learned something helpful that day.

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. absolutely

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. it's too long to articulate in the comments. It's like there's been a revolution and the people didn't win.

Comment: I thought so. And yes, that emotion is exactly how I feel since weeks...

Comment: I mean... i feel like we've been saying this all along, and you were pushing against us on it. At least it felt that way.

Comment: @KevinB I wasn't pushing against anything. I just knew that the network would have it's way. I'm a realist. I won't fight a futile fight. It's not a community owned site and it's clear we have little to no say. I woke up to that fact and grieved it a [while ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387651/the-world-is-big-and-i-am-so-small-what-are-the-implications-for-our-meta-commu). Just because I'm saying it as I see it, doesn't mean I'm pushing against anyone. Rallying against an organisation within the platform of that organisation is doomed to fail.

Comment: It's really very difficult to win from within although I have not given up all hope, I still hope we might be able to convince them to change course drastically especially if they realize that their way is not working. But even if not I don't have to agree with all they want. Everything kind of works up until a certain point and then the whole thing becomes unstable and suddenly crumbles and everyone will run away. The question is, I think, if we are yet at this point. Once one is prepared to go away if necessary it doesn't look so bad.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Are you willing to join the elite squad of resigning moderators?

Comment: I don't know what I am going to do yet, @machine. It's very hard being stuck in this position. I completely understand why the folks who have chosen to step down have done so. I'm strongly considering it myself, with the departure of Shog9, one of the last people that I could trust and that I knew had our backs. On the other hand, I feel like forcing out people like Shog and myself is what the company wants, and I'm not the type to want to give folks that satisfaction.

Comment: Why would you want to become a moderator again if you don't plan on participating on Meta? Doesn't make much sense to me. The community here is the only reason why I decided to start moderating in the first place, and it's the only reason why I continue. I certainly don't do it for the benefit of the company.

Comment: I didn't mean to offend, Yvette. Just because I question your thought processes doesn't mean that I don't respect you. The fact that I care enough to ask speaks volumes. Active participation on Meta is not, of course, a requirement. Although all of the moderators do at least follow what is going on here on Meta, as frustrating as it sometimes is to/for all of us. Being that defensive is going to make moderating a real strain, but I don't have to tell you this; you did the work for years. Anyway, I hope you, your family & horses are safe and doing well, despite the fires raging down under.

Comment: @CodyGray the fires are catastrophic, we had 500,000 hectare fire burning 10 km from us for 2.5 months. We now have animals on the endangered list. These are things that are important and where I put my energy. I do enjoy pottering and handling flags, but I'm not willing to put in the emotional investment into this site any longer. I guess that's what I'm trying to say. I do keep an eye on meta, I need to know the rules to follow and if someone disputes the way a flag is handled. Thank you for your well wishes. I hope you and yours are all good.

Comment: There's a weird deafness about the company these days. I like Shog, he'd (she'd?) run a query, make a graph, and listen to what the data said. Without prejudice. These days, the company tells us to be friendly to newcomers, then itself acts arrogantly towards newcomers and apparently doesn't notice, or even hear it when anyone says so. What is this, what's happening? SO was data-centric and openminded once. I'm sorry that Shog leaves.

Comment: Fair play to you Yvette for wanting to come back and help moderate, it's not something I would be giving my energy to. I've tried to fight in favour of SO for a while now, but I can't justify it any more. I used have so much respect for them, and they've eroded almost every last bit of it away. Save for a few well respected employees that remain there, they are now being actively hostile towards us. Such a sad state of affairs.

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. Since I've only ever made one post on meta I can respond to your first comment. I posted this in the CEO's 2020 Kickoff Blog: Where do you see Stack Overflow going? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393454/1819684 It sums about 5 years of decline I noticed. SO is not the site I found 7 years ago.

Comment: Off-topic: nice horses.

Comment: It's going to be worse and worse, soon yahoo answers will be a better place to ask questions

Comment: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9276/relicensing-content-under-cc-by-sa

Comment: Thank *you*, Yvette - for your patient, persistent prodding over the years. The company has always been too slow to listen (and then too quick to react), but it's folks like you, willing to step up and point out problems even when it takes years to get any traction, who've kept this thing moving forward.

Comment: @Shog9 thank you my friend and without you it feels so empty. You are an amazing person and honestly the best thing this site had in terms of a community face. Without knowing the details, I am not sure they can even realise how many mistakes they've made and how colossal it was to lose you. I speak confidently when I say that, as anyone who knows you would say the same thing. And there's some pretty awesome people working on the CM team, so to praise you so highly, it means something. I'm swallowed up in vet bills atm, I feel so bad I haven't given to the gofundme for you. You deserve it. xx

Comment: Don't worry about me, @yvette. Take care of your animals - once I get back on my feet a bit, maybe I can help.

Answer (score 168):

To me, in the past 3 months, this site felt a bit like this:

[image: Demolition]

I, like many other people wish Stack Overflow to grow strong in the years to come. But when there is a cause, there is an effect.

Shog9 and Robert Cartaino's departure further shows that company is unwilling to hear from the community.

You think it's okay to upset your regular users? Yes, you could probably upset a few users, causing them to leave without having any effect on the site. But when there is a mass exodus of your high rep users, there is an effect - few people will be there to answer questions from all your new users. When new users find out their questions will likely to go unanswered on this site, they will pay fewer visits on this site, if not stopping altogether.

With much reduced traffic, your next round of fund raising with the VCs will be hard if not impossible. Selling to corporate users will also likely be harder when you are rolling down the slope.

So, please, before it's too late!

Comment: I fear that ship has sailed. One part of me even *hopes* the ship has sailed.

Comment: [Was Monica's firing intended to “disrupt the status quo”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336623/165773)

Comment: It is already too late. Nine shogs too late, to be precise.

Comment: I see one problem with the image. It should read "Welcome! Demolition work in progress! No hats required!" instead of the "Danger" warning.

Comment: @gnat That's precisely it. The downfall began when the focus shifted from programming to socially engineering the profession of programming.

Comment: @user560822 Can you elaborate on what you mean by "socially engineering the profession"?  I do not follow.

Comment: @Amy It's much too complex an issue to properly address in comments. But it began with the "welcoming" debacle, which was a symptom of a vicious cycle of using the pursuit of diversity as an (insulting and unnecessary) excuse to dumb things down in a cynical attempt to meet exponentially increasing demand for developers, which in turn is a result of compounding technical debt created by the false economy of hiring cheap, dumb developers. This is a tech bubble, and it's going to be much harder to recover from than mere irrational exuberance.

Comment: @Amy Another interpretation is that SO has been taken over by ideologues who are pursuing diversity as an end in itself. That's always a mistake. Equal opportunity is the goal; diversity is the metric.

Comment: @user560822 I see, thank you for taking the time to clarify.

Comment: I think a big clearout of the old blood and an influx of new can only be a good thing. All too often on sites like this I see that mods and super-contributers get too entitled and feel like they own the place. There's never any shortage of talent, and a lot of the top contributors are only there because they're fastest at answering, not necessarily the best or most inventive. I, for one, welcome our new robot overlords.

Comment: There is a fallacy in your logic @GeoffGriswald.  First, You assume new people (or robots) would automatically fill the gap and provide as good answers to questions if old regular users are leaving in force. Second, you assume that those new people would not become feeling as entitled as current super contributors/mods if they contribute as much.

Comment: @GeoffGriswald this belief about fresh blood was quite popular in the past. And many were wondering why following it tends to break things instead of improving, until Clay Shirky posted an [article explaining why things don't work that way](https://web.archive.org/web/20191122004739/http://www.shirky.com/writings/group_enemy.html "A Group Is Its Own Worst Enemy"). Stack Overflow founders were probably among first who decided to give a try to alternative approach proposed in this article and it turned out to work fairly well until recent

Comment: I doubt questions will go unanswered. But the quality of the content will unquestionably drop. SO will have approximately the quality of content that Quora and Yahoo! Answers have.

Comment: @Telkitty the new people will obviously provide as good answers as outgoing curmudgeons. About 20% of the population is smart, 80% is dumb. There's a lot of people in that 20% waiting to fill Shog's shoes. I did assume that the new mods would eventually become as entitled as current mods, they obviously will, but it takes a long time for that to happen, years.

Comment: Is there a place in the web like the old stackoverflow - a place for technical discussions and zero politics? A viable alternative?

Comment: @user3002166 former SO members are currently building https://codidact.org/ which intends to be a site in the vein of how Stack Overflow was before it was ruined by greed.

Comment: @GeoffGriswald Your assumptions are fatally flawed. Stack Overflow of today is no longer a site that experts want to be on because it is perpetually flooded with barely-literate "questions" that could be solved by 5 minutes of Googling. Experts don't have the time or patience to slog through mountains of sand to try to find a single pearl - so the old ones stop contributing, and the new ones quickly learn that their expertise is less valued than their ability to answer "gimme teh codez" questions, and they stop contributing. What you're left with is a wasteland.

Comment: @GeoffGriswald Further, you're completely ignoring the fact that Stack Overflow's success is due in a massive part to the community of experts who have given their time and effort to curate the site, both in the form of moderation and by building tools that have become fundamental to its operation. Many of those experts are leaving or are no longer interested in continuing to maintain those tools when the community of which they are a part is actively being destroyed by the site's owners. The "new blood" of SO is wholly uninterested in that maintenance.

Comment: What a ridiculous claim to make. Why would new users care less about maintaining the tools? If anything, new users with zero or near zero reupation balance, no badges, no titles etc are going to work harder than established bridge-trolls who have nothing left to prove, no awards left to chase.

Comment: @GeoffGriswald: As a new user yourself, you are in no place to judge SE's regulars or older users.

Comment: Incorrect. I've been on this site for years, this is my work account. But even if I hadn't, this site isn't particularly special or unique, it's just a forum with moderators, same as any other forum online. Only this one has a few extra controls to upvote and downvote answers, a bit like Reddit. Other than that the principle is the same as any website anywhere. There will always be thousands of people willing to give up their time for free, in exchange for being able to wield power over users of a website. This is as true for SO as it is for a My Little Pony fan site or whatever.

Comment: Mods are not special, their contribution is not valued (otherwise they would pay you for it) and the work is its own reward. If you mod on this site, all you are is a normal user with a ban button. Nothing more nothing less. That's what Shog was, and there are literally a million Shogs waiting in the wings to replace him. Nothing of value was lost.

Comment: @GeoffGriswald: Shog was an _employee_. He did so much more than simply "moderate" the site. SE was his full-time ___job___.

Comment: Correct. I wasn't disputing that. The thread is no longer about Shog, and is now people responding to me for writing this: "I think a big clearout of the old blood and an influx of new can only be a good thing. All too often on sites like this I see that mods and super-contributers get too entitled and feel like they own the place." Ironically, this is a comment which you specifically should definitely read very carefully, but one which you appear to have skimmed over or missed..

Comment: You grossly misjudge me. Ironically, this is the usual approach by users that are "hating" on the "old guard". Complain, tell the old guard they're not reading, and resorting to ad-hominem replies when they can not come up with a proper reply.

Comment: @GeoffGriswald: Mostly, you seem to be trolling. That's the main reason you're using another account.

Comment: Mostly, I lost the password for my old account years back and started this one when I got a new job focussed on more technical and programming stuff to what I was doing before. The site has been an invaluable asset to me in the last few months, both before and after these high profile departures, which I only learned about by curiously clicking one of the promoted links while doing something else. My experience on the site was utterly unchanged before and after the "exodus", suggesting it has had little to no effect on end users. Or my end-user experience, at the very least. Site metrics agree

Comment: @Amy I think user560822's comments are slightly misplaced. Being welcoming is a laudable goal, and diversity is not the enemy, but obstinately burning loyal users and mods to get there is an incomprehensible approach. SO owners are chasing growth and the IPO at the expense of quality and community.

Comment: No they aren't. The quality and volume of answers is unchanged, if anything it's slightly improved. All they have lost are a few old-timers who were very, very replaceable and have already been replaced with better, newer models. Any sense of "community" is entirely imagined.

Comment: @GeoffGriswald I can see that none of your SO questions have been answered (apart from yourself) in the last few months, and the one question you got answers on was from non experts which didn't help you at all, to me that says everything about the situation.

Comment: Incorrect. I've had a few questions answered, and in every case where I've asked something, I've been given helpful advice which has led me to an answer or a solution. Where that has been given as a comment rather than an answer, I've gone and added an answer myself so that anyone else searching for the same thing sees it. There's no need for "super answerers" who collect tens of thousands of rep, and actually those people hurt the site rather than help it, by swinging their massive ego around. No need for moderators really other than to remove abusive replies... The site manages itself.

Answer (score 103):

Shog no longer being here is, well, unacceptable.

I am kind of caught between wanting to honor him and wanting to verbally lash whoever thought it was a good idea to let this type of talent walk out the door.

Shog is one of the most profound influencers for this space, and is invaluable. His insights are pure gold.

It is time for the Board of Directors to completely clean house on the decision makers of the company if this is the type of decisions they are making.

Comment: Hopefully the two ex-employees will come back [in case if they did not get another job]

Comment: @Mulligan with still Reinstating Monica in their name: we're entering delusional territory here. Time for you to enter the second stage -- anger.

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica They did not leave of their own free will.

Comment: Spolsky is the chairman and ultimately behind all of it. No sane person will buy the shares so he and other board members are stuck with them. So until they finally go bankrupt, nothing will change. The site is dead since many months back.

Comment: @Lundin or the potential buyer just requested the diminution of the number of employees as a condition for buying Stack Exchange.

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica Would you willing return to an employer that fired you? They'll have no trouble finding *better* work.

Comment: @meagar Nope. However, they manner they were let go is nevertheless really controversial.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; a protracted conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207011/discussion-on-answer-by-travis-j-in-case-you-missed-it-shog9-and-robert-cartain).

Answer (score 73):

At first I just assumed that those in leadership just didn't truly understand the impact their decisions where having on the community.

Now I realize that they actually have some sort of agenda. I'm sure there will be a lot more surprises in the coming years, *sigh*. I guess I'll just lay low until Codidact is ready. It's kind of interesting watching everything unfold, but at the same time it's very sad, and I'm quickly losing what faith I have left in Stack Exchange Inc.

Comment: What makes you think Codidact is going to succeed? I've seen multiple users mention it over the last few days, but there hasn't exactly been very much progress since they started months ago...

Comment: @Cerbrus If the quality of SO content is decreasing further, more and more people will try to create an alternative and at some point one of these attempts might succeed. I guess that some people put hope in codidact so that it may be the one, but it doesn't have to really and nobody knows really. I think about supporting them, if only financially. It seems to be a worthy cause.

Comment: What about the dozens of existing clones with actually _functioning_ Q&A, @Trilarion? Why not support a project that actually has a working site? Because they don't have the content or userbase to be of significance?

Comment: @Cerbrus That's a good question. I would restrict my support to open source clones just to make sure I don't end up in the same situation like here, but I fully agree that instead of reinventing from the scratch one should carefully evaluate all the existing alternatives. I did not do that yet, but would it needs to be done.

Comment: @Cerbrus  I remember that I glanced quickly at some examples listed at [Are there any clones/alternatives for running a Stack Exchange style Q&A site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/are-there-any-clones-alternatives-for-running-a-stack-exchange-style-qa-site) some time ago and found none really convincing. But improving an existing software might still be more worthwhile than starting from scratch.

Comment: One of the major flaws with codidact's process, imo. They've started from scratch. The project was set up back when Monica-gate happened, and they just now added the first actual code... Which is barely anything more than a template project. Waaay too much politics behind the scenes and too little getting things done.

Comment: @Cerbrus How much time would you give them to develop something usable before giving up on them? I think a couple of months is the minimum that one should wait at least.

Comment: Well, barebones functioning Q&A shouln’t take more than a week to set up, for a single developer.

Comment: @Cerbrus Ok. I see. Their progress is not as good as you would expect it.

Comment: That's the gist of it. They also seem too focused on the politics of it.

Comment: @Trilarion 6 to 8 weeks ...

Comment: Development started 2 days ago -- https://forum.codidact.org/t/development-is-go/561. topanswers.xyz/databases was created in a week, and it looks like crap. Codidact is being more meticulous than that. I believe they have spent an appropriate amount of time in their design phase, and they have quite a lot of people who will be contributing to the project.

I don't think the majority of people are going to just suddenly start using Codidact, but I do believe they will create a viable alternative to SO, and I will be using them once they do.

Comment: That 6 to 8 weeks time frame sounds way too small to me. This is an open source project being put together in people's free time, and there are a lot of components to a system like this: core dynamics, reputation/rewards system, moderation system, search system, frontend layout, database schema, user registration system, etc. These all have to be discussed, agreed upon, and implemented before an MVP can be considered ready. Edit: And I do understand that they have already been at this for some time.

Comment: Re: how long it "should" take... It took Jeff and whoever was working with him at the time six months or thereabouts before they were ready to go public with SO v1.0 (https://blog.codinghorror.com/choosing-your-own-adventure/ is dated March 2008, SO launched that fall).

Comment: @wp-overwatch.com: ["6 to 8 weeks"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/203057)

Comment: Thanks for posting that, i will check the platform soon as i can