# Why is "In case you missed it shog9 and ... " no longer featured?

Tags: discussion, meta, moderation, featured-questions

That [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392867/in-case-you-missed-it-shog9-and-robert-cartaino-are-no-longer-staff-members-at) was turned "featured" by a community moderator, it get "de-featured" by a staff member, without any further explanation.

Simple question: why is that?

Comment: Is popcorn included by default with these posts now? Cause I feel I'll need some...

Comment: I should invest in popcorn stock.  I have a feeling it's going to be a good year for popcorn.

Comment: Because on SO Meta this post can have greater impact than featured posts on main Meta and can actually drive more traffic and dissatisfaction.

Comment: @Patrice:  It's just a bag with butter and salt now.  Not even palatable.

Comment: @Makoto I am just trying to channel anger into reasonable requests for transparency. To avoid becoming too angry and rude ... see https://twitter.com/shog9/status/1217542885605662720

Comment: I'd be fine with it if a mod removed the featuring. Having a CM do it after explicitly telling us that only the mods control [meta-tag:featured] is... well... in line with recent events, I guess

Comment: @Ghost that is..... heartwrenching...

Comment: I've seen how this plays out, though @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC..  We get an official answer.  We don't *like* the official answer.  Much weeping and gnashing of teeth ensue.  While I'm [looking for a compromise here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392867/in-case-you-missed-it-shog9-and-robert-cartaino-are-no-longer-staff-members-at#comment749331_392867), I don't think anyone will ever be satisfied with the answer that's provided, since it'll be...what you think it'll be.

Comment: Also @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. [I happened to see that Twitter post too](https://twitter.com/MakotoTheKnight/status/1217549125345955841)

Comment: @Makoto That link to chat, maybe pulling in the quote ... would be enough of an answer for me. It is really helpful to know where the disconnect it, and why it worked out like this in the end.

Comment: tl;dr; Don't blame Tim Post.

Comment: @TravisJ:  I won't *blame* him, but the water level is rising and he happens to be caught somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Apparently Moderators don't "fully control [meta-tag:featured]", as [a previous super-unpopular action](/q/387546) claimed.

Comment: @pppery:  Analogous to how moderators don't control the Stack Exchange legal team and their advisers, I suppose.  It's very easy to say that a company precedent or legal concern would supersede any control *we* have with the content on the site.  There's already existing precedent in regards to this regarding [what the Dread Pirate Roberts already posted once here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445285/how-can-i-connect-to-a-tor-hidden-service-using-curl-in-php).  Also, DMCA.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[This seems to be the message in Chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8174309#8174309) that's being referenced, and is thus the ultimate reason why the post is unfeatured.

> Tim discussed this with me in a private channel. He wanted to unfeature it because of legal concerns. I was sympathetic to his position, but continued to press for more details/explanation. He explained that they're under a lot of pressure right now. Please don't blame Tim. I wasn't going to unfeature it, so he felt he had to.

Comment: Legal concerns of featuring a post? I have exactly the same feeling like always when somebody tries to explain quantum mechanics to me.

Comment: They're digging the hole deeper and deeper. This is depressing.

Comment: "He wanted to unfeature it because aliens"... way better now.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392972/what-are-legal-consequences-of-featuring-a-question

Comment: This is my fault, I nominated the post to be featured, but I didn't say for how long. Live and learn. ;-)

Comment: From the outside it looks as if SE is simply hiding behind weasel words.

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/48240/what-legal-concerns-may-be-caused-by-featuring-a-post-on-meta