# CEO's 2020 Kickoff Blog: Where do you see Stack Overflow going?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Hello members of the Meta community - I wanted to share [the blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/21/scripting-the-future-of-stack-2020-plans-vision/) I wrote to kick off 2020 and reflect on my first 90 days at the company. It’s intended for a wide audience, the tens of millions of people we serve, but also because I know you all want to hear directly from me. My style is to show, not tell, and I wanted you all to be the first to know when I shared a vision with our larger community. Our team and I will try to address your questions directly if you post them here.

I’ve been reading Meta and following along with the conversation here. My blog post is a high-level vision of what we’re doing, so it doesn’t speak to a lot of the topics that have been discussed on Meta lately, but I still want to know what all of you think about our message and our plans.

Given the goals of the business as I outlined in my blog post, and given that supporting the Community is a top priority for Stack Overflow, where do you see the network going in the next five years, and what do you think should be done in order to get there? I appreciate all of your feedback and answers. My team and I will read your answers and comments and will look for ways to include them in our planning moving forward.

Comment: Welcome to Meta, new contributor

Comment: G'day. Hoping for the best, but I don't think you're going to get far without directly addressing the sacking of community managers and ignoring everything that has been said on meta in the last 6 months.

Comment: I feel like having some input from you would be good on this MSE question, there seems to be misunderstanding somewhere as to terminology in your podcast; https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342646/merging-technical-sites-with-stack-overflow

Comment: Thank you for engaging with the community and giving us the opportunity for respectful discourse, something that has been severely lacking with upper management for months now.

Comment: Please take off-topic discussons to [The Meta Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197438/the-meta-room), or [Tavern on Meta SE](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), or [Discord](https://discord.gg/tpgZmwR).

Comment: If the style is "show not tell", then I don't really get how the latest actions SE has taken could ever be aligned with "supporting the community is a top priority". Also, the blog post talks about inclusivity, but there's no transcript for the podcasts, for instance

Comment: *2020 Kickoff...Where do you see Stack Overflow going?* If you want my honest opinion, the answer is *directly down the tubes* or *to the most dramatic type of system crash that follows a Stack Overflow* unless Stack Overflow the company starts recognizing & respecting the value of the community who created all the value in the company and site, enabled and supported by employees. In recent months, it *seems like* the company is intentionally pushing the community as far away as it can. Whether that is true or not, if it doesn't change quickly SO will be done.

Comment: *Supporting the Community is a top priority* Doesn't seem to be the case. If you want us to think that what you say is true, or have any real respect for you, you ought to be making some big changes soon. There are things going wrong, things have gone wrong, and the biggest thing that you need to do is *stop things from going wrong*.

Comment: Personally, I don't know what to say. My constructive feedback of your post and good wishes was ignored. Plus more resignations are coming like the case of Monika and SE is ignoring everything. Therefore, I'm not sure what I can conclude with these small actions. I wouldn't be surprised if the staff try to delete this comment too.

Comment: From your blog post: "and only 10% were women. Statistics like these have significant implications on how we think about making our community more welcoming, engaging, and inclusive." From wikipedia: "A National Public Radio report in 2013 stated that about 20% of all U.S. computer programmers are female.[24] In open source fields, only 10% of programmers are women." Love the statistical scare tactics. Since most of the technology asked about here is "Open Source". How do you propose to make the site more "welcoming, engaging, and inclusive" when the numbers here are the same nationally?

Comment: The lock on this question for 7 days while at the same time featuring it looked a bit strange, as if mods are a bit over-protective. On the other hand, the question was closed during that time twice. Maybe we need the functionality to make questions uncloseable (for example for important announcement from the company or the moderation) while leaving the ability to comment open (especially when they are featured) and only deleting single comments.

Comment: Where do I see stack overflow? I see turning into a place that only cares about enterprise helpdesk

Comment: So how about _showing_ the community how you're no longer sacking valued community members left and right.  You do realize that the value of your company is based on a community that does the hard work for free, right?  And that alienating them might not be the wisest business decision?  _Show_ us that you understand this, and stop blowing smoke up our asses.

Comment: @ChuckAdams From what I can tell, they seem to think "the community" (which is OK and going well in their eyes) is different from the "meta community" (which is seen as a nuisance by the management). That's why they seem to think all the recent fiasco (Monica's handling, license changes, firing Shog, et al) isn't really that big an issue (but rough waters for the time being). Just shows how out of touch they have become.

Comment: @P.P. They're not wrong, in that the meta community is comprised of, well, people interested in meta, and that's a subset that admittedly includes a share of drama-generating squeaky wheels.  Dysfunctional family or no, the meta community is still an essential piece of what keeps the place running, and they do help set the overall tone for good or ill.  If they want to get rid of toxic people with god complexes (c.f. Wikipedia some years back) then good for them.  Shog9 kind of struck me as one of the least toxic people here however, and the reasons for all the recent sackings are STILL opaque

Comment: @ChuckAdams The meta community is considerably small indeed. But it's designed (when a global meta was split) to be a place where the rules pertaining to SO discussed, clarifications asked, ideas porposed, disagreements expressed, etc. Disagreements were always there (even when Jeff Atwood was quite active). But the trust, goodwill & "OK, we agree to disagree & move on" aspect was always there. But recently, the attitude of management has been "I won't talk to you" and appear to surround themselves with "yes (wo)men" & fire anyone who disagrees...

Comment: I am not really an active meta participant myself but I always thought of it as something akin to a tag that I don't frequent often on SO (not as a separate group) and considered myself as a part of the "meta community". Personally, I read (read a *lot*) on meta but participate occasionally. So it doesn't sit well with me to cast some members as "toxic". Like any online community there are always a small number of trolls and unhelpful members. But such numbers are extremely low on SO, IMO. It's ironic that SE has sites like "the workplace"...

Comment: Apparently, naming an SO employee is now considered a personal attack. Any post referring to a certain senior employee by their name is very shortly deleted by a staff diamond no less. Are SO employees now beyond reproach?

Comment: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9276/

Comment: Locking comments for such a question is an evidence of bad faith. Why did you lock the comments?

Answer (score 709):

Prashanth, thank you for posting here. I did not expect you to engage with the community, but it is certainly the *right* thing to do. I hope you have a good experience doing so.

Let me address your question:

> where do you see the network going in the next five years, and what do you think should be done in order to get there

You are at a crossroads.

**In summary, you need to rebuild the trust of the community**

Let me outline my analysis of the situation for you.

This is a difficult problem to analyze and I go out on a limb to do so for you, risking the enmity and possible recrimination of others, especially your employees. However, I have a degree in political science and an MBA, and I won the moderator elections in a landslide not yet eclipsed by others, so perhaps I am uniquely positioned to provide you with an analysis.

I hope you'll give it consideration given the risk I take, since I don't intend to resign any time soon.

### Situation and Problem

I would have hoped you would come in at a good time for a smooth handover from Joel, but that was not to be the case.

Instead, you were handed a community upset over the firing of an extremely popular community elected moderator and the communications both before and after it.

You needed time to learn about your stakeholders and the system that is Stack Overflow so that you can make the hard decisions - perhaps that explains the timing of the moderator firing. This situation, however, was unfair to you, the moderator, and to the rest of the community.

Between then and now we have seen many community elected moderators - unpaid volunteers like myself - resign in protest. Their [resignation posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moderator-resignation) were prominently displayed ([featured](/questions/tagged/featured)) on the main pages of the site.

More recently we have seen employees released from service, especially the community manager Shog9.  [Never has a community manager been more respected by the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342059). We firmly believed he was on the side of the community. When he spoke for the company, we believed the company was also on our side.

Perhaps that is why he and the company separated: what he *was able* to communicate and what the company *allowed* him to communicate were incompatible.

### Implications

A community that trusts you is a community that is a sales force that eagerly asks their organizations to adopt your technology.

A community that feels betrayed will go out of their way to sabotage your sales and revenue.

I, for one, have been silent at my organization as they considered adopting Stack Overflow's technology, and as the goodwill between the community and the company has eroded, I have been glad more often than not that I did not become a strong advocate for the company.

The company has taken on investors. The investors demand a return on their investment. This is a problem that requires addressing.

### Need

Since before the community moderator's firing, community strategy and communications have been mismanaged.

I strongly suggest that you rebuild the trust of the community. This is a people problem, and you are the CEO. You need to make hard decisions.

One specific recommendation I will make is that you go to Shog9 with your hat in your hand and ask him to come back to consult on, and if it works out, direct the community strategy and communications for your company.

### Payoff

You say:

> supporting the Community is a top priority for Stack Overflow

If you rebuild the trust, I believe you will greatly improve the feeling that the community has that you support them, and perhaps win back your built-in sales force, which should have a significant impact on your revenue, pleasing your investors.

### Conclusion

I don't know if you have a plan to rebuild the trust of the community, but whatever you're planning for the near future you need to keep this in consideration.

We all have invested much time and energy, for no pay, into us building together a community and material with immeasurable value to society. The company has provided the capital, the strategy, and the tools. But we, the users, provided the content. And we licensed it to you.

We are partners, not employees that you can fire at will. We don't just go away. We want to feel like partners. We want respect. We want patience and consideration. We want to signal our intent and carry through without being shut down or called trolls. We matter. We want to believe we matter to you.

Thank you for your patience in reading this, if you got this far. I'll be happy to drop by sometime in NYC if you want to chat face-to-face.

It's the least I could do.

Comment: Given that I haven't exactly held the same viewpoints held by the vast majority of the community regarding all the recent controversial events, I definitely appreciate the impartiality of this answer.

Comment: *A community that feels betrayed will go out of their way to sabotage your sales and revenue.* I'm a comparably junior developer, but whenever someone has asked me about my professional opinion on SE teams in the past months, which turns out was a non zero number, I won't be caught dead advocating for it. This is the reason.

Comment: "*One specific recommendation I will make is that you go to Shog9 with your hat in your hand and ask him to come back to consult on, and if it works out, direct the community strategy and communications for your company.*" - Except if you have insider priviledged non-public information, we don't know how or why Shog9 was fired, and thus, we don't know if this is a reasonable request. So, you might rework a few text details here in light of that.

Comment: @VictorStafusa I don't have insider information, but I would put money on the fact that shog did nothing wrong in that situation and that management just made a (fundamental, deeply damaging, natch) mistake in letting him go. In fact, quite a few of us have put money on our trust of shog, as the literally 10.000$ gofundme campaign we raised shows.

Comment: @VictorStafusa I have known the actors here for a very long time. My analysis is based on the mosaic of information (immaterial non-public and material public) that I have, and it is as complete as I wish to make it given my limited time and energy.

Comment: @Magisch Yes, he probably did nothing wrong. In fact I think that it was more likely because he standed a personal decision in doing it right and refused an order to do something wrong. But we really don't know.

Comment: @VictorStafusa I'm fine with the egg on my face in case I'm wrong, and i'm pretty sure Aaron is too.

Comment: @Magisch And add another egg for me...

Comment: I will agree that I have not/would not push Stack Exchange for Teams in part because of what you said.  However, I acknowledge that what the Meta users think of as "The Community" is actually a very small part of the SO user base, so the impact of this is probably small to SE. (Though I am a normal user that recently got educated, so there may be more of "me" out there.)

Comment: @Vaccano on the other hand, many of the "casual" users of Stack Overflow don't even remember its name. I couldn't count how many times I've seen people with a Stack Overflow answer up on their screen and I've said, "Oh, you use Stack Overflow?" and they looked at me like they had never heard of it - and when I dug deeper, they had just got there from a Google search, and while they had seen the site many times, they never realized the name of the site was "Stack Overflow".

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer 100s of times, thank you @AaronHall

Comment: I would never "sabotage" SO. That implies malice and I would never do that. But the point is that decision makers have never heard of SO and it's developers that suggest this product or endorse it or speak out for it. And I won't speak out for SO anymore, because if I endorse them, my reputation is on the line too. And I won't risk that seeing what they did last year. But that's not malice, I don't do that out of spite. I just don't support it either and developers are the only support SO has. Without my voice, an SO product will not even be on the table when a decision is made.

Comment: @AaronHall that was precisely my experience - I learned about SO because after Google took me here numerous times, the name gradually seeped in.

Comment: Have you considered that by taking actions that are reducing the active user community, Prashanth *is* making the hard decisions ? -- Just not the decisions we want him to make.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Even if the actual plan is something we cannot agree with... actual execution of the plan and how people are treated during that process is what absolutely hurts the most. Also discrepancy between words and actions. If company is making 180 turn, at least they could be honest about it and drop the "building the community and cooperation" talk...

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Absolutely but transparency is in short supply these days.  Ironically, transparency is required for a healthy community.

Comment: @AaronHall - thanks for your thoughtful answer. I would like to take you up on your offer to meet face-to-face at our NYC office. My team will reach out to you by email to arrange a meeting. I look forward to engaging in a deeper discussion with you.

Comment: This is a great answer Aaron. I'm sad that you fear retribution from the community for voicing such an opinion. I think that this can be great improved though by spelling out some examples of rebuilding trust. It's the central crux of your answer, and you state it several times (and I 100% agree with you), but without some clear examples I fear SO will just continue to make decisions that, at the very least, look bad to us (e.g. 'into the loop').

Comment: It seems to me that running SE has much more in common with running a charity or a political campaign than being a traditional CEO.  The vast majority of the people that "work" for SE aren't paid, they do it because they think they're making the world a better place (i.e they're not paid in economic power, they're paid in moral power).  The second people decide they're no longer doing good for society, that workforce dries up.

Comment: @TylerH To be honest I wasn't confident with my edits either, but I'm a bit surprised to learn that it deserved a full rollback. Mind sharing your ideas?

Comment: @iBug I read the first half of your edits, did not agree with them, and at that point I looked for and noted the rollback and moved on - please hold off on more editing for now.

Comment: @AaronHall re: casual users, an important thing to remember is that a small minority of the user base generates the answers to questions, and so pissing them off even if they are a small percentage of the userbase can have a much larger effect.  It's of course hard to balance this with the fact that they are also the most vocal, and so you hear from them the most, too.  But what I worry about recently is that SE is alienating the people who make the site run, and that the effects of that won't be felt until months or years later when it's too late to change course.

Comment: @iBug Aaron's already commented, but FWIW I felt the edits ranged *mostly* (there were one or two helpful/correct changes) from unnecessary to incorrect. Specifically, some of the changes changed the *intent* of what Aaron was saying.

Comment: @BoycottSEforMonicaCellio They're easy to replace. The quality of answers expected now days is so low that we hardly need "experts" providing answers anyway.

Comment: "... risking the enmity and possible recrimination of others, especially your employees ..." Is that a sentiment shared by your co-moderators? Do you all walk on tip-toes these days?

Comment: @AaronHall, thank you for taking a lead on this, both in writing this answer and in offering to represent the community in NYC.

Comment: I would really like to recommend that my company use SO for Teams, as I think it would help our business quite a lot, but given recent events I won't be doing that.

Comment: Funny, I have entered a comment to the blog post and nothing appeared.  Perpaps the CEO is afraid of the users' posts.   Why to give an option to write a comment when nothing is then shown? I won't recommend the SO for Teams either.

Comment: He won't fix anything, he'll be gone in a month or so, and we'll get a new CEO who will promise to fix all his mistakes, to the delight of the community - but in the end will keep the changes and continue to run the site into the ground.

Comment: > supporting the Community is a top priority for Stack Overflow;  but on the flip side, it's also peddling things in addition to being a Q and A kind of website. I can see the difficulty in balancing the for-profit impact of stackoverflow, and the need for such a thing in the community by and large

Comment: If the CEO does this I will disable my adblockers for SO sites and disable "less ads" (although I might still disable tracking). I might even click on some.

Comment: @tukan, do not bother adding comments on SO blog. They so heavily sensor them. I made a minor comment that Sara incorrectly used coders and developers interchangeably, but the moderators didn’t publish it to avoid upset Sara. Also [Jon Skeet says:](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/11/the-loop-1-how-we-conduct-research-on-the-community-team/#comment-486655)
“I find this blog technically awful to support any kind of discussions”

Comment: @MiFreidgeimSO-stopbeingevil I see.  Why they just don't switch the comment's section off?  This a *huge* red flag for me.  CEO shows himself after a huge outcry after 4 months on Meta (first comment made me laugh really hard - welcome new contributor)?  Makes a blog post where the comments are not shown.  Is this a joke?  The SO wants to be sold or IPO?  I would not invest a single dime into SO company.

Comment: @AaronHall When you meet Prashanth (or not—any relevant event), where can we read about it in the future? Will you post on MSE or MSO? Your Twitter?

Comment: When? Let's not be too specific to best manage expectations (anything could come up), but should be within a week. I haven't decided where I should report yet. Maybe as an extension to this answer, as it responds to a comment? I want to keep the discussion on the thread, in the proper context, as best I can. Also, to everyone commenting here - I understand people are upset, but taking it out on the CEO who just got here (in CEO time) doesn't feel apropos. Please temper your language. By itself it may feel justified. When everyone does it, it feels like a riot. I don't think it helps.

Comment: @AaronHall I would post a separate MSO question about what (if anything) comes of the meeting. While I agree keeping context here is important, it would be lost in the goal of this question (SO/SE goals feedback). It also helps to have focused comments/answers and is [in keeping with prior efforts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334551/244695)

Comment: I still can't find any info on what the controversy is about and why SO management have taken their particular stance to community mods. Am I right in interpreting this as a factional war between groups vying for what type of North American liberal ethics should be imposed on the community?

Comment: @Frank Not sure this has anything to do with politics. If anything it probably just is a company wanting to make more money and thinking that the culture on this platform and specifically Meta needs an upgrade in order to do so.

Comment: @Trilarion Not sure we're on the same page, I was querying this recent controversy about the mod firings and so on, but I recently discovered that essentially it's about different factions arguing about gender politics and all that stuff the 'Anglo-Saxon' lot are banging on about these days. As far as I can tell, one group wants to adopt this US/Canadian 'woke' liberal PC craziness and redefined SO along those cultural lines (thus abusing SO as a vehicle for propagandizing this stuff, IMO),and one group wanting to avoid it. AFAICT it's a battle for a global tech platform,for propaganda efforts

Comment: @Trilarion In fact, if I had to make an educated guess, this is about some people getting fired because they fell on one side of the fence on this woke PC nonsense. Either for or against it. I can't quite tell. Not sure what the SO management or CEOs want, or the investors. But I guess what we are seeing here is a conflict between people wanting to make this community make money and people who want to hijack it for weaponized language.

Comment: @Frank This is all very speculative and I don't see the evidence for it. But it could be of course. It could also be that correct pronoun usage results in tons of profit, who knows. For the time being I believe that everyone at the company really wants to make money, one way or the other.

Comment: @Trilarion I still don't think we're talking about the same thing. I did some basic digging and found some vague online suggestions that the whole controversy is about someone who was fired for disagreeing with gender pronoun policy. Beyond that, I am not clear what the whole controversy is about. "correct pronoun usage" - it could also be that this fad of obsession with redefinition of the English language results in SO becoming of limited use to a soon-to-be obsolete minority. I don't see any long term profit in commitment to a short term religion.

Comment: @Frank: your understanding of the situation seems to be wrong, and your inflammatory descriptions of people's political beliefs ("crazy", "nonsense", "propaganda", "banging on" etc _ad nauseum_) are not helpful. Monica has tended towards being welcoming of all people, and her questions that seem to have led to her firing were merely clarifications of the policies that the company wishes to lay down.

Comment: My advice - if you are open to it - is to not see this as a debate with only two positions (with either side lobbing snark at the other). There are plenty of nuanced positions in the culture wars, and it is better for everyone if we can have neutral, useful discussions intended to elicit information. I think that was/is Monica's position too. (Most of us probably do not need to determine the exact red lines in the pronouns debate, but moderators probably do.)

Comment: @halfer Well this is just it. I have no idea who Monica is, nor do I care, and I think hauling up this person on a flagpost for some kind of religious martyrdom is as nauseating for me as my stance must be for you. I merely attempt to understand the situation, and so far my take on it is that there is a small community of SO members debating what is essentially 'gender politics', a topic that is practically off the radar where I live.

Comment: @Frank: well, you want to find out what the situation is about, so you need to care about who Monica is. Plenty of information on Meta for you - good luck!

Comment: We're supposed to meet in a few days. I'm going to try to post something by Monday. I'm quite busy as well, so please give me a little slack here. A person who will sit on their hands and bite their tongue while you do the analysis and make up your mind is someone you want to work with. Someone shouting "decide! decide! decide!" and shaking you is much more likely to get a "no-deal".

Comment: @AaronHall Thanks for this, and best of luck with the sit-down.

Comment: @AaronHall "we licensed it to you" - be sure to mention we licensed it under CC 3.0, not 4.0 or any other license. That's going to blow up sooner or later and the shareholders will not be pleased. (The board will act surprised, I'm sure.)

Comment: I want my analysis to include every important point on the table. I am considering that as well. I have limited time, but I'll do my best to mention it. Do you have a reasonable resolution for that? To optimize from where we are, all I can figure is we let users opt-in to the 4.0 license explicitly. Regardless, I'm not aware of licensing on Stack Exchange content ever actually coming up in a court case. Is it worth the cost and complexity? Why is it a priority to you?

Comment: @AaronHall [Relevant MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333094/). I wouldn't spend any significant time in the meeting on it, other than to say it was part of the broader pattern of ignoring the community. If you need a contrast, consider [the ill-fated MIT license change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271080/), which was halted due to community objections. I'm not sure I'd try to hash the particulars out on this (it's a legal nit-pick at this point). I'd rather see the points you raised dealt with.

Comment: @AaronHall "Why is it a priority to you?" If you would ask me, it would be because a clear legal basis is fundamental to every activity that follows, so rather more on a principled side. I'm a stickler for respecting the laws. But I guess that others are not so much interested in that. The contributions towards the gofundme site of jhpratt are currently well below $1k, so I guess most people don't really care about the license.

Comment: If you can change someone elses license, why have licenses at all? Why talk about copyright or CC this or CC that? Why consult layers? *(Why not start ripping Blurays and start streaming Disney movies here, you could just relicense them to CC 4.0, no big deal.)* It irks me that a company gets to pretend that they can *unilaterally* change the license of *somebody elses* content. It's either an incredible *naivety* or incredible *arrogance* which frankly, baffles me. Someone will sue.

Comment: The reasonable resolution is of course: since content was licensed to SE under license **X** - stop pretending it was licensed under license **Y**. (What new content is licensed under can be changed in the terms. I am talking only about old content.)

Comment: Changes from 3 to 4 were made for [good reasons](https://creativecommons.org/version4/), including global compatibility, in line with most users' wishes, to encourage the sharing of their content. If a user wants to enforce, in a court of law, terms of content written and published under 3.0 using 3.0 instead of 4.0, they still can do so. I haven't heard of a single enforcement action taken under law - and I don't see it happening because it would work against sharing. I expect the vast majority of users appreciate it when made aware. I'll bring it up - but I don't have anywhere to go with it.

Comment: re: "casual users" -- Yes! I was one. Landed directly in SE/SO answers from search results for years before I realized what the name/scope of the service was. I had no idea (nor did I care) why the pages were formatted so strangely and what all the little numbers/symbols/sidebars were, I thought of it as "that odd site w/ the answers" (I guess bc it was about helping people get to answers, not branding?) Finally registered, asked, and got downvoted, lurked for another year-ish before trying again to participate. Now add firing respected staff (Shog) to that user onboarding story...!

Comment: @AaronHall "Changes ..were made.." That's the thing. If the changes were unlawful, then they haven't really been made and we would be in a kind of legal limbo. Just because nobody sued so far, doesn't really mean it was legal. Can anyone still share content, if it's unclear which license the content is under? It might be best to wait until the dispute has been solved, but I guess that people mostly don't care. I would like to have clarity there or at least more reasoning; the company's legal department should publish a detailed analysis of why they think the re-licensing was actually possible.

Comment: It's not just between old content and users, SE is also misrepresenting to *third parties*, i.e. visitors what license the content is under.

Comment: @AaronHall what the heck are you talking about 'sacking of community managers'? This is the first time I have heard of anything. I am just a programmer who comes to SO to solve my programming problems. What was the reason SO gave for the sacking?

Comment: I didn't use the word "sacking" - and employers do not discuss that sort of thing. We non-employees make conclusions based on the few details we do have. I do not believe any party acted in bad faith here.

Comment: It's difficult for me to see Monica's dismissal as anything but bad faith.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I did my best to communicate that the community sees it that way to management. The community will get my report in a few days.

Comment: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9276/

Comment: Aaron's comment about being silent at his organization echoes with me. I've done the same - Teams could be a good fit, but I'm not going to advocate for it unless I believe in the direction and future of SO. And right now I (and I suspect others) are waiting to see what will happen.

Comment: I hope to post my report in the next 24 hours.

Comment: @AaronHall - I suppose your meeting will be on Monday.  I hope I am posting this in time for you to see it.  Apparently the company would like to add more participants with massive, quick growth, to enable it to make a quantum leap, and its focus is a handful of sites such as SO.  Maybe it's time for an amicable divorce, splitting off the sites that the company isn't prioritizing, and reforming as a non-profit, with greater autonomy than currently.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336246/287826.  Could you also please take a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337117/287826.

Comment: One more thing.  Reading between the lines of Monica's settlement text, my guess is that she never did get the dialogue she requested.  Could you try to get that set up?  After the tremendous amount of time and energy she put in, doesn't she deserve an exit interview?

Comment: `silent my organization as they considered adopting Stack Overflow's teams`.. I was expecting a consultant follow up..  in the past I would have jumped to advocate it, pretty sure they saw my comments on one of these threads and/or lack of any reply in email exchanges and decided not to pursue it. I've also noticed the price has dropped from $17 to $12. Joel isn't going to sell Atlassian another $400M Trello and SO is the prize. Jobs worked out well. However the entire business model without a community is down the toilet.

Answer (score 375):

The blog post talks exclusively about Stack Overflow and technical sites that are targeting developers. There are a lot of SE sites that are not technical at all, and they are not mentioned in these plans for the future. And many of the technical sites like Aviation are not about software and don't target developers.

Does the non-technical branch of the Stack Exchange network have a future here? And what does that future look like? What are the plans for the wider SE network?

Comment: I was about to write an "answer" the same effect. "It is critically important that we evolve our platform, community infrastructure, and culture to be more useful to our community so we continue to be a core part of a developer’s workflow." and "As we look forward to 2020, we plan to invest in public Q&A, expand our community, and continue to cement our place as a pillar of the software industry and broader knowledge economy." seem to be at odds with what we already evangelize about the network. We who are dedicated to this network WANT the entirety of the network to be maintained. Not just SO

Comment: I also wouldn't mind seeing more details around "[companies] have all announced efforts to use Stack Overflow as a platform for helping programmers to use their products." because people have been using [so] to support their products for years instead of maintaining their own forums. This feels like fluff for marketing "oh look now these companies are doing this yay for today now look new shiny!" and not "[companies] continue to invest in our ecosystem".

Comment: @jcolebrand a lot of companies "using" Stack Overflow as a place to support their developers simply dump them on the Ask Question page with no guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the question @MadScientist - We have ideas for how to better integrate technical content from across SE with the knowledge sharing that happens on SO, and vice versa. For the broader SE community discussing non-technical topics, we have no plans to change anything at the moment.

Comment: @Pchandrasekar first of all, thank you for coming here and engaging with us, that is very appreciated. Could you explain what you consider "technical"? For example, [bioinformatics.se] is a very technical site, but it isn't really about software, as such. Same for sites like [physics.se]. Conversely, [su] or [linux.se] are both techie and IT-related, but have little to do with programming.

Comment: @Pchandrasekar so are you contemplating the idea of merging the technical sites (ex: [dba.se] and [so])?

Comment: @Pchandrasekar When you say "we have no plans to change anything", do you mean "we will not be investing any time and effort"? The blog post definitely gives the impression that the concept of Stack Exchange as a broad community of sites on different topics is not a priority for the company right now; is that impression correct and deliberate?

Comment: @ChrisF valid. I hear you. And some don't monitor the tags for their own product, I agree.

Comment: @Pchandrasekar technical sites also means international sites? that are not adressed anywhere, and they rank high in Q&A...

Comment: @gbianchi: What do you mean by *"international sites"*? Stack Overflow in other languages than English? Foreign language sites (e.g. [German](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour))?

Comment: @PeterMortensen [SO in spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), [portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [japanese](https://jp.stackoverflow.com/) and [russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @PeterMortensen maybe localized were a better wording...

Comment: @gbianchi Speaking specifically about international sites (I'm not directly involved here - just chiming in on the technical aspect) - they would at the very least need additional thought beyond other communities. There are 2 additional issues involved: 1) much more overlap with question duplication, and 2) showing 2 different user-generated (language-specific) contents in the same chrome/page. For example: is the chrome of the site in English? Other? Just links? AFAIK nothing is set, but a lot of ideas on _how to better expose that these communities and content exist_ is what's in progress.

Comment: @Pchandrasekar While you say there are no changes planed for non-SO sites, does that include changes for SO that affect other SE sites? There have been a few recent changes ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337846/381197), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337915/381197)) that have been pushed for the sole benefit of SO, despite negatively affecting other sites on Stack Exchange

Comment: @JoKing If anything "Rewarding the question askers" was not for the benefit of SO.

Comment: @Pchandrasekar Can you please directly address [What resources is Stack Exchange dedicating to meeting the needs of Photography Stack Exchange and other "non-technical" sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340383/154627)

Comment: To be fair, both the location of this post and the blog are specific to SO, not SE. And I don't think it's unfair to address those two populations separately. All that to say, this response just seems "off topic". If it, and the corresponding follow-ups in the comments above, are going to be addressed, it should probably be moved to SE meta to hit the right audience.

Comment: @chill94 We were told to discuss the blog post here, and the author has responded to comments here; the "audience" for this response is the CEO and other staff who know about the context of that particular blog post. Separating it would serve no purpose other than bureaucracy.

Answer (score 318):

Hot take:

## These KPIs *terrify* me.

> We have seen some encouraging results: more people are asking questions, we cut the number of negative comments nearly in half, and December was our best month ever for new user signups!

Is it the case that the company is chiefly interested in:

- More users asking questions, and
- new signups?

I leave off the discussion of question quality only because it's not explicitly called out in the post.

This is also a bit concerning as well, even if I understand the rationale:

> A key part of great product development is to stay close to customers, listen, and take a thoughtful, data-driven, and research-oriented approach to building products. In our case, it is critical that we work closely with our community to listen, change, and evolve rapidly.

You describe two almost mutually exclusive indicators - something that is data-driven and something that is a heuristic.  **Who wins in a tie?  What carries *more* weight?**  What if the data is saying that downvoting questions should no longer be a feature for X, Y, Z reasons, and the *heuristic* is desperately trying to resist that?

Note that I did glance over the parts about other products bringing their support forums here, but [I have already left some thoughts on this matter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390991/1079354).

I'm glad that we're getting the high-level view of this, but I would believe that a few of these goals - stated explicitly or otherwise - deserve introspection at a very, very low level.  Thus far, I'm not too comfortable with what I'm seeing.

Comment: Could you clarify what you consider a heuristic and what not? I don't see any conflict here. What am I missing?

Comment: @terdon:  Data points are things which are measured, like polls, surveys and site data that can be queried, then analyzed to produce a numeric result in a consistent fashion.  A heuristic is going to get you a result but won't be consistent (e.g. talking to ten people in a room about how they feel about X).  **We are outnumbered - woefully outnumbered -** when it comes to how much people hate having their questions closed or downvoted, and my only waking nightmare is that the data from those users completely overrules the very real heuristic that doing those things with questions is **good*.

Comment: Oh. I see no reason why used impressions can't be quantified too. They'd be one more data point. But OK. I couldn't understand which part you were objecting to.

Comment: @terdon:  I will have to agree to disagree.  Enumerating the heuristic of whether or not morale is low or rations are poor or is the slipperiest slope you can find yourself on.  As a software architect, I believe that the recommendations I make for technologies should be borne out of my actual usage of them, and it should be an educated recommendation based on the pains I've run into when using them.  If one who is making decisions doesn't experience the same pain, then the decision doesn't feel like one that's meant to help with that pain.

Comment: Along with data points mentioned in today's post, we also keep a close eye on question quality. The blog below was our most recent look at the topic, and we feel good about the direction things are heading. This post also includes a link for a deeper dive into how we define "question quality."

https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/12/research-update-a-b-testing-the-new-question-form/

Comment: @Pchandrasekar:  Would this metric not be [*too* simple](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302970/175248) going forward?  This has been, in the past, a data point which has flown in the face [of well-established heuristics](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384376/1079354).

Comment: @Pchandrasekar:  I now see that this is in context to the new question form.  [I have thoughts on this, too.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381794/1079354)

Comment: @JuanM:  I see that.  Could I also slice that data up by traffic volume or by tag?  That's what I've been asking about for about a year now.

Comment: Looks like we're now [optimizing for sand, not pearls](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).

Comment: More questions require more answers.

Comment: The amount of new sign ups can most likely be explained about people fearing to post their opinions using their main account, given the extensive censorship and that whole pronoun debacle.

Comment: On *Stack Overflow*, @Lundin?  *Bull*.  If you're talking about your pronouns on Stack Overflow, you're already discussing something off-topic here.

Comment: ...see how long it took before I expressed that opinion, for example. Already someone cursing at me.

Comment: @Lundin:  Mostly because I had thought that [this was a settled matter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336857/175248) even if it left a backdoor open [for picking a fight with a mod](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337672/175248).  I'm cursing the very thought of this being a thing in this capacity - especially since we now have the ability/power to edit those out of technical questions as if they are noise.  I mean *you* no offense.

Comment: @user2943160 I don't see any correlation... Why do you think "more questions require more answers"? It would be fine with all extra questions going unanswered - you still get more questions and new signups...

Comment: "more signups" and "more questions" ... nothing about quality questions, and more importantly quality engagement from subject matter experts to provide good answers. I'm not a huge contributor, but in my limited focus I've seen quite a jump in really bad questions (that don't get closed or improved), and less than useful answers. As a contributor it's very disheartening to think that things are going to actually get worse not better as focus shifts to growing a userbase to try and emulate MySpace...

Comment: "piece of deliberately provocative commentary that is based almost entirely on shallow moralizing"?

Comment: These are the simplest KPIs that they can go with: more users and more user activity. Those are proxies for generating revenue. Honestly, I would be happy at this point in my career to pay $5 a month personally (or have my employer foot the bill) if the answers had a certain level of quality. More questions and signups != revenue.

Comment: @RudolfOlah:  Just because they're *simple* doesn't make them *good*.  I maintain that more people asking questions has no bearing as to the quality of those questions, nor does more signups have any bearing to how much more revenue the site will generate (e.g. unauthenticated users without an ad blocker will always get ads, and they aren't participating on Careers/Jobs).  But...I think you get my main thrust here.

Comment: @RudolfOlah: sure, but be extremely careful of using the wrong KPI. A 'signup' is not necessarily a 'user', at least not an active user. Some fraction of new user signups will bounce, some will only ever ask a single question and not come back, some will not even remember they signed up on that Q&A site that Google brought them to. Some fraction of new users will convert into active users (as measured over say 30/60/90/365d retention), and some of those will post low-quality/bad questions, some will post duplicate questions, and a small number will post good ones (non-duplicate, MCVE, etc).

Comment: And then there are the "sign up anew for each new question" - users ... and ppl using 20 accounts - not for voting fraud, but for oither unbeknownst reasons. There are even ppl having automated create / sign up scripts - funnily enough often revealing themselfs to be of indian origin - not a hard fact but just a impression of the very limited parts of SO I watch.

Comment: To some extend this is because of the odd dichotomy of the community at large *wanting* people to ask experts what's going on, and the need for the community to have *quality content*.

Comment: I agree with the replies to my earlier comment. They're the *simplest* KPIs, but they may not be the best for increasing quality of content on the site. It's like Eternal September all over again and the solution so far as been to walk away, find a smaller, higher quality community.

Answer (score 249):

> Given the goals of the business as I outlined in my blog post, and
>   given that supporting the Community is a top priority for Stack
>   Overflow, where do you see the network going in the next five years,
>   and what do you think should be done in order to get there?

Bankrupt, unless drastic changes are made quickly.

I think a 180° is needed in terms of communication. It is very clear that Stack Overflow has entirely and permanently lost the trust of the most engaged users of the site. There's no complete going back to what it was before, that much is clear.

I appreciate that this may sound ridiculous coming from me, an absolute nobody by comparison, but the greatest resource y'all ever had was the consent and enthusiastic cooperation of a large swath of high-activity users. These users provide a large chunk of Stack Overflow moderation efforts, and used to be your advocates at the decision making centers of your customers.

In business terms, most of us are software developers by profession. Most of us have medium to high influence on which products our companies buy for us. Given that you're trying to sell Teams directly to companies, and Careers to us, it's vital for Stack Overflow to have and retain the trust and cooperation of the user base.

I'm being blunt here, but I hope I'm not being rude. In no particular order, these things need addressing:

- Stack Overflow needs to regain the trust of your moderator community, which has seen waves of mass resignations on direct account of the company's conduct. If this trend can't be reversed, the biggest advantage Stack Overflow has over unmoderated spaces like [Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) or [Yahoo Answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Answers) will be gone.
- Stack Overflow needs to invest in curation tools. The process by which engaged users keep the quality of this site high enough to retain experts has been terribly outdated for the better part of a decade.
- Stack Overflow needs to lay off the current PR strategy. This isn't an ordinary company, and that much should be obvious. Textbook-style marketing and PR does not work here. Many of us know how the sauce is made, working in software development ourselves. That means that managing the message will **always** cause more damage than it prevents.
- The friction of the new user experience is the greatest cause of unwelcomeness and unhappiness in the model. Most of the "elitist" and "unwelcoming" reputation of SO can be traced back to this. We don't have the tools to help new users succeed, and new users get too little actionable feedback to improve their posts and get that feedback too late. Some steps have been made in this direction, but it's not enough, and it's been done seemingly from top-down, rather than by soliciting our feedback. This might not be true, but it feels that way. This feeling is a symptom of the communication issue listed above.

If y'all take anything away from this answer at all, I'd like to say that we used to have a really good thing going here. Despite all the historic dysfunction, despite the obvious mistakes of the past, you used to be able to tap into the expertise of a diverse and highly skilled community of volunteers.

The mistakes of the past were that not enough was done to support Q/A. The mistakes of the present are that it seems like the company has forgotten who it owes its success to, namely the volunteers. Even if that isn't the case and Stack Overflow is very well aware, that fails to come across.

Also, and this might be petty or unrealistic, I still hope for and expect a full postmortem and resolution of [the Monica situation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFiQPkdb5Qs&lc=UgzzH7ULmytO6-qi8HV4AaABAg), unblemished by what lawyers dictate. And I would hope for some respect towards the community managers y'all just let go.

The fact that we have to crowdfund severance pay for someone who, literally, dedicated the last decade of their life helping the company succeed; because y'all won't give them the respect of due notice or severance is heartless and incompatible with any company vision that keeps us in mind.

Comment: Quora has moderation. It is just unpredictable to a large degree, and totally lacking in transparency. The *only* thing they do better than SO is that you get a notification any time one of your posts gets deleted.

Comment: Look, can we forget about that crucial employee kicked out without any kind of warning, send-off, and severance pay? That was already a week ago, let's not dwell on the past. Let's focus on what is *really* important: what is the absolute minimum we need to do to stop more mods from resigning? Because we *really* like the free work they put in

Comment: @Pekka I would suggest that there's a common theme here: **the engaged community needs to be able to trust the company**. The PR strategy violates that trust, as do ignored feature requests (for better curation tools and for improvements to the new user experience). The company's treatment of a long-standing employee also violates that trust.

Comment: Quora has lots of moderation. It is 100% opaque (and no appeal), done by paid persons, and low quality (likely due to low wage). Quora is also ... less focused in its scope (which on one hand lowers the required moderation as there aren't any limits to [the](https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-a-wooden-ball-the-size-of-Texas-fell-into-the-ocean/answer/Dave-Consiglio) [silliness](https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-asteroid-16-Psyche-was-teleported-approximately-50-miles-off-the-coast-of-Southern-California), but on the other require moderation on (politically) charged subjects).

Comment: Paid answers (even with imaginary Internet points) and paid moderation haven't worked very well anywhere so far.

Comment: @PeterMortensen _Paid answers (even with imaginary Internet points) ... haven't worked well anywhere._ Please correct me if I'm wrong, but the Stack Exchange network appears to have been quite successful in it's original mission of creating a high-quality knowledge repository (at least until 2014 or so) by paying with imaginary Internet points.

Comment: @Pekka The CEO _engaged with the community_; we can't afford to drive him away, even if you're saying what we're all thinking. Best behaviour, and a little less snark, please.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 after all that happened, deigning to write a Meta post and answer a few questions is a long, long way from "engaging with the community" yet - if a good starting point. Should this turn out to be a genuine, long-haul renewal of community relations (which I'm not holding my breath for) you will see my snark melt away like a snowman in the spring sun

Comment: @wizzwizz4 you're opting for saying "it's okay sir, continue this way"?

Comment: @Zhigalin-ReinstateCMs “It's okay sir, continue to read our passive, emotionless explanations of the issues we are experiencing, and do not be put off by the feelings they've evoked in us” is indeed what I'm opting for. We have to walk on eggshells around the high-ups in SE, because making them feel even a _little_ bad about listening to us will merely discourage them from doing so, and we _can't afford that_.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I fear that an emotionless explanation is not conveying how much bad the things are currently going

Comment: @Zhigalin-ReinstateCMs We can state our emotions, which will convey it. But anything that'll invoke an empathetic reaction risks making the CEO associate "visiting meta" with "feeling bad", and we _need_ a CEO who listens to us going forward. We've lost CMs, so we've got fewer people to relay information to the decision-makers, so we need the decision-makers listening to us directly, and we mustn't make them feel bad doing so. We have to make them feel _good_ about hearing our complaints and doing something about them.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 that ship has sailed, circumnavigated the globe and sailed again.

Comment: Could be interesting to add a cryptocurrency tip feature, nothing mandatory, but you can tip the contributor you liked.

Comment: Hello @Magisch - thanks for your response. You make some good points and I agree with you in several areas. We should be working on different sets of tools to help mods and new users. Thanks to recent changes, we have seen encouraging results in terms of new user signups, more users completing questions, a lower percentage of questions being unfriendly, and stable question quality. But there is more we can do.

Comment: In terms of changing our PR strategy, we are making efforts to highlight the authentic voices of more developers - many from our community - on our blog, newsletter, and podcast. And finally, when it comes to rebuilding trust, I will  endeavor, through these conversations, to earn your trust about the rational for the changes we make and our long term plans.

Comment: @Pchandrasekar I would like to see that. For all the grief you're getting here (a lot of it is residual anger), the jury is out at the moment, so you have a opportunity to deliver on what you say. That you engage in these spaces is a good first sign.

Comment: @Pchandrasekar is getting rid of downvotes altogether, and making Stack Exchange be a social network part of those long term plans that you mention?

Comment: @Pchandrasekar can we have **any** specifics though? Cause.... you're in an era where SE doesn't have much trust left... and this post points to "yeah yeah, I'll listen, trust me!". But then the post gets locked. It's....... too little too late. And whenever you do come in and post (props for that, **truly**. It's a step in the right direction), what you answer with is..... very high level, doesn't point to any true solution, and seems to come down to "trust us, it'll get better".

Answer (score 229):

> All of this is in pursuit of new and more productive ways to work with and listen to our community in the next era of the company.

I won't bring up all the gory details again, I'm sure you have heard of some and had your hand (aka signature) on many more than we know about. But let me sum it up:

Many of the experts that this community builds on think that the last 4+ months have been a *huge* step backwards in this regard. It has not been productive and you did not listen. Those employees that did listen were fired. So what is left of new, productive, listening is basically just "new". That's not a lot compared to where we started off.

This community lives from experts, not new users. If I ask a question, I don't care how many millions read it or feel warm, fuzzy and welcome browsing it. I care about the one person answering it. And even if that answer would not be perfect, not welcoming, not inclusive or anything, if it solves my problem? Hell yeah, I'm gonna take it. Because I'm a professional. I need a professional solution. I can tolerate everything around that, all that "feely" stuff that has moved into the focus over the last year. Would it be great if everybody was named Skeet and every answer was perfect? Sure. But on average I can tough out a non-welcoming answer when it compiles and solves my problem, but I *cannot* solve my problem if the expert with the knowledge is gone.

So please, as much as I like your drive to make the site better, you need to moderate your zeal. A good and welcoming community is not a quality on its own. This is not Facebook; nobody is here because of "the community". Everyone of us is here to solve a programming problem, first and foremost. If your insistence of being nice and politically correct to the point of avant-garde gets in the way of solving my problem, **that is a problem**. Because, again, I'm not here to be nice or experience niceness. That is a *secondary* objective in all parts of my life. If it becomes (or apparently *is*) your prime directive for this site, we move in very different directions.

Comment: get off of your soapbox. Alienating experts in the making in droves is not an acceptable price to pay for retaining current experts. This is true for small companies and teams as well as for larger communities. Even experts are replaceable

Comment: @Vogel612: Thanks for the vote of confidence.

Comment: Experts in what? It seems like you may be referring to two groups of experts - SMEs and people who know how to write good content. Which type of expert are you focusing on here?

Comment: @Catija For me those two groups overlap heavily. I would probably not recognize a subject matter expert if not for their good content. But if someone who insists on calling me "dude" posts something that solves my SSL problem, my prime directive is getting my boss a secure connection, that's what I'm here for. If I'm treated nicely in the process, that is added benefit, if I'm not, I'll just complain that the internet is evil... but I'll take the solution anyway.

Comment: Thanks @nvoigt to phrase out something I very much agree with and which seems completely forgotten in many recent changes.Also I would recommend everyone looking at Crocker's rules at http://sl4.org/crocker.html ; I think they are a far better start to build something than just lowering the bar and pampering users to feel "welcome" but just allowing them to do anything and blaming anyone that tries to put them back on track (like nowadays even downvoting a question is perceived by some as being "unwelcoming", without even considering the **content** of the question, which is all what matters).

Comment: Re *"Everyone of us is here to solve a programming problem"*: Some (the majority?) are here thinking they are on a forum, at a helpdesk, or at a bootcamp (asking the instructors any question). The question interface does (almost) nothing to dispel that expectation.

Comment: I'd define experts as users who have written thousands of upvoted answers. Such users are contributing much more to the site that a hobbyist asking a few questions, but this group of users is being marginalized to the point many of us are leaving. I for one have stopped contributing to stackoverflow three months ago. I was a member for 10 years, wrote 1161 answers, received over 5000 upvotes, and helped 5.8 million people.

Comment: @nvoigt Overlap, yes, but they aren't exclusive and, as one can learn to program, one can learn to write questions or answers - sometimes you just need some help. For whatever reason you care to accept, even if only by reputation and not reality, many very talented developers are afraid to write answers here. I've talked with several of them. So, as long as that reputation remains, we are poorer as a reference because we lack their potentially excellent contributions. I believe that helping both askers and answerers to succeed from the start are good things to work on.

Comment: So, when we listen to the community, we are also working to listen to the people who want to participate but are afraid or confused... either they tried and failed and don't understand why, or they tried and got nothing in response, only silence, so they don't feel like their work was appreciated. And, to be clear, I believe the engaged meta community has long been asking for improvements to question asking and answering guidance so there's not necessarily a disagreement there. But talking to people who have failed is a good way to know how to improve things for them or people like them.

Comment: I don't read this answer as saying that being *welcoming* isn't a priority; I read it as suggesting that it's a *secondary* priority to professional, correct answers to on-topic questions.

Comment: +1 This exactly. Several years ago, back when I was new to SO, I got question-banned for a few months. Am I bitter? No. Did it scare me away? No. Instead, I think it is that kind of “beginner-unfriendly” moderation that makes SO (and, by extension, SE) the high-quality place it is.

Comment: And I am by no means saying SO is perfect in every way, or that it should be actively mean and user-hostile - not at all. Rather, I just think that SO should not give up on quality, both for questions and answers, since that’s the secret sauce in the first place.

Comment: Beginner-friendliness is amazing, full stop. But the minute quality starts suffering as a result, it destroys the reason _beginners want to come to SO in the first place_.

Comment: @Catija  What about the fact that according to SEDE data signups that post an answer within 3 months have been going down year on year every since 2013: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1184890 Are there any plans to encourage growth in the number of answers to match growth in questions? Or is this basic query miss-representative in some way?

Comment: @user1937198 It’s a good question. We are looking for ways to improve the answering experience much like we’ve improved the asking experience. I’m not sure where that is on our calendar but we definitely recognize that answering a question so that it meets our standard is hard and we could do more to improve the UI/UX. As to your query, I don’t have any alternative numbers and I don’t actually know SQL to check it. There’s some really experienced SEDE users around, like rene. :)

Comment: @Catija "many very talented developers are afraid to write answers here. I've talked with several of them" Did *any* of those mention they would be less afraid if a more zealous, en vogue, avant-garde policy around personal pronouns would be implemented? I have not heard that even *once* when I talked to people. Yet it is the thing SO did and it's driving away real experts. The fact that the new norm here is so over the top US political instead of a common sense common ground people could rally behind is what I mean with "zeal".

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head (this and the other answer that mentions KPIs). They want to grow but retention is just as important. Adding new experts to the community should help but retaining current experts is very very important. It doesn't matter how many new questions are asked if the answers are low-quality or if there are *no* answers.

Comment: @nvoigt "many very talented developers are afraid to write answers here. I've talked with several of them" I can testify that this is true. In fact, the vast majority of the talented developers I know, see stackoverflow as a "read only" resource and will never dare to participate on any role.

Comment: IMHO it's not so much "political correctness" per se which created anger, but the accusing and threatening tone used by some SE staff. It would probably have had a drastically better outcome for everyone, if the request to take more care with pronouns had been formulated as.... a request.

Comment: @yms I don't doubt that.I just doubt that any of the actions of 2019 improved on that.

Comment: @Catija "many very talented developers are afraid to write answers here. I've talked with several of them" I too know very many developers who see SO as a read-only resource, but the reasons they give (quite unprompted) for it being "unwelcoming" always stem from - on the one time they did try - being told that their question was poor quality, or off topic, or a duplicate... never because they were being personally attacked. It was the nature of SO itself that they found unwelcoming, the users were merely the voice for that nature. Without changing ...

Comment: ... the whole focus of SO, or at the very least vastly improving the feedback and interface presented to new users of why these things are likely to happen, it seems unlikely that would change. Unless we expect all of the SO users to develop their own long-winded pro-forma responses to every time they downvote, or vote to close, etc.

Comment: To add another data point: I've been a member since 2012, wrote 5701 answers, and "reached" (whatever that means) ~16.3M people. I stopped contributing back in November when SEI in an unmistakable way told me "eff you".

Comment: You [speak my mind](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335240/261639) to a degree that I feel all warm and fuzzy ;-).

Comment: @Klors But that's exactly what things like the question wizard are designed to address. If a user is guided in how to improve their question before they ask it, it's more likely to be higher quality, less likely to be off topic, and we may help them find a duplicate before they even ask... and we're seeing feedback that the new duplicate guidance is helping people find duplicates more useful or know better how to react to an incorrect duplicate closure... and we'd like to continue working on this.

Comment: @nvoigt I'm female. I have spent a non-zero amount of time complaining about people referring to me as "him" or "Sir". I've corrected people, too... It is stressful, annoying, frustrating, etc... to have people assume that you're the gender of the "majority" because the default in tech is male. On top of that, if I correct someone, there is no point where it's appropriate to have the response be "Really? You're smart for a girl!" This happens. It hurts. It's not political to want to be treated with respect or to not want to have to regularly correct people assuming your gender as male.

Comment: @Catija, yes it's not political, but wasn't "be nice" perfect, exactly because of that? Saying "You're smart for a girl" is extremely disrespectful. It's equally disrespectful to intentionally misgender non-binary people. I hope everybody agrees on that. The problem is IMO awareness. Somebody has to do that work, maybe there are ways which are less stressful and tedious. But instead, SE decided to stop talking, to accuse volunteers, and to fire moderators that asked too many questions. Well, it raised the awareness, but not in a positive way.

Comment: @Catija For the purposes of SO, an "expert" requires both skills. You must possess significant programming knowledge, be able to apply it, and be able to communicate it to produce a helpful, high quality answer. For the most part, those skills are equally required to produce a high quality question. (Non-experts do have interesting and useful problems, but without expertise, it will probably be a low quality post that experts need to improve.) Trying to split hairs about the nature of expertise is immensely unhelpful; it's just a distraction that doesn't help us solve any problems.

Comment: @Catija As for gender issues, the answer is not as simple as making advocacy a matter of policy. The old answer used to be to focus on the site's topic and leave other stuff out since it has nothing to do with the site's topic, and if something was kind of rude, you could flag it. The new policy is for staff to make as big a deal of the issues as possible. That's polarizing and frightening and turned SO into a sociopolitical battleground, irrespective of what your opinion on the issues are. Who the heck feels more welcome because of that? That's nvoigt's point.

Comment: @Catija I certainly am no activist, but I do believe gender neutrality would benefit this site. [This](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7335/should-rpg-se-enforce-a-specific-standard-for-handling-gender-pronouns#comment23066_7335) for example is from 2 years before the debate even started, from a SE even more male dominated than SO. Can you imagine how hard one has to screw up a gender neutral policy to have me be against it?

Comment: @Catija The answer is "pretty hard". I would call myself moderate liberal, in a country where we have a respectful female head of state and the whole US political landscape would easily fit into our conservative party, with Bernie probably being called a moderate conservative. Gender changes are paid for from our public healthcare system every citizen pays into. Our language has 2 pronouns (m/f) and the respectful way is to let someone pick which one they prefer. Telling me I'm a biggot and I have to refer to people with exactly the word they made up for themselves? That's US centric zeal.

Comment: "Be nice means do not use the wrong gender to address people. Do not assume a gender, when in doubt use a gender neutral expression like singular they or avoid the use of gender specific language." would have been a common ground everybody could agree to. It's rooted in common sense *and* the English language. Instead we are knee deep in discussions about neo-pronouns and it feels like firing squads are roaming the sites, read to jump when someone takes offense. With no middle ground between LGBT and biggot. It's either one or the other.

Comment: @Catija I'm male, but I have been addressed as a female from time to time (probably b/c my first name isn't very common in my country). Does it hurt? No, it's just silly. If needed I correct people and move on. Otherwise I simply ignore it. Gender neutral language would help avoid these pitfalls, but that obviously is not where SEI is headed, quite on the contrary. As for remarks like *""Really? You're smart for a girl!"*, that's just plain rude and hasn't been considered acceptable for at least as long as I'm participating.

Comment: @nvoigt *"With no middle ground between LGBT and biggot. It's either one or the other."* It's the old "if you're not with us you're against us" false dichotomy. Well, I guess I'll be against these people then.

Comment: @Vogel612 Experts in the making will make themselves.  Their future sucess does not depend on a passing mollycoddle from a semi-anonymous userbase on a development Q&A site.

Comment: I don't understand why *professional* seems to be used to excuse rudeness. As far as I am concerned *a professional solution* is a solution I'd be happy presenting in the work place, to clients or managers, and a *rude* solution would be regarded as very unprofessional.

Comment: @MatthieuM. *"I don't understand why professional seems to be used to excuse rudeness."* It isn't. That's just a red herring.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm not excusing rudeness. It's not professional to be rude. But as a professional I'm willing to tolerate more rudeness if it brings my boss results than I might tolerate if it were just my hobby project. Just imagine a waitress being more professional at their job than at their own kitchen table, still smiling at guests they would have kicked out of their own kitchen for far less. That's what I mean. I can be professional and ignore rudeness to get my answer. But there is no way I can ignore the expert no longer being here, because then there is no answer.

Comment: @nvoigt: Much clearer, thanks :)

Comment: @nvoigt I wouldn't call it "U.S. centric." Canada is facing many of the same sorts of controversies. And a significant portion of the U.S. population, from what I can tell, is not convinced on the pronoun issue, either. (There are *certainly* significant factions opposed to it.) I'm not sure what a better term is, but I don't think it's quite right to view it as an American thing to do.

Comment: @jpmc26 Lets put it this way: if I google neo pronouns in my native language, I get one private LGBT wiki, two private wordpress blogs and the fourth hit (and I'm not making this up) is already a SEO spammer/scammer telling me I can buy refurbished neo-pronouns if I click the link to their shop. Maybe I'm using the wrong search terms, but I'd say it's not that big a thing here. I have not seen anyone talking about it on a major late night show for example.

Comment: Another thing I maybe attribute unfairly to the US, I should say English native speakers: People say *words* make identity and their identity is hurt when I use or don't use a *word*. And yet, I'm sitting here communicating with them *in English*, giving up not only words, but *my whole language* just so we can talk. My "identity" as defined by words went out the window in our base compromise to communicate (that is you give up nothing, I drop my language). The irony of that does not seem to register with people.

Comment: @jpmc26 In many ways, Canada is just another US state... (and I live in Canada)

Comment: @nvoigt Sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm not saying that it's not a much more prevalent idea in America and other English speaking nations; nor am I saying it makes moral or logical sense. What I mean is that I would distinguish it from the culture as a whole because it isn't something that's really been accepted yet. I would tend toward calling it according to some ideological term instead. "Postmodernist" comes to mind, but I don't know if there might be a better one.

Comment: The problem is, is that many americans can simply not correctly feel that cultures are different, as a country the people have little direct interaction with other countries and there's no history to fall back on. And hence even the idea of putting "indecisive" pronouns somewhere can be utterly offensive to other cultures (like where I live), I fully respect whatever gender someone is, but the "indecisive" to me feels strangely offensive and out of place. -- Just like I do not care what people do or are, others shouldn't care how they are being called.

Comment: @paul23 It's more like the fact that so many different cultures exist in the country that people don't really think about the differences. I honestly don't think it's possible to *not* encounter people from other cultures regularly where I live, and I don't live in a particularly populous place (not even in a major city). New York or CA would be even more diverse. Then you have people who think they can "change the world" or something because they've become convinced that our culture is completely unjust and should be discarded in the name of diversity; SO seems to be influenced by that.

Comment: @Catija agreed, the question wizard would be an example of a move in the right direction

Comment: @nvoigt, totally agree on "US centric zeal". The weird thing is that it is supposed to be about diversity, but the way it is discussed is so narrow, so dogmatic. From the outside one is reminded of the Soviet-style show trials. Monica did not oppose inclusive language, she just preferred one approach to it over another.

Comment: @nvoigt I think yours may be the best reply, naturally it also seems the most mis-understood.  For a bunch of programmer-types, comprehending an "if" statement in a non-coding context appears beyond the grasp of many!  Oh well, lol, I guess.

Comment: @jpmc26 I would say North American as this is where this doctrine seems to be emanating from. Thankfully I live in Europe in what is essentially still 'Austro Hungarian' and the type of debates I see abroad on gender have not reached here. Those are looked at with a combination of ridicule and fear that this cultural influence might arrive here somehow. I echo that fear and feel that by injecting these ethics into the English language mandated by this site, SO merely becomes another vehicle to spread this cultural poison.

Comment: Just a final comment on this topic to emphasise the issue at stake. I came across this today: . https://www.bbc.com/news/business-51261999  This is an example either of a) the BBC inflaming the population to anger against PC b) the BBC raising awareness of a PC-motivated assault on British culture. Whether you agree with this or not, the issue is that by avoiding agnosticism SO is getting involved in a very dangerous and destabilizing sociopolitical war. This has nothing to do with being nice to people uncertain of their gender, this is about cultural subversion.

Comment: @Frank this is just pure silliness..... I mean... I can make the same point about any "TV reality show". (I don't watch football or cricket either btw...). Can't we just live and let live? it's **okay** if you don't like football. Just.... don't join the conversation when it's about that?

Comment: @Patrice I know it is absolutely ridiculous. But that is just one example of the affront this PC culture presents. It loves the notion of censorship and suppression in the name of some higher moral value. Perhaps why its advocates  have gravitated towards SO management and moderation.

Comment: After reading the comments on this thread, I think it's weird to assume someone who "doesn't have a lot of karma on SO" isn't an expert. I know many people that I would consider experts that don't post answers on SO. It is a weird concept in this echo chamber that "only people who post lots of answers on SO are experts". I've seen people with 20k karma whose questions I've looked at and said "man that person really farmed that karma for being a complete newbie". Karma points do not in any way directly translate to "level of expertise". Except maybe the top .1%.

Comment: @JacobH You're reading a claim into this answer that's not there. It's not that experts don't exist outside SO's userbase. It's that SO is valuable to people looking for answers because of people with expertise posting them. Sure, there are many experts not on SO, but if SO were devoid of experts, no one would want to ask here. So for the purposes of how SO interacts with its user base, it needs to retain a significant portion of the experts who are here posting extremely useful content. For SO's business model, experts who never post are irrelevant, despite the fact they most certainly exist.

Answer (score 145):

I'll keep my feedback and question simple:

What is Stack Overflow's New ["Why"?](https://www.ted.com/talks/simon_sinek_how_great_leaders_inspire_action?language=en)

Comment: That's a great video.  Hopefully everyone who sees your post has the 20 minutes to view it.

Comment: Prediction: there will not be an honest answer to this. ... not because Prashanth is a liar, necessarily - but because there can only be one main "why", one [Telos,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telos) and [we already know what that is,](https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1218174860205199365) and neither Prashanth nor anyone else has the power to change this

Comment: @Pekka since when did you became a socialist? There is absolutely no problem whatsoever in making money and being "for-profit" company. Not Steve Jobs nor Tim Pool built and operated Apple out of pure altruistic motivations. I just wish Stack Exchange Inc. will understand they actually hurting their business and brand. I'm a strong advocate against the website I devoted thousands of hours for, maybe even more than League of Legends .

Comment: @gdoron `There is absolutely no problem whatsoever in making money and being "for-profit" company.` I never said there was. The problem arises when you have massive VC interests pressuring for exponential growth, when that growth conflicts with what used to be your original goal. There is a limit to how much money there is in curating a high-quality library of questions and answers. There is much more money in selling luxury devices and maintaining the surrounding ecosystem like Apple does. It's in the nature of each field

Comment: @pekka, I totally agree. Their mistake was trying to bake it all into one company and product. They could have let SE Q&A stay as it is, and focus on Jobs or compete with Pluralsight or LinkedIn or 14784 other things. For some reason which I honestly hands down can't understand they decided to move on AND burning everything including their brand and employees.

Comment: @gdoron it looks like they thought they could move on without those employees and the invested users and all the difficult problems of actual community dialogue. The cynical part of my brain (still very small compared to the naive idealistic one, despite how I've sounded on Meta lately) thinks that maybe now they started to realize they need the community and mods after all, for the free moderation work! So now there is an interest in making it look like they care about people here, to keep more mods from bailing

Comment: [Related tweet series](https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1217841321806901248).

Comment: Hey George - for a long time we have said that our mission is to "help developers write the script of the future." This continues to be true. Recently we have begun to say our mission is to help developers AND technical workers write the script of the future, reflecting the increasing diversity of knowledge being shared across our network. To accomplish this goal, we need to have a healthy, growing business and community. The blog post I shared today is a good articulation of how we plan to move forward in 2020 to fulfill this mission and support our users, customers, and community.

Comment: @Pchandrasekar '*for a long time we have said that our mission is to "help developers write the script of the future."*' - WHO has ***EVER*** said that?! Your own tour states: '*With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.*' **Edit**, rest of the answer is corporate mumbo jumbo.

Comment: @Pchandrasekar  _"help developers write the script of the future"_ That doesn't sound familiar.

Comment: @PChandrasekar `help developers write the script of the future` is a good marketing slogan (I mean this without snark) but it is not a good "why" in the above sense. One such "why" for the site used to be "to build the best and most up-to-date library of programming questions and answers on the planet, accessible for free to everyone with Internet and a computer". That's the kind of "why?" that can inspire well-paid professionals to voluntarily give up significant chunks of their time, for free, because they feel they are making a small contribution to making the world a slightly better place

Comment: @PChandrasekar Now you may want to respond that, yes, that is still your "why", of course, but it is not really true any more in any meaningful sense, a new, more elusive "why" seems to have replaced it. This already started happening long before you came on board... even long before the mess around Monica Cellio's termination... but your kicking THE most community-trusted and respected employee who still represented this "why" to the curb with what from the outside can only be interpreted as absolute callousness strongly suggests there is no renewed desire to revive it; quite the contrary.

Comment: For all those who are not familiar with the phrase, help developers to "write the script of/for the future" and its association with Stack Overflow, I suggest that you try Googling "write the script for the future spolsky". This has been a company goal/mission statement for over three years.

Comment: @YaakovEllis after some Googling, it seems that that phrase didn't seem to make it onto meta or main? Only YT videos and external blogs. Was it not more of a tagline for the public?

Comment: I have to confess, this is the first time I've ever heard the phrase "writing the script of the future" used in a Stack Exchange context. And I have to say, I'm not a fan, despite the clever play on words.  What does it mean, really?  Aren't we all "writing the script of the future," in the sense that we are living on this earth and making our mark in whatever way we best can?  If you like that phrase, you must certainly love phrases like "strategic initiatives that provide value-added propositions to our stakeholders," a similarly flowery (and equally meaningless) affectation.

Comment: Perhaps *"With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming."* isn't as inspirational or memorable from a sound-bite perspective, but it does have the virtue of actually meaning something specific and actionable.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: It is probably a play on Joel Spolsky's catch phrase *"Developers are writing the script for the future."* (he could be quoting someone else, I have to check my references), used in many public presentations in the last 2-3 years. [Sample 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aiUoEHB7Qqg) (recorded 2018-10-01). [Sample 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DlFQKPEgDXE) (published on YouTube 2019-01-14). [Blog post](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2016/12/09/developers-are-writing-the-script-for-the-future/) (2016-12-09).

Comment: Inbetween [open heart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBDWgWBEbVQ&t=12m48s) [surgery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfQ2RM53SJo&t=12m47s)??

Comment: @YaakovEllis I've done that, I'm getting a lot of talks and blog posts from Joel with that phrase, but nothing directly to do with SO. If it's been a company goal & mission statement for the last 3 years, you must be able to link to it at least *somewhere* on SO surely?

Comment: @RobertHarvey That is my main gripe as well: “writing the script for the future,” independent of whatever context Joel’s talks might imbue it with, is _meaningless_.

Comment: @YaakovEllis tried it without "spolsky" and...I'm getting suggestions related to futuristic screenplays (how to write one, discussions of others, what can we learn from previous ones) and pages on how to rewrite "my future" via some mix of positive thinking and planning, as well as possibly more esoteric means. So...searching for this phrase *using an external search engine* is about as bad as searching for something using the search on this site. You have to known the precise incantation to conjure forth your result, else you don't get what you want.

Comment: "Writing the script of the future" sort of lost out to "Where Developers Learn Share & Build" as a marketing scheme back in 2017. You still see it in some places, but it was mostly a sales pitch when they were trying to increase onboarding prior to Teams. It probably shouldn't be confused for a mission statement or a corporate vision though... those are completely different things. I am sure that Nike's corporate goals aren't to "Just do it", the only thing McDonalds corporates "I'm lovin' it" is profit - to name some famous ones which clearly highlight the difference between slogan and vision

Comment: My take: this "writing the script of the future" was a phrase that Spolsky threw around loosely as a description of what developers supposedly represent in society. The idea of this being some kind of SO mission statement doesn't seem to go back any further than mid 2019, as far as I can tell. I think it'd be fair to say Prashanth has taken a strong liking to the phrase and elevated its importance. (It doesn't make terribly much sense to me personally as a slogan/vision.)

Comment: I'm an *avid* reader of Meta SO and Meta SE. First time seeing this phrase "script for the future".

Comment: @Pchandrasekar 2 points you must immediately fix. 1) "for a long time we have said" (etc). This is incorrect attitude because a problem has occurred. Opinions about its severity vary but you must regard it now and take no excuses. The solution is something new that must be done now, since prior behaviours are exactly what have cause the problem. Do not pretend you have always said. 2) A commercial phrase will not help at all. What people expect with your "why" is an explaination in your simplest and most understandable plain words. - The current unfixed attitude will make the new resolve fail.

Comment: As an example of valid "why", when I first read about wikipedia, they explained their goal is to collect the entire knowledge of the world. Feasible or not, it was very clear and understandable. On the other hand "writing the script of the future" does not mean anything to me.

Answer (score 135):

I have a small question: why was the decision made to put the announcement here, instead of on Meta Stack Exchange? Putting it here has the effect of shutting out users who participate elsewhere in Stack Exchange, but don't participate on Stack Overflow or don't have enough reputation to qualify for an association bonus.

Also, can we please post this type of discussion over on Meta Stack Exchange instead next time, to allow these users to participate in them?

Comment: If you want engaged users, putting this somewhere where anyone with an association bonus or site participation can post doesn't seem too weird to me. Also... I'm lazy, let MSO have the moderating of this one XD

Comment: @Tinkeringbell:  I think we have fewer pitchforks here too.  At least, the few who had pitchforks are...um...otherwise preoccupied?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell But why require SO participation for users who don't have enough reputation for an association bonus?

Comment: @Makoto that's a good reason too. Parts of MSE have definitely been not so nice lately.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell: Not everyone *wants* an SO account, some of them because they want to limit who has access to their e-mail & IP addresses.

Comment: We will engage on MSE as well. The blog post was referencing Stack Overflow and we wanted to keep discussion of it here primarily but the CMs will help watch MSE.

Comment: About MSO/MSE as the place for the main post (versus the link to the main post): Please don't get too hung up on it. There was deliberation about this internally, and and arguments made in each direction. I can understand both sides. If you don't want to reply on MSO, just reply on MSE. It will be read as well.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Would be nice to know what those arguments were, and why the pros of posting here outweighed the pros of posting on MSE.

Comment: @gparyani sorry, not going to happen here. It will only lead to people saying why their preferred argument is correct. And in the end, it is what it is. I just want to emphasize that we are sensitive to the feelings here, and sorry that we can't satisfy everyone. That said, I would direct you more to the content than the location as a subject for discussion.

Comment: @YaakovEllis if you would abstain from mentioning those arguments because that would lead to hurt, well, that ship has already sailed.

Comment: @Renan I will not avoid a discussion solely because it will raise tough questions (please see my lowest voted answer on this site if you want proof). I will avoid it if the discussion itself will not add anything positive. I also have to ration my time and energy among many different things. I have said my piece here, am not going to invest more. Too many other bugs to fix.

Comment: @Yaakov Personally I find it sad that the company can't even be transparent and open about such trivial things any more :(

Answer (score 134):

> given that supporting the Community is a top priority for Stack Overflow, where do you see the network going in the next five years, and what do you think should be done in order to get there?

Is there a plan to replace the missing community managers, or is another team being lined up to support this? A community like the one you see here didn't come about by 'magic' and however or why it happened you've lost a lot of the people recently, who helped make the community what it is today.

With so much that's happened which the community (at least the active vocal part) have been hurt by, can you make some promises of where the business is heading, and what plans there are around this expansion into the future?

Comment: Yes, we fully intend to kick off a new round of moderator elections on the sites that need them. We're still working through updating that process, but want to be sure our communities have the support they require to thrive.

Comment: "want to be sure our communities have the support they require to thrive" Then why have CMs been fired recently?

Comment: @Pchandrasekar I believe this question was about the community managers, the employees, rather than the volunteer moderators. The numbers of each have decreased recently.

Comment: We are looking at ways to restructure the workload for our CM team. We know that we’re in for quite a stretch but the leadership is coming together to create plans for community support. We’ll keep sharing about this as we get more updates.

Comment: @JuanM Better update quickly. Because this awfully sounds like: "we intend to invest in the community ... by having more volunteers doing all the pesky work". This is really crucial here: when asked about CMs, to come back and talk about "more moderators", that is really ... not good.

Comment: I'm presuming this to mean 'No more paid employees' which.... sucks, but if that's what required then so it will be. Hopefully it means the mods (and moderation teams) get more tooling etc to deal with the issues.

Comment: @djsmiley2kindarkness Most of the really powerful mod tools (e.g. utterly incinerate all traces of an entire network-wide distributed coordinated spam attack with the press of a magical button and some SQL scripts) aren't available to moderators; only CMs. And I would be a little bit terrified if I gained access to some of them. It'd be illegal and unethical to give moderators access to do some things that the CMs do on a regular basis (not going into details). More tooling would be excellent, and help _hugely_ (can't stress this enough!), but it can't solve all the problems; we **need** CMs.

Comment: @Pchandrasekar You don't need elections on Judaism; simply reinstate Monica.

Comment: @Pchandrasekar first, this question is about your staff, the CMs (and we're still demanding an explanation why they've been fired at least). second, if you continue with the current policy I'm afraid you will have no candidates for that new round of moderator elections...

Comment: @Pchandrasekar: Why do you need a new moderator election "process?"  Is there something wrong with the one you already have?

Comment: @RobertHarvey We're not really changing how elections work externally in a huge way. The big work being done is on automating the internal side of things so that we can handle multiple elections simultaneously more easily. Right now, elections are quite a bit of work so we generally only have one in each phase per week. With the automations being built, we could increase that to address the backlog more quickly. On the process side, we're looking at small improvements like letting people rank as many nominees as they wish rather than only the top three.

Comment: @Catija - That sounds interesting.  Thanks for describing the anticipated change.  Approximately when do you think elections will start to be announced?  I'm guessing it wouldn't be before the last week of February?

Answer (score 113):

## TL DR

**1.** Why are you seeking our input now?

**2.** What do you consider our role and the level of importance of such for the continuation of the site?

**3.** Does it matter to you that people on here are devastated?

**4.** ... That people feel discarded and unappreciated?

**5.** How are you going to make the business model mix with a community driven model?

---

## Meta is supposedly a teeny minority, so why come to us now?

It was [pointed out](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/46855268#46855268) in no uncertain terms, by your company that meta is insignificant, in terms of the traffic/participation on the site.

> there are Millions of users on Stack Overflow whose needs aren't being met because in the past we've spent so much time on Meta which has .015% of Stack Overflow's active users and is not representative of the community as a whole.

**1.** Given this, why are **you** seeking our input now?
**2.** Rather, what do **you** consider our role and the level of importance of such for the continuation of the site?

## Mistrust for the company, are you willing to remedy this? If so, How?

I have long held a mistrust for the business side of Stack Overflow. I have been fully aware that it's a business and, by definition, needs to make money. [I gave up the illusion that the community has control some time ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387651/the-world-is-big-and-i-am-so-small-what-are-the-implications-for-our-meta-commu). Which is why I have been impatient with people rallying against the business, as I know the business will ultimately do what it believes to be in its own interest and will only include "us" - the community - if it's in the business' interest to do so.

Call me a cynic, I call it realism.

[image]

#### Bear with me, this is leading somewhere....

To back up a bit. Many years ago - maybe 8? I was not happy on this site. I came across two people. [Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) and [Shog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9). These two men gave me a tremendous amount of hope for this site. They are highly intelligent and have unique ways of grasping this community and how it works and what it (we) need. It is solely because of these two people that I stayed on the site. Well, left and came back.

I spent many years working on the site, getting to know people and being part of a real community. A community that mattered. I took a break last year and a few weeks into the break all hell broke loose and four months later the site is no longer identifiable. The fallout on this has forced many people to leave parts of the network or the network completely and I suspect you probably want some people to leave, but you've lost a lot of wheat with the chaff.

Now Shog has gone. A lot of the moderators have gone, I'm feeling even more grief than I did when I wrote [The world is big and I am SO small. What are the implications for our meta community with the changes in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387651/the-world-is-big-and-i-am-so-small-what-are-the-implications-for-our-meta-commu). The thought of going back to the mod room without Jon C, Robert H, Ed, George, Madara and Shog is unbearable. You have **NO** idea how much these men gave to the network. **NO IDEA.** Shog went above and beyond! The number of chats and time he gave on weekends and late into the night. Always helpful, always kind. He would call it like he saw it, but he was never nasty. So on top of these great mods you've lost the **best Community Manager Stack Overflow ever had**.

Now Shog "leaves" the network, suddenly. Sudden and shrouded in mystery, unlike [Jon Ericson's resignation announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342424/change-in-roles-for-jon-ericson-leaving-se). It breeds suspicion and mistrust. Even writing this, I'm wondering, will this affect my chances of being reinstated as a moderator. It's really not a nice atmosphere.

From an email from [Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) (yes I have his permission to post)

> I think the thing that hurts the most is that none of my contributions seem to have had any value to them.  I spent endless hours toiling on Stack Overflow, working with the corporation on quality issues, shepherding the scope of Not Programming Related into the site that it is today.  And that all gets swept under the rug because I've said a few things on Meta in the past month that they didn't want to hear.

This breaks my heart!

Your business has hurt us! It has caused people to shed tears!

**3.** Does it matter to **you** that people on here are devastated?
**4.** That people feel discarded and unappreciated?

Even writing this, I cannot reconcile how even if you do care how that fits into a corporate structure of making a bottom line. $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

## Your business and our community are a bit like water and oil - they don't mix.

The irony of the welcoming push and zero tolerance for abuse, what about compassion for the feelings of the people who have been here for years and put hours of work into the site: Contributing content, moderating content, brainstorming.

**5.** How are **you** going to make the business model mix with a community driven model?

Please be honest with us. You are dealing with an intelligent community,  many of us are literal thinkers, and we spot inconsistencies. So be straight with us, *Please.*

Comment: This really captures how many of us feel. `How are you going to make the business model mix with a community driven model?` that seems like the key question! Pretty sure most of us would much more appreciate a candid response à la "hey, I'm here to get revenue to X million USD; everything else - including you guys' lofty idealistic goals of being a knowledge library, your feelings, etc. - is irrelevant to the investors who are my bosses. Sorry, nothing personal. BUT here is why I think things can still work out for all of us: ...." over optimistic pep-talk we all can recognize as BS

Comment: @Pekka Exactly! I don't mind business people doing business, in the end, that pays the servers, and the people running the servers and providing the technical basis for all of this. But don't come here telling us that the agenda is about the community, when it is **only** about the business. I think there would be ways to get to both. But not by starting with BS (business school) bingo with us.

Comment: The only thing I can disagree with is "Your business and our community are a bit like water and oil - they don't mix." I think that making money is not in contradiction with building library of knowledge. Main problem this site has (if we take out recent events that broke trust) is managing expectations of people that come by and think they can just ask any questions they like. I think that problem is solvable one. It was just never tackled the right way, and it might be harder to tackle it now when the whole place is on fire, but it is not impossible.

Comment: Users should stop feeling hurt and having their hearts broken. When one partner of the relationship refuses to admit any wrongdoing, refuses to talk about the hurt and betrayal while newcomers, and disgruntled users, continue to blame the toxicity of Meta and SO, it's time to acknowledge the truth. The rapport is doomed, call it trust, call it relationship, call it community, call it whatever you like but stop hoping things will go back to the good old days. It won't. Unless, or until, the day comes SO begging with cap in hand for users to save it from bankruptcy. If that day ever arrives.

Comment: I think you're a romantic. A true realist wouldn't pour their emotions in an answer to someone who will not read the upteenth post that is telling them what they already know. The **CEO's job** is making SO profitable.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Not in my experience. The CEO's job is often just to achieve the investment goals of the investor. This often means diluting the shareholding with incremental convertible loans to rescue the company repeatedly over a sufficient length of time that the investors can exit by selling a firm that seems to be sustainable on the surface.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't expect an honest answer, I wrote this for our community. I gave up rallying many months ago - as mentioned in my answer. This is a counter post to the CEOs post. Asking for our feedback. Why? To use us? Do they need us? Are they placating us? Who knows.

Comment: @Frank I did a youtube video  about just that - they've over extended and put money into things that are a waste of time and neglected the thing that brings them traffic - this site - it's no accident the ceo has posted on MSO. Most of the other sites are incidental. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfQQ0x2uFdE&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @YvetteColomb I don't want to second guess you but even if it can't be answered, these questions are probably important - and a side that folks that haven't been immersed in the company will not see. I don't think it should be deleted, even if there's no direct answer

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I would dearly like answers to these questions, I just don't expect any honest answers to them. I didn't post it here originally, as it didn't seem an answer to the actual question, so I posted it as a question. I don't mind either way, as long as someone asks. It's what's been torturing us for some time now. In this format, I can't see these questions being answered in the comments at any rate... :/ Edited it out, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 112):

2 instant reactions to the blog post:

1. These websites and communities are bleeding for months now, why is this the first time we hear from you?
2. Even now, you didn't actually address anything that bothers the community. Like the disgusting slandering of Monica, the mass resignations of our moderators and your **volunteers**, the abrupt firing of [Shog9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9), etc.

Comment: I guess you are unaware, but Monica and SEI reached a settlement. The terms of the settlement probably restrict SEI and Monica from saying more on the matter. So it is very unlikely that he will address that issue here, now.

Comment: @Raedwald, I'm fully aware of the opaque settlement, but I'm pretty sure the settlement doesn't prevent him from issuing an apology.

Comment: @gdoronissupportingMonica Pretty sure it does. They've reached an acceptable stand-off where nobody will go further than what has already been said.

Comment: @gdoronissupportingMonica It actually might - issuing an apology would be tantamount to accepting responsibility - and from what [was made public of the settlement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio), it seems that they are trying to put it down to (mostly) a misunderstanding on Monica's part.

Comment: @Raedwald You are likely correct. But the boss needs to know - **directly in response to his post** - that this is still a very **big** issue among the users. (Arghh...strikethrough doesn't work in comments...incomplete markdown support...but that's minor in the grand scheme of things.)

Comment: It's important not to get hung up on the mention of the company's treatment of Monica. There are many other breaches in community trust that the company must take steps to address; some noted here and many not.

Comment: @Lewis - misunderstanding?  Have you been paying any attention??

Comment: @GeorgeMReinstateMonica Yes, _i_ have been paying attention - I said the _company_ were putting it down to a misunderstanding - that **does not** necessarily mean that it is _my_ point of view.

Comment: OK, *stop asking for apologies.*  An apology and a couple of dollars will buy me a cup of coffee, and that's all it will do.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I taught each one of my sons to say sorry every time they misbehave. There is no shame at admitting of wrong doing, it's human. And most importantly, unless you actually acknowledge your misdeeds it's 100% likely you'll repeat them. And if you wish a *Scripture bit*: King Saul had 2 very very minor sins and God took away his kingship while King David that had 2 horrible sins (sleeping with a married woman and causing her husband to die in war) kept his Kingship. Why? Because King David immediately owned his mistake _I have sinned against the LORD_ while King Saul made excuses.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334551) is what an apology gets you.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I literally loled. I agree this is what an "apology" will get you. It doesn't really invalidates my point, acknowledging wrongdoings is an essential **first step**.

Comment: Cricket . He wont answer the serious questions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That post was very highly upvoted for quite a long time -- while it still seemed like it might be a genuine apology and outlining what sounded like it would be an attempt to make good. However, it eventually became clear that it promised something very very different from what was being delivered and that is when many hundreds of upvotes turned to many more downvotes. By then it wasn't anything but an "apology"; there was no attempt to right the wrongs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey we want a **sincere** apology, not that half-assed excuse you have linked

Comment: @Raedwald If SEI agreed to a settlement that restricted them from explaining and apologizing, then that was yet another massive strategic blunder on their part. They need to learn when to stop listening to lawyers.

Comment: @Robert you are linking to one of the rare posts I upvoted.... then revisited later and downvoted it. I **wanted**... oh how I **wanted** that post to be honest and true.....

Answer (score 99):

I would like to take a moment to welcome the new CEO to meta.

> Community engagement and inclusion is a top priority for Stack Overflow in 2020. Already, the team has established and released a plan for improving communication and empowering our users internally

This is indeed a nice way for community engagement but **how will SO work towards repairing the previous trust issues that they had with the community?** Which I think is more important than better-established communication. For healthy community engagement, the company needs to have the trust *of the community*.

Comment: '*It will be a pleasure to work with you on making this community better.*' - I hope this comment doesn't get deleted because I don't mean offence by it but I highly doubt we'll be working with him. This seems more like a formality than anything else. But, I'd happily be proved wrong. '*Throw a dog a bone and it'll stop barking*'

Comment: @Script47 Actually, I now recognize that this _looks_ like its formality but that's wasn't my intention there. I happen to write the post in a certain flow that I forgot about the actual disaster. I have edited it out if it looked like a formality, I don't want it to look that way.

Comment: I understand trust is something that is earned over time and through actions. By engaging here, I can better listen and communicate. As we push forward with The Loop, our moderator council, and our Tiger Team initiatives, I hope these efforts will prove useful to the community and productive in rebuilding a good working relationship.

Comment: @Pchandrasekar what is the "Tiger Team" initiative? I don't remember seeing anything about this on the blog, and a quick Google search doesn't turn anything up.

Comment: The "Tiger Teams" are the cross-functional teams described in [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/), @LShaver. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_team)'s the general definition of the concept.

Comment: I can only quote from George Stocker's excellent Twitter commentary: "- After ignoring repeated questions from the community  - after not engaging on Meta  - After avoiding any and all feedback they could   - after firing their best CMs ... Stack Overflow has a tiger team charged with figuring out why community relations are so bad." https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1219710774949621763

Comment: @Pekka: That's very amusing, but consider this perspective: the current Stack Exchange administration *might genuinely not get it.*  Ergo, the need for a study.  ["Well, I could explain it better, but I’d need charts and graphs and an easel."](http://quotegeek.com/quotes-from-movies/the-american-president/1735/)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I may be wrong - but I can't see how it could be possible they don't know exactly what they are doing. The administration still largely consists of the same people that were firmly at the helm back in October. Shog was fired only a week or so ago.

Comment: @Pekka: I don't think the people with that knowledge are calling the shots anymore.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am confident the people who are calling the shots know what they *want* to know... and nothing in this post will change any of that one iota

Comment: @JNat Why is this "tiger team" operating behind closed doors, why has **nobody** said they have been contacted for further precisions/clarifications (I've done things like this in the past. Feedback is **never** clear enough that you are fine with the original version), and why should we trust a process operating behind closed doors for anything? The last closed doors process saw two respected, esteemed CMs get fired.

Comment: The CMs have been trying to keep the moderators as up-to-date as we can (particularly with regards to the mod council and mod training teams), and have posted on the private mod team about this too. We're calling these "Tiger Teams" here not having used the term before, which may also be confusing... so I'd agree that it's fair to say that the initiative is fairly opaque, yes, @SébastienRenauld — particularly to the community in general. As the blog post says, `By the end of this quarter, all of these initiatives will be shared publicly` — hopefully there'll be other updates along the way too.

Comment: @Pchandrasekar you are aware that people here think that the "Loops" are a way of **excluding** the community?

Answer (score 89):

> ... and given that supporting the Community is a top priority for Stack Overflow, where do you see the network going in the next five years, and what do you think should be done in order to get there?

First of all: if *supporting* the community is your top priority, I am really worried about things that have lower priority for you. Because the actions regarding that top priority were epic fails for months to come.

What I see is:

- SE Inc. seems to have given up on the initial idea of a really broad network with many different communities. You only talk about Stack Overflow, and if at all, it is about bringing together "IT related" topics. So: I see that part of the Stack Exchange network to be left out in the rain, to slowly die. If so, just say so. Offer the affected communities a reasonable path forward (out of here), instead of not doing anything.
- That you try to win back our hearts, without moving one inch towards the community requests. I hear the same "great" words that Sara and David used some months back. Empty promises, which weren't executed on. I don't care about *words*. I care about **actions**. And your actions were to throw out a respected moderator, and to then simply sit out the massive drain of moderators and users. To a point where you released the hounds, err, lawyers and of course, to then stop talking at all. And to finally let go of two of your most respected community managers. It is nice that you dare to show up here in person, but it really doesn't matter much. Actions matter.

So, what is my outlook?

- Very much depends: if you are lucky, you can convince more people to buy your product than you convinced former users to badmouth SE Inc. and its products. Bleak reality: any IT professional I know who is just slightly interested in this place has a bad opinion about it by now, because they observed what happened here over the last months and years.
- Then maybe, you end up with a growth of user base, revenue, profit.
- But it is also very much possible that fewer and fewer users will be willing to do that "user moderation" work, and that Stack Overflow turns more and more into a garbage bin, populated mostly by people going "Give me the code for my homework ASAP". And even with millions of *such* users, you might not be so happy. Because it isn't such people who get consulted when the CTO asks "should we buy SO for Teams for our company?".

Beyond that, simply see what George Stocker has to [say](https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1219664660338823170).

But yes sure: I intend to stay here, too. To learn what you have to say, and more importantly: to observe your actions in the next months.

I can't tell you what I would need from you to convince me to start providing content here again, or do much moderation work. But I can tell you: probably a **lot**, but **zero** of the things that you tried lately.

Comment: I don't think "community" means the same for SE as it does for us now. We see community as the folks we've seen around on main and meta, answering and interacting, the folks who've built the value. They see community as everyone who's not actually on the site yet, and everyone whoose identity fits their vision.

Answer (score 72):

What is the plan for [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) and the SE sites that are still listed as Beta? The person spearheading that is [no longer with the company](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342082). Is SE interested in launching new sites? Will there be a definitive plan to [graduate sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614)?

Comment: I doubt anyone in the current SE management even knows what Area 51 really is. For them it's probably just some weird relic from the past, kept just for historical value. Otherwise really can't see any reason why they kicked out the only person who kept it alive and running.

Comment: I'm actually one of the people doing a lot of the work on the site lifecycle - Robert, JNat and I were working on it together. We had a plan that was about ready to roll out in September but... well... things happened. We're in the middle of discussions about the future of Area 51 and the beta sites. There are lots of options but we're doing what we can to advise in a way that shows the whole picture of what each option would mean.

Comment: @Catija - When you say "beta sites," do you mean the sites that are still called beta, or the ones that were called beta up until recently?  When you say "advise," should I take it that you are like the career diplomats at the State Department, who stay in their positions for long periods, as opposed to the political appointees? // Will new staff be recruited to replace the three community managers who left recently?

Comment: @aparente001 There's two kinds of graduation. Full graduation means you have standard reputation levels to gain privs (i.e. 2k rep to edit, etc). It also means you get a custom favicon and top banner design. [Partial graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/244695) means you lose the word "Beta". Contrast [Parenting.SE](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) (partial) with [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/) (beta)

Comment: @Machavity - Thanks.  Which do you think Catija meant?

Comment: @aparente001 I think she means they want to full graduate all sites, but the process is ill-defined at present

Comment: Agreed on the process being ill-defined at the moment, @Machavity — what we hope to be able to accomplish is that it is clarified, and simplified, from start to finish.

Answer (score 72):

I've been a moderator on Skeptics for almost 9 years, and a few years less on Biology. I resigned earlier this month. I have more reputation on Meta Stack Exchange than any sane person should have; the only user that was never employed by SE with more MSE reputation than me is Monica Cellio. I have more highly upvoted feature requests than anyone else on Meta Stack Exchange, so I'm kind of the poster child for the heavily involved MSE community.

If this outreach had happened a few months ago, I'd have welcomed it. I had already decided to resign at the end of the year, but I was still waiting for a reason to reverse that decision. That justification for keeping my moderator status never came, but one event happened that was outside even my worst predictions: SE fired Shog and Robert.

Robert was instrumental in getting all the sites in the SE network off the ground. Anyone that participated in the early beta of a site has seen him involved in that. Firing him means you don't care about the original idea of the SE network anymore.

Shog was the strongest presence among the CMs for the whole time I was a moderator. There was nobody else with that much knowledge about all the details of the software itself, a lot of wisdom about how to handle situations we moderators weren't sure of, and a bunch of kinda inscrutable gardening metaphors. I can't really put into words just how destructive firing Shog was for the relations between the moderators and SE.

A few months ago, I would have been cautiously optimistic about this message. Firing the two most experienced CMs, and causing the resignation of the third most experienced CM, tell a quite different story than the blog post and this meta post. Why should we believe that SE wants to invest into the community when the CM team is being gutted and the most experienced members are fired or leaving because they're frustrated with SE?

Actions speak louder than words, and the most recent actions by SE speak very loudly that the company doesn't value the community. Firing two experienced CMs in this undignified way is a very clear message, and words alone won't change anything about this. I don't know how to fix this, but it will certainly take more than words.

I don't expect an answer to this post; there are a few good reasons and plenty of bad reasons why an official answer to this would be a bad idea for SE. But I wanted to use the chance to post this in a place that is likely to be read by SE management.

Comment: I am also a long term mod (more than nine years on physics plus a *pro tem* bit on Code Golf; and beta badge holder on Stack Overflow) who has left the network, and while I held out a few days after the firing of Shog9 and Robert that was the event that pushed me from confused uncertainty about the future of the network to considering if I still wanted to be part of it.

Answer (score 67):

Hi Prashanth,

I strongly disagree with the removal of Shog9, the circumstances motivating Jon Ericson's departure, the "legal says so", and the overall disregard that has been given towards transparency with the users of this platform. I will give you the benefit of the doubt and not go into depth about each of these, but if these events continue, there won't be any more content creators and none of this will matter.

Your leadership team needs more people who are actually experienced in the type of content creation that makes Stack Overflow what it is today. Jeff, Joel, Sam, Ben, Jay, Jon, Josh… they all had that and they are gone. I wish you luck in replacing that talent pool.

Stack Overflow itself needs to expand the on-topic definition to include more experts, to refine the tools for new users to build quality posts, and a way to forge alliances in the community to allow users a path towards being successful here.

To recap, in order to move forward, Stack Overflow the company needs to build:

1. Trust
2. Experience
3. Tools

in that order.

If by some miracle all of that gets accomplished, then perhaps we can all reconvene and discuss how to get to the 10x revenue growth that is the underlying theme here.

-Travis

Answer (score 64):

> [G]iven that supporting the Community is a top priority for Stack Overflow, where do you see the network going in the next five years, and what do you think should be done in order to get there?

To say that the community-company relations have been... turbulent lately would be a severe understatement. I don't exaggerate when I say that in the past few months, we've experienced the largest loss of trust in the company by the engaged users of the site to date, on a scale so far unprecedented in Stack Exchange history.

Unfortunately, this coincided with the exact time that you took over the mantle of CEO from Joel. This means that the community blamed you in particular a lot over the past few months - a new CEO and a heck of a lot of chaos at the same time? People make the obvious connection.

**Whether or not blaming you was justified, that is now something that you have to take into account.** You have to keep in mind that people are angry at you, and that those are the very people who you as a company most rely on to keep your most basic feature - public Q&A - running.

If you sincerely want to support the community, then that's awesome. The problem is, you have a lot of different problems at the moment that are going to get in your way *majorly* if you don't address them.

Off the top of my head, some of the issues that are *most* affecting the community at the moment are...

- [deteriorating communication between staff and community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331513/294691)
- [Meta being cast as toxic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387633/4946380) and [its usefulness being compromised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340164/294691)
- [endangerment of users by SE corp's actions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341024/294691)
- [the loss of the most trusted members of staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342041/294691)

...and there are others.

People are going to blame *you*, personally, if you now fail to address these issues. People are angry. Whether or not it is justified, **any changes you make are going to be met with anger and resistance until you have regained the trust of the community**. That's something you need to bear in mind.

I certainly hope you have a plan to address the issues mentioned above and the others that are currently affecting the network. But in any case, you should be aware of what the reaction is going to be to anything you post.

---

For instance, I was rather annoyed this was posted on Meta.SO instead of Meta.SE. After all, *I don't use Stack Overflow* the site. I'm more a user of the rest of the network - I have over 100,000 reputation accumulated across the network. I would have missed this rather important post if it hadn't been cross-posted to Meta.SE (thanks for that, Juan, BTW). Small things like that build up to a general state of dissatisfaction, especially against the backdrop of the total loss of trust in the company that has happened recently.

Comment: Apparently there was [some internal discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393155/ceos-2020-kickoff-blog-where-do-you-see-stack-overflow-going?answertab=active#comment750847_393160) as to whether to post on MSO or MSE; kudos to Juan M for posting on MSE, but I get the impression it wasn't his decision alone.

Comment: Well, the Monica case happened shortly *before* him joined the company, so it is probably not his fault.

Comment: @VictorStafusa [Yes, it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_responsibility).

Comment: After reading the CEO's long-awaited blog post, I could only draw three feasible conclusions: (1) The new CEO has been kept blissfully unaware of all the recent turmoil; (2) The new CEO doesn't really care about all the recent turmoil; or (3) The new CEO is mostly concerned about "driving forward" and doesn't really mind how many of us old-timers depart in the wake of the new program and new vision. (I'm not really sure which of those is most accurate, though I suspect it's #3.)

Comment: Why shouldn't we blame him?  He's the CEO, he's responsible for all this bad behavior.  And hiding in the bushes is frankly not the mark of a good leader

Answer (score 60):

> Where do you see Stack Overflow going?

Down the drain. From the blog post it is pretty clear that growth has become the only relevant factor, even though the post is filled with some fluffy words about community building to obscure that fact. This is not going to go over well with the parts of the community interested in building a *high quality* content repository - although you've already lost many of those people, like me, a while ago.

Saying something like

> We learned that we needed much better channels to listen to our
>   moderators and community members

after actively ignoring meta over issues such as the CC 4.0 license, malevolent ads, or the Monica situation is simply absurd. The issue was never with the *community* side of communication, but the SE Inc side; and firing / letting go people like Shog and Jon clearly shows you have no intention to improve this. So under that premise, the blog post is yet another sign that SE as a company is rapidly becoming toxic - which has also been made clear from public statements of your former employees.

I wish you the best of luck on your road of turning the SE network into [Yahoo Answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Answers) 2.0. Personally, I will begin mirroring the latest SO data dump to ensure the content is not lost in the event that SE folds or decides not to make this data available anymore.

Comment: Well, even Wikipedia knows that Yahoo Answers is trash. See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Answers#Quality_of_answers. "Researchers found that questions seeking factual information received few answers and that the knowledge on Yahoo! Answers is not very deep." Maybe Stack Overflow is looking to sell to Verizon (Yahoo's owner)?

Answer (score 58):

In the blog post, you mention

> As we look forward to 2020, we plan to invest in public Q&A

Can you share any details or even vague directions of how you plan to invest in public Q&A? I ask because there is already an [established (and very long) list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfeature-request%5d%20is%3aq%20-%5bstatus-declined%5d%20-%5bstatus-completed%5d%20closed%3ano%20hasaccepted%3ano) of things you can do to improve it.

Answer (score 56):

You remember the debacle 3-4 month ago?

> I am more committed than ever to creating a welcoming and **inclusive community** across Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange, and the mistakes we made over the past few weeks made that worse, not better. **I know we have lost the trust of many of you, and that trust must be re-earned over time by more than just words**.
>   <sub>by [David Fullerton](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334551/292385), emphasis mine</sub>

[My response 3 month ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334593/292385):

> I want to say *Let's forget it*, but currently I can't. But with the
>   above statement it seems I can in future.
>
> I say this, **because in the past you often said sorry, promised
>   improvements, but forgot it a few month later. Just make sure you
>   remember this statement in a year.** And ten.

Between this and today, the rate in making things worse increased.

Why should we trust you today? Why should we ever trust you?

Comment: The idea of 'inclusive community' is, ironically, very divisive. For me personally, living in Central Europe, 'inclusivity' is a very North American idea that is strongly related to domestic politics and modern trends. I would prefer if SO remained agnostic to prevailing religion/dogma/fashion etc.

Comment: Removing 'religion' from @Frank comment and I don't understand it - at least not from a SO perspective.  Why not evaluate the quality of an idea on its merits rather than from where it originates?  If we change time periods, Frank could have easily substituted "democracy" for "inclusive community" above.   Technically, my literal reading of his comment says that if some new language comes "in fashion", we should not address it, that is, if said language originated in North America.  Hopefully, NOT what he meant, but that is what it says, at least to me.

Comment: @JoeG A modification to my response. No! The fact that these ideas are originated in N.America and propagandized by N.America is literally a culturally attack. They are antithetical to national traditions, a good example being this: https://www.bbc.com/news/business-51261999  which I came across today. This is an attack on British culture. It is not acceptable. It is precisely the same as if Soviet cold-war ideas became popular in N.America. There is no intrinsic merit to an idea, it is always arbitrary and subjective. Culture, tradition, and identity has meaning beyond the abstract.

Comment: @Frank It is an attack on American traditions as well. It's not so much "North America" launching the attack; it's a set of ideologically motivated people. In many ways, it's an ideological decedent or rehash of Marxism (same basic assumption of class oppression, same basic answer of top down societal transformation). The people pushing those ideologies are already present in your own culture, even if they haven't gotten as entrenched into positions of power there yet. I assure you they're doing everything they can to get there.

Comment: @jpmc26 agreed I would not characterise N America as attacking, but characterise the attack as North American  . The ideas are hard to separate from N.American climate, mood, conditions. This PC oppression, ironically, could not originate from for example Russia, because while the country does have highly centralised media, it does tend to have much more on nduvidual freedom in what can be said or done than in 'liberal' West

Answer (score 55):

> The key to Stack Overflow’s future and growth are the millions of developers from around the world who find the site useful, **but who haven’t yet been welcomed into the community. We need to expand our reach and engagement to ensure these developers join the conversation and push their own learning to new heights.**

- What sort of "welcoming" are we talking about here?
- How do you plan on expanding your reach and engagement while not further eroding the original goal of building a quality archive of Q&As?
- Is the goal of the platform changing to focus on teaching as opposed to just building an archive?

> A key part of great product development is to stay close to customers, listen, and take a thoughtful, data-driven, and research-oriented approach to building products. In our case, it is critical that we work closely with our community to listen, change, and evolve rapidly. **As an example, over the past several months, we had a lot of dialog with our community about how best to enforce and evolve our code of conduct. We learned that we needed much better channels to listen to our moderators and community members. We have not evolved the existing channels of engagement for power users in our community, like Meta, or articulated how we intended to make improvements going forward. This has caused friction as our user base and business have rapidly grown. We acknowledge these issues, apologize for our mistakes, and have plans for improving in the future.**

I think it should be clarified that this paragraph makes it seem that the cause of the issues was a lack of tools or rather the tools not being sufficient (essentially blaming meta as a piece of software). But that really wasn't the case, was it? It was your (read: SE's) refusal to budge/[communicate coherently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387599/whats-up-with-the-breakdown-in-communication-between-stack-overflow-and-the-com). No amount of tools will fix that; the teams need to be fixed. So, my questions would be:

- What steps have been taken to prevent something like that happening again?
- What steps are being taken to address the concerns of the power users that have been raised for so many years?

Comment: Thanks for the question. Respectfully, we do not believe that welcoming, teaching, and empowering new generations of beginners is mutually exclusive with building a quality archive. As noted in one of my comments above, we also pay attention to question quality and have been encouraged by recent data. You can check out our research on this topic and how we define question quality at the link below. https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/12/research-update-a-b-testing-the-new-question-form/

Comment: @Pchandrasekar should I expect a comment addressing the other points I raised?

Comment: '*Respectfully, we do not believe that welcoming, teaching, and empowering new generations of beginners is mutually exclusive with building a quality archive.*' - Please, ***STOP*** using these buzz words, also, respectfully, the goal of this site was not to help new beginners or to empower them. Those were side effects.

Comment: @Pchandrasekar: I don't believe they are mutually exclusive either.  But sometimes that encouragement has to come in the form of "learn the fundamentals first."  The Stack Exchange platform was never designed to provide extensive teaching of the fundamentals of software development to neophytes.  Nobody teaches brain surgery to a first-year med student.  Nobody teaches taking a company public to an intern.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: But perhaps it is time to extend the platform with a teaching aspect? (Like it was extended with a chat facility.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Sure.  Just don't pretend that the existing platform supports this in any way, shape or form, or expect that some small tweaks would get it done.  it would take a *major* undertaking to do it right, and there's already been [one failed attempt.](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation)

Comment: @Pchandrasekar _[W]e do not believe that welcoming, teaching, and empowering new generations of beginners is mutually exclusive with building a quality archive._ Won't these two goals inevitably conflict? A "quality archive" requires some minimum standard of quality, which means some contributions will be rejected; those contributors are liable to feel unwelcome. And the poor beginner now has to manage a double learning load -- both learning the new skill in question, and learning how to meet the standards of quality; the higher likelihood of failure is invariably not empowering. ...

Comment: ... Isn't the only possible resolution for this conflict, to make crystal clear this vision of a quality archive, to manage beginners' expectations?

Comment: @Pchandrasekar If SO now seeks to teach "new generations of beginners," does that mean the site is no longer ["for professional and enthusiast programmers?"](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/) And if so, what will the site be doing to be suitable for beginners, because as Atwood lays out, it's currently the opposite of that, and that extends to the core of the site's design rather than just community behavior.

Comment: @Pchandrasekar the problem is, they ARE mutually exclusive if you are talking about a single resource. You can NOT have both in a single place. You CAN have both, in two separate places.

Comment: @Script47 "the goal of this site was not to help new beginners": It is now. The exponential growth which is the business target clearly requires a focus on beginners.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Teaching (learning resource) requires structure. SO does not have any structure at all. Even Documentation lacked proper structure.

Comment: As someone who tried to provide both beginner-friendly and intricate descriptions of inner workings on Documentation, I can very much attest to running into the lack of structure mentioned by @DalijaPrasnikar head-on.

Answer (score 54):

I have been a member of Stack Overflow since may 2012, almost 8 years now.
I mainly use SO as a resource to find the answers what I need, when I need it. The pro of Stack Overflow is, that if you know what to search for, you can find your answer relatively quickly with some google fu, related questions, etc...

Over the years I've slowly been becoming invested in the community aspect, willing to help people, trying to help out here and there occasionally, and I've seen the community grow, change and adopt scary new things of controversy several times. So I'm not scared about change per se.

I am scared about the direction Stack Overflow the Company with shareholders is approaching its user base, its community and alienating the core of that community. With a tight-knit community where you have a few "big" names who take the lead consistently in adopting things, or fire other people on to take action and "do stuff", talking, arguing, investing in issues.

The drama of the last few months though, have sent massive shock waves through this tight-knit community and the weave has started to unravel. I can see this, as a lurker and occasional partaker on meta, I don't say much, but I read a lot of the ongoing discussions and concerns.

People, who have been taking the lead, taking pride in their moderation duties, their badges and their feeling of fighting the "horde" of spam, are ceasing their activities. Questions that would have been closed in seconds, now live on for hours sometimes, gathering bad answers, and muddling Google search results.

The value of SO is concise, to the point googleable questions and answers. Bad questions and bad answers muddle the results. Muddle makes more muddle, and it will decrease the value of SO, because Google does care about duplicate content, and will devalue results if this trend continues and new people don't step up.

My **personal** journey over the last months with the new front page, hiding the questions when going to the website directly, the new TOS, forced license change which is legally extremely questionable, firing of a community elected moderator and pillar of community Monica, the letting go of community managers which were role models and central to the community as a source of reason, the consequent no answering of community concern, or if there is an answer it's carefully worded lawyer speak, which is frankly **insulting** to me as a developer, I don't know how others feel.

I have gone from I want this to be a community I invest in and help make better, to this website only needs to give me answers; when it doesn't I'll go somewhere else. The last few months when I've encountered a problem that wasn't on Stack Overflow I have refrained from posting it here. **I've stopped caring** about contributing to Stack Overflow, the company with shareholders out to make money.

Until now people have been looking at Stack Overflow as this:

It's a company, of course it needs to make money, but we have faith that Stack Overflow realizes the value of its community, as that is the content-generating thing that drives people there and slowly, but surely, we will get features that makes everything better for us the community to help in this symbiotic relationship.

But the last few months, it seems that Stack Overflow wishes to reposition itself. To increase shareholder value and revenue. All fine and well, but we the community really do not care that much. As long as Stack Overflow makes a profit and keeps the site up, we are good, do your thing. Experiment with teams, documentation, etc... all you want. But the moment your shareholder value increasing strategy touched the community, you have hurt us deeply, tore deep wounds in us and we lost trust of the our symbiotic partner. You have removed pillars of the community by force. These are wounds. Deep wounds.

The sentiment of the remaining core of the community can be summarized in this GIF image:

[image: I don't believe you]

So, when you want to increase shareholder value, I applaud you. But do not believe Stack Overflow is a **normal** website. The people who use Stack Overflow build the web and the supporting infrastructure. Heck, the inventor of the next greatest programming language may be on here now. You don't want this to turn into [Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora), [Yahoo answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Answers) or god forbid Technet. You want this to remain the gem that it is, that pops up in every Google result as a highly valuable resource, that drives ad revenue, etc... Because... we can and will build your greatest competitor in a heartbeat if we as a community abandon ship. It's not like it's a hard website to build; we as a community just like it here.

Let in the bad quality, drive away the core community that bind the lurkers like me and that goes down the drain over the next few years, losing any relevance Stack Overflow had and it goes the way of [Myspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myspace).

You have a chance to rebuild your symbiotic relationship with the community, to stop the bleeding from the gashes, to heal the wounds but it takes time. **Trust is hard to earn and easy to lose**.

**My suggestions to you**

Please take a tablet, a nice cup of [insert favorite beverage here] and read the most answered/upvoted/downvoted questions on the global meta and the Stack Overflow meta. Start with those from the beginning of the sites, the oldest.

Read the discussions the members had, see the passion, the changes, the arguments, and the bitter arguments. Perhaps also of other sites, Area 51, etc... I don't know how much you wish to invest in this really.

Get to know the creature that is wounded, but essential to your survival in a symbiotic relationship. And then make a blog post about it, and reach out to us. Don't focus too much on shareholder value when you communicate to us, but acknowledge us, acknowledge our desires, our worries and provide us with a roadmap of what's going to happen to us as website communities. Do we get tools, new ways to approach things, etc...

Just look at what we, the community did for Stack Overflow, that made Stack Overflow the company possible. Don't hurt your symbiotic partner, or else rogue symbiots will come in, and that may work out, but if you look in nature, it usually doesn't end up good for the host. Do you feel lucky?

Comment: *Because... we can and will build your greatest competitor in a heartbeat if we as a community abandon ship.* Might be too late to stop that already. It's a question of who builds a workable acceptable alternative first. A **lot** of people are ready to jump ship. Projects are already in the works, too.

Comment: @Magisch I know. I've seen the githubs slowly filling. One of the projects uses C#, which I personally don't fancy much. I've considered building my own alternative the last few months, with the option of importing answers from stack overflow and taking ownership with a key to be inserted in user profile so the questions can be decoupled from the CC-by-sa stack overflow attribution links and be put under new CC-by-sa [insert new site] attribution. This greatly decreases SEO value for SO, as google hates duplicate content. I haven't yet because I don't feel like managing yet another community.

Comment: @Tschallacka There are already a number of (malicious) sites that mirror StackOverflow content, but Google definitely has a preference for the earlier results

Comment: What is *"Technet"*? [Microsoft TechNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_TechNet)?

Comment: @forresthopkinsa actually, Google prefers newest most accurate results. Google measures how long people remain on site and sorts accordingly. Another disadvantage is that those sites have to abide by CC-BY-SA, linking back to SO, which decreases their ranking as well. But if you make a competitor, you can take the content, have the owners take ownership of it, and re license it back to the competitor, breaking any links to Stack Overflow. Then because that content will change and SO's content will grow stale, Google will prefer the competitor because people remain there longer.

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes

Comment: Mostly +1, but I think that you're actually contradicting yourself, in a way: you insist on the importance of community, and then say that building a competitor would be easy. That's true on technical level, but it's precisely the community that is difficult to build, and maintain.

Comment: @Tschallacka it's a bit difficult to gather the message you are trying to transmit. Could you please make a TL/DR section?

Comment: @Zhigalin-ReinstateCMs **TL;DR;** We don't trust you, so don't be a typical CEO that comes in and leaves after two years. Invest in the culture, read up on the community and know what moves us. Then take that along in long term strategic positions. end **TL;DR;** On another note, this CEO hasn't held a position longer than 2 years, with longest continuous employment for 7 years at rack space with multiple positions. He has studied harvard, so with this track record, it's most likely he'll be gone within short time to pursue other opportunities to further his carreer.

Comment: Excellent post - captures my feelings exactly. Another thing the SO Inc appear to believe is that "out of x million users we have, the Meta community is negligible.
So if they don't like or make ruckus or even a few thousand users leave, it doesn't really affect us". But in my view, that's both a dangerous as well as inaccurate.
A lot of users like me don't exactly participate in Meta but read a *lot* and broadly happy that the Meta exists and functions well. So if Meta is ignored, it'd affect
and alienate more users like me than the SO management believes.

Answer (score 52):

Thank you for posting here.

You are just few months late... *Better late than never...* but under the circumstances it might be way too late.

> Where do you see Stack Overflow going?

To be blunt... with current pace and accelerating - straight to hell...

Note: I will continue using *you* interchangeably to address both company and you as CEO and highest ranking person in the company responsible (even if you have to report to the investors you are now at the helm and you cannot evade responsibility for what is going on under your watch, whether you have personally participated in some events or not).

> it is critical that we work closely with our community to listen,
> change, and evolve rapidly.
>
> All of this is in pursuit of new and more productive ways to work with and listen to our community in the next era of the company.
>
> We acknowledge these issues, apologize for our mistakes, and have
> plans for improving in the future.

You keep talking about working with community, building the community... but actions in past few months do exactly the opposite. How can we trust you when all you have done is burning one bridge after another until there are none left?

All we got is one apology after another, and that future where you will improve never comes...

How do you think you can improve and build community by firing the very most people that know how to work with community and to whom community have trusted the most.

I am sorry to say, but you have lost that trust for good. It will be very hard to rebuild it, if possible at all. Maybe with some new users...

But, let’s focus on where you want to go and what is the actual plan for SO and SE

> The key to Stack Overflow’s future and growth are the millions of
> developers from around the world who find the site useful, but who
> haven’t yet been welcomed into the community. We need to expand our
> reach and engagement to ensure these developers join the conversation
> and push their own learning to new heights

I am not sure that you know how these sites work...

SO is the most useful when you don't need to ask questions at all. You don't even need an account to successfully use the sites. The last thing we need is more questions.

It has been repeated many times before, that quantity is detrimental to quality and quality was what attracted the experts and made this place successful in the first place.

> This is a big mandate. So as we embark on the journey this coming
> year, I’ve asked everyone at Stack Overflow to maintain a growth
> mindset (through hard work, openness to feedback, and resilience), to
> always operate with our “why” at the center, and to conduct every
> meeting as if there is a community member and customer in the room.

Even if we forget that you have basically burned all trust with community and that quality wise we are already sitting in the mud for quite some time, you have never actually said what **WHY** represents. We no longer know, and all the actions in last few months (even years) indicate that original *Why* is lost.

Before we can embark anywhere, we need fewer words and empty phrases we cannot possibly trust (because actions contradict words).

**We need exact blueprints of what you are trying to build. And we need them yesterday.**

Comment: "You don't even need an account to successfully use the sites." - Visit http://stackoverflow.com when you aren't logged in. It takes a lot of effort to find the single link that leads you to questions.

Comment: @Andy It wasn't like that few years back, before I joined. And even if having account makes it easier, the whole point is that asking questions is not needed. Most of the time, people that really have the need to ask question are the ones that ask rather poor questions. The whole "place for asking question" philosophy is kind of backward now...  it should be "place where you can find answers (without asking)"

Comment: Sorry @DalijaPrasnikar, my comment wasn't meant as criticism to your post. It was meant to point out that if you visited stackoverflow.com, there is a very low likelihood that you're even realize you could get anywhere without an account.

Comment: @Andy No worries... I keep forgetting that main landing page has changed a lot.

Comment: I don't think the landing page is so much of an issue regarding this.  I assume most questions are found through Google, thus completely bypassing the landing page.

Comment: @Andy while it's a good point.... how many users go "stackoverflow.com", then do a search from there? Compared to people who Google "how to foo the bar"?

Comment: The fact remains that the very incompetent decision to change the front page was made & implemented early summer 2019. Why so many thoroughly incompetent decisions were made during 2019 specifically, I don't know, but whoever made them caused permanent damage to the site and company.

Answer (score 50):

**What is the value of community?**

You talk about the value of the community. Let's put a number on that. There are currently about 500 volunteer moderators across all SE sites. If we assume they each spend 10 hours a week on SE, how much would it cost to employ them? Let's take a conservative figure of $20/hr (I hope you pay your community managers a lot more than that, btw). That's $5.2m in unpaid moderator labour each year, or $52m over the decade SE/SO has been going. We could get a more accurate figure from @Shog9's "year in moderation" info, but of course you sacked them.

Personally I would also include all answers as unpaid labour too. Questioners get something tangible in exchange for their input; I don't think magic reputation beans count as fair exchange.

Last year there were 2.8m answers. Let's say each answer takes five minutes (some clearly take very much longer, but let's be conservative). Let's cost the volunteers at $20/hr as before, a seriously low rate for expert software developers but about right for astronomers or mathematicians ;). That gives us $4.7m per yr.

So let's say the value of the community is a minimum of $10m/yr, or $100m over the decade SE/SO has been running. You can halve that if you assume linear growth of course, but we're talking a ballpark figure here and I think activity has been relatively static or even falling for a good few years now (happy to be corrected on that).

My point is, in pure financial terms the community has put a similar amount in to the business in kind as the investors have in cash. What do the investors get? A 10x return on their money (they hope). What does the community get? Not even a seat at the table.

Some people, possibly most, think that's absolutely fine and dandy and just how modern internet businesses work. There's nothing wrong in making money off the labour of some poor schmuck who's willing to work for free, right? I'm the kind of actual communist who thinks it is morally wrong, but regardless of where you are on that particular spectrum, you have to admit that the community has given you a huge investment and if the last few months are anything to go by you (as in SE Inc, not necessarily @Pchandrasekar personally) do not seem to appreciate that or value it, or their opinions.

Which brings me on to another couple of numbers from your recent podcast. There are apparently 23m professional software developers in the world (which was news to me) and 46m SE/SO users (did I hear that right? There are only 12m registered on SO according to the site list). Either number would suggest a certain degree of market saturation. This means that you can't rely on user churn to supply future moderators/answerers. Simply put, there aren't many expert software developers out there who haven't heard of Stack Overflow. The number of those who have who are willing to work for you for free is relatively small and finite.

This means you should care about (power)user retention, and mod retention, much more than you seem to. There is not an infinite pool of experts and potential mods out there to draw on. It also means that wherever your 10x revenue growth is going to come from in the next year, it isn't going to come from SE/SO user growth. So if you really expect that 90% of your income at year end is going to be coming from elsewhere, why do you care about this community at all? Why not just ditch it altogether?

It's a serious question. If the Q/A sites are a valuable shop window for your broader business then you need to support the community and listen to them as if they'd invested $100m in the company. Because they have. On the other hand, if they're just a drag on your resources and you think your staff's time would be better spent on paying customers then why not cut the community loose or spin it off as a non-profit? You might make everyone happier.

PS I spent an hour on this. You owe me $20. And I mean you @Pchandrasekar personally.

Comment: May I plug my recent question [Where's the new boatload of experts who can explain stuff to me like I'm five?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392414/wheres-the-new-boatload-of-experts-who-can-explain-stuff-to-me-like-im-five) here?

Comment: SO made more than 80m in 2018, even more in 2019. The money you quoted was nothing for SO scale size. Also, if SO was paying the community, there'd be strict in performance measures, not just like now where everybody can do anything. There'd be much less people involved due to better quality. Your arguments simply make no sense.

Comment: @HelloWorld I wasn't trying to make an argument, just trying to roughly quantify the value of volunteer labour to SO. Was that 80m in profit or 80m in revenue in 2018? If the latter (I've read 70m revenue but don't have a reference to hand) then 1/8 of revenue would imply that volunteer labour is a pretty important contribution to the company's success. Would be very happy to see other estimates.

Comment: @CodeCaster you may. Have an upvote from me. I find the quality of answers on the non-technical sites I (used to) frequent has declined markedly too. It's a vicious circle, and can happen pretty rapidly on some of the smaller sites where a small number of high rep users provide a lot of answers.

Comment: Standing ovation.

Answer (score 49):

Within your blog post, you contained a couple of sentences that sounded condescending to me... in particular:

> We want to serve all of the millions of people who use Stack Overflow, not just those who know the most about how the site has worked in the past

What do you think we've all being doing all this time?

We *all* want to serve the millions of people and it's really not a lot to ask that before we spend 5+ minutes of time helping someone that they have already done the same.

---

I want to believe you, I *really* do. But it's things like this and removing anyone that provided community insight that make this currently impossible.

So I think you need to be very clear on what you want this site to be: a place for *any* question or a knowledge base of questions.

Answer (score 45):

In the blog you say:

> All of this is in pursuit of new and more productive ways to work with and listen to our community in the next era of the company.

which read to me as that up till now working with Meta was less productive than you hoped for. I would like to learn what I did wrong that made it less productive. It is a bit of a waste of time and effort for both of us if how I engage causes friction and I'm more than happy to adapt to certain needs within my abilities.

Comment: You, personally? That seems a little specific :)

Comment: @terdon, Doesn't seem too specific to me.  He can really only affect his own behavior.

Comment: Don't you mean: "I would like to learn what "the community" (i.e. we) did wrong that made it less productive."? What makes you think that you (s) did something wrong?

Comment: @Mari-LouA no, not really. It is much easier to pin-point what I did wrong and coach me on that. Others will recognize my behavior and can decide if they want to follow the same advice. I don't think talking about "the community" is much useful, as there hardly is one, single "the community".

Comment: Alternatively, I'd like to know what the *moderators* could have done differently in order to address the inevitable issues that come from having a textbox on the Internet to make Meta into a usable venue for feedback and discussion.

Comment: Unsure if they're still answering but it'd be a damn shame if they ignored this one which is actually asking for pointers on how to be more productive.

Comment: @CodyGray I've been thinking about it a lot... I love meta. I think it's a great way to interact with the people using the platform in a more relaxed way... relaxed meaning... it's not about the subject of the site and the rules aren't quite as strict... but - and I think this was a lot of what George was saying - it also led to a bit of a relaxation in judging what was nice. But where do you draw the line between enforcing be nice and tone policing? This is difficult. People can say important things in rude ways... what should be done? Should they be edited? deleted? addressed?

Comment: I've seen a lot of things go ignored. Heck, as an avid MSE user, I've **been** ignored. Many of my FRs there have met with silence or defensive responses... and I happen to think that I'm pretty good at putting things constructively and openly and I do my best to help others do so, too. And, so that frustration grows. Your next post gets a bit more angry and a bit less constructive... you're still making good points but it's harder to read if the post is directed at you. Eventually, you may cross the line from making points to scoring points... and that's where it's gone too far.

Comment: I want meta to be a useful and constructive place and I know that getting it back there is going to take reversing a lot of silence and instead communicate more about what's going on... and those steps are moving forward, slowly, granted... but the more we can be open and the more people can respond constructively, the faster things can change, I think. I'm going to have to work on not taking frustrations directed in my general vicinity so personally and... well, I'm probably going to respond more to people who can interact kindly. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: So, I guess, @CodyGray , the answer to your question is - as a mod - think about what's being said on Meta. Is it there to forward the discussion and keep communication open or is it there to "score points".

Comment: I go for "score points" ... I see myself out ... ;)

Comment: @Catija "Many of my FRs there have met with silence or defensive responses... and I happen to think that I'm pretty good at putting things constructively and openly..." If you have seen people get defensive even when you were constructive, that should lead you to conclude that not being constructive or friendly enough wasn't the source of the problem. Far more often, the problem is that a person is impassioned about an issue or simply *isn't getting what they wanted*. The latter is extremely common on SO **because we moderate** and can't be eliminated as long as we do.

Comment: @Catija So we have to make a decision about what's more valuable: clearing out low quality content so people can more easily find the information they need, or making people happy and pleased when they post here? Those two are, in many ways, fundamentally incompatible. We can nibble at the edges to improve the balance a little, but we can't have them both. SO was built with the former priority.

Answer (score 44):

Perhaps it's just me, but I hate "marketing buzzword" comments. Unfortunately, I feel like that's what we're getting here - a lot of replies feel like generic "go away" style support desk replies rather than genuine engagement from a CEO who wants to listen to the community. Can we please get something more concrete than the below examples?

> Along with data points mentioned in today's post, we also keep a close eye on question quality. The blog below was our most recent look at the topic, and we feel good about the direction things are heading

I read this as: "We've picked a dubious question quality metric and it makes us look great, so we're sticking with it."

> and for a long time we have said that our mission is to "help developers write the script of the future."

Never heard it, and it just sounds like a meaningless marketing catch phrase.

> As we push forward with The Loop, our moderator council, and our Tiger Team initiatives, I hope these efforts will prove useful to the community and productive in rebuilding a good working relationship

...what the actual... seriously? Is this a joke? Can we just call a spade a spade, or are we expecting a fractal lion council of Alderon to emerge from next month's blog post to engage with the community about developer toileting issues?

...anyway...

As for the main question:

> where do you see the network going in the next five years

I honestly think that's entirely down to the actions of management. A lot of longtime SO users have felt really let down recently on a number of fronts - from "big" events such as the Monica situation and Shog's firing, to smaller annoyances such as removing featured moderator resignation posts and refusing to send out swag to 100k members.

If a turnaround in attitude can be demonstrated, I think you'll start to win people back over. If not, I suspect Stack Overflow will increasingly be a "homework dump" site of more and more poor quality questions, with fewer and fewer good Q&A.

Comment: Blog post by Joel Spolsky, 2016: *[Developers are Writing the Script for the Future](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2016/12/09/developers-are-writing-the-script-for-the-future/)*. I am not sure if it goes longer back or is a play on something [Marc Andreessen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Andreessen)  (of Netscape, 1994-2003) said ([*"Why software is eating the world"*](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2018/01/24/software/) (2000-10)).

Comment: That "homework dump" problem could be a significant one. I've always thought I've perceived a correlation between the overall quality of the questions posted and the likelihood that more experienced and engaged users would stick around to answer them. Too much drivel and why keep coming back? (Or, as our Tour pages collectively assert: _We're a little bit [different](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) from other sites. Here's how:_)

Comment: @J.R. I think you're correct - anecdotal, but I know a few people who couldn't be bothered to carry on posting for that reason. I pretty much only hang around in a few niche tags these days. I used to follow the Java tag and pick out a few interesting questions to answer when I had the time, but these days the few good questions there are tend to be lost in the noise.

Answer (score 41):

**Success Factors for Stack Overflow**

When I joined Stack Overflow in the fall of 2009, it was a site for experts and enthusiasts. World leading experts took time out of their day to answer questions, and provide feedback that proved invaluable to my professional development.

Back then, there were two groups of users:

- experts, who liked to share their expertise
- enthusiasts striving to become experts

Both groups shared the same set of values and goals, and each benefited from the interaction:

- experts learned from other experts,
- experts were thanked enthusiastically, could empathize with the people they helped
- enthusiasts received invaluable guidance for the professional development

The high quality content left behind by these interactions attracted links from all over the internet, massively increasing stack overflow's google ranking and traffic.

This however attracted a new kind of user. After all, people googling programming problems are not necessarily enthusiastic, nor likely to be experts. These help vampires, as they were pejoratively called, did not interact with other users in a mutually beneficial way:

- help vampires received the help they wanted,
- experts were not thanked, flooded with boring questions, and started to doubt whether they were actually truly helping, or merely enabling the helplessness of others by providing quick fixes

Growing unhappy with these unsatisfying interactions, experts asked for the previous ethos of the site to be codified into rules, and used comments such as "what have you tried" to remind new users of those rules.

Alas, being frustrated by constant annoying interactions, they were not always very nice about it, which in turn alienated newly arriving enthusiasts and experts, which resented being subjected to a host of poorly communicated rules.

Seeing its growth throttled, the company attempted to fix this, first by gentle nudging ("summer of love"), then by increasingly desperate measures. The experts and long-term users resist this, because they fear that interaction quality will deteriorate even further, causing an exodus of experts, causing a drop in answer quality, a drop in google ranking, and stack overflow to go the way of yahoo answers. I think that is a real risk.

Speaking for myself, I used to be in awe at the competence displayed in the average stack overflow answer. Nowadays, I am usually embarrassed because most answers are so poor.

In summary, stack overflow derives its value from interactions between people of different levels of expertise. If these interactions are mutually beneficial, people will flock to your platform and grow your business - but if they are not, they will leave.

The platform must ensure that all users, the drive-by help seekers, the enthusiasts, and the experts, have a good experience on the platform. The core business and challenge of stack overflow is matching users that can have a mutually beneficial interaction, and structuring their interaction to maximize value created.

**Ideas for better matching**

So far, questions are matched based on tags and activity.

Have you considered splitting the brand to account for the specific needs of different user groups? This is not without precedent: splitting of "software engineering" from the "stack overflow" brand totally eliminated the tension surrounding "subjective questions". Might a dedicated brand for programmers in training alleviate the tension around "newbie questions"?

Have you considered asking for additional meta data to improve matching? For instance, experience level?

Have you considered using machine learning to predict who might be interested in a question? The wealth of voting data that you have might allow much better predictions that what you use now.

**Ideas for beneficial interactions**

Have you considered helping users to include all relevant information? On Github, issue templates are used by pretty much every project now. Perhaps question templates might serve a similar purpose on stack overflow? Perhaps even different templates for different tags?

Have you considered limiting the audience of downvoted questions? Either opt-in, or probabilistic in that downvoted questions are shown to fewer people in their question lists? That negative feedback is "piling up" on poor questions (as Sarah Chipps puts it) might be an artifact of "active" questions being shown to more users ...

**Ideas for productive community relations**

Do not shoot messengers. Do not delete dissent on meta. Do not suspend dissenting users. Do not fire dissenting moderators without due process. Do not lay off dissenting employees. Instead, listen to these people. They are your early warning system, and if you silence them, the problem may grow until it is wholly out of your ability to control.

Do not try to deceive your community. Do not manage the message - manage the content! The various attempts at whitewashing and deception we have seen lately have made us distrust pretty much all company communications (we are hoping you are different, but I guess we will see).

My outside perspective is that you have a severe people problem in community management. And no, it's not the people who have been let go.

Comment: I agree with almost all of this, except: how can the help vampires be satisfied? They have no interest in investing in the site -- learning the rules of how to properly ask and answer questions. Instead, they'll loudly complain on Twitter that the site is "unwelcoming".

Comment: @ZevSpitz: For instance by being shown an existing answer that matches their question.

Comment: I fear that the only way the help vampires can be appeased is if the matching question is almost word for word the same as the question which brought them here in the first place, which is statistically unlikely. Anything less, and they'll have to invest in reading and understanding the existing question, and attempting to apply its' answers to their problem; which I suspect they'll be unwilling to do.

Comment: @meriton we do show them an existing answer that matches their question. We use the dupe system for that. But apparently that's not enough - we're still guilty of closing their perfectly good question (that's been asked countless times) and even *daring* to give them a "duplicate" that in no means answers their question (because they have a variable called `foo` but the dupe uses a variable called `bar`).

Comment: "*downvoted questions are shown to fewer people in their question lists*" in my experience downvoted questions are not that often "piled on". They tend to have lower views than similar questions that simply have a score of zero. Because that's what the voting system is for - negative score means it's not worth it, so fewer people check out the question. Some clearly low quality questions even have trouble getting enough close votes because not enough people bother checking out the question (and close vote). The "piling" tends to happen to *really* bad questions.

Comment: I've upvoted quite a few of the answers I've read so far, but I clicked my mouse most emphatically on this one.

Comment: Actually, I don't want the help vampires to be appeased. I want the experts to be happy. Because it's the experts that provide the value to everybody else who visits this site. If you cannot be bothered to invest a few minutes into phrasing a non-abysmal question/answer, you are simply not ready to contribute to a site where your content will be visible to experts world wide. And if you endeavor to join a community of experts, you must be able and willing to learn. I, for one, am very grateful to the people who downvoted my early answers and explained why they downvoted: That's how I learned!

Comment: There is a precedent for your proposal to create levels of expertise.  ELU and ELL are sister sites, with one aimed at the sophisticated user, and one aimed at beginners and intermediate English learners.

Answer (score 41):

Want a radical idea?

### Transform Stack Exchange Inc. into a non-profit organization.

Nearly everything of value here, beyond the plumbing, was created by community volunteers.  The more you try to squeeze that generosity in pursuit of profit, the more the trust of the community will erode, particularly when the quality of the community falls into conflict with the objectives of profit.

Stack Exchange Inc. is now almost the same size, in terms of employees, as the Wikimedia Foundation, and they survive quite comfortably as a non-profit.

SO Jobs, Teams, etc, can roll into a for-profit subsidiary if you want, but if the past 10 years, and especially the past year, have taught us anything it's that the community is much better at managing the Q&A than the company.  Make a daring move.

Comment: Not to mention, it's also somewhat comical that I've heard that portions of this post are copied...

Comment: A slight variation: let the unhappy invested veteran crowd go off build the high quality question SO they say they always wanted. You have them out of your hair & have a prestigious nonprofit that bears Stack Overflow's name  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390983/create-a-separate-independent-advanced-so-focusing-on-being-a-knowledge-library

Comment: Whether or not Stack Exchange Inc is for-profit or non-profit has little to do with whether it's leadership listens. They Wikimedia Foundation has very similar problems in that it cares more about social justice goals then making the core users of Wikipedia happy. You have conflicts about Code of Conducts in both cases. The Wikimedia Foundation currently wants to push through a code of conduct against the wishes of the community as expressed by the Request for Comment votes.

Comment: @Christian It's not a trivial fix-all, I agree, but it would be a big step from the company in demonstrating good faith.  We can debate codes of conduct, but at the moment I feel much of the discord between the company and community is centering around profit motives conflicting with the community's objectives for quality - something we've demonstrated the ability to deliver when unencumbered by overbearing corporate interference.

Comment: @J... The issue of the ads was the only issue that was about profit motives and if it would be the only issue, the relationship betwee SE and the community would be a lot better.
Monica was fired over a conflict about the Code of Conduct. Focusing on Welcomness has nothing to do with focusing on profit. It happens because it's the political correct thing to do. Question quality or something that tracks the amount of valuable answers would be a better KPI if the focus would actually be on profits.

Comment: @J... If the core goal would be to push a product for professional software companies, there would be no need to be welcoming to beginner hobbyist programmers but it would make more sense to focus on making professional software developers happy so that they want to support the company.
SE largely engages in bad actions for the same non-profit reasons that make the WMF also engage in bad actions.

Comment: @Christian I disagree.  Welcomeness drives memberships - it drives traffic.  Traffic drives revenue.  Sometimes we must be less welcoming to preserve quality - standards must be met.  These are in conflict.  It's not the *only* source of conflict, surely, and you're correct that WMF is not perfect either, but I think it still makes sense from a quality and long-term sustainability perspective to separate the community Q&A from the commercial interests of the rest of the Stack Exchange portfolio.

Comment: @J... :Most traffic doesn't come from memberships but from people finding posts on Google. Getting users to write more content that ranks highly on Google would do more for traffic then getting more low level beginner questions that often aren't clear enough to be good Google hits. Traffic from professional software developers also happens to be much more important for revenue of SE then traffic from hobbyists. StackOverflow careers only monitizes professionals. Ads are targeted at professionals. The Teams/Enterprise products are for professionals.

Comment: @Christian And yet, here we are.  The community of professionals that are the backbone of this stack are in flight.  And it seems to correlate pretty strongly with VC injection up top.

Comment: @Pekka I think I tend to agree with [Dalija](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390987/327083).

Comment: Another option might be to run the whole thing as a new kind of giant multisig smart contract with reputation supplanted with deposit forfeiture, and participation as a decentralised paywall.

Comment: @Christian Also, the other main KPI that is being thrown around is new user signups - growing a userbase with raw numbers as the success metric.  This makes sense if you're trying to build a userbase to farm all of that sweet, sweet personal data from them as a corporate asset, but it does nothing whatsoever to improve the quality of the site.

Comment: This post gets it. When you're a neo-liberal fundamentalist every organisation looks like a more efficient or a less efficient monetary profit-generator. When it's less efficient (ie. it's not maximising its potential profit) then the solution is easy: saw off the dead wood and transform the less efficient profit-generator into a lean, mean profit maximiser. **But** *this misses the point* that back in the real world not every organisation is (or can be, or should be) a monetary profit-generator. [1/2]

Comment: We can agree that every organisation might, ideally, generate some kind of _value_ - but it need not be financial value. It might (whisper it) be _knowledge value_. It might also be the value that comes from the sense of being part of a community, from helping others, from mentoring; or from being helped, supported, mentored. There are many kinds of value, many kinds of capital. Financial value / financial capital is only one kind. Neo-liberals will tell you it is the only kind (or the only kind that matters). They are wrong. [2/2]

Comment: Re *"Nearly everything of value here, beyond the plumbing, was created by community volunteers."*: No, there was also the design of how the site works (that is more than plumbing): The mashup of ideas from other failed and successful attempts, stirred into a very successful mix (voting, badges, separation of the actual content and meta content (author info), reputation points, scaled moderation by means of privileges, wiki-like features, competitive answering as a means of getting extremely quick answers, seeding of the community with 50,000+ highly engaged users from day one, etc.).

Comment: @Frank: That sounds very interesting. Can you elaborate? E.g., are there some existing similar sites already in existence out there?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I think we disagree only in terminology. All that is what I meant by "plumbing". In the same way that AutoCAD is plumbing to a nuclear reactor. Surely the latter was built using the former, but it is also the culmination of a massive human collaborative effort. Here, the Q&A content is the mass of value on the SE network. The IP for the system that runs it also has value, certainly, and this works fine as a for-profit asset (Teams, etc, for example) in the same way that AutoCAD is a totally viable for-profit asset. The Q&A content, though, is entirely the work of the community.

Comment: @Rounin I'm an economic liberal, and I'm suggesting a non-profit solution.  So what does that tell you about what you think you know about economic liberalism?  It sounds like you need a soapbox.

Comment: It tells me that your definition of _neo-liberalism_ might be different from mine. The Wikipedia entry on [Neoliberalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neoliberalism) states: _"Some scholars have described the term as meaning different things to different people as neoliberalism has "mutated" into geopolitically distinct hybrids as it travelled around the world."_ The same entry also refers to (some) economists regarding neo-liberalism as _hyper-capitalism_ or _"capitalism with the gloves off"_. These sound to me like succinct definitions.

Comment: @Rounin The failing of the SE executive don't need to be blamed on some spectre of an economic philosophy.  They are the result of bad decisions and poor management.  I'm not sure why you feel they need to be shielded from the responsibility of those actions by deflecting it towards a branch of academic thought that you disagree with.

Comment: We may agree that recent management decisions have been poor. But in the context of a culture, laser-focused on extracting maximum profit (and anything else only as a means to securing that maximum profit extraction), senior executives may disagree with us. They might argue - were they to speak plainly - that they are not failing to achieve their vision. It's simply that their vision does not align with that of the former CEO. (Or with ours).

Comment: @Rounin Whatever - it's plain short sightedness.  Running a company into the ground for short-term gain is a long and honoured tradition of financial vultures.  It's got nothing to do with liberal economics.

Comment: @J.... New user signup, is a poor metric for business purposes. It's what Eric Ries would call "vanity metric" in the Lean Startup. If you look at a company like Facebook, Facebook cares about daily active users. Business-wise it would make much more sense to focus on monthly active users then new user signup for SE.

Comment: @Christian Or like Wikipedia, where most of the traffic simply comes from anonymous non-account holding users and a vastly smaller group of competent contributors actually produce and maintain the content.  The honeypot here at SE is that content creation has the veneer of an interactive user experience so focusing on account numbers and activity is really just a distraction.  The main metrics really should be the number of people using SE as a *reference* - it's perfectly possible for SE to reduce the number of active users as long as content quality goes up and total traffic increases.

Answer (score 39):

I'm a moderator (though I wouldn't describe myself as a long serving one) and a long time member of one of your smaller communities, I have a few specific questions.

> The team’s mission is to improve our feedback loop and working relationship with our community.

.

> The work we do would not be possible without the contributions of our incredible community. Across Stack Overflow, hundreds of thousands of users, supported by hundreds of moderators, helped to review questions, triage answers, propose new tags, and keep the discourse respectful and on topic.

On these points - as a MSE moderator on and off over the past year, I've noticed that engagement is often one way, more so than it has been.

There has been friction, and members of the moderator corps quitting over corporate decisions and what is often an inability to communicate policy effectively.

How do you plan to rehabilitate the loss of trust from the community that does much of the moderation and maintenance workload?

In relation

> We learned that we needed much better channels to listen to our moderators and community members. We have not evolved the existing channels of engagement for power users in our community, like Meta, or articulated how we intended to make improvements going forward. This has caused friction as our user base and business have rapidly grown. We acknowledge these issues, apologize for our mistakes, and have plans for improving in the future.

While the community manager team has been the lead there, they've been increasingly unable to actually engage with us. There have been complaints of overwork for years.

From [Jon's Blog](https://jlericson.com/2020/01/17/leaving_stack.html)

> Sometimes perspective changes rapidly. In September and October, a series of events demonstrated that leadership within the company neither understood community management nor was willing to learn. In retrospect, that’s likely been the case for years, but the community team has traditionally been given discretion when it comes to community relations. The double-edged sword of attention meant more resources have been going to community-related projects, but also leadership has asserted more control. Unfortunately, their decisions repeatedly violated my standards for healthy community management. By November I was actively looking for a new job.

If management is unable to listen to those within the company - how are they going to listen to folks without?

We've needed more community managers for *years* as the community grew. Yet this is a team that keeps shrinking. It is a request that has been repeatedly been made. We keep getting fed lines about "improving their work process" instead.

The result of this was us losing 2 experienced staff members - apparently unexpectedly, and a third quitting. All of them were highly respected, experienced and key to building and nurturing the community so far. We've heard nothing from Robert, and apparently the conditions for Shog's severance were bad enough that the community has a [gofundme](https://www.gofundme.com/f/thanking-josh-heyer-for-shaping-stack-overflow?utm_medium=copy_link&utm_source=customer&utm_campaign=p_lico%20share-sheet) for him

Are there plans, as in the past to assist the employees who were let go ? It seems the right thing and hearing from folks that "the company helped us" means a lot, especially from someone who helped grow the community from the early days.

> As we look forward to 2020, we plan to invest in public Q&A

The most important investment you can make is in the CM team that's been [Thanos](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Snap)ed last week.

> We are also forming a moderator council, which will include a group of users with diverse experience levels and backgrounds who can help guide our processes. We’re making hard choices and treating no assumptions as sacred in considering ways to evolve the community.

I trust and respect the remaining CMs for most part. I'd even say they're the only reason I'm still here. Not the directors or veeps or C level people making decisions

I can say less so of some other staff. I will say this. It *will* be difficult for many mods to trust in the process as things have gone. We're unpaid volunteers, and our only ties are with our communities, and *people*. Considering that over the past half decade, the community team has been systematically downsized - it gets harder. They have always tried their best to do right by the community. They are our interface with the company and damned good ones. If you want to bring value to, and show the community they are valued, value them. Every single one of them, past and present probably  *understands* us. This has been lacking over the years, and it pains me to see them get treated as "a cost center" to be cut back.

I think you see a trend here. We need strong, robust community support to thrive and keep the things that made the network *great*.

While hanging out on Root Access and other chats like Jeff used to is probably asking a little too much, I'd like to share something Jeff wrote about [his next project](https://blog.discourse.org/2014/08/building-a-discourse-community/) after SE

> Leadership comes from the top. The presence of staff speaks volumes about whether your community is alive and thriving. Don’t just say you believe in this community, demonstrate that through your personal participation and enthusiasm. Lead by example. Reply to questions people have, help your community learn the ropes, gently guide and shape the community as you go.

That has been *distinctly* lacking.

> I’ve asked everyone at Stack Overflow to maintain a growth mindset (through hard work, openness to feedback, and resilience), to always operate with our “why” at the center, and to conduct every meeting as if there is a community member and customer in the room.

We're here. Lots of us are disappointed, angry and confused.

While not on the blog, there's a bit of uncertainty over the future of the Network.

In my role as a moderator of Super User - and on behalf of the other 2/3 of the original trilogy, as well as smaller sites - we're uncertain over the direction the network is taking. Lots of folks are worried that smaller sites will be shut down or merged into SO.

What does closer integration mean? SU and SF have their own cultures, and scope, and frankly if we're rolled into SO, we'd lose a significant part of our utility and distinctiveness. I'd also like to know so I can plan a graceful exit, and not wake up one morning and find a blog post saying its now "Superuser.Stackoverflow.com" and accessible over the left side bar (and that the mod of one of the earliest sites is saying this is how little trust I have)

Considering that one of the complaints of SO is "its too busy and not newbie friendly" - how do these plans tackle that?

I don't think *our* communities were consulted over this either. It would be nice to have some *clear* direction on where we're heading.

Comment: Re *"...smaller sites..."*: Not referring to the [second-largest](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic)?

Comment: Oh - SU, SU + SF and *everyone else* in that order. SU is my main site. SF was my second site for *years* and I still have a soft spot for it. I'm pretty sure sites like pets and IPS need love too, but they are certainly not going to be a natural fit for getting merged into or even cross pollinating with SO

Comment: And frankly at this point- I didn't even think about the fact that we were the second biggest site.And I certainly don't think that's something that I wanted in the post proper.

Comment: *That has been distinctly lacking.*  Not distinctly lacking.  **Deliberately** lacking.  They're throwing their mouthpieces under the bus to take the flak.

Comment: Hey @JourneymanGeek - one thing I learned during my first 90 days as I gathered feedback from a broad range of customers and community members, was that many of them knew of Stack Overflow, but had never heard of the many amazing communities we have inside Stack Exchange. There are ways to make the knowledge sharing on SE more discoverable to folks on SO, and to encourage cross-pollination between sites like DevOps, Software Engineering, Information Security, and many others. So we intend to work on some ideas around that.

Comment: I understand this may cause concern from moderators of Stack Exchanges about how their roles will change. Right now the goal is to test this hypothesis in the spirit of improving the community user experience. As we move forward with exploring how it might work, we will be seeking input from our community and sharing our thoughts with you.

Answer (score 39):

To be overly indulgent, I have a second question. **Will Stack Overflow remain a site for "[professional and enthusiast programmers](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/)?"** (text that still appears on the official [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page), which Jeff Atwood defined as "people who either already have a job as a programmer, or could potentially be hired as a programmer today if they wanted to be." I ask this because of ongoing debate about the future of the site and this paragraph in your blog post:

> It is critically important that we evolve our platform, community infrastructure, and culture to be more useful to our community so we continue to be a core part of a developer’s workflow. Of the ~90,000 respondents to our 2019 Stack Overflow Developer survey, 80% tagged themselves as hobbyist programmers, 60% wrote their first line of code before the age of 17, and only 10% were women. Statistics like these have significant implications on how we think about making our community more welcoming, engaging, and inclusive. The key to Stack Overflow’s future and growth are the millions of developers from around the world who find the site useful, but who haven’t yet been welcomed into the community. We need to expand our reach and engagement to ensure these developers join the conversation and push their own learning to new heights.

And [your comment here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393155/ceos-2020-kickoff-blog-where-do-you-see-stack-overflow-going/393167#comment750853_393167):

> Respectfully, we do not believe that welcoming, teaching, and empowering new generations of beginners is mutually exclusive with building a quality archive.

If the goal is to expand by attracting more "professional and enthusiast programmers," especially and including developers (and other types of technical workers certainly) who don't also consider themselves hobbyists, learned as adults, and come from diverse backgrounds, that's fantastic; the community will benefit enormously from having them here, and we need to address the barriers keeping them away. But given the enormous focus on growth and metrics throughout your blog post, there's reason for concern that the goal may be to expand by seeking more and more "reach and engagement" from the millions of people who are interested, but not professional and enthusiast programmers, the "new generations of beginners" you speak of, which is something the community has expressed many concerns about.

And I don't want that to amount to gatekeeping. The millions of people who are interested but not professional and enthusiast programmers (and practitioners of other technical fields) need quality tools and resources to learn and become professionals (or have the knowledge that they could be). For all the reasons Atwood lays out, Stack Overflow has been designed as "pretty much everything you would not want as a student or beginner." **So if the goal is to "expand reach" by continuing to attract and teach "new generations of beginners," what will SO be doing to provide resources that specifically cater to their needs?** And if the goal is to "expand reach" just among professionals and enthusiasts, what mechanisms will be used to specifically target that group of new users?

Comment: Let's.... make a forum for them.... because that'll work out great

Comment: There are any number of ways to provide resources that are designed for "new generations of beginners," or to partner with other places that already do that, if SO is now explicitly targeting that group of users. It's not fair to beginners, or to the professional and enthusiast community that's already here, to attract them to a site that's explicitly designed not to cater to their needs.

Comment: I think that it's lived practice for a while now that SO is for everyone interested in programming. This doesn't give necessarily good experiences for all, but that's what it is. For example the "requires minimal understanding" close reason is gone for a long time, but then it was also abused. There is no clear boundary between enthusiasts and everyone.

Comment: @Tschallacka: it may not be such a bad idea to do that, as long as that is a separate entity to Stack Overflow. "Beginner Programmers" would have a different set of on-topic rules, and they would be much looser than SO. I think some experts would be willing to go there, and try to help, especially if it protects the quality levels on the main site. It may be a disaster, as you imply, but at least it would demonstrate to the company what happens when you have a free-for-all.

Comment: @halfer nobody in their right mind will start a voluntary dumpster fire...

Comment: @Tschallacka: heh! While I agree that it is not likely to create quality content, I don't mind helping beginners in traditional discussion rooms like Reddit. They're trying to solve a different problem to SO, and that's OK.

Comment: (The great thing about dumpster fires is that they are safely contained `;-)`).

Answer (score 36):

What do you plan to do about quality on Stack Overflow now that Monthly New Sign Ups and Questions Asked are such an important metric you keep focusing on?

The tide of bad questions and answers was held in check somewhat by the same community you seem to have alienated. It may be a vocal minority, but those same people shoulder the majority of the workload when it comes down to ensuring I can actually trust what I find on here.

I am eternally grateful to all of the people who put in their free time making this site worth visiting. How do you plan to win back the trust of the people who make your site not just another google result that I need to spend my time vetting?

Because that is where I see stack overflow going in the next 5 years. It will just become another questionable link in the result list.

Comment: I don't think you can actually trust what you find on Stack Overflow. The envisioned collaborative editing / updating of content never took off (due to reputation points envy, how the system was designed, and other factors). It is essentially forum posts with slightly better grammar, spelling, and signal-to-noise). Bad content survives and gets upvotes if it can survive the first few hours (where the attention is) - there is *only* attention on new questions.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: As someone searching for an answer to a programming question, it's better to start from the perspective of a Google search.  For example, [this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+split+a+string), which yields [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java) as the fifth search result.  Granted, it's just a simple example, but in my experience, results from Google searches usually yield pretty good results from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 35):

You ask:

> where do you see the network going in the next five years, and what do you think should be done in order to get there?

It sounds like what you're really asking is: **[What does Stack Overflow want to be when it grows up?](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/)**

I won't try to summarize everything in Jeff's article, but I will simply point out that, despite not having anything to do with day-to-day operations of Stack Overflow since 2012, Jeff's understanding of the problems this site faces and how to solve them seems more relevant in 2020 than ever.

Your blog post thanks Jeff (among others) for having "contributed so meaningfully to our mission". Is it possible that Jeff still understands the mission better?

I think so.

Comment: So far, of all 2 pages of answers, I think this one is the best.

Answer (score 35):

I posted [some reflections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342676) on the blog post over at Meta.SE, but since you say you want the community "to be the first to know when I shared a vision," I wanted to ask a simpler question here: **where's the vision?**

---

I'm sorry if that sounds snarky, but I've read "Scripting the Future of Stack Overflow" several times now, and I don't see a vision. What I see is basically:

- Metrics and KPIs
- A goal to expand "reach and engagement"
- Somewhat-vague statements addressing communication with the community (important but not a vision)
- Grow the existing businesses, especially Teams. More metrics
- More opportunities for developers and companies to interact (more of a suite of product features than an overall vision, but the closest we've come to a vision)
- Grow Stack Overflow

And the immediate efforts to achieve that, what is described as a "big mandate" are to:

> As we look forward to 2020, we plan to invest in public Q&A, expand our community, and continue to cement our place as a pillar of the software industry and broader knowledge economy. We also know that we have work to do on improving how we engage with our community, as well as continuing to strive for more diversity, inclusion, and approachability.

Bluntly, I'm not seeing a vision out of this. There are lots of numbers that you'd presumably like to be larger, a clear desire to be bigger, and a general desire to be better, but KPIs and hockey stick graphs are not a vision, and they're not really meaningful to the community in the abstract.

In a comment on [George Stocker's excellent question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393171), you write:

> Hey George - for a long time we have said that our mission is to "help developers write the script of the future." This continues to be true. Recently we have begun to say our mission is to help developers AND technical workers write the script of the future, reflecting the increasing diversity of knowledge being shared across our network. To accomplish this goal, we need to have a healthy, growing business and community. The blog post I shared today is a good articulation of how we plan to move forward in 2020 to fulfill this mission and support our users, customers, and community.

I'm all for the expansion to broader categories of technical workers, but that change doesn't seem like a vision either. The vision you wanted us to be the first to know under your leadership is...a slogan Joel Spolsky coined a couple of years ago, and to accomplish that vision, you seek to...grow? That's the mission for a "visionary company" where we're going to "help move humanity forward," a phrase you've tacked onto the end of a blog post that otherwise doesn't discuss much of a future vision for Stack Overflow, let alone the forward progress of humanity?

So to ask a another version of my initial question: what is the vision beyond growth? What kinds of things will you be doing as a company, and what will we be doing as a community, to "help move humanity forward?" Because if the actual vision is simply "get big and IPO," you can save us all a lot of time and pain if you just say that right now, and we can all stop pretending there's a broader vision.

---

Comment: Absolutely this: _"[...] what is the vision beyond growth?"_ What other ideas does the "new" pro-censorship, pro-banning, pro-sacking Stack Overflow have?

Answer (score 35):

I would like to answer a question with a question. Reading through your blog, I noticed this:

> The key to Stack Overflow’s future and growth are the millions of developers from around the world who find the site useful, but who haven’t yet been welcomed into the community.

One thing that has fascinated me about financialised industry and the economics of the last few decades is the rationale for 'growth'. People are obsessed with it, and often without really knowing why. It has become something of a religion, an unquestionable axiom, that 'growth' is necessary.

Blog posts like yours are very typical of communications from entities in the modern financial capitalism, in that they present growth related goals without really explaining the rationale for growth. These messages present growth as implicit, and to some extent help to reinforce the idea that 'growth' should be assumed without question.

I understand the reason why growth is necessary in the modern economy, though it is less the case now post the 2007 financial crisis in the new framework of permanent stimulus, but I don't think it should necessarily apply to entities like Stack Overflow. This company does not need to participate in the ever expanding credit creation game that banks, real estate, energy, automotive and military firms need to play in the US.

So my question to you is 'why the need for growth?'

I believe [Deming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Edwards_Deming), credited with revolutionizing Japanese industry in the late 20th century, recognized early on that aiming for quantity has inverse results, whereas aiming for quality produces the quantity and costs less than poor quality. His number one principle is:

> Create constancy of purpose for improving products and services.

The primary goal of quantity (growth in this case) is likely to result in the converse. Permanent quality improvement is the goal.

"Do what you love and the money will follow" is the mantra for many. Unfortunately, modern corporate management much prefer the mantra of ['pump it and dump it'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pump_and_dump)...or more politely put 'achieve growth with an exit strategy'.

Comment: A discussion between Magisch and Frank about the ownership and financial interests of the company has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206566/discussion-on-answer-by-frank-ceos-2020-kickoff-blog-where-do-you-see-stack-ov).

Comment: Seriously, you *already* know the answer to your question - in business, Growth == Profits. Everything else in the blog post is PR (or is that BS, I tend to confuse them) and make sense once you accept this.

Comment: @dfd No that is incorrect. Growth and profits are two different concepts, though granted profit may result in growth, and growth may result in profit. So that I do not impress as condescending or cryptic, I can offer you the example of an online retailer, with a revenue model measured in sales per user, and where growth is propelled by investor loans diluting the shareholding but directed into television advertising. If you would like further help in understanding the concept of growth, I am at your disposal for the fruitful lifetime of this discourse.

Comment: Two degrees, including BS in Business Management here (second is BSCS). Trust me, I do know the difference. But you directed your question to the CEO of SO, Inc. and a specific blog "post" (it read much worse than that to me) who *does* pretty much spell out that on their end Growth == Profit. That was my real point. I do think I'd love to hear your "fruitful lifetime of discourse" between you and him! :-) Peace.

Comment: @dfd ok gotcha I misread your intention there. Sorry. Gimme a sec to respond again

Comment: @dfd Once again, my apologies. I didn't expect the irony. Overall, I feel I would like to step to the side and say I sympathize with this CEO. At the end of the day we are all humans who just want comfortable lives, to live a healthy and fun existence and see our children and family thrive. To be thrust into the position of being the CEO of a sociotechnological entity hitherto without precedent and have to publicly represent it must be terrifying. I send love and best wishes to this person. But I hope that he realises that it's all different. Growth, money, profit. Vulgar, misplaced ideas

Comment: I can agree, but for one thing - he was hired to do what is happening. He came in knowing the board's agenda (not that I know what it is) and if it wasn't him stepping in, it would be someone else doing *exactly* the same thing. I took an early retirement 4 years ago after working in two places for over 35 years. The second was a place that started out as a local brick'n'mortar business that my dad worked for almost 30 years until he dies in 1980. I started there in 1999 when it was just starting to become global and privately held. Over my 16+ years there? (cont.)

Comment: IT was split - 19 people forced to move 800 miles away because of literally checking of a checkbox on some near-annual "what do you want to be when you grow up" survey. Last year they were bought out by a larger firm snd IT is pretty much gone because that place doesn't use SAP. It was about 10 years ago today the thenCEO talked in terms of doubling sales to be a 2 billion dollar company. This about 2 years after the last local owner from the 1930s passed away and nobody else was around. I have no sympathy for someone probably making 7 figures who was hired to do their job - but do understand.

Comment: @dfd yes, I understand your point of view. Interesting story. I am living, thankfully, in a semi retirement, spending most of my time on reconstruction of a house. My current aim is to learn dry stack walling and do something with the garden, which still looks like a building site. I have noticed that those who end up politicians or CEOs tend to be the types obsessed with bean counting and monetary 'value', sadly missing out on the meditative creative processes in the lifestyle of software or gardening.

Answer (score 30):

Thank you for taking the time to post here.

I have read most of the answers, but I feel there is something missing
– or rather hidden beneath the words.

I'll try to keep the part about me short, but you need some background
in order to get my point.  Unlike most of your users, I was
self-employed and owned a community pharmacy.  Which means that I was
employer, recruiter, controller and customer service -- all in one
person.

In a medium-sized town, you have to make sure that every single one of
your employees and customers trusts you and is pleased with your
services.  Because once you lose their trust, they will leave and
usually take lots of customers with them.  Everybody knows everyone
else, and there is enough competition both employees and customers
could run to.  Thus, I made sure to address every single issue
immediately and in person.

You also run a business and, although you might not be aware of it,
you have got customers: *us*.  You might try to transition to big
companies as your customers.  But even then, you are highly dependent
on your user base.  Employees will only efficiently use tools they
trust in (believe me, I've been through this).  And what is easier than
building trust in a service that you use privately on a daily basis?

But trust has been eroding over the last few months (and possibly much
longer than that):

1. SO is losing (and firing!) premium employees and community members
   almost by the week.  I wonder how you can sleep these
   days.  I only ever lost one premium employee and I didn't sleep
   well *for weeks*, because this can cause a business to spiral
   down, many customers may leave because of that, and you don't
   know how to replace that talent any time soon.
2. SO has re-licensed their content without asking the respective
   licencors (read: us) for their consent.  Not only that, the licencors
   weren't even notified of the change.  There was no real dialogue,
   too, at least I only read "company speech".  This caused more users
   to leave or consider leaving.
3. SO has instituted a new code of conduct and lost several high-level
   users over it.  Again, I initially saw no real dialogue.

> In our case, it is critical that we work closely with our community
>   to listen, change, and evolve rapidly.

So very true.  But in order to start a dialogue, you do not only have
to listen, you also have to answer, to explain your vision and fight
for it, and to *give in*. That is the only way to gain trust and keep
your user base.  Wherein, as I said before, are your customers.  The
people you want to (and are allowed to) make money from.

> In 2019, [...] over 1.7 million new users join[ed] the community.
>   [...] now over 150,000 people sign up for a Stack Overflow account
>   each month.

Pure numbers just don't count.  Many merchants measure success on the
amount of user accounts.  Which is flawed.  You have to measure the
accounts of users *which actually buy at your place*.  In terms of SO,
measure the number of accounts that actually contribute content.  That
earn at least, say, a hundred reputation per quarter.  Although I
obviously don't know the numbers, you might be in for a surprise.

In addition, you might overrate the value of new users.  I have
recently started reviewing posts of new contributors.  Most of them do
not seem to bother reading the "How to Ask" page and simply drop lots
of code with a sketchy question.  Do you expect these users to come
back after their question has been solved, and add value by giving
high-quality answers to other users' questions?  Not to mention the
time they take off a scarce resource, your moderators.

Which brings me to another business truth: [Pareto's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle).  You earn
most of your money from a very tiny number of customers: your
high-profile users (and moderators).  Which, unfortunately, are the
ones you are currently losing by the week.

> Visionary companies are guided by a mission, not just a sustainable
>   business model, [...]

You are quite right.  However, I find neither vision nor mission in
your blog post.

Finding and living a vision is important, but before you do so, you
need to realize that your ship has rammed an iceberg.  Go below, have
a good look at the leak, and, most importantly, do not oversee others
in trying to fix it.  *Help them fix it with your own hands!* There is
no other way to build trust with employees and your customers.

Thanks for listening.  I sincerely hope that you will do well!

Comment: Interesting post that addresses a point I was also thinking about recently.  We're somewhere in between customers and product, surely?  You make some very good points though.  Incidentally, that's why I like being a customer of businesses that are based in small towns!

Comment: We're unpaid volunteers. You can boss volunteers around (or ignore them, or talk down to them) like they're paid workers, but since they're not there for any other reason but that they want to help out, they might decide their time is better invested in a more positive environment, elsewhere.

Comment: +1 for the numbers comments - we already have ways of seeing some of that from the badges: 150k users sign up each month, we've awarded 1.5m "Teacher" badges, and 2.4m "Student" badges, and 2.1m "Yearling" badges out of 11m users - so about 13-18% of those uses will contribute in a positive way.

Comment: This iceberg metapher occurs in many answers. I wonder who the iceberg was in this case? Typically it's even larger than the ship.

Comment: My brain just sucked up the iceberg from other answers, so please ask there. :)  Joking aside, I think the Titanic disaster is still very alive in collective memory and has been used as a metaphor for a huge blow. Or, in my case, to create a vivid image for the actions to be taken.

Comment: On second thoughts, most financial boards have enough power to sink a ship. Occasionally, I think that some feel they are larger than the ship (the one they are on board of)...

Answer (score 29):

While I hope that Stack Overflow continues to be a valuable source of information for my life as a software developer, the latest changes make me afraid that it will stop providing the quality that I'm used to.

When I read the post, I get the impression that you focus on the wrong metrics. Metrics that are both bad commercially for Stack Overflow and that are bad for our community. Having a good KPI is very important for a company to succeed.

Instead of caring about new user signup you should care about the number of active community members. A user that signs up, asks one question and then goes away isn't very valuable for our community. If the user however sticks around and becomes an active member, the user learns with time how to contribute in a way that's valuable.

Even if the user sticks around for two months and then leaves there still a lot of potential contribution lost. If you would track monthly active users, you would have a much better metric than tracking new user signups because the metric of monthly active user gives you an important metric. You likely want monthly active users who wrote an answer as an additional metric as there is a good chance that you currently wouldn't notice when that number goes down even through it's very important.

When it comes to metrics it's very important to understand that a lot of the value of Stack Exchange lies in providing already existing content to its users. When you redesigned the question workflow you defined it as task failure when a user gets shown an answer that solves the problem of the user and the user thus doesn't ask his/her question. Given that those cases often result in the question getting closed as a duplicate, which a user might feel as unwelcoming, this is a bad measurement that causes damage.

You got three themes from the loop: (1) question and answer quality, (2) welcomingness and inclusion, and (3) discovery for relevant questions.

Each of those isn't trivial to measure and given the metrics you were public about before, I think there's a good chance that you will make bad actions in all of those areas because of bad metrics if you continue to do things as you are doing. Before deciding on how to measure those variables it would be great if you would be in dialog with us on meta about the best way to measure them.

Comment: Btw. Facebook, Twitter, etc. also all use the number of active users metric. Not sure, why StackOverflow Inc. doesn't talk about it publicly. Surely they calculate it at look at it internally.

Comment: Sorry for the second comment in a row. I would edit the previous one if I could. Actually, the only reason I can think of for the company not telling us how the number of active users developed is that the number of active users has dropped and/or really is very low.

Comment: @Trilarion: If the number of active users has dropped/is really low, even if they do look at it internally from time to time, it doesn't seem to factor into their strategy. If the numbers are dropping they should focus much more on user retention then on welcomness.

Comment: A lot of users are only signing up because they can't ask questions otherwise. If SO allows questions to be asked *without* signup (such as an anonymous user), I bet the new user signups will be down by 50% at least ;-)

Answer (score 27):

### Preface

First let me say I have never posted on Stack Overflow Meta. To be honest I've limited everything I have ever done on SO to technical programming questions and in a limited range of tags. I was one of the ignorant masses when it came to site politics, policies and the like. I just wasn't interested. Not really my cup of tea, so to speak. I never even explored any of the other networks in Stack Exchange.

### A little about me

I have been a programmer of things that could be programmed since I was in grade school. My 5th grade classroom had 2 IBM PET computers. Don't ask me how the little country town I grew up in managed to afford those. To this day I still don't know where they came from, but my fate was sealed the day I first saw them. From there I went on to college and then automated machinery (Allen Bradley PLC's and the like), robotics (I once had a job at Fanuc) and a lot of other things. Fast forward to web technologies (present day). If it could be programmed and someone had a manual and asked me to do it, I did it.

Now I didn't tell you all of this trying to break my arm off patting myself on the back (my profile description still says "dabbler" as the only thing). I told you all of this so that you understand that for my entire adult life, programming things that could be programmed has been my only profession. And I want you to understand that so that you understand where I'm coming from. A place like this did not exist when I was learning my craft and yes I consider myself a craftsman.

### Why I decided to make my first post on Meta as a response to you

I came to SO a little over seven years ago (a co-worker pointed me to the site) to ask two questions. They are the only two questions I have ever asked, but over that seven years I found more answers to questions I had than I can count and after about five years of getting those answers I felt I should contribute back.

So I started answering questions. My reputation went up, privileges were granted, etc... I started reviewing edits and posts and whatever queues and whatnot any new privilege gave me. I did this because I was trying to help keep SO the same place I had found valuable information about my technical issues and questions for five years.

All that changed today because of that little sidebar on the right hand side of the site and link that said "In case you missed it: Shog9 and Robert Cartaino are no longer staff members...". For some unknown reason it piqued my interest and that lead me down the rabbit hole, through a ton of posts, external articles, letters of protest, on and on and on (that's a support group in case you didn't know OnAndOnAnon :), sorry I've stayed up way too long reading all that stuff and I need some sleep). I realized there was a lot going on here that I really had no clue about and that lead me to a link in that same sidebar that lead me here.

About a year or so ago I got a PM from a moderator chastising me for how I might have hurt someone's feelings in a comment I made that was basically chastising a newer user for not following the rules of the site when they posted their question. I wish I knew how to see that PM again, but I can't seem to find it. The comment I made was not out of character for me. It was along the same lines as all the other comments I had made for about four years that had to do with the same issue. Because of that, for a while I even stopped answering questions.

Over those four years I had noticed a steady decline in both the quality of the questions and the quality of the answers in my chosen tags. It seemed to me that in trying to find a quality question to try to provide a quality answer for, I was wading through an ever increasing amount of (not to put too fine a point on it) **garbage**.

I literally spend **hours** doing nothing but flagging garbage posts and downvoting them because it's the only option I'm allowed. GOD FORBID I dare to educate anyone on the rules. If I do that I'm told I'm rude. The last time I checked, blatantly ignoring the rules **anywhere** is rude, but for some reason it's ok for new users to be rude in that way. Today for the first time the light came on as to why that PM was sent to me and why there was some much garbage accumulating at an ever increasing pace. You see until just now I couldn't figure it out.

I was baffled by the fact that the moderators weren't sharpening there proverbial machetes and just brutally and without mercy pruning the endless amount of the "Do you haz teh codez?" questions by people who have no interest really at all in my craft. I read the rules before I asked my first question. I followed the rules when I asked it. And to be quite honest about it, it's been pissing me off. It's kind of like being a teacher at an art school and all of a sudden the majority of "students" are asking why they just can't have a paint by numbers set so they can pass the class. And that finally (mercifully?) brings us to...

### My answer to your question or TLDR; (as the cool kids call it)

> Given the goals of the business as I outlined in my blog post, and given that supporting the Community is a top priority for Stack Overflow, where do you see the network going in the next five years, and what do you think should be done in order to get there?

I'm going to start by telling you a short story. Every startup I have ever worked for followed the same basic pattern you're following now.

- We're so glad you're here.
- We couldn't do this without you.
- We can only afford to pay you peanuts right now. Because of that...
- The hours are flexible.
- There's no dress code.
- If you need a day off, no problem.
- And other stuff...

This all changes to (once they're making a bunch of money):

- We're a **real** company now.
- Here's your handbook.
- In it you'll find the defined hours of work that you can't deviate from.
- The dress code.
- The paid time off policy in which you accumulate some fraction of minutes a week and you can't take any time off until those minuscule minutes add up to at least 4 hours
- And other stuff...
- Oh and don't even think about breaking any of the new rules because just **thinking** about doing that and we'll cut your ass loose in a heartbeat, because we don't need you anymore.

Your business is going exactly where you're trying to take it in the next five years. My guess is by then you'll have privatized the information library to the purchasers of your other products. That library will only be for the "Do you haz teh codez", paint by numbers, new users who are your only real interest now because they will convince their companies to use your products because you nut cupped them here.

Now I understand you can't privatize the existing knowledge base because of the license the answers were generated under and SO will just become a marketing platform to get new customers. Which is basically what it is now from what I can tell. You'll keep SO around for that reason until it's either no longer sustainable or it's just not worth spending any more of your profits from you other ventures on.

Then I wouldn't be surprised if you just shut this whole thing off. At that point your end goal will be achieved. You'll have proven out the technology and methodology for your sparkling new, privatized, customers only, information library. The one crucial point you're missing from the startup analogy: Almost your entire library of knowledge was generated by unpaid volunteers. It was looked after, nurtured and grown by **unpaid volunteers**. Like me.

> because we don't need you anymore

It's not like the startup in that one important part. You can't find a bunch of knowledgeable people, who are educated in their craft and just hire them to volunteer for free and take abuse from you, your staff and your potential new customers (err I mean "users") at the same time. WTF are you thinking? Your only course of action as far as I can see at this point, I already outlined for you and you were already trying to go there.

> Oh and don't even think about breaking any of the new rules because just **thinking** about doing that and we'll cut your ass loose in a heartbeat, because we don't need you anymore.

Yeah I read all about the Monica fiasco. And at this point I'm done with this post. If you noticed my tone got abrasive at the end it's because **I'm an unpaid volunteer**. Who has only asked two questions in a little over seven years, so I really don't care if my account gets suspended at this point because I might have hurt someones little feelings. I can still browse for answers. Though as I have seen, those gems of answers are getting further and further apart. Thank god for search engines indexing your site for you. I know right?

/rant -off

Comment: well the search engines aren't indexing it the way they used to. Not since Google deemed the site a forum.... *hmmmm*

Comment: o'rly? I did not know that. No wonder my tops hits don't hit here at the rate they used to when I go searching.

Comment: exactly - a huge difference. I found this post, cos you posted under my post.. I'm opposite to you - been a meta poster for a looong time.. I'm taking more of a back seat on meta. I cannot effect any change - the business will do what the business chooses.

Answer (score 26):

First of all, thank you for asking for feedback. That's actually really refreshing. Here are some of my thoughts on the blog post. Please read what I'm about to say and take it to heart.

> In 2020, in order to continue to fuel our growth, we’re expanding and diversifying company leadership.

By diversifying, do you mean firing the members of your staff most well-loved by the community you intend to grow? Because that's what it kind of feels like to us.

I'm all for bringing in new talent. But you shouldn't discount the experience your older, more experienced CMs. Forget community morale for a second: you lose that experience permanently. If there was anyway you could have benefited from both, you should have went for it. And you probably should have given the community more warning if you still felt these staff members needed to go. Give us time to say goodbye before they're gone.

> As we look forward to 2020, we plan to invest in public Q&A, expand our community, and continue to cement our place as a pillar of the software industry and broader knowledge economy.

I hope you do invest in us. I want to keep investing into you. But to do that, you have to stop undermining yourself. SO is already down several moderators. The network at large is down even more. Don't get rid of your most talented people. That's just a recipe for disaster.

> The work we do would not be possible without the contributions of our incredible community.

That's very true. After everything that has happened with Monica, Robert, and Shog, not to mention other things like hot meta posts and the license change, the community trusts you significantly less now than it did before.

Do yourself (and us) a favor: rebuild that trust. Focus on that more than "growth." Because if you don't, you won't grow at all, you will die. The community which made Stack Overflow what it is will walk away in disgust.

Here are some ways you can help rebuild trust:

1. Don't fire anybody

Like seriously, unless they are robbing you blind or something, don't fire anyone you don't have to. Anyone else that gets fired will now just look like you care even less about us than before. So don't.

If you still have to fire someone for some reason, then see number 2...

2. Be more open and transparent about what happened

If you had said, "Here's what Monica did, so we fired her," the blow back would have been significantly less. Would people still have disagreed with you? Maybe. But at least we would hear both sides be able to make our own decisions. The way you did it just made it feel like you were hiding something--regardless if you were or not. That's just how it looked.

3. Tell us in advance you're changing something.

Don't inform us of a change you already made: tell us what you're thinking and why. And let us tell you why we agree or disagree. Most importantly, listen to people who disagree with you. It won't hurt to listen, even if only for a little bit. And hey, you might even change your mind once in a while.

4. Let us hear it from you.

If anything, this at least let's you control the narrative. Information doesn't come from various sources and leave us to jump to conclusions.

More importantly, it lets us know that you care about us. It shows you cared enough to let us know. Sometimes, that's all we would even ask.

Don't let us hear about it in the press. That undermines whatever sense of community you have left.

Answer (score 26):

Dear Prashanth Chandrasekar,

Thanks for sharing your thoughts and ideas in this recent blog post and also for advertising it here on Meta and asking for feedback. I worry about some things you said, so I feel compelled to tell you what possibly could go wrong, especially with the public Q&A.

I see that you focus on quantitative growth, but that unfortunately might sacrifice quality of the public Q&A. For example, from the 18 million questions on Stack Overflow only 8 million have a positive score and looking at more detailed statistics than were presented in your blog post, one sees that most of the new questions added in 2019 don't have a positive score. As it happens often, quality is not distributed equally. Most of the views and visits are concentrated on a minority of items. The danger by just reporting quantities of new questions without weighing them by their quality at the same time is that you may not be aware if the quantitative growth is actually accompanied by a qualitative decline. How much knowledge was really generated in 2019?

I think that the quality is steadily declining and that this is a big problem, but the easiest way to detect for yourself would be to take 1-2 hours of your time and try to use the public Q&A on Stack Overflow especially to answer questions. You will see that many questions are missing vital information or are duplicates of questions already asked and answered. Even questions that are perfect fits are suffering, because it's so difficult to locate them first, similarly to finding the needle in the haystack problem. Don't just believe me, but try for yourself and you'll see how desperate the situation has become.

The expectations of users are not compatible with what the experts answering questions can actually achieve. Teaching beginners by just letting them ask anything is not an efficient approach and won't work. As a supporting element it's fine, especially to improve existing skills, but otherwise we will end up with an ever growing collection of not very useful questions. Not sure there is much value in it. You may run out of volunteers, especially from the answers side. Don't encourage users to ask more questions; encourage them to ask more good questions instead. It's a small, but very important difference.

As you said, the number of unwelcoming comments has been cut into half, estimated by some more or less reliable measure, so I think that missing welcomeness may be less of an urgent problem in the future while quality of contributions may become more so. I like to see Stack Overflow as quality public Q&A and I think that makes most of the difference to other such services. People value quality and increasing the quality of the content would be a big achievement.

The other issue is the development speed of the public Q&A software. There are so many feature requests on Meta over the years, which have not yet been processed fully. I hope that the number of engineers working on it can be increased in the future, because it feels like more could have been implemented. I started looking actively for open source platform alternatives, because they may feature a faster development speed.

All in all, I'm not sure that in five years the public Q&A of Stack Overflow will be in a healthy state anymore. The focus of the company seems to be wrong; it should be on quality of the content and speed of development, but it seems to be on rather secondary issues instead.

I hope you find this helpful. I was a bit disappointed by the rather short paragraph about "We acknowledge these issues, apologize for our mistakes..", which I think could have deserved a bit more time and space than just a single short line. I don't even know exactly which issues you meant or what mistakes. In the last months I lost trust in the company and this short statement was not enough to change that.

I really wish you all the best and good luck and please don't forget to use the service and see for yourself what works and what doesn't.

Comment: For the sake of honesty, re: "because not much has happened in the last years there" <= Yaakov has taken on him to update a lot of them in the past months, on this side there's clearly someone in the company willing to show goodwill. I've no idea if he's doing all the work or just risking the heat of declining,updating the status and answering when something is done.

Comment: @Tensibai Just made a query. From the 4863 non-closed questions tagged feature-request on this meta only 766 have some sort of status. More could be done there. Of course this is a subjective thing.

Comment: @Tensibai Made a list of [1.5k feature-requests](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1186546/feature-requests-with-without-status) without status and score > 10, sorted by score.

Comment: My point was more that something is ongoing, let's have the honesty to recognize it, at least to show Yaakov we appreciate the effort. I understand more could be done and that depends no the leadership decision, but that doesn't mean we have to deny the existing effort after years of no action on this side. That's not fair IMHO

Comment: Thanks for the edit :) (I know that's chatty and not useful, etc. so it will be deleted, but whatever :))

Comment: @Tensibai Your point is good. I appreciate the effort by Yaakov and fully recognize it. To me it feels like more could have been done, that's what I wanted to convey and I made a few edits to make that more clear.

Answer (score 25):

**TL;DR; SE/SO need to stop being a public forum and start being a repository of knowledge like it once was.**

And now the long version, which is vastly more nuanced:

> where do you see the network going in the next five years, and what do
>   you think should be done in order to get there?

## Where to go from here

**Backwards**. Specifically, ditch the effort to reach people *via* making them comfortable. That's not at all the strategy a site such as this one ought to be using. This site, as well as others (like Wikipedia), are community-driven repositories of knowledge, and as such, tasked with building knowledge, not relations or social networks.

SE is *NOT* a forum, it is not a public square. It *has* a related forum and a sister meta site, but it (purposely and deliberately) is **not** a social networking site.

*Inclusion* is not what, in my most humble of opinions, drives people to the SE sites, it's the ***content quality***. And yes, on some of the sites inclusion correlates strongly with content quality (both in questions and in answers). And for those sites (specifically!) it might be a good idea to treat the perceived inclusivity of a question/answer as a quality marker.

But on all the rest of the sites, the vast majority of them, it is absolutely not required, and perceived by the community as an authoritarian imposition, as it has in the last months.

## How to get there

Again, by moving backwards, not forward. You can not make up for a wrong turn by just plotting an entirely new destination. Go back, get on the track you were supposed to get in the first place, and move from there. And please, once we start moving forward again, do not dispense with the best and most abundant resource you have: ***us, your community***

Answer (score 23):

I strongly agree with the many comments already posted about the loss of quality on the site and the feelings of betrayal. I'd like to put a slightly different spin on it though. Most people are lamenting the loss of talent and usefulness of the site. That's certainly lamentable, but what I think most of us are also feeling, but not necessarily stating, is that the community has a deep mistrust of the company's ethical integrity.

Firings, mistreatment of individuals of high standing, arbitrary and poorly articulated policies, censorship, legalese, lack of transparency, lack of acknowledgement of moral lapses, lack of appreciation of admirable members of the community and their deep contributions, disingenuous promises to address corruption, etc., etc. It all has the sordid tone of a petty dictatorship. But there's a big difference between SE and a dictatorship: we aren't your subjects and we'll go elsewhere if you don't reform.

More legalese, more empty promises, more fake "explanations" of the obvious abuses, more poorly thought-out policies, and the like aren't going to win back trust. You need to commit to, and enforce, transparent rules that will ensure fair, open, and equal discussion.

Your organization has a kind of moral cancer, and your recent response has been quite counterproductive: denial, surgically removing the healthiest tissue, and protecting the diseased tissue. Above all, you need to show decisive leadership by removing -- yes, firing -- the most corrupt employees -- you know who they are -- and embracing the most exemplary. I would treat this issue with the urgency it demands.

Comment: "*what I think most of us are also feeling, but not necessarily stating, is that the community has a deep mistrust of the company's ethical integrity.*" I'm not sure why you think it's unstated. I thought this was pretty well described by now. Every one of the moderator step downs has in some fashion talked about *exactly* that issue. It's been a hot topic around various Metas for the last four months. Enough that you could just reap free rep on Meta.SE by just posting any decent critique. It's not unfeasable for somebody to have gotten to 10k rep by just by doing that.

Comment: _Your organization has a kind of moral cancer, and your recent response has been quite counterproductive: denial, surgically removing the healthiest tissue, and protecting the diseased tissue. Above all, you need to show decisive leadership by removing -- yes, firing -- the most corrupt employees -- you know who they are -- and embracing the most exemplary._ Very well put. But it takes genuine courage to support unpaid volunteers over and above paid employees. [1/2]

Comment: I have seen no small number of situations (outside Stack Overflow) where those who are on a paycheque are supported (no matter how poor their judgement is) and those who give up their time for free are derided and dismissed (no matter how good their judgement is). [2/2]

Comment: Re *"corruption"* and *"corrupt employees"*: What do you mean by *"corruption"* (not a rhetorical question)? Can you elaborate?

Comment: In any case, we don't know about the power dynamics inside Stack Exchange. It could very well be some vice president that we have never heard of in public that is pulling the strings in all of this.

Answer (score 22):

As a relatively new but motivated user, I will share my thoughts on this new development and the blog posts as well, and hopefully share some insights not otherwise considered:

I have been following the recent developments and especially the whole situation about the moderator shifts mostly from the sidelines. Mostly because I joined when it literally was in full swing, and I didn't come here for "Drama" so to speak, I came here to code. But when reading more on Meta and reading about the situation and opinions from different people my viewpoint shifted quite rapidly from "I don't really care." to "What cesspit have I stumbled on here and what do I think about it?" and finally to "Have I really made a good decision by joining SE and investing my time to become an active user? Or **have I wasted my time joining a crumbling community not long for this world?**".

The latter mostly because the community seems to present a solid case about what is going on not being right, and the company does not seem to listen. I'm not saying I fully agree with one side or the other, I've not been around long enough and have no way to know all the things in play yet. This would make me far from the leading authority on opinions about the subject. But at first glance it is very obvious that there is a massive rift between the company and its community.

This is why **I am generally very positive about this message from the new CEO**. From the blog post, it seems he is aware of the issues going on (although it seems impossible not to be), and he is willing to work on them. The areas touched in this blog post suggest to me that suggestions like [this brilliant answer by George Stocker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390495/11936678) (amongst others) have been read and taken into consideration.

Now I cannot comment on how much of this is corporate happy speech, and how much is genuine willingness to move forward together with the community. But it seems like it is understood that the site cannot go forward by alienating its community, and this is acknowledged and there seems willingness to improve. The promise of transparency (like the [Through the Loop](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/) initiative), *if delivered upon*, would be a good step in the right direction.

**Only one thing I noticed I am *very* sceptic about**. The following passage from the blog:

> In the fourth quarter of 2019, we created a large task force made up of passionate community advocates from across the company to propose solutions to this core problem.

This suggests this has been done while the rift was getting bigger by the day, and has me wonder if the right choices have been made. Especially since there seemed to be two camps at the time (and even now) and it would be **an easy pitfall to only pick people from the camp you agree with to represent the whole community**. This is absolutely wrong for obvious reasons, and therefore you should consider revisiting this, and probably **give the community a vote in who represents them**.

*Edit:*

Another suggestion I would make is based upon these statements:

> and December was our best month ever for new user signups!

and

> We want to serve all of the millions of people who use Stack Overflow, not just those who know the most about how the site has worked in the past

While this is nice, it is important (as stated by many wiser users than myself) to listen to every slice of the community. The new users are important, as are non-users trying to join, but I see almost an alienation of **your most important and valuable asset: SO veterans**. Even though they might represent the SO of a time gone by, and their opinion might seem outdated to you, these often highly knowledgeable users should (in my opinion) have a more hefty voice when new changes are considered, as they (almost literally) hold the future of this site in the palm of their hand. It should be obvious to you why this is, which is why I don't think I need to elaborate on this any further. **Listen to them, and whatever you do, don't alienate them in favour of new users or investors.** Or it might cost you dearly.

Comment: Just as an addition, the statistics presented does not give a complete picture. Large number of signups could be accompanied by equally large numbers of leaves, the net inflow is important,  even more specific the activity and even more specific the valuable activity. It's not clear how important a high number of signups really is.

Answer (score 22):

> where do you see the network going in the next five years?
>    what do you think should be done in order to get there?

As a long-term volunteer who has contributed to the site for almost 10 years and seen all ups and downs, there is no way for me to give a constructive answer to this. Sorry, but it is too late.

I don't see how the network will survive even one year. If the recent rumours about merging sites are true, it rather seems it will be dead within a few months. Even though the SO site specifically will probably live on as a bleak Quora-like ghost for some years yet.

The damage to what's left of the so-called community is extensive. The damage in trust of the company is irreparable. The company let the situation escalate too far many months back. Firing the only people that your customers still trusted somewhat is not exactly helping.

The only reason I'm still around is that open source alternatives are not yet launched. As soon as they are, I will permanently leave the network and never look back. There is no longer anything you can do to prevent this. Nor do I believe that there is anything you can do to prevent the eventual collapse of the network and SO.

I already stopped using your commercial products (job advertising) long before the many disastrous events of the past year, because the quality of the site and trust in the company has already been in slow decline for many years. In 2019 it went from slow decline to rapid destruction.

Comment: i mean, the "rumor" as you describe it has already been responded to by staff as not what they're doing. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342646/merging-technical-sites-with-stack-overflow#comment1147281_342646

Comment: @KevinB Okay. I still don't believe it will make it one year.

Comment: @KevinB considering that comments have always been considered second class citizens, I don't think saying "this has been responded to" and linking to a comment is *really* as effective way to say "you've not done research on this". If staff want to stop rumours, they can communicate properly and not in comments. Yes, they've not had to before but I'm not sure they deserve leeway any more especially when improving communication is (apparently) on their ToDo list. As it has been for a few years, I might add.

Comment: (While I fully agree your post) Afaik not we are the customers of the company, at least not in their view. In their view, people buying ads, teams and developer CVs are their customers. We are not customers, we are volunteer contributors in the best case, but more realistically: aggregated stats.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica And what makes you think I wasn't buying any of that? Specifically, it was job adverts. Huge waste of money since candidate matching was non-existent. Most importantly: there exists no magic unknown companies that haven't heard to SO for 10 years and suddenly pops up out of the blue want to buy the products. Those who were willing to do that were 100% existing users.

Comment: Also there is nothing to agree or disagree with here. This is just a personal message from a leaving user/customer to Pchandrasekar, who was not around when the chain of destruction started. If it wasn't already obvious, someone needs to tell him he's been appointed as Captain to Titanic and that there's a slight iceberg problem in the keel.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, SO makes the hits, and attracts the visitors to paid products. So should it happen, if I understand their logic, this is what they are trying to optimize, only they are doing it on a psychotic Big Company way (while they are a medium company).

Answer (score 19):

Can you give more details about this claim?

> we cut the number of negative comments nearly in half

Is this year over year, or October vs December?  Across all stacks and metas, or just SO?

To what do you attribute the reduced negativity?  Do you expect this trend to continue?

Comment: the #'s are also important... considering the stats they gave originally on what the percentage was of negative comments vs good ones.. cutting that number in half isn't all that crazy. Making the flag icon more visible alone likely attributed to most of that.

Comment: It would have also been nice if "negative comment" was given a definition,  I suspect it includes "what have you tried?" which many dont see as negative but just got tired of asking

Comment: AI-driven comment flagging was introduced; us moderators were given a new queue with automatic flags for comments that are possibly unkind. As AI-sentiment detection goes, it’s not bad and we do catch more issues earlier because of these.

Comment: I see that this means that negative comments were removed more quickly, not that people stopped posting them, which was part of my question. Interesting to hear about the new AI!  Thanks for your response @MartijnPieters.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But did moderators delete more comments per user per time or less with the new queue? Is the number of surviving comments meant or the number of deleted comments that is cut in half?

Comment: @Trilarion I don’t know, sorry

Comment: I found two initial blog posts, where Julia Silge describes the methodology. See [Classifying Comments on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/07/10/welcome-wagon-classifying-comments-on-stack-overflow/) and [Community and Comments on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/12/04/welcome-wagon-community-and-comments-on-stack-overflow/) and they even wanted to publish the data "in 2019 we will release this dataset upon request so that other people in our community and beyond can explore this data for themselves".

Answer (score 19):

**ICEBERG!!**

Since autumn 2019, Stack Overflow very much conveys the impression that it is concerned chiefly with **quantity** and rather less with **quality**.

The impression may be wrong, but if it is right, we can speculate this might be because **quantity** translates rather more easily into quantifiable numbers like: **KPIs** and **margin**.

But the community *isn't here* for **margin**. You won't be able to tell me any point in the last 12 years when it has been. Because it *never has been*. The community is here for **quality**.

Try to understand what incentivises the community to stay and what might, if removed (and, yes, some of it has already been removed, perhaps irrevocably) mean the community is incentivised to go elsewhere.

Above all, understand this, because I'm sure I'm not alone: I don't answer questions on Stack Overflow to help those with a paycheque from Stack Overflow. I answer questions to help people who have problems which they need to solve. Why? Because I'm *paying it forward*.

In the last 8 years, no small number of community members on Stack Overflow have helped me out of their own free time and good nature. I want to help others, just as others have helped me.

The fact that Stack Overflow (in terms of an organisation) is now seeking to become more like Yahoo! Answers and less like Wikipedia isn't enamouring to me.

Please *change course* if you value the community. If you don't, by all means, full steam ahead to the iceberg.

Comment: Not since autumn 2019, it has started at least in March 2018, some would argue the shift goes back to 2015, it has badly accelerated on this way late 2019 that said.

Comment: Sure. To be fair, I've only noticed it since September 2019, but I recognise that many members at Stack Overflow have observed trends going back way further.

Comment: Overall I totally agree with your post, just wished to give a sense there was already bad signs before the fiasco of September 2019 :)

Comment: [Titanic was on fire even before it left Belfast](https://www.history101.com/discovered-photo-album-reveals-the-real-reason-why-the-titanic-sank/10/) for Southhampton (near *"from the day we sailed"*). That likely contributed to the full steam ahead into the iceberg (low on coal).

Answer (score 17):

> what do you think should be done in order to get there?

This may be a bit finer-grained than you were looking for, but...

In a response to an [Answer by Script47](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393167) you write

> we do not believe that welcoming, teaching, and empowering new
>   generations of beginners is mutually exclusive with building a quality
>   archive.

**Summary**: If this kind of thing should be integrated into Stack Overflow (Main) it would be helpful to have some way of distinguishing the "level" of a question. Were this not possible, mixing beginners' issues with questions from experienced developers could alienate professional contributors who desire to work at a more advanced level of their expertise. Losing such contributers would, in the long run, have a negative impact on the site's reputation, perhaps irrecoverably.

**Previous attempts to accomodate more basic issues in SO Main**:

- **branch off a "beginners'" site**: This community suggestion did not meet with a positive response from the company. Advantages to having such a site would have been: 1) People who want to answer those kinds of questions would know going in what to expect. 2) it would be easier for others who are not (yet) experts to help the absolute beginners - both sides would learn.
- **[SO Documentation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/07/21/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/)**: An attempt to provide information on how to do things and supplement/improve confusing software manufacturers' documentation. It [failed and was abandoned](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/07/21/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/) for a combination of reasons.
- **[Mentoring program](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357198/mentorship-research-project-results-wrap-up)**: This was basically successful in its approach, but did not scale for the site.

**Proposal**: If everything is going to be "lumped together" on SO, I believe those contributing answers would profit by being able to identify at a glance (a tag, for instance) in the question lists, questions that are very basic. (And also be able to filter for them.) If they feel like guiding someone at that level, they have the choice of looking at it; if not, they can skip by it rather than spending ("wasting") time looking at it, feeling annoyed/frustrated, downvoting, voting to close... and making the OP feel "unwelcome". People who want to work at a more basic or educational level would also be able to better target questions they can answer.

**Implementation**: Of course, someone has to make that first judgement about whether a question is "basic" or not. A first opportunity would be allowing the OP to check a box when posting the question if they realize they have minimal (or no) experience.

After that, perhaps a checkbox only visible to people with a given amount of reputation (perhaps rep in a tag on the question) so that the first person with enough experience who comes across it can categorize it.

**Conclusion**: Personally, I have nothing against teaching/mentoring people new to the programming environment I support. I do what I can, given the restraints imposed by the site, as well as my time. When questioners truly have *no idea* (and it happens!) it requires a certain mind-set to deal with their issues as opposed to more professionally presented and "interesting" problems. Not everyone can access this mind-set, and those who are able can't always manage to do so.

Just as using tags to identify technologies help us work more efficiently, a way to identify whether or not a question is "basic" would help.

Comment: This isn’t going to work, sorry. What is “basic” to some is too advanced for some beginners, and people are notoriously *bad* at judging their skill levels. What will happen instead is that a high level of bickering will take place over what “tier” questions go in to, and less scrupulous question askers trying to bump their question to the “difficult” tier so they can get “better answers” from experts that are “obviously filtering out our questions”. And experts *will* be filtering in the hopes of avoiding dross but then get angry at askers misclassifying. This already happens with tagging!

Comment: And what does “no experience” even mean? I have no experience in programming in Scala. But I do know programming (I better, I’ve been at this for decades now), so the kinds of questions I would ask about Scala are going to be vastly different from a junior dev fresh out of a web stack bootcamp and different again from a teenager learning to code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's difficult to judge a single question, but after a couple of contributions this task might get easier, maybe averaging over what different people thought about different contributions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I posted a question to english.stackexchange.com and also noted that I “have a Russian-language background but have been living in Australia for more than 25 years”. And the question was moved to English Learners site https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/228470/what-are-the-correct-pronouns-for-referring-to-someone-whom-i-have-never-met-in. The same could work for “Programming Learners”

Comment: @MartijnPieters Another comment reminded me of this, on which I've done some ruminating in the meantime. One possibility would be to present someone asking in a tag for the first time (or with no rep in it) who does *not* choose "basic knowledge" with a test that covers very basic knowledge such as conditional, looping or whatever would be appropriate for the language. The test would have to be dynamic to a certain extent, of course, so that no one can simply publish the answers somewhere. Don't pass the test, it's automatically marked as "basic level".

Answer (score 15):

Up until recently I thought Stack Overflow was amazing. You held the [Amazing 2018 Stuff-A-Way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321399/announcing-our-amazing-2018-stuff-a-way/321926#321926) and that was super cool, especially when you actually sent me a Stack Overflow t-shirt.

Then everything fell apart. And rather than try to fix the situation it seemed like the company just ignored it. Even in your post here you don't really address any of the issues that are really bothering people, especially Monica's firing and continuing non-reinstatement. (And no, I don't accept the answer everyone is saying that they already reached a legal settlement. Monica should be reinstated, even if she is no longer interested in participating.)

I think you should be especially concerned that there are at least two new open source Stack Overflow competitors that are in development. That doesn't seem to bode well for Stack Overflow's future.

My first practical word of advice for you would be for the company to return to its roots and redouble investment in the community. The only difference between Stack Overflow and every other programming site out there is the community. Without the community the site will flounder, and new competitors will benefit from the exodus.

My second word of advice would be to focus on making Stack Overflow actually better. I don't want to make any specific suggestions since that will probably polarize people reading this answer :-) However I don't think that the core functionality of Stack Overflow has improved since I started using it years ago. If you focus on improving the product you will retain users and retain your market share.

Best of luck!

Comment: Interesting! Incidentally, I threw away my t-shirt last month.

Comment: Yes, innovation is overdue.

Comment: I never got my stuff from the 2018 stuff-a-way, sadly.

Answer (score 15):

## Can you spot the problems with just this post alone?

(To make it easier, I've outlined them in red.)

[image]

---

[image]

Stack Overflow isn't going anywhere. It's time to throw in the towel.

In the off chance you really care, what will **you** do to prove you deserve to run Stack Overflow? Our trust in the management is near zero - what credentials do you have? What leadership experience do you have? How do we know this wasn't just a massive money/power play?

Comment: "How do we know this wasn't just a massive money/power play?" Time will tell. There is surely enough inertia in the public Q&A, that it will go on for quite some time, even without trust of the core users. We will see if the decline can be turned around. We cannot really blame the new CEO for things that happened before he took the job. On the other hand, I have no idea why this post is locked. Moderators presumably wanted to protect the CEO from too much criticism.

Comment: I'm not so sure. This could also be a way of insuring that the discussion is based around specific answers instead of resulting in a huge number of comments in the question.  But I concede that locking a question of the new CEO certainly looks bad.

Answer (score 15):

Do you have any response to (and plans to address) [the various problems plaguing SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342950/296857)

I know majority of those issues are before you came onboard and your question isn't really about the *past* but future... But if someone abuses their partner for *months*, if not years, and then suddenly one morning asks "so where are we going for holiday this summer?" then I bet the conversation isn't going to be about Maldives or Hawaii.

Besides, all the issues comprehensively put together by Monica in that post are *still* current and valid. As the CEO, you ought to address them (Just saying "supporting the Community is a top priority for Stack Overflow" doesn't really wash it without **evidence** given everything that's been going on for a while).

Answer (score 12):

I don't know how useful the thoughts of a very new user are, but here goes. I've used SO as a developer for about 5 years, but only in the past few weeks have I decided start trying to contribute back. I've generally been focusing on unanswered questions from new users, since I am myself inexperienced at answering. I've done my best to teach new users the best practices of SO question asking.

My impression is that SO, in addition to its normal usage for professional developers, is becoming a place where **non-programmers learn to program**. Because of this, there's constantly "my code doesn't work" questions that boil down to the same core concepts, adding a burden onto established users who need to mark them as duplicates (even though they earn no rep for doing so...).

My understanding of the question-asking process is that it's supposed to make the asker learn the process of solving their own problems, for example by requiring a minimal reproducible case. I wonder if we could make this better by creating a **list of core programming habits** we want new programmers to learn, and part of the process of asking a question instructs you to read this list.

For example, for the `c` tag it might be:

- Always initialise your variables
- Always check return values of functions
- etc.

with links to appropriate SO questions that explain in more detail. This way, we can help many new developers **learn best practices before they need to ask about them**.

Comment: Why do you think new askers will bother looking through a list of frequently asked questions? Real help vampires are only interested in resolving their problem as quickly as possible, and presume someone on Stack Overflow will be willing to do it for them. And IMO, to the extent that the asker is not a help vampire and doesn't presume this, they will already have searched online for resources with precisely this kind of information before clicking on the "Ask a Question" button.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Those are both fair points, although I think it would be helpful for some people. I guess I was thinking of them more like a small list of "coding standards", rather than a list of faqs. Having a small list would make the closing process easier. Rather than needing to go find an appropriate dupe, I could just say "Your problem would have been solved by Best Practice #3" and close the question.

Comment: Q&A is somehow not the best for learning how to debug. Learning how to debug means not giving the answers right away but given people the means to find the answers for themselves.

Comment: Re *"there's constantly "my code doesn't work" questions that boil down to the same core concepts"*: The artifact from this ought to be (real) [FAQs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAQ), but the current model is not good at producing them. This worked really well in the Usenet days before the AOL catastrophe and I don't see why it shouldn't work today. There are some of this in some tag wikis, but tag wiki content is way too hidden from view (difficult to discover). E.g. until recently the PHP tag wiki had a FAQ section, but [it was wiped out](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3607050/revisions).

Comment: (The [AOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOL) catastrophe = [Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) - AOL effectively destroyed [Usenet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet). This was replaced by equally horrible forums and later [the hyphen site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts-Exchange). Then we got Stack Overflow and all was good for a while.)

Answer (score 11):

I understand and support this:

> We need to expand our reach and engagement to ensure these developers join the conversation and push their own learning to new heights.

In the mix product development, marketing, communication, leadership and community which of those do you expect to contribute most over the next years to reach your goal?

Answer (score 10):

I have limited experience both in life and on Stack Overflow, but on the off chance it will prove useful I will offer a small piece of advice.

People can, and will, debate the details for the direction of the site and its counterparts *ad nauseam*. When the members of the community and the company are holding separate debates then divergence between their consensuses is inevitable.

Opacity in this is the antithesis of concord, transparency its architect. Your engagement with the community here is an undeniable positive - if it proves a token occurrence then the divergence between community and company will worsen, if it proves a pattern then the divergence will lessen. Make it a pattern.

Comment: Jeff Atwood posted more than 4k anwers on Meta during his time, on average two per day, every day. This much dedication to make it work with the vocal community cannot be expected from everyone, I guess, but I agree that regular engagement with Meta can only be good.

Comment: Your "limited experience" is quite wise, I shall say.

Comment: @Trilarion I haven't been here long enough to know firsthand but from what I've heard Jeff Atwood set an impressive standard

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Thank you, I hope it proves useful

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange will be going into the trash can, at this rate.

By the sound of it, all of your most important contributors are leaving, since this new CEO was appointed.

Great job. I am not exactly sure what you have been doing, but it's quite the achievement to ruin a perfectly good company this quickly. Universities should make case-studies about this.

And to anyone considering downvoting me for not sugar-coating this, it is what it is.  The situation going on right now is not good and needs to be dealt with in a serious manner.

If you are interested in learning more about these issues, this is one such example.  Although if you search around, there are many more.

*[Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper)*

Comment: When a new CEO comes in and everything breaks, it's sometimes I tactic where after doing all this damage, they'll run off and we'll get a new CEO, who will promise to fix all the mistakes of the old one, without actually changing anything. We're in phase 2 now.

Comment: Virtually all the downward trends in the company's actions vis-a-vis the community have begun a long time before the current CEO was appointed, since 2018, 2015, and even earlier. We can't assign all (or even much) of the blame to the current CEO, even if we want to hold him accountable to fix the current state of affairs.

Comment: @ZevSpitz they've...gotten worse as of late, though. The trend was definitely already there for a long time but not to *this* extent.

Comment: @VLAZ   agreed.  zev spitz's upvoters    are just wanting to keep their heads buried in the sand, and pretend that things unknown things, outside of everyone's control, are to blame, and there is "nothing we can do about it".

Comment: Not quite. It seems to me that without management's active participation, it will be impossible to fix anything, short of moving the entire community to a different environment. Pointing fingers at the new CEO, who (at least in words) has expressed interest in trying to fix things, is IMO simply not useful, whether the blame is deserved or not. Now, you might argue the community has already been buried under an avalanche of nice words and empty promises, but the new CEO is just that -- new -- and I think we need to at least be open to the possibility that he honestly means to change things.

Comment: And no, the most important contributors haven't left. Check the activity of the top 50 folks, and most of those are doing the same things they did a year ago: provide content on main.

Comment: @ZevSpitz " Pointing fingers at the new CEO, who (at least in words) has expressed interest in trying to fix things, is IMO simply not useful" What ever happened to "The buck stops here?" He's the CEO and ultimately responsible for every decision made by any and all employees. This is the end of his 4th month. This: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392867/in-case-you-missed-it-shog9-and-robert-cartaino-are-no-longer-staff-members-at was posted 17 days ago. If we can't point fingers at the person ultimately responsible, then why are we even discussing anything in this post at all?

Comment: @ZevSpitz   stop defending a bad CEO.  I think you really aren't realizing the scope of his role / impact.  everything that is happening is absolutely within the control of a CEO.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your posting of this is done here in MSO, rather than in the [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) seems to indicate that the company focus will steer more towards Stack Overflow and away from the other sites, mostly the non-technical/non-IT-related ones. That, along with talk of [a merger of sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342646/merging-technical-sites-with-stack-overflow), seems to hint at discontinuation for sites in the network.

Is the company going to discontinue, or somehow focus away from the non-technical sites of the network?

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393155/ceos-2020-kickoff-blog-where-do-you-see-stack-overflow-going/393187#comment750847_393160) for MSO vs MSE and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342646/merging-technical-sites-with-stack-overflow#comment1147281_342646) for merging sites.

Comment: i mean, posting it on meta would indicate the opposite, that it cares more about it's small communities rather than the one that "brings home the bacon" so to speak. you can't please everyone.

Comment: @KevinB I believe MSO gets the better treatment because it generates more revenue too. I just want to know whether or not other sites are going to get axed at some point.

Comment: I *reaaaaaaly* doubt that's in any way in consideration at this time.

Comment: @KevinB I would like to have that doubt, but the firing of Robert Cartaino just a few days ago, coupled with this blog post now, seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: That was unfortunate... but i wouldn't jump to such dire conclusions without more evidence.

Comment: Https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393156 seems to have already asked this and gotten an answer from the CEO.

Answer (score -2):

> given that supporting the Community is a top priority for Stack Overflow, where do you see the network going in the next five years, and what do you think should be done in order to get there?

I'd really like to see the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) renovated. You'd like to support the community and I think this would be an awesome way to do it!

Much of the community uses chat. Moderators often have discussions there both with moderators and with regular users, users may move extended conversations to chat, and some people just like to talk with people about a particular language or topic.

Chat has not been updated in years.

- It is still HTML4.

  > `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`
- Many features have ceased to work such as Twitter embeds
- The star board doesn't allow Scrolling
- No dark mode
- Extremely buggy on mobile
- Aesthetically outdated

Nothing builds a community more than giving the community a place to chat. So I ask that you please renovate chat!

Thanks! And welcome aboard!

Comment: Also, certain bots that live in chat are integral to the site proper functioning correctly. An actual chat API would be a nice gift to those hard-working pieces of code.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Really great point. Totally agree.

Comment: Having never used chat, and not seeing a reason to, I don't see this as a priority.

Comment: PorkChat - "Dark theme - a light-on-dark theme with optional fixed-width font" (chrome and Firefox version available).

Comment: @DavidPostill I know those extensions exist however an official dark theme would be nice. Not just for chat but in general.

Comment: @meriton Come join us :)

Comment: A couple more comments on this post and it may have to be moved to chat!

Comment: That would be unfortunate, considering 99% of all comments moved to chat result in an ended conversation

Comment: @KevinB Maybe on StackOverflow, but my experience has been the complete opposite on other network sites.

Comment: The use of chat to hide important comments is not a point in favor of having or improving chat.

Comment: @jscs Regardless of whether you agree with that feature (if not maybe create another meta post), it is showing that chat is used and relevant. That, in it self, is a reason for improving chat.

Comment: There is also [the problem of readability / text size](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFiQPkdb5Qs&lc=UgzzH7ULmytO6-qi8HV4AaABAg&t=38m36s) in chat.

Comment: I couldn't care less about chat being improved. This is a Q&A site: let's focus on doing Q&A the best way we can. Chat works well enough for what it is: an ancillary adjunct to Q&A. I don't want to spend any more developer time on it, short of ensuring it is minimally functional. The mobile chat site works very well for me; I use it more often on mobile than anywhere else.

Answer (score -36):

To resolve the recent moderator dispute I have one suggestion:

Create a *Voice of moderator's council*: A group of five moderators of moderators, elected by moderators. They will manage all other moderator duties like the CoC, removal, election, reinstate (including older disputes).

Benefits:

1. If someone is fired, they will blame these guys/gals, not SE.
2. They will be a buffer layer between SE and moderators.

There should be an option to report an unwelcome flag for a specific moderator, and if a moderator gets more than 100 unwelcome flags, they should be fired.

Comment: Moderators are quitting left and right partly because SE is so utterly unresponsive and unsupportive of them. Yet another buffer layer is _not_ the solution.

Comment: Is this a sarcastic joke?

Comment: This is a very nice idea. Although the members of the mod council will need to have likely CM permissions, too. I think the SE won't do that because it would decrease the power of the internal employee. The meta community voted your suggestion down, because they are evil. These are different problems, your post hit both.

Comment: @Caleb If the mod council could do most things what today needs CMs, yes they could do what the SE currently can't or won't. Although it is a theoretical discourse - Quora, after a similar scandalum, simply fired all the community elected mods, and now all the Quora mods are employee. I suspect, the SE might want some similar - their unresponsivity is effectively a "polite ask" to leave. For all the mods. They only won't say it (yet).