# What does "writing the script of the future" actually mean?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I've been trying to understand Stack Overflow's [new mission statement](https://stackoverflow.com/company):

> Helping write the script of the future by serving developers and technical workers.

I honestly don't know how to interpret the "script of the future" part of this in any meaningful way. Can someone help me?

For starters, "script" is ambiguous: is it short for "scripting language" (Bash, Lisp etc.), or is it short for "manuscript", used metaphorically (like the script of a play, a TV show etc.)?

So I see two possible interpretations:

1. "the script" is a kind of loose synonym of "any programming language", so it means "helping write code in the future". (Which I don't totally get).
2. "the script of the future" is a kind of metaphor for "what happens next in society", so it means "helping build our society's future, by supporting programmers".

If interpretation 2 is correct...why such a weird and flowery turn of phrase? And how is anything that Stack Overflow is doing connected to making a better society, other than simply helping programmers do their job more efficiently? (For instance, I have never come across anything in the SO universe about the kinds of work programmers should be doing, ethics, anything like that.)

How do you interpret it?

*(Please, let's avoid using this as an opportunity to dump more negativity on the company. Let's keep it neutral and analytical.)*

Comment: It means the current SE executives are not happy with futures being initially called promises in Javascript. Therefore, most of the dev efforts will be focused in reimplementing [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) with Rust's [Future trait](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/02_execution/02_future.html), therefore *writing the script of the future* *(of T)*.

Comment: My first impression was that it's a double entendre meant to evoke both of your interpretations.

Comment: It's just a pun. We're writing the script for the future in the play/movie sense, establishing what will or can happen, by writing the script in the code sense.

Comment: Huh. You make that sound so simple and obvious, heh.

Comment: I bet it is explicit switch from "languages" (which surprisingly include a lot of -script ones like *Java*script) to "scripts" - bash, cmd, … maybe even PowerShell but that last one allows languages inline... :)

Comment: The real answer should be that one should not need to interpret a mission. It should be clear or it isn't a mission.

Comment: @Trilarion Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to correctly divine the meaning of the mission.

Comment: @CodyGray Already consulted my tea cup this morning and the pattern of the tea leaves told me everything. My crystal ball later confirmed it. Question can be closed now. Answer is that the motto needs clarity or additional details.

Comment: It is just a slogan invented by non-technical people (who usually earn N times the money earned by the technicians that do all the work) in order to sound cool and to sell something to non-technical customers.

Comment: No, it was invented by Joel Spolsky, who is very technical.

Answer (score 32):

I started doing a bit of research, though I don't think I have a clear answer.

Even tracing the history of the phrase is a bit confusing: Prashanth Chandreskar [claimed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393171/263268) that:

> for a long time we have said that our mission is to "help developers write the script of the future."

Stack Overflow doesn't seem to have, as a company, been saying this publicly in any written form, much further back than about mid 2019, as far as I can see.

However, there are a number of YouTube videos of Joel Spolsky talking, frequently with a title like "Writing the script of the future" or "How to write the script for the future", dating from [this keynote in December 2016](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2016/12/09/developers-are-writing-the-script-for-the-future/).

Digging into one, we see [Spolsky explaining what he means](https://youtu.be/DlFQKPEgDXE?t=715):

> A programmer at Uber can make a change to the user interface of Uber and have much more of an impact on the **future** of the world than the legislators can by trying to pass laws.
> And in fact, all that code that's getting written, and getting run, when it runs, those are actually probably 90% of really the laws in determining how things are gonna work. And sometimes it's very small things and sometimes it's very large things, ...
> In a lot of cases, code is sort of going to define the **future**. By definition, when programmers write a **script**, when they write a line of code, that code will run in the **future**, and because the code that we're running today is so entwined with our lives, it really makes a big impact on the **future** how that thing gets written.

So, confusingly it seems he meant "script" in the "JavaScript" sense, but overall his message is "the code that programmers write is hugely influential on society".

It looks like the transformation of this phrase into a mission statement may have begun with the VP of marketing in 2017. In [this talk (May 2017)](https://vimeo.com/215808321) she says (11:17):

> There are really just three stories that I want everyone at Stack Overflow to tell, all day, every day. One: "Developers are writing the script for the future". There's that Marc Andreessen quote that software is eating the world. Software is everywhere and the world is increasingly dependent on developers. So, people should understand that. That is the way the world is headed. Andreessen-Horowitz's entire investment philosophy is almost based on the fact that everyone one day is going to be a developer.

I don't know that that adds a lot more clarity, but I notice that she says "script **for** the future".

So, I think my understanding is:

- "writing the script of the future" means "the code that [some] developers write now has a big impact on how society functions in the future".
- Therefore, SO is claiming that helping developers write code more efficiently somehow translates into improving society. (I think there is a huge logical disconnect here, since SO makes no attempt to influence *how* that code is written, only that it is done quickly and with less hair-pulling.)
- I think there is a genuine muddied confusion around the two meanings of "script" that has gotten worse as the phrase has journeyed from Spolsky's original keynote through a VP of marketing and now, boosted by the new CEO, to become the company's official mission statement.

(Some time later...) I kind of think what happened here is Joel came up with a cute, somewhat cryptic pun that worked well as a title for talks - because he then has the opportunity to explain it. It became part of internal SO culture somehow. But then a mistake was made in elevating it to marketing slogan, and then finally mission statement. That's just not the place for cryptic, ambiguous language or wordplay. It's the place for clarity, succinctness and precision.

[Update, Feb 2022]

It looks like SO has stopped using this phrase. The phrase at the front of stackoverflow.co is now "Empowering the world to develop technology through collective knowledge."

The phrase was [tweeted in December 2020](https://twitter.com/stackoverflow/status/1334565592167231494) but I don't see it used much after that.

Comment: Clueless folks spewing out key buzz words in hopes to make money.  How clever!

Comment: Nice sleuthing! Just one nitpick about *"since SO makes no attempt to influence __how__ that code is written"* — I'd say SO is precisely about the *"how"* ("How do I do X in Y" being the canonical everyday question here), but we don't influence ***what for*** that code is written (i.e. we don't know and don't influence what business logic the code will fulfil, which is ultimately what's influencing society).

Comment: Yeah, "how" is a bit ambiguous. I mean, SO doesn't generally tell you "while you're implementing this algorithm, also remember to check for sex and racial bias, consider accessibility and protect people's privacy" - it just tries to answer the question you specifically asked. That's the "how" I mean. If the person's question is "how do I make the code faster", sure, *that* how gets addressed.

Comment: Haha, nicely put. SO helps people coding. If the coder is on a path to make the world a bit more horrible, SO helps with that. SO is a tool, a number of degrees removed from how the tool is used.