# Is there any way to get Stack Overflow swag through competitions or challenges or any other way?

Tags: discussion

I am a newcomer with skills in C++ and Java, also holding hands on HackerRank and HackerEarth. Any quick ways to get swags through Stack Overflow or any other sites?

Comment: You get swag at [100k](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291797/2970947). Currently waiting on mine.

Comment: Yes, but if you ever ask an off topic question on stack overflow you're permanaaaaaaaawwwwwwwwwww, too bad.

Comment: @UmeshKumhar It's off-topic on Stack Overflow main because it is _not_ a programming question as defined in the [help]. It's _on-topic_ here at Meta Stack Overflow because it is about Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network. And yes, Stack Overflow _is_ just a Q&A site- A Q&A site _only_ about specific programming problems. The [ask] page tells you what questions you can ask on Stack Overflow. (And no, you can't post on Meta until you have 5 rep. That's by-design and _does not_ mean you can ask questions like this on Stack Overflow main.)

Comment: You were supposed to review what was on and off topic prior to posting your first question.  Guess you cared so little for us that you didn't even pay attention :( Why do you not like us?  We're here to help!

Comment: okk @will nd kemdra

Comment: @Will - That needs to be prefaced to every closure alert section :D

Comment: okk help me to remove this question..??

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes there are contests or giveaways, like the semi-recent 10,000,000 questions give-aways.

- [How Did Stack Overflow Help You?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303988/how-did-stack-overflow-help-you)
- [10 Million Questions - Let's Share Some Stories That the Number Doesn't Convey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey)
- [Choose your own swag - the craziest contest idea ever! What were we thinking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271359/choose-your-own-swag-the-craziest-contest-idea-ever-what-were-we-thinking)

These are not regular, so you have to wait until they are held, and the "6-8 weeks" for delivery is ague-ably not quick (I think I just got my last package from that in the mail today).

Alternately, people who get 100,000 reputation on a site get a box of swag, but that's not a quick feat.

There used to be a swag shop a while back, but not anymore, so the only way you could buy swag would be through another user who is willing to part with theirs.

Comment: I didn't know about the third. Why am I always late to the swag parties?

Answer (score 2):

You can use your skills to post great answers and reach 100K reputation.

According to [Where is my box of Stack Overflow swag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280634/1529630), you will receive an email from SO:

> It's not often I get to reach out and thank someone individually for
>   their contribution to a site, but I wanted to congratulate you
>   personally for reaching 100,000 reputation on Stack Overflow! [...]
>   You've worked hard, and you deserve a lot of credit for what you
>   accomplished. I hope you've found the experience rewarding in your own
>   way. But getting a big ole box of cool stuff from our sites is also a
>   fun way to mark the occasion, so I put together a collection of swag
>   for you.

According to [What do I get with 100k reputation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291791/1529630), that swag is

> One email , a T-Shirt (with stack overflow logo), one coffee cup, few
>   Stack Overflow stickers....and of course six digit rep

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally, there will be special events or contests in which you can get swag. For instance, we had the [10 million question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey) [special event "contests"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303988/how-did-stack-overflow-help-you?lq=1) just a few months ago. (Both of these have ended now, though I'm sure if you wanted to *answer* either question you still could...)

There's also swag awarded for certain achievements on any of the sites. For example, elected moderators receive some swag after being elected, and users that reach a certain reputation level (100k rep) are sent swag.

There's no place where you can *buy* swag, currently, from Stack Overflow Inc. There used to be a swag shop, but it has been shut down.

Contests and special events in which swag is awarded are generally announced on meta, for any given site. Check meta for your sites of choice on occasion, and keep an eye on the "Community Bulletin" (The box with "Featured on Meta" and "Hot Meta Posts" in the right sidebar.) if you're interested- But keep in mind that these don't happen regularly. It may be a good, long while between events/contests on any given site.