# Do users still get the "package" when their rep reaches 100k?

Tags: discussion, reputation, swag

By accident I get to know that user whose rep reached 100k will get a "present package" from Stack Overflow. Also I found the following link:

[What do I get with 100k reputation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291791/what-do-i-get-with-100k-reputation)

My rep hit 100k about a couple months ago. However I haven't received "the email" described in above Q&A. Just come to ask, if the thing mentioned in above answer is still valid?

### update

Today 4th May 2016, I received the package from SO.  So it is proving that the thing is still valid.

[image]

and

[image]

**Thanks SO**

Comment: congrats on the 100K (better late than never) btw :P

Comment: I read your avatar as "Gimme the damn package or I punch you in the face"...

Comment: @TJ  :-D I knew that "A picture is worth a thousand words" .... but I think imagination is more important...lol

Comment: It might take some time after you hit the 100K - you know, 6 to 8 weeks :-)

Comment: I'm doing my best not to make a rude joke about someone giving you their package.  My very best.

Comment: Let's try to reproduce. Please upvote all of my answers so I get 100K and I'll let you know if I get something.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Okay, I am working on that... however I got an exception: `Operation aborted: Not enough answers.` Can you just post more answers?

Comment: @MarounMaroun "let's try to reproduce" jeez, buy a guy a drink first.

Comment: @MarounMaroun So I tried.  But your answers are mostly [tag:java], and an uncollected prejudice instance is causing my mouse to move down about an inch when I try to upvote.  Let me go try some more!

Comment: I dunno, and I never will.

Comment: I did not get the package until I mailed the team. The problem was I opt-out email notifications in my profile and was never notified automatically.

Comment: [Status-norepro] I wish I could even have a chance of getting 100k... :(

Comment: Congrats on the 100k mark, According to my graph I am most likely to get 100k in Anime.SE sooner than here on Stackoverflow I guess, Reason `Not Enough Answers`

Comment: we should be given present on every 10k rep increase :D

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I would love a sticker every 1k rep xD

Comment: @MykAgustin it won't happen I guess. They send per Fedex from US to all over the world. The delivery cost is simply too high, if send to every user every 1k rep... :-)

Comment: @Kent what about on each 10k or atleast reahing first 10k or 20k completion ? because 100k is too much :(

Comment: btw cool stuff,  i would love to have T-Shirt <3

Comment: @Kent or just sell them that would be great to wear or stick around the house or car :)

Comment: Email Received within 24 Hours! :)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Yes, we still process swag requests for users who hit the 100,000 mark and the 250,000 mark. Assuming you have a valid email address on your profile *and* you are opted in to receiving emails from us, you should get an automated email within a week of hitting the reputation threshold. If not, check your spam folder and make sure it didn't end up there.

If you still haven't heard anything after a couple weeks, feel free to send us an email directly at community-support@stackoverflow.com mentioning you hit the threshold, and we'll reply with some instructions for the information we need to process the request.

As far as actually processing them, it is a manual process. The email contains a link to a form that, once submitted, sends all the information to our support queue for processing. There's not really a timeline for how long it'll take to get processed - it's completely dependent on how much other stuff we have to do / what's going on at the time. Sometimes requests get processed within the week, sometimes it takes a couple months.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the process, I think I should try the team@so.com email...

Comment: Gah, not 200k? I'm at 198,577 you gits!

Comment: Just for a point of timely reference, it's been a little over a month since I got the 100K email, and I got an email today that my package is now being processed.

Comment: *"and you are opted in to receiving emails from us"* I see a couple of emails settings in my profile, but which one needs to be checked to get these? I never got one :(

Comment: @FelixKling It should be the "Email chat event reminders, bounty expiration notices, and achievement announcements" setting, as reaching a rep threshold would be considered an achievement.

Comment: Thanks! That one is indeed unchecked in my profile. Email on the way :)

Comment: hmmmm 1ook rep....If Only **712.5 users** upvotes all my answers

Answer (score 33):

TL;DR: I received one a "long" time ago, and I can confirm it was "6 to 8 weeks" after I went over 100k.

---

I cannot check when I first hit the 100k mark, but I received an email from a Stack Overflow employee in September 2014 about it, and it may have taken a couple months before I finally got it... but get it I did.

The process seemed very manual though; but as long as it is still in place... 6 to 8 weeks, you know :)

Comment: According to your fancy [graph](http://stackexchange.com/users/49441/matthieu-m?tab=reputation) - July 5, 2014

Comment: See, only 2 months and a half to be contacted, and another couple months to receive the package :D

Answer (score 27):

It still seems to be a thing. I hit 100k rep three weeks ago (weekend of March 26th-27th) and received an email on Monday the 28th asking for my address to send me stuff. I haven't gotten anything yet, but it hasn't been 6-8 weeks yet :)

Answer (score 22):

Got The Package when I reached my 100k ~6 months ago. As far as I remember, the email arrived within a few days after reaching the threshold.

Comment: Curious. What was in the package?

Comment: @DhruvJoshi: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291791/what-do-i-get-with-100k-reputation

Comment: @DhruvJoshi  check the updated question

Comment: The Tee is same as the one I got last year end for 10 million question celebrations

Answer (score 17):

As far as I know, no. I received no email and no package.

Comment: Curious; is your email address listed on your profile valid?

Comment: Yes; it's also my openid username.

Comment: @CarlNorum Looks like you opted out of emails a while back, and we err on the side of caution. Drop us an email to team@stackoverflow and reference this thread. We'll hook you up ASAP.

Answer (score 4):

**THANK YOU STACKOVERFLOW :)**

[image]

1. Received email within 24 hours!
2. Package delivered to me in 7 days!

Package delivered by DHL Express Shipment.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As of Feb 2017, 100k rep SWAG is still being delivered to happy users such as myself. I passed 100k rep on Stack Overflow on 2/15/2017 and received the ["You're killing it"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/where-is-my-box-of-stack-overflow-swag) email within 24 hours. I filled out the swag form the next morning. I got a shipping notification on 2/22/2017 and FedEx delivered the package on 2/27/2017. Elapsed time between passing 100k rep on Stack Overflow and receiving SWAG: 12 days. Much faster than the 6 to 8 weeks others have quoted. Thanks, Stack Overflow team!

I posted some [pics of my 100k SWAG on Twitter](https://twitter.com/asaph/status/836327844871467008).

Comment: Email Received within 24 Hours in my case as well :)