# Can we have Stack Overflow shop where people can buy stuff using points?

Tags: feature-request

Stack Overflow should have special goodies that people could buy using points like tees, mugs and stickers. All of these goodies should have Stack Overflow on branding on them.

Edit:
I have read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326492/shop-system-reputation-points-buyable-for-real-currency?rq=1). My question only involves giving things like tees, mugs and stickers.

2nd Edit:
I didn't knew Stack Overflow already gives all of the goodies I mention when you reach 100K. That is even better than buying them with points and getting your points deducted. Thanks.

Comment: StackExchange sites are currently free, if they then "sold" merchandise for internet points which you get for free then it would be an unsustainable business, which would probably lead to the site costing money to join i.e a subscription or the site shutting down

Comment: @DanielJames: Not really. I have read that question. I am asking to give stackoverflow branded stuff for promotion and people could buy via points.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint: Makes sense. I got this idea because Quora gives gifits to its top writers every year.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate – the proposed one seems to suggest quite the opposite. This, OTOH, is ... *interesting* ... However, my Inner Cynic says that if "reputation" becomes a real life currency, the panhandling, swindling, racketeering, and counterfeiting we already have to endure will increase beyond control. `#SOCoin` mining, anyone?

Comment: Well, when you reach 100K rep, [they give you a bunch of stuff](/q/291791/5764553). Not sure it would make sense to _consume_ (for lack of a better word) rep, since rep is supposed to be a rough ["measurement of how much much the community trusts you"](/help/whats-reputation). Would using up rep by buying something make the community trust you less?

Comment: I would actually love it if they sold their coffee mugs and shirts and mousepads, etc., again... for real money!

Comment: There used to be a [real store](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store) where you could by branded merchandise.

Comment: @DanielJames That's an inverse of this question; this one is about using internet points to buy real merchandise, not about using real money to buy internet points. Still gonna be the same response, though.

Comment: Giving bounties doesn't make the community trust you less either, but you still lose rep. Wait... that's another question.

Comment: What?  Jon Skeet could empty the shop with back pocket change:(

Comment: @FahadUddin Also, Meta.SE has had several events where you could win swag. I'm not aware of anything active right now, but [this question tells most of the recent events](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272621/318307).

Comment: Why the massive number of downvotes on this?! I could make my own SO Tshirt, make my own stickers, but I would much appreciate if an official store existed so I can indulge _at my own expense_. Why do yo many of you have your panties in a twist. ***I am tired of SO purists!***

Comment: @iamdanchiv: StackOverflow wants to remain annoying. Good luck to them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

StackOverflow already hands out goodies at [specific milestones](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321681/do-users-still-get-the-package-when-their-rep-reaches-100k).

Let's not turn that "something special" into a market, which would only serve to reduce the awesomeness of the swag. It wouldn't be "special" any more.

Comment: The goodies you mentioned are exactly what I asked for in the question (tee, mug, stickers). I didn't know SO already gives these goodies. The reason for asking was to have something like a tee you can wear and have pride of being active in the community.

Comment: @FahadUddin well. Only 94000 reputation points to go. Get cracking :)

Comment: @Gimby: Haha. Very tough to reach there.