# Can we definitely say goodbye to swag?

Tags: support, swag

After reaching 100K reputation last year I got this message:

> Because we are in the process of setting up with a new swag vendor, we are not currently sending out swag. Once we've completed that process, you'll receive an email with instructions on retrieving swag so long as you are still subscribed to the Community Milestones email bucket in your email settings.

<sup>On Fri, 30 Aug 2019</sup>

After more than a year, still nothing...

Should I stop dreaming about wearing the Stack Overflow T-shirt and drinking coffee in the Stack Overflow Mug? Or maybe there is still a little hope.

Comment: I hope you keep dreaming and that your dreams come true :)

Comment: FWIW, I also haven't received my mod swag since Feb 2019 for the same reason, but I still believe they will be back to it, while maybe not the highest priority :)

Comment: Oh yeah, I recall getting the e-mail way back. They invited me to fill a ticket and provide my shipping details. Then all was mum for 3 months. When I reached out and asked I got the response you did. Has it really been that long? Wow.

Comment: I would say, yes... goodbye swags https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341192/will-there-be-an-amazing-2019-stuff-a-way

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341231/replace-the-100k-and-250k-swag-instead-of-just-dropping-it

Comment: That stinks. I'd gladly pay up front for the international shipping costs of the swag...

Comment: I think swag died in 2018: [New swag for Stack Overflow's 10th birthday: wear-ables or desk-ables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314941/232762)

Comment: What do you mean by *"drinking a coffee inside the Stack Overflow Mug"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I was going to ask how they planned to get inside the mug to drink a coffee, but people are creative... ;)

Comment: @HereticMonkey well, I was told that the Mug is a huge one ;)

Comment: @PeterMortensen hm, I meant nothing .. it was for sure a bad french to english translation like I always do. Since your are here, you can probably make it a perfect english sentence :) or let people imagine me inside the mug ... ;)

Comment: I prefer keeping it as it is and imagine you inside the mug, @TemaniAfif :)

Comment: At this point, just pay someone to screen print you a mug or t shirt; Stack Overflow clearly isn't interested in using that application of the trademark anymore, despite people literally begging to throw money at them for such products.

Comment: Swag was [officially declared to be on indefinite hold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341194/377214) in December 2019. That said, hopefully some of the recent $85 million investment can also be put toward swag.

Comment: So I don't have to reach 100k? :( I was hoping I would get a t-shirt for that. I'll stay at 2k.

Comment: I don't think I ever got any message or offer of swag for reaching 100k (in June 2019). I just assumed there were enough people at this reputation level that they no longer considered it worth rewarding that way. This is the first thing I've seen that suggests otherwise.

Comment: @10Rep the physical swag may be out of reach, but it's still good to aim for the delete vote rights which in my eyes is actually far more swaggy. You can't buy that in a webshop!

Comment: @Gimby What delete vote rights? I thought you reached those at 25k! But that was obviously a joke, I will try to reach 100k.

Comment: @10Rep ["only" 10k](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). What you were thinking about is probably to be a [trusted user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), at 20k.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do I get with 100k reputation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291791/what-do-i-get-with-100k-reputation)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We're excited to announce that swag is making a comeback! I just [posted on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/swag-is-coming-back) with more details about it. The short version is yes, swag is back for those who reach the high reputation milestones, for moderators, and for contest winners we've owed swag to. Please check the link for additional information!

Comment: oh Yes! too bad there is no more mug ...

Comment: [Tim Post suggested I should leave a comment here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/where-is-my-box-of-stack-overflow-swag/280637?noredirect=1#comment837280_280637) about my 100k swag which I became eligible for last year. Is these a procedure I should follow or something?

Comment: We will email users who are eligible to receive swag. Based on what you wrote, you'll be hearing from us soon!

Comment: As a brief update to this, I got an email about a month ago asking for my shirt size and address. There was a link to a form which I promptly filled in and submitted. I guess under the current circumstances I should be prepared to wait a few more weeks.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, we're collecting the info and preparing to send it to the warehouse for distribution.

Comment: FWIW [my 100k swag arrived](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411242/874188)