# No email received after filling in "Contact Us" form

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, contact-form

I have reported sites which reproduce Stack Overflow's content a number of times before, but now it looks like the email replies are broken since some time back.

The [*Contact Us* form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=) says "Thank you for contacting the Stack Exchange Team. You should receive an email response shortly." when you submit the form, but this doesn't seem to be happening.

I just reported a site which reproduces Stack Overflow content without attribution, and was reminded by the text above that I should have received an email from the last time I did that, a week or two ago.

Checked the spam folders etc, but nothing.

Looking back through my email history, the last time I received one of these ("Ticket Received - Stack Overflow - Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution - 202001191057426542") was in January 2020 -- I find it unlikely that I would have reported no other sites since then.  But the latest time from which I *know* the email to be missing is from earlier this month or perhaps the last week of last month.

I do receive other email; I have a subscription for posts to a tag I follow, which last arrived mid-March.

Is just the email functionality broken, or does this actually mean that these form submissions are not being received?

Comment: Annoyingly, I would have taken notes to remind myself of what I had reported if I wasn't relying on an email in my inbox with those details "shortly".

Comment: six to eight weeks

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was just me.

Comment: I've never recieved an email like this, but I assumed that was because they handled it and just didn't tell me that it has been handled. I've waited around 3 months and no email yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update**

We have now integrated our contact form directly with Jira to insert tickets with an email the correct way. New tickets coming in through the API integration will start receiving an auto-responder that the ticket was received. This is enabled on Stack Overflow now and will be enabled across the rest of the network within the next weeks.

We have kept a fallback so that if the API fails for any reason, the ticket will not be lost. It will send an email to ourselves like before and will not receive an auto-response, per the details below.

---

About a year ago (maybe a little less, I forget the exact timing), support switched from Freshdesk to Jira. This switch inherently broke the way we process emails which prevents us from being capable of sending out automated "we received your message" emails to users.

How it currently works is we actually send an email to ourselves. The From and To are both *our* email address. This is done to ensure that all messages submitted via the contact form actually reach us, as we can set up a filter within Gmail to never spam-flag an email under those conditions.

With Freshdesk, we could easily just set the Reply-to field on that email and Freshdesk would pull in that email and set the Reporter as such, allowing everything to work correctly and easily contact users.

Jira, however, does not respect the Reply-to field and every ticket we get via the contact form just lands in our queue as from ourselves. Before we reply, we have to manually go create the contact with the user's email address and update the Reporter - a process which can take up to a minute to complete given Jira also caches the list of users in our support portal. Because the Reporter is not set correctly when the ticket comes in, this also prevents an automated response. That message would just be sent to ourselves which is not very helpful.

Because of these hassles, there are a couple of email types we chose to just stop responding to until we have a fix for the issue, as it was considered too time consuming to send the messages. Those include Scraper Reports, Third-Party Requests (things that had nothing to do with us), and Deletion Requests where we performed the deletion immediately and required no follow-up.

Our development team is currently looking into an integration via the Jira API to insert contact form submissions directly into Jira rather than using email as a medium to resolve this issue, as we have determined it to be the only possible way to resolve the issue at hand. This is a considerable undertaking that we did not expect to have to take on when we made the switch to Jira and it has taken some time to investigate. I don't currently have any timeline on when that work might be completed.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Perhaps in the meantime the form should not say there will be a reply, then?

Comment: For the record, I now received a response to another [unrelated form submission](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/where-is-my-box-of-stack-overflow-swag/280637?noredirect=1#comment837682_280637) with some Jira-esque formatting (including some priceless spelling: "Disaable furhther notificaitons")

Comment: Accepted now, but the message I receive is quite useless; it only contains the text "We are confirming that your request has been received. You do not need to reply to this message unless you have further information to add." Would it be possible to include a copy of the original submission so that I don't have to keep a separate text file somewhere (and occasionally guess which ticket number goes with which submission, if I send several in a short time span)?

Comment: @tripleee We've discussed this multiple times in the past and the simple answer is we can't do that. Not everyone submitting requests to the contact form is authenticated and you can type whatever email address you want there. Sending the original message along allows bad actors to utilize our contact form to send messages to any email address unfiltered. We can't be responsible for that.

Comment: I'm all for protecting our inboxes. The question then is whether this single bit of information you can provide is significant and useful enough to warrant sending an email at all. The ultimate inbox protection is no email.

Comment: @tripleee There are many people who feel more satisfied with an email notification that the ticket was created rather than just text on the website saying it was. And it also needs to be turned on for those people who directly email us to confirm the email created a ticket (there's no way to turn it on/off for only certain types of requests). This notification has actually been on for the past year; people who direct emailed were just the only ones who benefited from it due to how tickets made it into the system.

Comment: Re: "*...and will be enabled across the rest of the network within the next weeks.*" - Has this been completed across the network? Or is it still in the works?

Comment: @zcoop98 Yes it has. We experienced no problems and just turned it on network-wide a few days later.

Comment: As vaguely predicted above, this happened today: I reported two distinct sites for violating Stack Overflow's licensing, but only received one reply. Now, which one of my submissions failed, or got ignored?

Comment: Wait, the second one actually arrived, some six hours later, while I was here. Still no idea which is which.