# Is support.stackenterprise.co legitimate? What is it for?

Tags: support, email, copycat-sites, contact-form

I sent a report about a site where Stack Overflow content appears to be reproduced in violation of the license (as suggested in earlier versions of [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-should-i-do); I was not aware that it had changed) and as offered in the "Contact Us" page form.

Shortly after, I received two email messages: The first one a familiar one telling me that a support ticket was created (and, upsettingly, now [ignored as a matter of policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413386/i-reported-a-copycat-site-content-farm-and-was-responded-with-this-may-help-y)) and then, a second one offering me an option to create a new account on https://support.stackenterprise.co/

The latter seems quite suspicious; the logos etc indicate a relationship with Stack Overflow, but these things are easy to copy and paste. There is no option to log in using my Stack Exchange credentials, and the domain name is obviously of the type which phishers and other practitioners of social engineering have been using to fool gullible users in recent years, and correspondingly taught the rest of us to mistrust entirely.

However, because the email arrived at an address which I only use for Stack Overflow, and it seemed obviously related to my recent interaction with the site (and also, because I was in the past [unhappy that there was no way to keep track of what tickets I had submitted already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406802/no-email-received-after-filling-in-contact-us-form#comment852772_406852)) I ultimately went ahead and created a new account on this site.

Only after taking this pioneering small step for one gender-unspecific green tripod avatar, I was able to verify that this site is actually able to display one closed ticket of mine, though establishing this wasn't entirely obvious, partially due to various usability problems.

- The Tickets tab displayed no tickets for me until I realized I have to open a dropdown and select "all tickets" to have it include closed tickets.
- Searching for a ticket by number returns nothing (probably again because this ticket was closed).
- There seems to be no way to rediscover the URL after you close the site, other than find the invitation email and click the activation link again.
- The ticket I submitted includes a link to my profile as I was logged into Stack Overflow when I submitted the ticket. Why isn't this information used to link my accounts, and integrate the site into my profile?

My main question here is: What could be done to integrate this site better with the main site (including, but not limited to, make it look less like a fraud site)?

Comment: It would be nice if earlier tickets of mine could be linked to my account, too. Over the years, I believe I have reported on the order of 30 copycat sites, though probably less than 10 after you switched to Jira.

Comment: Looks legit: https://www.whois.com/whois/stackenterprise.co ... also *"There is no option to log in using my Stack Exchange credentials"* ... did you really intent to use your credentials on a (in your eyes) suspicious site? Isn't that a bit careless?

Comment: Related on MSE: [Did Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange shift from Jira Service Management to something new?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372717/241919)

Comment: "*Over the years, I believe I have reported on the order of 30 copycat sites, though probably less than 10 after you switched to Jira*" as you might have probably heard, [SE is no longer entertaining the request for scrapers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/241919).

Comment: @AndrewT Indeed, I'm linking to a post about that from a parenthetical.

Comment: @Tom Not sure if you are serious. The only detail in the whois record which isn't generic or nondescript is that the organization is identified as Stack Exchange Inc, NY, US; but it's not like it would be hard for a fraudster to convince the registrar to put that there without checking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We did move back to Freshdesk (from Jira) in October and support.stackenterprise.co is the domain we use for that portal.

> The Tickets tab displayed no tickets for me until I realized I have to open a dropdown and select "all tickets" to have it include closed tickets.

There's not a lot that we can do about that. We have very limited control over the design and functionality of the portal. I was able to pull off some pretty amazing things with redesigning it, but those feats quite literally stretched Freshdesk to its limits in customization. I did spend time Friday trying to make that page look nicer, which included changing the message when you have no tickets to look like this:

[image: No tickets matching current filter]

I hoped the word "filter" would help imply that you can fiddle with the dropdowns to change what is being displayed. Unless this was already the message you saw at the time, in which case Im curious how you would make it more obvious.

> Searching for a ticket by number returns nothing (probably again because this ticket was closed).

The search box does not search your tickets at all in the popup (it has to be filtered after submitting the search), and that is not functionality we have any control over. It actually searches through the solutions in the portal. We currently only host our Enterprise documentation on this portal, and it is only visible to Enterprise customers based on the email domain they use to login. We may eventually host the Teams documentation there as well, but that is not certain.

> There seems to be no way to rediscover the URL after you close the site, other than find the invitation email and click the activation link again.

I don't know that we'd ever publicly disclose this URL on the contact form or another relevant place. We *do not* want people going directly to the portal to create Community Support requests because it bypasses all the automations and other instructions we built into the contact form that cannot be replicated in Freshdesk (particularly for merges). In fact, attempting to select Public Q&A as the product when creating a new ticket there redirects you back to the contact form for this very reason.

> The ticket I submitted includes a link to my profile as I was logged into Stack Overflow when I submitted the ticket. Why isn't this information used to link my accounts, and integrate the site into my profile?

This isn't possible in Freshdesk. They provide a select few authentication services that can be used and we are limited to using those. We cannot implement our own authentication systems or add Stack Exchange as a login option there. The only way we could really "integrate" in this manner would be utilizing the API to pull all ticket data onto our site and building our own portal to display them. That's far too much effort to replicate something that already exists.

> What could be done to integrate this site better with the main site (including, but not limited to, make it look less like a fraud site)?

While there is pretty much nothing we can do to integrate it into the network better, there are probably a few tweaks we could make so it appears less like a scam site. This includes doing something with the home page. We currently redirect the home page to the solutions page, which then displays an empty page for all non-Enterprise users. This was ideal when this portal was only used for Enterprise documentation and nothing else (not even support), but we should probably revisit this now that a bunch of other users are being directed into this system. Landing all users on a blank page is not ideal. I'm still actively working on various aspects of this portal to make it more user-friendly (even trying to get dark mode working as an option using local storage).

Comment: So in summary, not a good fit for the use case but not negotiable at this time. Part of my motivation for creating this question was to bring visibility and provide some feedback, which I guess I have accomplished.

Comment: If the email contained my Stack Overflow user id (screen name), that would work to somewhat better convince me that the email really came from you.

Comment: Also, perhaps the domain's main page could be a "yes, this is us" information page (perhaps with some technical details for those who are really skeptical, like perhaps a pointer to a DNS record we could check? Say, a TXT or PTR record under stackenterprise.stackexchange.com which is obviously under your organization's control) instead of the portal itself.

Comment: @tripleee To circle back on this: We've finally added a legitimate homepage for the portal as well as made many additional design updates to try and make it look more professional and official.

Answer (score 0):

This email address looks suspicious but it is a genuine Stack Exchange domain. They use it for their ticketing system through a tool called Freshdesk.

Here is an explanation by staff member, Catija:

> Those emails are created as part of a contact from us or one you initiate...
>
> ... apparently that's just the email that FD sends to people when they create a ticket. So... I guess if you fill in the contact form now, you'll get the email.
>
> stackenterprise.co seems to be the URL we're using for FD entirely. Even when I log in, that's the site I see - not a [something].freshdesk.com or anything like that.

Comment: Where is that quote from? The email thread I link to indicates that they moved _from_ Freshdesk to Jira.

Comment: @tripleee SOCVR

Comment: @tripleee We moved back to Freshdesk in October because nobody liked using Jira for support.