# What happens when users reach 1m rep - does Stack Overflow do anything to reward them?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Some users are fast approaching a reputation score of 1 million.

Does Stack Overflow do anything about this? Is there a hall of fame? I know some argue that the reputation score is relative to popularity of language, but I'm curious if the sites do anything in recognition to thank people's efforts.

Comment: *What happens when Jon reaches 1m rep* ? - SO will send him some *waffles* and then there will be another *big bang* in one of those parallel universes

Comment: The rep will wrap over.

Comment: @Oded So he will have a *wrap* of 1m?

Comment: @Oded - I hope you've used *unsigned numbers* :)

Comment: Do you diamonds have an alert on your dashboard when someone mentions Jon Skeet?

Comment: @Stijn Whenever anything related to Jon happens anywhere, the universe knows immediately. You're not getting those twitches behind your ear…?

Comment: @Stijn *I think they have a fire alarm in the office for that. When someone mentions Jon in a post they go off.*

Comment: Umm... the Jon Skeet alarm just went off... what am  I missing? Oh hi there @Stijn...

Comment: @TheLostMind, you can start to worry about unsigned numbers after 2 billion reputation :)

Comment: Obviously, there will be a stack overflow.

Comment: @Grundy So, like… next week?

Comment: i can't see the reasons of down-votes considering other linked question (by Glorfindel ), interesting question though

Comment: Jeez, I've got some bad memories of the Jon Skeet alarm.  Sometimes, late at night, I still think I can hear it going off... *aaaaaah, skeet skeet!  ... aaaaaah, skeet skeet!* It's giving me the chills as I write about it.

Comment: What happens when 1M is reached? This happens: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362019/540552

Answer (score 16):

The current answer is: we don't know yet. There are rewards when you reach [100k reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291791/what-do-i-get-with-100k-reputation), [200k reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261505/is-it-true-that-if-someone-reaches-200k-reputation-he-she-gets-a-painting-with-a?noredirect=1&lq=1), but no other reputation barrier rewards are known. We'll know in [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/295232).

Comment: It nears - 999k rep

Comment: it has just happened.