# Happy 10th anniversary Stack Overflow! Commence ... au festival!

Tags: discussion, swag, 10th-anniversary

Stack Overflow [turns 10 years old today](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/09/27/stack-overflow-is-10/). In the world of Internet startups, that's a pretty big deal — most assumed we would have flopped or gotten ourselves acquired by now. Many of us have had *pets* that didn't last this long, and in dog years, we're really pushing it. See the linked blog post for some pretty interesting numbers (and you've *gotta* watch the video), and those are numbers that we should all feel good about.

When you look at the ground that we've covered through the rear-view mirror, it's hard to not be a little amazed that we navigated it as well as we did. We ended the crappy practice of baiting people with knowledge in search engines, we turned the best elements of the tools we had for knowledge sharing on their head and invented something better, and we built a colossal community consisting of the smartest and most selfless people anyone would ever have the pleasure to know.

As we stand where we do today, passionately finding better ways to come together so *all* of us have a seat at the table as we look for the best way forward, it's important to not lose track of what we've accomplished thus far. That's why this party is all about *you*.

#### Tim, can we get to the 'au festival' part?

Yes, we certainly can. Starting in the *very near* future, we're going to be writing some interesting posts here and on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com). While the network itself isn't turning 10, its DNA (the realization that we innovated a better way to learn) has. And, our network sites do a *great* job of putting up with Stack Overflow getting all the shiny new stuff initially, so they are getting their fair share of treats at this party.

Your missions, should you care to accept them, are to accomplish whatever unit of 'fun' we set up in a series of posts in order to unlock some pretty awesome limited edition swag. And we're *not* just talking t-shirts and stickers here (though, those are awesome, they're also too typical for this occasion). We're talking *the good stuff*.

Bigger gifts mean bigger asks. Maybe you'll be looking at our rendered markup for proof that [Joe Friend](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7782017/joe-friend) is really [Illuminati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminati). Maybe we'll ask for a few paragraphs sharing your thoughts on a particular moment in time. Maybe we'll ask you to [break out the craft supplies again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304500/a-moose-some-silly-putty-and-a-desperate-plea-for-help). What's important is you can expect something special every 7 - 10 days from now until just before the start of Winter Bash (which may or may not be heavily inspired by fondant, LEGO bricks and constrained closet space).

I won't say any more this early, and you won't break me, ever.

#### The point is, you're awesome, and thank you. We really mean it.

None of us would have these awesome jobs where we get to annoy you constantly if it weren't for your support. Wait, that didn't exactly come out right. Well, I guess it's a small part of it, but it's more about the millions of people that get help *every single day* simply by clicking the top link in their search results.

You've taken a craft that once required a *considerable* amount of failure just to uncover a glimmer of success *and you've made it more accessible than it has ever been before*. You've taken a huge stab at removing the barrier of needing to learn English proficiently in order to learn programming through our international initiatives. You're doing your best to help us be sincere when we tell every visitor that *they will be respected*, and that those who show some ownership in their problems will be welcomed by getting the kind of help that we've become famous for providing.

You, all of you, have taken control of a *major* part of our future by *showing people a better way to learn*, and for *mostly* better and *sometimes* worse, helping them find the best versions of themselves.

I know this, because that's what this place has done for me, and I know I'm not alone.

So, any [last suggestions for cool swag ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314941/new-swag-for-stack-overflows-10th-birthday-wear-ables-or-desk-ables)? Anything else you want to share? A haiku? A GDPR-compliant recipe for cookies we could bake and eat together in chat?

Our only request: Let's just enjoy this. We <3 all of you, and we're looking forward to going out of our way to try and delight you outside of our everyday problems straight into the holidays. We'll work on serious stuff, too, but ..

#### Let's have some fun.

Comment: wonder what does one need to do to get a [gift like that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374490/839601)

Comment: "Member for 10 years"

Comment: Congrats to SO - company and community. Only it's too bad that SO isn't old enough to drink alcohol in celebration!

Comment: If I can choose the gift, a simple *keychain*/key fob is fine - to make sure not losing important keys in careless way. Anyway, congratulations for all efforts made till today!

Comment: `the crappy practice of baiting people with knowledge in search engines` I wonder what that was like, you're a little vague about it.

Comment: @Hack-R depends where it is [hosted](https://drinkingage.procon.org/view.resource.php?resourceID=004294):

Comment: Same birthday as Google? Wow!

Comment: Kind of a weird morbid joke about pets not living 10 years

Comment: @andrewtweber Maybe a tamagotchi ..?

Comment: @andrewtweber Likely context: https://twitter.com/spolsky/status/921387638472499200?lang=en

Comment: @WelcometoStackOverflow that makes it worse... "ha, even Joel's DOG didn't last this long!" .. ?

Comment: keep everyone busy and let's take CVQ to next level

Comment: By "good stuff", do you mean [unicorns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216179/where-can-i-get-a-unicorn)?

Comment: @WelcometoStackOverflow I really hope that's *not* the context and that's coincidental, because that would be.... f'd up, to be honest.

Comment: @StephenLeppik A reference to [that hyphenated site](http://s.tk/hyphen). A recurring theme in the early days of SO; e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/08/22/us-versus-hyphen/) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12989/stack-overflow-taking-down-the-evil-hyphen-site).

Comment: I demand that all swag be unicorn-themed.

Comment: 3d-printed black plastic hands! And maybe tiny red flags. Cocktail umbrella sized.

Comment: NOT fair giving winter bash teasers *this* early! and I was planing on not being that active for this one...

Comment: Providing some kind of certificates or merchandise to the users as a a thank you.

Comment: "But the big numbers don’t tell the real story. Every one of those times someone finds help is a developer who nails their initial project at their first job. Or a teenager who finishes her first project – the one that makes her realize she wants to be a developer when she grows up."

Just WOW.

Comment: @JETM, never mind unicorns... my youngest has recently discovered My Little Pony, and has asked for a "real life alicorn" for her Christmas present.  For the uninitiated, an alicorn is a cross between a unicorn and a pegasus!

Comment: And the YT link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwS1r1mc888

Comment: @David Considering the contest post from WB last year was a teaser for potential future hat designs... this is late ;)

Comment: So can we finally get that Tim Post (in)action hat? Needs the SO logo

Comment: The [*Then A Miracle Occurs*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/09/15/then-a-miracle-occurs-public-beta/) blog post dates the public opening of Stack Overflow to September 15. Why is the 27th our birthday now?

Comment: @MichaelMyers So does [yesterday's blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/09/27/stack-overflow-is-10/): "And on September 15, 2008, Stack Overflow’s public beta went live." I take the first sentence of this meta post as a typo.

Comment: Woow.Time runs like hell and so does Stackoverflow.Great site with great programmers!

Comment: I would be also happy to see some cute symbol of stackoverflow on my desk...really sorry for absence of creative idea because I've to implement excellent functionality even at cafe, Saturday.

Comment: I love the NON-crappy practice of being the top result for most of my questions on DuckDuckGo!

Comment: so where can I get an SO Mug then?

Comment: This is a great service you offer.  You put together a great community of helpers.

Comment: I'm not sure why they take the birth date age of the meta as the official start date. On SO itself, there are questions as early as July 2008.

Comment: @OurManinBananas achieve 100k rep and you get your mug for free…

Comment: On the subject of breaking out the craft supplies, what's the status of the final shipments of swag from that challenge? I'm still waiting...

Comment: @PeterTaylor To my knowledge that was 100% fulfilled _months and months ago_ and I'm really sorry that your stuff didn't reach you. Please email team@stackoverflow.com, point them to this comment, and ask them to re-send it DHL or FedEx next day (whichever applies based on where you live).

Comment: @Holger: that's easy for you to say with your 150K rep :)

Comment: I'd like... a mug with the truly marvellous regex parsing rant on it (no line breaks allowed). I'd ponder a T-shirt, but it might be a joke that does not find an audience... `:=)`

Comment: A mug with the truly marvellous regex parser rant on it (no line breaks).

Comment: I've been a member for 9 years, 11 months. Didn't realise I'd been with you so close to the start. Was already an awesome site when I joined and thought you'd been around much longer.

Comment: I don't even drink coffee but a SO mug is something I can definitely see sitting on my desk at work (and home). So you could say I'm purty stoked... :D

Comment: Is there an easy way to stay informed on when the swag becomes available?

Comment: Only 10 years? Meh, come back when you've been around for 1010 years. ([For the benefit of confused, innocent bystanders](https://res.cloudinary.com/teepublic/image/private/s--JrsXn6-E--/t_Preview/b_rgb:191919,c_limit,f_jpg,h_630,q_90,w_630/v1533226922/production/designs/2970567_0.jpg))

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs SO sparked the whole thing but it didn't take long for other sites to pop up as Stack Exchange sites. Server Fault is the second oldest and went live less than a year later. You can see the age of all SE sites here: https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest

Comment: @ryvantage As someone who's been around SO a few years now but missed all the swag opportunities, I was thinking the same thing...! I keep checking meta to see if there's anything I've missed.

Comment: Please Tim, never send me a cup that looks like [these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374836/3956566)

Comment: @Lundin OK, and what language is that where you can write undecorated binary numbers?

Comment: So..when does this start? :D

Comment: Happy 10th Anniversary :) From Iran

Comment: The French (or ?) in the title here is really not what you meant, I think.

Comment: Glad to have been here for over 6 of those years!

Comment: _"What's important is you can expect something special every 7 - 10 days from now until just before the start of Winter Bash "_ Does "now" mean 6-8 weeks, because I haven't seen anything in the two weeks since this was posted

Comment: @j08691 I was out on family leave all of last week. Getting back into things now :)

Comment: For anyone else confused as hell by the franglais, "Commence au festival" is apparently a line spoken by the Joker in the 1989 film *Batman*. Literally it means "Start at the festival". God knows why.

Comment: @SteveBennett I think it means "Let the festival/festivities begin!" I just wonder though at using the Joker's line, because in the movie it really meant "come and enjoy my festival suckers, that I might kill you all. Muhahahaha!".

Comment: Well, that might be how it's intended, but that's not what those words mean literally, and all the references I can find to it all seem to relate back to Batman. It's particularly weird because it's in the singular *commence*, not the plural *commencez*. The closest correct equivalent would be something like "Que le festival commence !" or "Commencez le festival" but even then I'm a bit dubious.

Comment: It sound like bad french traduction, or traditional franglish. I read it at "Start at festival". Simply using "le" instead of "au" make it a little bit more readable. "Commence le festival!". But in traditional franglish "le" is hard like œufs and beurre. The e '\œ\'. The letter E doesn’t have just one pronunciation, in English e can be so manything: bee, pretty, anthem, cafe, sergeant. In franglish the rules is : When you can't prononce something you, you replace it.

Comment: I want to see SO by the numbers. How many questions have been asked, and how many still exist? How many answers are there? How many accounts have been created? How many answers has Jon Skeet given? Has anyone answered more than Jon? How many users have rep under 10? >100K? A separate Meta post would be a good place for this.

Comment: Congrats on 10 years!

Comment: Many Many Congrats many more to go   we are still working alive because of stackoverflow :D

Comment: @DragandDrop I was really disturbed by this line as it looked like French without any meaning to me (I'm french, and it really doesn't mean anything as is). I was like "wut?", even wondering if those "..." were hiding one or more word(s)

Comment: @Rafalon, the 'le' is quite infamous every time one try to speak french they drop every "le"/"de" and go for "un"/"au"/"du". I don't remember who, but a famous Hollywood actor claimed that the sexyer word in french was "beure". Because that \œ\ is like an unknow/impossible sound.

Comment: @DragandDrop isn't French "eu" really close to the "e" in English "butter". I mean maybe I pronounce "butter" wrong, but I'd believe removing the "t" would make it sound a lot like "beurre". (obviously if "beurre" is so sexy, then so shall be "leurre", "peur", and more generally many words with "eu" in it - and get to hear "Et ta soeur? Elle bat l'beurre")

Comment: @Rafalon, "EA sports". The E is the same in EU. Not that any reference of your "sœur" being sexy is not mine but an Hollywood actor statement. I will try to find the reference once I'm home.

Comment: @DragandDrop I couldn't argue about the sexyness of my sister, but I think we're getting a little lost here - haha

Comment: Has it started yet? If not, any way to get to know about it when it starts? :)

Comment: Congratulations folks, with this great forum .. thanks for keeping all this valuable information online for us !

Comment: why dont I see any such posts, as suggested in this post?

Comment: @YvetteColomb All of this and nobody suggested a poetry slam? :(

Comment: lol what happened to "every 7 - 10 days" ;-)

Comment: So, is this officially not happening anymore?

Comment: There is an update about the events that were supposed to be started..

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/376692/1795279

Comment: @Div good question. I don't know. I originally thought they were to give ideas of what sort of swag would be good. Perhaps the top voted ones will get some swag. Hopefully Tim will let us know.

Comment: @YvetteColomb, Thanks let's wait then for Tim, I would ask him

Comment: @TimPost, Are these(following) answers eligible for a swag?

Answer (score 290):

I know you said they're 'boring', but a limited time run of Stack Overflow t-shirts/coffee mugs for sale would be *really great*; limit of one or two per purchase would be fine - you could have the classic Stack Overflow design or add some fancy "10 year anniversary" prose to the design for a limited run.

In the past I recall a Community Manager has said, when these used to be available, that the company ran delivery and packaging out of their office. Today you are much bigger (and wiser) and there are no doubt countless local shops/services in New York that handle t-shirt or mug creation, packaging, and delivery... even internationally (I wouldn't mind paying $30 plus shipping for a plain black Stack Overflow/SO Anniversary t-shirt, personally).

Comment: Indeed, emphasis on delegating packaging and delivery to a dedicated service that can ship worldwide.

Comment: first step: delegate away the entire process.  second step: ???  third step: PROFIT!!!

Comment: The purchase limit needs to happen to stop me from spending several hundred dollars on SO swag because so help me I will otherwise

Comment: One reason I like mugs and T-shirts is because they're just *practical*. Call me boring, but stuff like a Unicorn pluche is certainly funny, but also something I'd stuff in a closet and never see, only to donate it to the charity shop when I move a year later. I regularly wear my Stack Overflow T-shirt (in fact, I am wearing it as I'm writing this!)

Comment: As an Australian I will be quite disappointed if any merch doesn't ship worldwide.

Comment: Stack overflow hoodies would also be nice.

Comment: Hoodies would be very nice indeed.

Comment: Lets make a compromise an ask for Unicorn Hoodies.

Comment: Hoodies would be great! Shipping world wide please!

Comment: I can't believe it's only 10 years!!! The site must have only just started when I first found it and I clearly remember thinking, 'Jeez, I have wasted my life', and even now I shudder at a world without stack overflow. So the T-shirts would be a great publicity push, I just entered some query about .htaccess in wordpress and Google did not show a single entry from stackoverflow - people out there are suffering...

Comment: I'd also _buy_ a couple of new T-shirts. I've a few stack overflow shirts that I wear "a lot" (including right now) - more than any other shirts - so much so that they're starting to get a little worn.

Comment: Why would they do this? You can literally just go to a local gift shop with your "$30 plus shipping" and order one to be made to yourself.

Comment: "CM"... Indians would read it "Chief Minister"..  :D

Comment: I think then rewarding 100K+ users with the same swag is not worth it if other users can buy them

Comment: @Mr.Alien Then they should find some new swag for 100k users :-) Like I said, these t-shirts can be both limited run *and* specifying a 10 year anniversary, or either of those things, to help distinguish them from the 100k user rewards. It's clear that lots of people want to spend money to rep Stack Overflow via clothing or coffee mugs or hoodies or something. This could be a fun way to engage with appreciative members and earn some extra bucks to cover the upcoming holiday electricity bill or help fund a SO office Christmas party.

Comment: @totymedli That would be illegal. And some of us want to support the organization.

Comment: yes I wouldn't mind some shirts and hoodies :D Hope they ship to my place also lol

Comment: As @Mr.Alien pointed out, the swag should be something an user gets for contributions. Asking my mom for the needed money to get one would be very easy.

Comment: I wish we could get those t-shirts in Iran too. :/

Comment: The t-shirt and coffee mug are both great hits in my house.  I'd be happy to purchase more.  Well done to Joel, Jeff, and the SO team.  You've changed the world - not many people get to say that.

Comment: Is the [Who cut the cheese](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316515/who-cut-the-cheese?cb=1) related to this post in meta?

Comment: @PeterHaddad If by this post you mean the question above this answer then yes, it's all part of the same anniversary celebration.

Comment: @TylerH ohh okay I thought we can buy

Comment: I, too, would love a SO tshirt.

Comment: I could sure use a mug, or maybe a tumbler. I had a StackOverflow mug once; it was bigger than your average mug. Unfortunately, it broke, and it broke my heart too. I'd BUY an SO mug, if you ever sell them again. Heck, I'd buy a second one for backup.

Answer (score 192):

Congratulations and happy 10th Anniversary all you Stack Overflowers!

Our tech community would be quite a different place without you; thanks for all your grand works!

Edit:

I made you an origami thing:

[image: Origami]

Comment: I like the origami thing! On a seemingly unrelated note, for some reason I'm suddenly hungry for sushi. ;-)

Comment: Are those things sitting on table or mounted to walls , I cannot imagine it properly

Comment: @Redman Re: table or mounted - a little from column A, a little from column B. The white background is a 8.5x11" sheet of paper L-folded with the stack and container sitting on the lower, flat portion. The heart is hanging from tabs on it's back from the top of the vertically aligned portion.

Comment: old school, eh? :)

Comment: @WillNess Back in my day we built our stacks out of porcelain clay fired from our own kiln! (Imagine the cleanup from an overflow) Get off my lawn! :)

Comment: This plays to MULTIPLE ways I am dorky. I love this.

Comment: Your stack is overflowing with one extra.

Comment: @BlackThunder Finally someone noticed. ;)

Comment: I like the gaming dot stackexchange dot com pre-pre-rebrand logo!

Answer (score 91):

**Congratulations on happy 10th anniversary of Stack Overflow !**

Lets make items with Stack Overflow logos on them. Here are some examples:
**T-shirts**:

[image: T-shirt]

**Cups**:

[image]

**Book**/ **Magazine**:

[image]

**Cap**:

[image]

**Cookies**:

[image]

**Chocolate**:

[image]

<sup>***Click on the images for high resolution!***</sup>

Comment: Was going to downvote, but then I saw the cookies... Have a vote for a cookie!

Comment: ... Chocolate?? I can't upvote twice!

Comment: Delete most of your post and just convert it into a "let's bring StackOverflow edibles!" crusade. That's were the money is, I tell you.

Comment: More items in revisions.

Comment: @BlackThunder what I read on the book was "stackoverflow is 10 factorial" (10!).

Comment: lol, the brightness on the t-shirt made me read it as `slackoverflow`, +10 for the edibles!

Comment: & exquisitely crafted one should say, props for that!

Comment: I think the cap should just have the image part of the logo, followed by 200. It would be a bit of an insider joke, admittedly...

Comment: @JonSkeet how do you feel about being [part of the swag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374834/3956566)? More importantly, are you any good at [housework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374617/happy-10th-anniversary-stack-overflow-commence-au-festival/374836#comment635644_374834)? I don't see you having any tag badges in [tag:housework]

Comment: Wait what's in the book? Most frequented questions? Stickers with vote-to-close reasons?

Comment: @YvetteColomb: Yup, happy to do housework. Laundry and dishes I'm okay at; my cooking is somewhat limited. Happy to vacuum, less experience with other cleaning. Quite good at driving kids from place to place...

Comment: I'll have to make sure this use of cookies falls in line with our GDPR framework; I'll get back to you.

Comment: @TimPost What is GDPR framework?

Comment: @BlackThunder https://www.itgovernance.co.uk/gdpr-privacy-compliance-framework-and-standards

Comment: **Click on the images for high resolution!**

Comment: Only if i eat those chocolates all the ideas shared to stackoverflow will register to my brain.

Comment: where we can buy these items ?

Comment: @KhalidShah These items are edited. I hope that SE/SO will create these items to sell.

Comment: Sounds good, i wish i could have these chocolate....

Answer (score 75):

I have to say, for me 10 years is an *extremely* long time: back when this site launched, had you asked me what tells a computer what to do, my answer would have been along the lines of "fairies and pixie dust", because *I was six years old back then* and I didn't have an account on Scratch until November.

Let it never be said that that is the wrong answer.

## [Pixiedust](https://github.com/The-Snide-Sniper/pixiedust), a new esolang (esoteric programming language) by me

This language uses the characters `*+.`. Any other non-whitespace characters will result in a syntax error. This is an assembly language with instructions separated by newlines.

### Instructions

- `* O R X Y` is a mathematical operation:

  - `O` specifies the operation to use: `.` for copy, `++` for addition, `+.` for subtraction, `**` for multiplication, `*.` for division, `*+` for modulo. `+*` is reserved for future use.
  - `R` specifies the register to store the result to. Registers hold single 32-bit integers. Each register is two characters, with a few special registers: `**` is the memory pointer, `*.` is the value at the pointer, `*+` reads a byte from STDIN or writes to STDERR, `..` is the test register, and `.*` is the numeric literal portal.
  - `X` and `Y` are expressions. More on these below. For a copy operation, `Y` should be omitted.
- `. C X Y` performs the comparison specified by `C` and stores it with 0/1 in the `..` register. `=<>` are indicated by `*+.`, respectively. `X` and `Y` are expressions.
- `++ X` prints the Unicode character represented by expression `X` to STDOUT.
- `+. L` defines a program label; `L` can be any number of characters.
- `+* T L` jumps to label `L` based on the condition `T`. `T` can be `*` to jump if `..` is not 0, `.` to jump if `..` *is* 0, or `+` to jump regardless of the value in `..`.

Expressions can be either a normal register, or the reserved `.*` register followed by a number literal. A number literal is up to 32 `+` or `.` characters terminated with a `*`. With `+` meaning 1 and `.` meaning 0, they should form the binary representation of the number exactly how it would be stored as an `int` in a Java stack frame. Leading `.` characters can be omitted, and the terminating `*` can be left out if it's at the end of a line.

A *golfed* Hello World program would look like this:

```
++.*+..+...
++.*++..+.+
++.*++.++..
++.*++.++..
++.*++.++++
++.*+.++..
++.*+.....
++.*+.+.+++
++.*++.++++
++.*+++..+.
++.*++.++..
++.*++..+..
++.*+....+
```

But that's *boring*, and it doesn't even look too much like pixie dust! So I wrote some code to rewrite it to the following, equivalent program:

```
+           +               .   *+       ..  +.        ..            .                  .              .          .
+            +   .*    +   +.    .    +           .+                         *
                   ++.        *   +  +  .  ++     .  .    *                         .              .      .   .       .*
               +     +.     *  +    + .+         + .   .*                         .                 .   .    . ..
            ++      .  *     ++.    + ++        +  *                 .      .   ..          .              .*
           +     +   .* + .   +     +.              .  .                  .           .   .   .                .
              +           +  .*+           .   .. .     .*                                 .  .  . ..         . .   .*
+               +.  *      +. +      .        ++          +*
 +         +. *+                       +       .  ++  ++             ..                                 .     ..
            +  +.        * +  +                 + ..   +  .*                         .
          + +        . *            ++        . + +       ..*            .                          ..
+                  +  .  *  ++.                  .+.. .          .    .                    . ...        ..
            +       +   .  *+                ..    . .    +*.         .      .       .         .       .*
```

Comment: It's amazing how far one can come in 10 years. 10 years ago I was 13. I was just beginning to struggle my way through BASIC and really had no clue what I was doing. Now I work as a (nearly) full stack web dev and I make games in my spare time.

Comment: Amazing. It's like brainfuck^2, in magic.

Comment: _"` L` can be any number of characters."_ But how is it delimited?

Comment: ^ Never mind, instructions are new-line separated. But then that means `\n` is important and part of the language's vocabulary.

Comment: @Clonkex the greatest gift a programmer can have is learning at a young age. The greatest curse this site currently faces is programmers learning at a young age.

Comment: aw damn. You made me pull out my base Python CPU implementation for various online code challenges again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how about we just open a chat room for all of these? I don't want to clutter the comments.

Comment: @StephenLeppik: excellent idea: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180949/pixiedust

Comment: I think this is the best esolang I've ever seen.

Comment: @ChrisAkridge then clearly you haven't seen enough esolangs.

Comment: Python interpreter for PixieDust: https://github.com/mjpieters/pixiedust.

Comment: The 'dusted' version has issues (there are extreneous characters on the lines generated that are not legal PixieDust, according to my reading) but golfed HelloWorld.dust program works. No further testing has been done beyond that, so caveat emptor!

Comment: Feels a bit weird to see esoteric languages discussion on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Happy 10th anniversary <3

Answer (score 61):

Congratulations!! for Stack 10 times Overflowed :)

I've learned so many things since I joined Stack Overflow. it's just not about the code *really*, it's more than that, it also helped me to identify the way of interact, understand and appreciate other members. So I would like to thank you community for helping me out!

*Doodle?* I just tried :D

[image]

Let's keep making community awesome for coming years!

> Bigger gifts mean bigger asks

Here are my asks ;)

[image]

Comment: Doodle is great! However, the angle is a little interrupted.

Comment: Updated a ask list, check it out!!

Comment: You have chosen plain t-shirts etc (not rough) to make it easy to edit.

Comment: I have decrease my post size because I was suggested by 12+ users to decrease my post. I will suggest you to do the same.

Comment: Done! @BlackThunder

Comment: Actually, I used HTML code to decrease image size. Why waste time in editing?

Answer (score 49):

Happy birthday!

My idea what to do for the celebration is to undelete the very first SO question, question #1, just for a while.
Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1 (but only for the high-reppers of course, wouldn't it be nice if everybody could see it.)

And here's my doodle. Subtle eh? Simple, yet inspired! (by the other entries, that is.)

[image]

Anyway, I want a mug. No, let me rephrase that. I don't just *want* a mug. I *need* a mug! Do you have any idea how hot this coffee is when it comes out of the machine? So how am I supposed to not burn my hands without a mug? Besides, holding the coffee in my hands makes it so much harder to type. I want a mug!

Comment: [Here's your mug!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374836/3956566). Yes that sounds like an OWPCDSH (occupational workplace and coffee drinking safety hazard - I actually made that up!). Do you keep burn cream in your top draw?

Answer (score 36):

Happy birth day Stack Overflow.

It's 10th anniversary and a t-shirt and a mug isn't good in this occasion. but it's a huge community and you can't gave costly things to everyone who participate. I'll say, an exclusive **Stack Overflow** t-shirt, a mug or a bottle will be good. Yes I highlighted it in bold because I expected a Stack Overflow t-shirt as a swag for last year winterbash and you sent me a Stack Exchange one. Lot of people asked me why the Stock Exchange sent me a t-shirt, including my father and I wasn't really happy to pay the duties for a Sta(o)ck Exchange t-shirt. But I can pay up to $20 as duties for an exclusive Stack Overflow t-shirt.

Once again, Happy Birth Day Stack Overflow.
[image]

**Proposed Challenge**: Ask people to draw a doodle every week and put it as site logo for 1 week.

Comment: by duties do you mean import tax?

Comment: @NH no. It's customs duty. Charged by customs while import/export things

Comment: Doodles are fun! I had a go myself: https://i.imgur.com/b9YvKHN.png

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Made one too by myself: https://i.imgur.com/N2XAru3.png

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Whoops, I only see now that you had the same "10" idea as the one I posted today. Sorry about that, never meant to impose on your concept.

Comment: @SagarV Wait, are you really complaining about the fact that you received a T-shirt? If I ever got anything from SE, I wouldn't complain, no sir.

Answer (score 32):

Swag idea: Some kind of competition where the winner wins Jon Skeet for a day.

Disclosure: I have not thought this through.

Comment: An hour of Jon Skeet would already be an amazing prize.

Comment: Do we also get a day's worth of skeet rep?

Comment: Do we get him to do housework?

Comment: Or two hours with the #2 SO person [BalusC](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31/157882?sort=reputationchange#157882)! Or ∞ hours of time with anyone > 32 positions (roughly).

Answer (score 17):

Happy 10th birthday Stack Overflow!

In the past ten years Stack Overflow has grown from zero to a huge site, and it's currently the largest website for programming discussions.

Meanwhile, as Stack Overflow grows larger and larger, it has attracted more and more spam :) From initially those random links to random websites, Stack Overflow has collected a variety of spam. There are relevent spam like "Java training in $city" and affiliated blogs, or "Apple Customer Support Numbers" and "HP Printer Support Numbers"; there are blatant drug spam like (fake) weight loss pills and skin care serums; there are also amusing spam like priests, spell casters and even witches for "your lost love", as well as unwelcome loans and trades; there are attractive spam like tours and job offers; there are disgusting spam like escort services and call girls; there are illegal spam like passport and certificate forgery; there are bizarre spam like roof repair or pipe plumbers; there are plain ads like electric parts and PCB designers.

Beside spam, Stack Overflow has also survived from garbage. Be it random users answering asdfghjkl or zxcvbnm, or persistent trolls posting extremely long and repetitive text and ASCII arts, or legitimate users turning their questions and answers into deleted deleted deleted deleted deleted or just a page full of dots ....................................... they have never beaten Stack Overflow and its content quality!

Welcome to the Internet World of Spam and Congrats for your toughness and resistance against them! The more you get spammed, the larger you are it reflects. Happy spammy and trolly 10th birthday Stack Overflow!

Oh yeah, one last request: can you bring back the 404 polyglot for us? `:)`

Comment: Yeh it's not often I get a 404. They have random images now?

Answer (score 17):

**Congratulations, SO!**

I have to say that you guys can provide some kind of **certificates, merchandise** or some kind of **trophies** to the reputed users as a thank you gift like YouTube sends to its reputed channel owners.

The point is that these kind of goodies helps in keeping alive the spirit of an individual and moreover pushes the new users to work hard and contribute more.

By certificates I mean that online certificates that can be downloaded as a pdf file so that we can take printout of the certificates.

Comment: That is not new, they already provide physical gifts to those who reach certain reputation milestones (e.g 100k).

Comment: @E_net4 oh I didnt knew that.

Comment: Related [Is it true that if someone reaches 200k reputation he/she gets a painting with a unicorn on it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261505/is-it-true-that-if-someone-reaches-200k-reputation-he-she-gets-a-painting-with-a)

Comment: @NileshRathod Thanks for more info. :-)

Comment: @NileshRathod atleast they can provide online certificates that we can take printout of.

Comment: @E_net4 100k! ---No! I don't want to answer that many questions--- Sure sounds good.

Answer (score 14):

Happy 10th

I have completely worn out my SO Ts I was so lucky to receive a looong time ago.

I was always active at Q&A sites - since 1997 as editor at https://irt.org/ and I am so pleased that SO is still a place where I can answer questions

I’d love one of these with the Stackoverflow logo.

[image: snowboard hat]

Comment: What about this?  https://imgur.com/bMj7BHU.png

Comment: hm I'd like one of these too!

Comment: its really awesome.....

Answer (score 14):

A keyboard with StackOverflow logo + and a special key to open stackOverflow website?

[image: StackOverflow Keyboard]

Comment: I am in on this one, especially if you press the stackoverflow button over an error message, it will automatically search the error on stackoverflow and affiliated sites for you.

Answer (score 11):

A hard copy encyclopedia of Jon Skeet's contributions. Ready for the day the machines take over, crippling the internet, and we have to take them down from the inside without the aid of the actual SO.

[image]

Comment: why would someone downvote this?

Comment: Anyone who posts a picture of Margaret Hamilton deserves an upvote from me. In this picture she is standing next to the code she (and her team) wrote for the Apollo missions. This is literally the code that took humans to the moon.

Comment: OK, but the stack could have been tilted, couldn't it. More like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4LJf.jpg).

Answer (score 10):

Wait... I signed up on Sep 15, 2008. This is the same day the public beta went live!?
I kept seeing quality Stack Overflow results in Google. First I thought it was a blog (most quality code was in blogs at the time), but then I noticed there were different people asking and answering, and saw a banner explaining what it was all about. I remember I was pretty excited *I could be one of these people* so I signed up, but I couldn't find anything to answer...
I always thought I signed up after the beta, so when I got my 10th Yearling badge I thought the 10th anniversary already passed, and wasn't marked.
Even if I'm less active, Stack Overflow is still my favorite site online. Congratulation!

Comment: @downvoter - wow - downvoted in 4 seconds! thanks for the stack overflow experience `:)`. j/k I know this isn't an answer, not fun, and isn't particularly interesting. That's OK/

Comment: Downvoted for extra Stack Overflow experience. No need to thank me.

Comment: Glad you undeleted this ;)

Comment: @YvetteColomb - I guess good people undeleted it for me, which is pretty nice to be honest. It says up. Thanks `:)`

Answer (score 8):

**Prove of concept - StackOverflow stress ball**

Normal state:

[image: Normal]

When squeezed from less elastic end:

[image: Squeezed]

Using Stackoverflow stress ball to prevent stress overflow!

Answer (score 7):

Happy 10th Anniversary :)

A haiku?

Here's a childish one from me :)

> the ten times coffee
>
> naughty bugs / stuck in research
>
> ping ping ping, stack overflow

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't a standard 5-7-5 haiku. ;-)

Comment: Reducing the pings to a single one would salvage it.

Comment: Well this website showed that it actually fits in as 5-7-5 :p https://hku.me/2DPco3e

Comment: Hm... "ping ping ping es oh"... This sounds good to my ears, no problems.

Answer (score 6):

Whoever commenting some pets having a short life should elect this bird to be one of Stackoverflow's mascots:

[image: Soft Cockatoo]

This is a Sulphur-crested cockatoo, [it could live up to 100 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulphur-crested_cockatoo). One of my friends inherited one when her grandma passed away many years ago.

Unlike the ibis, which people here also [love to death](https://youtu.be/w4dYWhkSbTU?t=28), sulphur crested cockatoos have much better table manners. Instead garbage bin diving, those birds prefer to [chew on your wooden beams](https://www.environment.nsw.gov.au/questions/cockatoo-attack-property) and occasionally causing your roof to collapse.

They are however, [very intelligent and daring birds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7DE_lCrtAI).

... and energetic ...

[image]

Comment: Aside from the feathers slightly resembling the SO logo, what's the relevance of that cockatoo to SO?

Comment: @Cerbrus I think the user was reacting to the comment in the original question, of how 10 years is a long time for a pet's age: _Many of us have had pets that didn't last this long, and in dog years, we're really pushing it. _

Answer (score 4):

## What about a 10-day cooperative event?

Each Stack Exchange community can contribute its own special brand of expertise, say in a specially created (community).meta page linked into a meta.SE question. For example:

- The [UX community](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) can propose full mockups of 'the ideal SE page'.
- The [English Language & Usage community](https://english.stackexchange.com/) can overhaul the standard FAQs.
- The [Interpersonal Skills community](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) can come up with a new FAQ with standard cut-and-paste comments on how to effectively communicate Stack Exchange values and norms.

Programmers have long had hackathons. Why not organize one for SE's 10th anniversary?

There will be no obligation for Stack Exchange management to adopt any of the suggestions, but it would be a fun time for the wider SE community to dream and to express their ideas and ideals.

Answer (score 3):

Happy Birthday Stack Overflow!
I wrote my thank you note here: [10 reasons to start a SO account today](https://eduarduta.ro/stack-overflow-is-10-10-reasons-you-should-create-a-so-account-now/)

It's amazing what is happening on this platform!

Comment: Ugh, the link's broken.

Answer (score -1):

How about a Stack Overflow coffee mug. Big.

We wouldn't expect it to be as professional as these diagrams, but we could only hope ....

[image]

We could even have them mooded on either side.

[image]

Much like the Salieri fantasy of Mozart's father:

[image]

[image]

Please.

Or we could use this amateurish [design by BlackT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374617/happy-10th-anniversary-stack-overflow-commence-au-festival/374836?noredirect=1#comment636124_374836)
<sub>*Shhh please be nice, they've worked hard on trying to keep up with my standards*</sub>

[image]

Please be mindful we have a theory of mathematics riding on this post. We like to keep the

```
number of upvotes == number of downvotes.
```

<sub>(not that I'd be telling anyone how to vote, as that would be *bad*).</sub>

Theory of mathematics being tested live on Stack Overflow

[image]

Comment: I expected something like: https://i.imgur.com/skFXf50.png

Comment: @BlackThunder look that's not a bad effort, but if you ever want tips on how to get your images seamlessly lifelike,as are mine, just ask. :D

Comment: How about what Yvette said, but personalised with your best answer or question?

Comment: You could put both moods on the same mug; when the mug is full the smiling emoji appears; when the coffee line is below the emoji, the lack of heat causes it to revert to the frowning emoji.

Comment: @TylerH Yeah. Here is a similar mug: https://www.amazon.com/Cortunex-Smiley-Sensitive-Changing-Coffee/dp/B00N3HYI9Q

Comment: -1 as the votes were at 1, and also why are you suggesting they make mugs that you clearly already own (and hence could take un-edited photos of)? Looks like humble bragging about your cool SO mugs to me...

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland thank you for that minus 1. Honestly is this the first instance of bonafide gratitude for a downvote? And yeh... I might have to confess, the mugs are not real. IKR!!! It's a shock, as they look so real. :D

Comment: @brasofilo how much did blackT pay you to say that? It's clear they're used some primitive form of paint or worse edited using Preview in their Mac *(did I mention I use a Mac?)* Nevermind, jealousy of such a raw talent for mock ups is a thing I have to learn to endure :D ;)

Comment: @BlackThunder oh Black T. That's kind.. Oh I guess you can. As long as you know they just won't look as nearly as real or professional as mine lolol *(your were so good, mine are soooo bad - did I say that out loud?)*

Comment: @YvetteColomb Don't worry. I will make for you.

Comment: Here is frowny: https://imgur.com/9O4V5k6.png   . Smiley:  https://imgur.com/Y2UrD88.png   . Simple:  https://imgur.com/wqlsa21.png . Use these images and break the equilibrium.

Comment: Hmm... I'm envisioning a mug with just the "box" when it's empty (cold), then as you fill it up with coffee the bars of the overflowing stack appear one by one.

Comment: @DavidZ it's doable, but we'd want the artwork to be as pristine as my work.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Well of course, that's a given.

Comment: Phew, I was in the middle of my mathematical thesis. The one that will turn all knowledge on it's head.

Comment: may be i am late, but someone needs to balance the equilibrium state. lets see

Comment: @BlackThunder yeah Hahaha.. this is the funniest weird thing on stackoverflow I have ever seen.

Comment: We have noughtality. I repeat, we have noughtality. Anything you still can't cope with is therefore your own problem.

Comment: It seems like this post is "stable" yet.

Comment: @sohnryang nope, it went to +42 | -42

Comment: +43 | -42 you say? It is my moral obligation to keep it equal. Perfectly balanced, as all things should be...

Comment: +45 | -45 = 0 stable again :p

Comment: Wow! Just checking. Its ended up stabled.

Comment: @BlackThunder hahahaha you're loyal to the cause

Comment: Warning! Equilibrium is broken! lol

Answer (score -4):

Hope you had a Happy Birthday Stack Overflow. Sorry I missed it / Sorry I'm late.

I have recently started my journey with you and it seems quite interesting and helpful.

Thanks..for such a wonderful creation..

Answer (score -6):

I thought the au may be a reference to the importance of Australia, but am none the wiser.

If you really WANTED to make the site WELCOMING you could start by renaming the Winter Bash  which seems to coincide with near 40℃ temperatures

Comment: aussie aussie aussie oi oi oi

Comment: @YvetteColomb oi oi oi??  :)

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aussie_Aussie_Aussie,_Oi_Oi_Oi

Comment: @YvetteColomb oh I see...!! :p