# How can I quit using Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, gamification

I am spending most of my time on Stack Overflow, earning reputation and badges. This is causing me to be late on some of my tasks. How I can stop using Stack Overflow?

Comment: You can always checkout but you can never leave...

Comment: Related MSEs: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-keep-from-getting-addicted-to-stack-overflow , https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91609/how-do-i-prevent-a-stack-overflow-addiction

Comment: Call your doctor. Tell them "I'm addicted to a website". No need to explain which one. They'll give you advices about how to progressively get your life back. // I'm not joking.

Comment: @Moritz Therapist, not doctor.

Comment: @Dukeling Where I live, you have to tell your doctor/physician first, and they will redirect you to a therapist. I guess it works differently in other places.

Comment: If you're really serious about it, you can request that your account be deleted.

Comment: @Moritz - haha, you people are making great fun.

Comment: @Dukeling - Not at all. Just I asked for the sake of getting others openion on this.

Comment: @Arvindraja I can assure you I was not joking. Addiction is a very serious issue.

Comment: @Moritz - I agree altogether. As Cerbrus commented in his answer i'll take care it. Even I have busy schedule I am spending some time here that's why this idea came in my mind to ask question.

Comment: Voting to re-open: Of course this is opinion based. That's basically the point of discussions on Meta.

Comment: Just like you stop drinking; one day at a time.

Comment: @brasofilo If you stop drinking every day, you might have a problem...

Answer (score 17):

Close the browser tab.

That's all there is to it. Just do it.

Comment: Thank for your creative answer. :)

Comment: The deeper meaning in this answer is "Discipline". That's not something we can give you. That's something _you_ have to take care of.

Comment: Exactly! I agree altogether.

Comment: We can only show you the door *(and we're pretty good at it, according to some people)*, but you have to walk through it.

Comment: _"Something about red and blue pills, and rabbit holes"_

Comment: Disclaimer: This answer is sponsored by Nike.

Comment: I do, but it just keeps opening again...

Comment: @Script47 That's why the green tick seems familiar to me .. it should black in this case

Comment: @Dukeling yeh that happens when your browsers start page is Stack Overflow :D

Comment: @Script47 - The comment of Cerbrus seemed quite convincing to me.

Comment: If that would work for any addiction for sizable number of people life would be so much easier... While I don't think this is really that useful advice I don't see how SO can provide better suggestion as real on-topic answer (unfortunately).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov closing it off right away is like going ['cold turkey'](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_turkey) and that has worked quite well.

Comment: @Script47 did you ever succeeded doing so for something that society encourages or at least accepts (like participating in charity events or drinking coffee)? SO is very bad for quitting cold turkey if you are developer - participation is considered "help others" and you rarely can keep it from not showing up in search results...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the only issue here is that the OP is going after badges and rep which is causing them problems IRL. Therefore if we take the suggestion that someone posted above of deleting their account *and* going cold turkey from the account based stuff (answering, flagging, chasing badges etc) then they can still use SO as a "guest" user with no ability of answering or doing those tasks which previously caused them issues. With their account (read: hard work) being deleted, that might quench the temptation to start again.

Answer (score 10):

A few years ago, I asked a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42481/the-problem-with-extrinsic-motivation). At the time, my problem wasn't that the site prevented me from doing my job, but rather that it felt like a waste of time to pursue trinkets on the site. It is a serious problem—especially for people who are [prone to addiction](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-the-brain-gets-addicted-to-gambling/). I found myself embarrassed to discuss how much time I spent answering questions, which opened my eyes to the depths I'd fallen to.

There are some technical solutions, such as logging out of the site and [unsubscribing from email notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current). (Not in that order, of course.) I found it helped to shift my efforts to other sites on the network that exercise different parts of my brain. If you are a professional programmer, spending some time thinking about [travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) or learning about [biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) might be a better distraction than doing more programming work on Stack Overflow. (Though it does have the downside of putting pings from SO in your topbar. Maybe use an alternate account instead?)

I'm no psychologist and I wouldn't give advice over the internet if I were. Instead, I encourage you to seek out people you can talk to. If your work has a counselling benefit, that might be a good thing to take advantage of. There may be other resources available in your community. Even just talking about it with someone—a friend or coworker—could be of help.

We face a [similar concern with moderators](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312056/1438) who often feel responsible for the site and don't know how to leave. It's been on my heart to find ways to give people permission to quit a site. While that might seem to run counter to the company's goals, I think it's necessary in the long run. Avoiding [stealth lock-in is a mature strategy](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/06/03/strategy-letter-iii-let-me-go-back/) to building a great business. After all, if people know they can take time off, they won't be as worried about coming back in the future.

Answer (score 9):

Put a picture of someone that would be concerned if your success was put in jeopardy near your monitor. My kids work for me, but it could be any family member or friend that is involved in your life, or even a pet that depends on you.

It helps get a little more determination together to avoid tendencies that aren't good for your long-term goals. I used that method to cut back on SO / Twitter / Reddit some time ago, and continue to keep my .. err .. little Minecraft problem ... in check with it.

Ultimately you *do* have to just close the tab, and simplistically, that *is* it, but sometimes it helps to have a trick to overcome compulsive behavior, even if it's just for the sake of a little extra confidence.

Comment: Dear @TimPost, sorry to bother but, at your request: [_if you haven't heard anything from me about this in a month you should definitely get after me in comments._](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288274/please-implement-clause-7b-of-the-cc-by-sa-license/288276#288276)

Answer (score 3):

I totally understand. I have no answer, but have faced the same problem, so will tell you what I did.

I faced this agony time ago, it's an addictive site. Let's face it, it's not a "bad" place to be hooked on.

Some years ago I was active on quite a few sites and I found it hard to close the browser. I took some time off the sites (actually closed my accounts and I wouldn't recommend this, as I came back) and it was quite a difficult void to fill. I came back and instead of resisting my use of them,  I leant into it. I became active in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and [Charcoal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) which eventually led to me now moderating on two sites.

I have several Stack Exchange sites on my favourites bookbar and have a little ritual when returning online or *from doing other non Stack related activities (like working)*. ***I'll reward myself with Stack activity as a break when I've achieved a self projected "milestone" in my work.***

- I check the [pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) site for mod flags.
- Then answer any pings from across the network.
- I then go  to the Stack Overflow moderator flag queue. Will handle some flags and then check meta (the queue and some posts), then return to the flag queue.
- I then rejoin my favourite chat rooms.
- Repeat and rinse.

I do this many times throughout the day (and night if I'm awake). I enjoy it. I also try to post one pet picture or meme into the [litter box](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/the-litter-box) every day (I usually do this after feeding my horses, as I have fresh pics). I sometimes ask or answer questions on Pets or Stack Overflow (meta or main).

One thing I did do to curb my site use, when I was a member of [Charcoal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), I  joined every Stack Exchange site so I could flag spam. When I finally felt overloaded in my activities, I deleted most of my network accounts and kept the handful that I really enjoy the most or are most relevant to my work. Note I put enjoyment before work? As to me, that's what this is about for me. I enjoy it and I'm learning. A really nerdy thing to be pleased about hey?

Don't forget, it's not all hard work and bristles on here. We're allowed to have fun. I've been thoroughly enjoying the answers to this thread [Happy 10th anniversary Stack Overflow! Commence ... au festival!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374617/happy-10th-anniversary-stack-overflow-commence-au-festival). Especially the suggestion to [win Jon Skeet for a day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374834/3956566) ([he's willing to do housework!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374617/happy-10th-anniversary-stack-overflow-commence-au-festival/374834#comment636695_374885)). *Goes against every humanitarian law I'm sure.*  We have a running thread of the mathematical marvels on [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374836/3956566). It's nice to have a pocket on the site where we're light again.  We all need to remember to enjoy the site. For that I embrace your question. It's refreshing in a plethora of complaints to have someone who can't stay away.

Comment: So, for a TL;DR, how does this help the OP reduce his site usage? You're basically answering: _"I was in the same boat, and ended up using the site more"_

Comment: @Cerbrus I would add that this answer is encouraging him to use the site more and more until he become a moderator and have more things to do ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif sometimes there is no problem, it's in the resisting there is a problem. People often are bound up by what they think they "should" be doing. Do what makes you happy (do I need to add the disclaimer as long as it's not destructive?). Answers do not have to be linear or yes and no.  Sometimes it pays to think outside the box. I'm also giving the OP and other readers avenues to join into chat rooms and enjoy the community. What we post here if for a wider audience than the OP and voters, always.

Comment: OP: _"because of that some of my tasks getting late."_ I'm not sure using the site more is the right answer here.

Comment: @Cerbrus it is a trick ... ;)

Comment: yes but he has a problem " *because of that some of my tasks getting late.* " .. you probably found  a way to deal with all this and it's very good but it's not the same for him

Comment: @TemaniAfif the problem is not the site, it's procrastination. People will find other things to delay things they're avoiding, it's still not the site. Often when you're on a diet you'll think about the thing you tell yourself you cannot have. If you allow yourself to have it, it loses its power and you want it less. However this is getting too deep now. :D

Comment: Maybe hanging out in SOCVR en Charcoal make you realize how much garbage is posted hourly and that onslaught causes you to quit. I like the reasoning.

Comment: @YvetteColomb so let's hope the OP will get it this way ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif it beats reading facebook memes! :D

Comment: @usr2564301 you're aware that's a joke?

Answer (score 0):

Block the site with program and password, which you will forget, so you can't open it anymore.

Answer (score -1):

How ironic is this question with the current events happening: "How can I quit using StackOverflow?"

Account deletion.