# What happened to the 'au festival' part of Stack Overflow's 10th anniversary?

Tags: discussion, swag, 10th-anniversary

First, I'd like to congratulate Stack Overflow for turning 10 years old this year! (A remarkable feat!)

---

Now, getting to my question ...

In the post, [Happy 10th anniversary Stack Overflow! Commence ... au festival!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374617/happy-10th-anniversary-stack-overflow-commence-au-festival), it was stated that there would be a series of posts ***every 7 - 10 days*** to "unlock some pretty awesome limited edition swag".

> What's important is you can expect something special every 7 - 10 days from now until just before the start of Winter Bash

However, the only post so far is [Who cut the cheese?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316515/who-cut-the-cheese), which was posted ~35 days ago (on Oct 9 and ended on Nov 9)! So, just checking, is the 10th anniversary celebration still on?

Comment: 35 days is less than [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514).

Comment: French people were arguing over the grammatical correctness of the sentence. They have been reprinting all the banners, and remaking the cake. The delay is due to cases of force majeure and exceptional circumstances.

Comment: "were arguing..." or maybe just struggling to understand

Comment: @Pac0 Or maybe all the damn kids should watch Tim Burton's Batman to understand the reference. *shakes cane at clouds* ;)

Comment: @PeterMortensen We're in the range of 6-8 weeks now. :P. shall I check back in another 6-8 weeks? :D

Comment: @PeterMortensen Checking back as mentioned earlier :) One addition: "Time for some more swag! " but that's also past 6-8 weeks now.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

We had some departures in our operations department, in particular folks that were directly involved in ordering / storing / sending branded items. The good news is, that role has been backfilled! Yay! The bad news is the position also entails managing all remote employee operations, and a lot of other responsibilities, and we can't dump a whole lot of stuff on someone at once.

***We will continue as best we can*** because we wuv you and we want you to <strike>have bling</strike> feel appreciated and fuzzy, but I don't think we can do it at the frequency we originally planned. The positions were vacated *very soon after* we had coordinated the activities and that left stuff in a state of flux; nobody really saw it coming. I can't go into much more detail than that.

We also have a warehouse full of site-specific stuff that we need to give away, but we're *extremely* short-handed, and getting to that will probably fall into January.

As soon as I know for sure, I'll update the original announcement on MSE. Right now, we're working on ordering cheese boards to get 'em out to folks.

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like you have a lot of flux and it's causing problems. Have you considered a *flux capacitor*?

Comment: @DanBron That joke was really _cheesy_.

Comment: As someone X-raying (grating?) cheese, I rather get the chees board in 6 months time (or just, late) and let the community have more of these giveaways. We are not in a rush, you are not stopping us from eat cheese EVEN IF THAT IS YOUR PLAN BIG CHEESE

Comment: [Hope this helps (upvotes who cut the cheese)](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/929027/who-cut-the-cheese), Tim. ;)

Comment: "Right now, we're working on ordering cheese boards to get 'em out to folks." Are you sure? I thought they had to be ordered after you knew how many to get since they aren't cheap. I still haven't received an e-mail about it. (I just checked again).