# I am resigning as moderator on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-resignation

Effective immediately, I am resigning from my position as moderator on Stack Overflow. I will no longer actively participate on the site or network sites. I will move whatever discussions I can with the people here to other media, and mostly refrain from entering chat.

These words are very hard for me to write — a decent chunk of my life was made here on Stack Overflow. My programming practices, my career, and a good chunk of my professional knowledge are overwhelmingly thanks to Stack Overflow, and the people who make it up.

Back in September, when this whole thing started, I advocated patience. That we didn't know the story. That considering only what we had observed, and ignoring interpretations, there was still a good chance of salvaging the situation.

I no longer hold that belief. I believe that since then the trend had only more extremely sloped downwards, and yet downwards, the two turning points being the absolute lack of resolution with Monica, and the recent firing of two of our most valued members. I no longer believe that there's a good chance that the site and its ideals, for which I had joined all those years ago, can be saved.

I no longer believe that the company's leadership is playing in good faith towards a common goal with its users, and in hindsight I conclude that it has never played in good faith since the beginning of these recent events. I no longer believe that we are playing a [positive sum game](https://www.britannica.com/topic/positive-sum-game) — in fact, I am no longer sure of the expected payoff of many of the players, nor their goals.

---

I'd like to thank the community management team (both current and former) for their boundless patience, professionalism, and competence over the years, and especially in these trying times.

I'd like to thank my fellow moderators across the network, with whom I've engaged in a great many eye opening discussions — on moderation and other topics, and who had radically changed and shaped my way of thinking.

And I'd like to thank all of you. The members of our community. New and veteran. Currently participating and no. High reputation and low. You are who make this community great. And are the only real remaining light I see here. Continue to be excellent to each other, and stay strong.

Thank you. It has been an honor serving you, and with you. And goodbye.

Comment: Wishing you rest of mind. In the wake of the fact that so many mods/people are leaving, we are in a dire need for new blood on the site.

Comment: You would expect that after so many resignations it becomes easy to produce a thoughtful and caring comment. But at each event the words to express what I feel seem to matter less and less. I relate to the patience. And patience you have shown. But I'm not going to argue you should have waited a little bit longer. It is what it is, we were at the top. Gravity takes over, we're rolling down the mountain. I expect it to be an awesome ride down the hill. I'm sad to see you step-out early. I wish I had your courage. Take care. And thank you.

Comment: Gutted to see this. Always enjoyed conversing with you on chat whenever you showed your face.

Comment: Be well.  I enjoyed working with you.  I hope we meet again elsewhere.

Comment: It was always fun to talk to you. You are a great mod everywhere! Wishing you the best of luck for everything. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Hope the SE situation improves, but best of luck in your future contributions!

Comment: for this part: _I will move whatever discussions I can with the people here to other mediums_ I can propose Discord and/or Keybase. Both seem to be, for now, user-aware. Keybase is newer than Discord, but more privacy centered. So long and thanks for all the fish. (I've been eating from the SO plate for quite a while. Even learned how to fish, finally.)

Comment: I guess we will stop seeing the 500 Rep Bounties giving to canonial answers. I was hoping one day you will select one of mine but ... I am now wondering which moderator will be the last survivor of this *community*.

Comment: Not that I like it much, but it has become routine by now since last October. Farewell and all the best!

Comment: <3 I will miss you, buddy :-( I'll try to drop by on Discord every once in a while.

Comment: Thank you for everything Madara! Best mod in JavaScript chat!!

Comment: What whole thing?

Comment: Your twitter bio needs updating, maybe also tweet a link to this question.

Comment: @Oscar https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper#333965 followed by https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342039/firing-community-managers-stackexchange-is-not-interested-in-cooperating-with-t#342039

Comment: I never know whether or not to upvote these resignations, I support your decision and wish you well but it sucks that everyone is being left with no choice but to resign.

Comment: I saw your edited profile page. Does that mean that you gave a 500-rep bounty without actually giving up your own reputation?

Comment: @JL2210 It does not. It only means that I will no longer be available through chat -- which is the normal way people get my attention to excellent answers. Moderators don't have special bounty cheating powers, other than the power to cancel a bounty completely while it is in progress.

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica I will not be removing the account – the diamond will probably be removed (up to the staff, mostly, but that's just how it is). I will not be doing anything special to the account, I will simply stop using it, for the most part.

Comment: well problem is: previous moderators had Shog9 to remove their diamond… Looks like you're stuck with us.

Comment: This doesn't surprise me.  I have noticed a serious trend of moderators focusing on rejecting questions more than answering them.  It makes me want to use it less and less.

Comment: @Jafo The job of moderators has *never* been to answer questions. Their job is to *moderate*. Often, that does mean closing or otherwise rejecting questions that experience has shown aren't suitable for Stack Overflow. It may not always be pretty or glamorous, and I can understand why it's frustrating when you're on the receiving end, but it is absolutely necessary, and it's what made Stack Overflow into the high-quality resource that it is today. There are plenty of other sites on the Internet that have lower or no standards, but you chose to come here instead of there.

Comment: sorry to see you go; thanks for all you've done and all the best to your future endeavours!

Comment: Maybe time for all the elected mods to coordinate a few days of action (strike). And If you're fearing being sacked as a mod, hanging onto the covetous diamond is just FOMO, learn to let it go, you still get the Sheriff badge which is unique to elected diamond mod: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3109/sheriff so you can show new employers what a good boy/girl you were.

Comment: None of us are in it for the badges or brownie points, @Kev. As long as there is some good that can be done for the site by continuing to hold the diamond, there will be people who continue to try and use it to do that good. Obviously, as people feel that all hope is lost, they'll resign, as Madara has done.

Comment: @CodyGray I wasn't either, I only discovered the Sheriff badge yesterday. But I'm not suggesting folks resign, but there is clearly discord within the "community" about the direction of the site we put our energy into in ~2008 (look at my user id [that's not an appeal to authority btw]). I'd love to know how SE would function if all the elected diamond mods coordinated a strike for a few days. And if SE just shrugged their shoulders then why the hell carry on wasting your time in this Sisyphean grind.

Comment: sigh. sad to see you, and others, go. SO seems to becoming less of a place to go and get answers and share knowledge and more of a place full of "do my homework" requests, and without a good sense of community and good moderators it's going to go the way of ExpertSexChange ... perhaps that's their goal, start changing for access to the answers...

Comment: @Kev: I don't think that will work. All quality controls will probably be removed soon anyway (to not annoy anyone in the slightest), so this will be seen as a welcome experiment (*"What are these moderators doing anyway? - let us employ some that we pick to clean up nasty comments"*). That will be Eternal September Mk II on Stack Overflow (the first one approx. in 2010 - *"[... started to have some decidedly big city problems. The one we are most concerned about is an influx of very low quality questions.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/)"* --Jeff Atwood).

Comment: Questions not getting answered? *"Let us employ some AI. That will work. It will also be good for branding and PR."*

Comment: We haven't really spoken but I have nothing but respect for  you as a moderator and human being. Take care in your future endeavors, hopefully they bring you more joy than what you've had being here in recent months.

Comment: Um, newbie here. What exactly is going on? What's the downward slope he's talking about?

Comment: @Kev, I am pretty sure that the upper management wouldn't care much if everyone strikes and the queue hits 3k flags. ([reminds me of this](https://knowyourmeme.com/photos/1535069-i-dont-even-know-who-you-are)). There are already loads and loads of CM escalations in the back log which aren't even being handled.

Comment: @BhargavRao and now that they fired 2 more CMs in an already understaffed team, it's even less likely that they will be.

Comment: Thank you for your hard work.  I've decided to stop reviewing queues and any additional work except I decide.  If any better place appears I'll move there.

Comment: Thank you for all the unpaid hours.  They were much appreciated by those of us who have benefited from your work.  Wishing you many positive didactical experiences in the future!

Comment: @Kyouma A very black and white summary: Basically SO has been around for "ages", and start as a community by the developers, for the developers, to open knowledge of programming to the word, instead of hidden on page 17 answer 3 of an obscure forum thread you found. But in the last years SO has gone from community, to company, to maximizing shareholder profit. People are fired for questioning stuff, community is ignored, outrage is responded with by lawyer speak, re licensing issues, etc...  All your answers are just for making money for SO. They don't care about you or your input.

Comment: If people actually want to do something that SO pay attention to, stop using the site. The only thing that SO are going to listen to right now, is a drop in advertising revenue

Comment: @BhargavRao "I am pretty sure that the upper management wouldn't care much if everyone strikes and the queue hits 3k flags" - of course they would not care about any flag queues. But the management would care if all volunteer moderation stopped, because this would either force the company to hire people to moderate the sites, or let them be overrun with spam.

Comment: This has been a long long time coming. We've been talking about this for years. I totally get running out of patience. Cheers.

Comment: Can someone link/explain what's happening ?

Comment: @Tschallacka You do poorly to ignore the other faction dominant in SO's management at the moment: those pushing for initiatives to create what they term "social justice." There is apparently an alliance between these two forces at the moment, but if social justice proves to be unprofitable, I suspect they'll turn on each other rather quickly.

Comment: what are other mediums as refereed in **I will move whatever discussions I can with the people here to other mediums** ?

Comment: They are gonna need a lot of new moderators now and I have a feeling that they are not even gonna get enough nominations this year .

Comment: @Tschallacka It's not really a conspiracy theory when all you're saying is that a bunch of people are trying to promote and forward their ideas, irrespective of who they have to run over, and they're openly doing so. But yeah.

Comment: @jpmc26 unfortunately it will likely be to late to save SO

Comment: I really feel your disappointment @Madara's Ghost, but as long as you talk in riddles at least I won't understand what's going wrong here.

`when this whole thing started..`

So have the balls and speak clearly about what is going the wrong way. Perhaps you have done it in another post, but reading only this post I am out of context.

Comment: @Tschallacka Thank you. Do you think is this something that will impact the serviceability of the site for amateurs like myself, or more of an intra-community power struggle that will leave the site more or less intact?

Comment: @Kyouma [As someone not very active in this community, how do moderators' resignations affect me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392914/as-someone-not-very-active-in-this-community-how-do-moderators-resignations-af)

Comment: What is all the commotion about? I must have missed something. The site seems the same to me... Ask a question, get an answer, make a comment.

Comment: @TetraDev See the answer at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392914/as-someone-not-very-active-in-this-community-how-do-moderators-resignations-af Essentially: The quality of your answers will decline. The chance you'll get an actual workable answer declines, especially if you have a non-newbie question but something that goes in depth in complexer logic or libraries.

Comment: @Kev I think, alternatively, instead of putting all the burden on moderators and expecting them to do some action (e.g. strike) to make this situation better, we as normal users should think about what we can do. Some users, like me, has greatly reduced or stopped their activity (e.g. answering, flagging, editing, etc.) on the network. However, the problems still continue to be there and have worsen as it seems. So the question is: what else we (the normal users, and not only moderators) can do to show the management we are not satisfied with the current state, and to save this network?

Comment: A crying shame Madara. Was always a joy having you with us in C# chats.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain & all other newbies seeking a link for context: Start [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/287315) or [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526/287315) and if you want, find a more recent serious-step update [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342039/287315).  Note that even questioning harmful company actions & lies about them [can now get you suspended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336622/287315).  I considered editing some links in after a horizontal rule, but Madara could have done that and for some reason chose not to; I don't wish to override that

Comment: Removing the "featured" tag after only two days? Nicely played, SO. Oh, and apparently they still haven't found the time to remove the diamond. Maybe they need to hire a community manager to deal with this stuff.

Comment: @yivi - it's a [day longer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342253/how-long-can-moderator-resignation-notices-be-featured) than they'd have liked it to be featured

Comment: Thank you for recognizing many of my answers with your canonical bounty. Also, thank you for your overall contributions to this community, which were invaluable. I wish you good luck with your future endeavors.

Comment: @yivi the diamond's gone, pretty quickly too I may add. There is one mod I know, on a very different site, who has said to have resigned, but their diamond remains on display after nearly 3 weeks. Another SE mystery, go and figure. The inconsistencies Re policy and management decisions across the network is nothing less than astounding.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: what is a decent set of metrics we could use to measure decline in quality and participation?

Comment: @SamuelLiew - Thanks for re-featuring this.

Comment: @smci One possible metrics is for example the ratio of unanswered or not upvoted questions (corrected for aging effects). See for example [Why is the rate of positively scoring questions and answers steadily declining?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393032/why-is-the-rate-of-positively-scoring-questions-and-answers-steadily-declining). But that's only half of the task. The true and more interesting question would be what needs to be done (here or elsewhere) in order to reverse the trend. How to keep people from asking the same questions over and over again and search instead?

Comment: Press F to pay respect

Comment: Wish you all the best. Thanks for your contributions

Comment: @Trilarion: right, then you mean metrics on the number of recent duplicates which were not closed-as-dupes. It's clearly too high and rising. But measuring that, on a per-tag basis, requires more work.

Comment: So in the end the tide reached even programming and mathematics, hypothetically areas of sheer objective knowledge, that can reach devoidness of personal quirks and snowflaking contests. But it did not. ESR was right in his old classic essay.....

Comment: f @Madara'sGhost 
I'll miss you in chat

Answer (score 351):

Yet again Stack Overflow shoots themselves in the foot and blame someone else for their problems. Thank you for your years of service to the community, and the various chat rooms. It's a shame that the almighty dollar is worth more than the community these days.

Comment: The real shame is that the company seems to think that making money and having a good relationship with the community are mutually exclusive. They aren't (quite the opposite, in fact), and at this point I really hope their strategy backfires as quickly as possible.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica I don't think that that's what the company really thinks.  I think that the company simply doesn't like the current community and want to change them (but using what that community built)

Comment: It seems more like the quick buck instead of an invested dollar in the community that keeps coming back and back over time.

Comment: The almighty dollar might be the motivating factor, but without the community, stack overflow will decline. They may get some short term gains, but at the expense of the future of the platform. It's sad to see this happen to something that we love, but it's a classic story of mis-management, with the wrong people being placed into senior positions. We really need Jeff and Joel back to correct the course of the company. I really hope they're both aware of what's happening, and are thinking of stepping in to save the day.

Comment: @Lamak Daily reminder that they are illegally using content you submitted before the license change, and you (and everyone else) could probably force them to remove it or change the license back, if you're feeling vindictive.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica I disagree. It's not that they think these are mutually exclusive. It's that they believe that admitting one of their employees did something wrong and making money are mutually exclusive. The wrong act in question was certainly not motivated by monetary concerns, but clearly by a particular moral perspective. SO has decided that doing anything but doubling down and defending their employee's actions is too much of a financial (legal) risk, but that would never have been an issue if they hadn't done something defamatory in the first place.

Comment: FWIW I will almost certainly be filing an arbitration suit over relicensing soon. All they had to say in my case was "Whoops, sorry. You're right, 3.0 it is."…yet here we are a few months later having _zero_ advantages for SE, and people like me no longer participating in any meaningful capacity (either posting, answering, or moderating).

Comment: They should at least add a feature, where one can convert their worthless imaginary internet points into token money, which actually pays something ...everything else is exploitation of labor.

Answer (score 173):

Madara, when you first decided to run for moderator, I was generally opposed; I didn't think you would be the right fit. I was so wrong.

You have been the best moderator that I have interacted with on SO. I could always count on you to make the right decision, even when it came to kicking or muting me. You've done everything you could to hold down the fort. I have been generally impressed with how you deal with pressure, and how you decided to moderate a rowdy group of programmers.

I am saddened that you must step down, but I am gladdened that you have decided to "vote with your feet", as George Stocker has recently said.

Comment: This one means a lot coming from you.

Comment: Damn, I thought I was the only one whom he kicked and muted, but then understood his efforts were priceless. He'll he missed so long in SO

Answer (score 93):

You will be missed Madara, along with all of the other moderators who resigned.

We already had an intense wave of moderator resignations, *not only* because of the involuntary termination of one moderator leading to the "Reinstate Monica" movement, but *two* more staff members [yes, official Staff] have been terminated involuntarily. It is a wise decision for you to move on to other activities.

It is especially appalling that Stack Exchange is continuing to ignore the mass exodus of moderators and numerous other users who regularly contribute or even read here. Several contributors *completely deleted* their profiles, including  incredibly old ones with four-digit user IDs. The exodus continued unabated for *months and months* and Stack Exchange's wordings on their official apologies only add more fuel to the uproar.

Stack Exchange's reputation has plunged significantly; that is not the XP points gained through upvotes and lost through downvotes, but an irreversible destruction of reputation due to Stack Exchange's reprehensible actions and their refusal to take appropriate action to reverse it. It is already too late for Stack Exchange to fully reverse their actions; also Monica already stated that she is officially leaving the site as well.

Being a Stack Overflow diamond moderator doesn't define who you are. Best of luck in your future endeavours in 20⁄20 and beyond!

Comment: Where can we cast close vote for Stack Exchange ?

Comment: @Vivek: You have to be a reverse engineer.

Comment: @VivekMishra The only way to cast that vote is with your time, effort, dollars, and feet.

Comment: The professionalism of this moderator (who I did not know before -- I'm not that involved) is on the point of making me agree with this answer.  I'm on the outside of the core, so unlike Madara, I can't see what's actually going on.  But it has me worried about a site that I loved for years before I could get upvote privileges.

Answer (score 80):

I respect your decision here to step down; I wish you the best of luck elsewhere.

I'm still gutted about this whole thing, honestly.  It's a shame to have lost you as a moderator and as a supporter of this site.

Answer (score 77):

OMG I'm gutted.

You've been fantastic, a great mentor as a moderator. You'll be sorely missed. I don't blame you.

When I took a break from moderating a few months ago, the plan was to come back in the new year. I'm not sure what I'd be coming back to. So many of the team gone, Shog gone. It's just heartbreaking. Watching a site so many of us love and have invested so much into lose so many of its core community.

It's devastating, it will get to that point where there will be nothing to come back to.
I cannot participate on meta for this reason except to farewell my friends made over the past 8-9 years on the site.

Comment: What's wrong with the community these days? Oh, I want you as a moderator. :( after this post of equilibrium of votes on your post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374617/happy-10th-anniversary-stack-overflow-commence-au-festival/374667#374667 Why are so many moderators are resigning these days?

Comment: Not only are you gutted, the site is too. @HarshitAgrawal *why are so many resigning?* [Links here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392889/i-am-resigning-as-moderator-on-stack-overflow?cb=1#comment749519_392889)

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal that was fun :)

Answer (score 40):

Madara, I have been your friend for the better part of a decade and I can't express how this makes me feel. You are my favorite moderator, and basically mentor on this site. You guided me when I was struggling, you played video games with me from across the freaking world.

Thankfully, I have ways to still talk to you but this is a big loss for SO, the JS chat, and JS in general. May the strangers find your knowledge and continue to give you canonicals that I know you love.

Love,
Sterling.

Answer (score 29):

Another horrible news on this Tuesday. I hate it but I definitely understand you. Thank you for all the talks in chat, for everything you taught me both in general programming principles as well as JavaScript and TypeScript. Thank you for the several times you have been in chat to help out moderating and the great time in general.

Hearing you won't be around in chat is very sad news but I can understand that too.

Again: Thank you for all you've done and take care!

Answer (score 28):

We will miss you

---

As others have said, you have done a great job moderating!

Answer (score 24):

Nice job Madara. You will be missed.

To Stack Overflow owners: You don't want to end up like Experts-Exchange. Think *again*.

Comment: (and not just with respect to hyphen-less domain name choices!)

Comment: @WBT In 20 years, when "Stackover" becomes urban slang for "diarrhea", they'll regret naming themselves Stackover Flow.

Comment: @user253751 now *that* would be an interesting way for the community to respond to and somewhat accurately label what the company's doing here.  If widely adopted, it could be more effective than the username changes, especially following the [company name change](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/15/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/).

Comment: They will end up as ExpertSexChange.

Comment: I think they [officially unhyphenated themselves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Experts-Exchange#"Experts-Exchange"_or_"Experts_Exchange"?) (but for us it will always be the hyphenated site).

Answer (score 21):

Sad to see you leave.  What struck me most about you is that you were always objective about your opinions.  There is always a pro and con to every situation, and nothing is black and white.  You've helped me see that there's always an alternative view to everything and, right or wrong, it should not be overlooked.

Sorry if my post and the others sounds like a eulogy, but for me it is in a way.  I was / am happy to call you friend.

Hope you don't completely lose contact and that you'll pass by every now and again.  Regardless, no doubt your future is bright, and I'm sure you'll go on to do great things.

Answer (score 19):

It's really hard to see one of the mods that I have interacted with so much, in chat, in late night Overwatch plays, and more than that, a fellow weeb, leave the site.

Thank you for being such an awesome mod and I wish you luck for your future endeavors!

Answer (score 19):

It is very sad to see yet another moderator quit. I hope management reconsiders its harsh stance and comes to its senses.

We have lost a lot of moderators over the past few months. I think that the management is interested in gaining new users rather than retaining valuable members of this community.

Answer (score 15):

Our roads never crossed, but I had known you to be very inspiring. It is sad to see you stepping down. You would be missed for sure.

Thank you for all the dedicated efforts in building and maintaining Stack Overflow/Meta.

All the best for your future endeavors.

Answer (score 14):

Thank you Madara, we haven't interacted a lot, but you were an inspiration non the less.

It saddens me to see you go, but I wish you all the best in the future ahead of you.

Answer (score 13):

It is a sad thing to see you resigning as a moderator. Although, I understand and agree with the reasons, it is sad to see the once great Stack Overflow sliding down hill. At this point, perhaps plummeting down a cliff is a better analogy. :(

Answer (score 13):

You've been such a calm and stabilizing presence in the Java room. It's a shame to see you go, but I support your reasons for doing so. I will miss you! :(

Answer (score 12):

Thank you for all that you brought to the community Madara, probably, more than once I was saved by one of your valuable contributions in JavaScript and the beginning in PHP.

I wish you success in this next stage in your career. Maybe one day, we will cross our paths again. It's sad to see you go since you were an excellent moderator and can be seen in your work, but some paths always come to an end and I respect your decision.

Hopefully, some members from the Board of Stack Exchange would see how their actions are affecting all of us.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think I need to add a new answer. I think everyone else has pretty much covered it, but with the enormous wave of resignations (and terminations) lately, this one hits closest to home.

For anyone unfamiliar with him, Madara is known for being the picture of an ideal moderator: unfailingly level-headed, fair, and foresighted when the rest of us were not.

Your presence will be missed. Thank you for your service.

*And now his watch is ended.*

Answer (score 9):

Once upon a time I began to answer questions on StackOverflow and was happy before I started to figure out why the names of some users prefixed with "Monica". After I have discovered the situation I don't even know what to think...

I wish you good luck and be happy.

Answer (score 8):

We'll will surely miss you a lot!

Whatever you do next, wish you the best luck for that!

Answer (score 7):

It's always sad to see a moderator that has worked in Stack Overflow for a very long time resign. We will always remember you Madara, and how you made Stack Overflow a better place. From those great answers on JavaScript and PHP to literally filtering Stack Overflow, you will not be forgotten in a very long time. People will be inspired from a moderator like you.

Hope your future is bright and sunny!

Answer (score 6):

When we hear some one of our circle is going away, makes us very unhappy. Yet, it's their life so we should accept.

Madara you will always be missed. I wish you all the best for your coming future.

Answer (score 6):

You'll be missed along with the other moderators that have been fired/resigned.

Answer (score 2):

Wish you all the best! We will definitely miss you. Thank you for your contributions.

PS. I hope you will return someday (ahem *`rinne tensei`* ahem) if/when the conditions improve (hopefully!).

Answer (score -123):

> the two turning points being the absolute lack of resolution with Monica, and the recent firing of two of our most valued members

Sorry, I don't understand. You're not a paid employee at Stack Overflow; you're a volunteer. Do you really think the site management will care?

The site has proven successful in sharing programming knowledge, and that's what it was designed for. It's **not** a place for you to share your passion with "Monica", or interfere with the company's internal policy.

So firing two senior community managers is not your business. Neither is good in sharing programming knowledge anyway. I don't see any difference whether they're here with us or not.

Comment: How is Madara "interfering" with anything? And I'm pretty sure this is more related to Shog's and Robert's dismissals than with the Monica Cellio's fiasco. The message is for the community, not for "management". And as you can see, the community does care.

Comment: See comments [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392889/392994#comment749041_392901) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392889/392994#comment749051_392901) for an explanation of why your view is myopic. There are a lot of behind-the-scenes elements that go into making this site work. Moderators and staff members are *critical* to ensuring that the process of asking and answering questions goes smoothly. It may well be true that management doesn’t care about a moderator’s resignation, but the community does, and performative protest is not the only point of this announcement anyway

Comment: This will be the second or third time that I've seen comments like this posted to the metas in the last couple of days.  Frankly, I'm baffled.  Stack Overflow is more than just a place where people share programming knowledge; it is a *community.*  For that community to work, it relies on an army of volunteers that do crucially important work that extends beyond merely contributing questions and answers.  Stack Exchange has demonstrated on a number of occasions that it is hostile to that effort, despite it being one of the company's founding principles.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks, but sorry all mods including yourself work for SO for no money. Volunteer is a volunteer, you never had any real obligation here. Let's not be emotional. You are burning your own time for no return, not covered by employment laws etc. You're not part of SO. SO is a company, that doesn't include you.

Comment: We don't have any real obligations to be good citizens in any context, but most of us try not to be assholes all the time anyway.

Comment: That’s precisely why emotion *is* involved. You don’t freely give years of your life unless you care a lot. Besides that, no one is talking about “obligation” or compensation. We’re thanking and reflecting on Madara’s years of service as he decides to step down as moderator.

Comment: So you believe you need to get emotional when there is money involved, but if it's work you volunteer to help a community, you shouldn't? I'm confused about your outlook.

Comment: @yivi We're here to share programming knowledge, this is a programming site. Mods are nothing more than a cheap free labor, money => respect. No money => no respect. Now, someone is giving up on it and you guys are crazy on it??

Comment: Well, you're right about that.  If Stack Exchange really wants the kind of power and control that they seem to want to have over the volunteers, they should just hire people to do it.  While they're at it, they should probably hire some subject matter experts as well, so that questions will continue to get answered when all of the volunteers leave.

Comment: So you don’t respect me, or Madara, because we don’t get paid? That’s a unique view. I tend to respect and admire unpaid volunteers even more. But okay; I respect your point of view. Even though I didn’t pay you for it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding why you posted this. Are you suggesting we shouldn't have volunteer moderators? If so, couldn't you have just said that?

Answer (score -254):

I don't think most of you understand what Stack Overflow is about, at least from 99.(9)% of the users *(real users)* perspective.

First, I'll tell you what it's ***not*** about:

- ideals
- communities
- social justice wars
- e-friendships
- any kind of confusion that is prevalent in the world today
- Monica
- *(insert anything else unrelated to programming here)*

Stack Overflow is ***actually*** about:

- programming questions
- programming answers
- knowledge sharing
- professionalism

*Leave all your other agendas outside*, and your self-righteousness, virtue signaling sageness ***and*** just **focus on *code***. That's all! Real easy IMO.

Comment: I mean, you can believe that all you want, it doesn't change what the company is doing. In fact that's precisely the way i'd want SO handled.

Comment: I don't really know who/what are you ranting against, but I can tell you with certainty that SO wouldn't be the place it was if not for a sense of community.

Comment: Well, let me introduce you to [50+ communities that don't focus entirely on code](https://stackexchange.com/sites#)

Comment: @CássioRenan This Monica fueled drama is always running its show on StackOverflow.

Comment: No, it's "running its show" on **meta** StackOverflow. If you don't care about meta, why are you ranting here?

Comment: Unless this is talking to the company you're totally missing the point. Even then you're totally missing the point.

Comment: Intrigued about the point of this. Why don’t you focus on code; if this bothers you so much?

Comment: You’re right. That’s what this site is about: high-quality, professional answers to programming questions. Madara, for your information, had his eyes squarely focused on that ball, as does the rest of the community-elected moderator team. Unfortunately, it has reached a point for many of us where there is so much other nonsense going on that we simply cannot pursue this shared goal anymore of a high-quality Q&A site. This is not our fault, and events like this are merely a *reaction* to circumstances over which we have no control.

Comment: @CodeAngry a large part of what people are upset about is that SO is no longer just about code. SE ha virtue-signalled its way into a really strange place, where they no longer care about correctness, and are much more concerned with community, and people, but then they mismanage the community into the ground in order to get more profit. It's a cesspool of corruption.

Comment: @ndugger I don't understand. How can there be corruption on a Q&A site. (good or bad) Questions have Answers (right or wrong). That's all. How can you folks politicize such simple thing?

Comment: @CodeAngry I don't know who you mean by "you folks". I promise you that it was SE that has politicized its own ecosystem. You seemingly have not been paying attention.

Comment: Yeah, clearly, a large chunk of the moderation team, 2 CMs that have been here since the beginning, and a large percentage of the site's most active contributors aren't the "real users" and don't understand what SO/SE is about.

Comment: @ndugger "you folks" is those involved in the politics (the electees). I'm not. I ask questions and answer sometimes. I don't care for honors on a website. I'm doing gruntwork. So drama free.

Comment: CodeAngry, what you need to understand is that there’s a *lot* of hard work that goes on behind the scenes to ensure that users like you can do what you do: ask questions and give/get answers with a minimum of fuss. I totally agree that doing that is the goal, indeed the purpose of this site. But it doesn’t happen by accident. And it doesn’t happen the way it does here on any other site on the Internet. That should tell you a lot. Shog9, Robert, and the community moderators here were absolutely essential to making this place what it is. The fact you don’t have to care is testament to them.

Comment: People care about each other. That's a good thing, at least in my life. Everything you are complaining about is a consequence of this caring.

Comment: Do you really think [so] would have been able to resemble anything like a place to share knowledge without moderators and a community working together to set guidelines? You'd benefit from reading the recent history to see how much damage and dictatorship has been rained down like a shower of sh.. and were all supposed to take it and answer the same low quality crap that fills their coffers.

Comment: that's really a cold answer _shivers_

Comment: So if we should only focus on code, why participate in the review queues or flag garbage? It has no impact on CODE and it's completely unrelated to programming.

Comment: @DeadChex There exist people who genuinely think that.

Comment: _"Leave all your other agendas outside, and your self-righteousness, virtue signaling sageness AND just focus on CODE."_ - Why so rude?

Comment: @Modus Tollens People who say "leave politics out of this" usually mean they want everyone *else's* politics out, leaving only their own.

Comment: This just come across as a huge lack of big picture understanding. A lot more than coding is required to successfully run a website as large as the StackExchange network that's just facts.

Comment: SO is about high-quality answers to high-quality questions. I could care less how much I'm welcomed or accepted, but do I really believe that I can get a good answer or see someone else create a good question if there isn't a general sense of community and well-being? If recent events don't change the community, to hecc with them! But they do, and those who care about the community fight for it. Take my upvote.

Comment: @mackycheese21: The concept of community was in fact [rejected in the](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118383) [beginning on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a65264) (the first many years) Stack Overflow (*"[Stack Overflow is not a social network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178823)"*)

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs so true smh. Although I'm certainly not here for the community and I don't think anybody is, the site has nothing to offer without a community and as such I support its development. If community wasn't linked to content quality, I wouldn't care at all! But I believe it is, so....

Comment: This is easily the worst take I've seen on meta in a long time, and that's saying something.

Comment: @PhasmaFelis That has to be a famous quote by a famous somebody, right? Even if it isn't, it is now. :D

Comment: @PeterMortensen "The concept of community was in fact rejected in the beginning on" That's true, but with only a very low number of votes back then (10-20) and the now rather different user composition, I think that the statistical relevance of such old votes to predict a potential outcome of a similar vote now is rather small. People now could actually want StackOverflow to be a social network and looking at the emotional farewell posts in this thread, I would say it is to some extent. We are not just answering and voting machines, especially not on meta.

Comment: @CodeAngry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392914/as-someone-not-very-active-in-this-community-how-do-moderators-resignations-af

Comment: @PeterMortensen, I have to assume you have zero experience volunteering, or managing volunteers. FYI: getting people to volunteer their time (i.e. no pay), involves fostering a community. Yes, that community of super users are a tiny proportion of SE's total site hits, but they're also the most engaged (i.e. the longest session durations), and vital to keeping this place running in a cost effective way.

Comment: On your list of what SO is actually about, you forgot to add 5. unpaid hours writng answers and 6. unpaid hours moderating the site.  And 7. deciding what the site's rules should be.  Do you think a place like SO just happens in the same way that clean laundry breeds by itself in the airing cupboard?

Comment: It *wasn't* about "social justice wars" until the leadership of SO recently decided it *was* -- to the detriment of everyone but themselves.

Comment: For the record, my "e-friendship" with this resigned-moderator enabled me to get jobs I may not have been qualified for, without his patience and incredible teaching skills. This in turn led me to be able to answer harder questions, and help the community more. Without a community, mentoring each other, we wouldn't make it.

Comment: uhm... I'm quite noobie to this whole META thing, and visibly, not an active participant in the whole community, but back in the days when I was surfing the TechNet and now that I do the same in SE, I know one thing for sure, Q&A forums, not unlike any other community, network, generally entity built by mankind, has its own soul assigned to it, we simply don't interact with the entities directly, we interact with the soul, that's why Reddit for example, is so different from SE, and that's why when souls break, cold death comes, and members become stranger.

Comment: SO is not supported to be any of those irrelevant points. SE regrettably is trying their hardest to make SO and the other network sites embrace those points.

Comment: You're missing the bigger picture, stackoverflow is build on moderator, they are 
 pillars, guess what happen when they keep leaving?

Comment: I think it is not true, because most of the system (rep, badges, meta, etc) seems to be explicitly tuned to cause addiction. From the moment that the company uses our instincts to let us to produce content for them, it is not only about the content, but also about our instincts.