# Why was this answer to a controversial meta question deleted?

Tags: discussion, meta, deleted-answers

Recently this question was asked on meta:

[How do the moderator resignations affect me and the community?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392914/how-do-the-moderator-resignations-affect-me-and-the-community)

A number of answers that don't reflect one particular view of recent events on SE have been heavily downvoted. And [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393005/577088) has been outright deleted for reasons that aren't entirely clear to me. It makes some debatable claims, but I don't see anything that merits deletion.

I could certainly be mistaken in that belief. But I would like to hear some discussion of the rationale for its deletion.

Comment: it was deleted because three people (not moderators) with enough rep to do so voted to delete it.

Comment: A quick read indicates it was not much more than a rant, and moreover, it was wrong about the core reasons for the recent community frustration. Thus, it was just serving to muddy the water, and there is no value in keeping it.

Answer (score 11):

They seem upset about personal pronouns, which isn't *really* that much of a factor on a site like Stack Overflow (after [concerns were allayed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336857/175248) with respect to [the actual FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336367/175248)).

I don't see a reason to undelete that answer since...it's orthogonal to the discussion ***at best***.

Comment: This is why I haven't voted to undelete it yet. But it doesn't seem orthogonal to me. And I don't believe it's typical practice on meta to outright delete answers that are "orthogonal" to the discussion. If you had said "off topic," sure.

Comment: The answer is trying to portray the situation as about pronouns, which is an argument that can be easily shot down as not really a problem on SO when the actual problem isn't about pronouns at all. It added no value to the discussion.

Comment: @senderle:  What's the difference between an answer that's off-topic and one that's orthogonal to the discussion at hand?

Comment: @Makoto one has a relatively clear, agreed-upon meaning in this context, while the other doesn't. I assume if "off topic" obviously applied, you would have used it instead, no?

Comment: Why do you assume that?  Anyway, the real reason for the deletion was that it is an obvous distraction, whether you want to label it as "orthogonal to the question", "off-topic", a "dead end", a "red herring" or "a tin of kidney beans".   If you *really* think that the topic of that answer is actually worth discussing, you could always ask a question about (um) whether StackOverflow moderators have an issue with personal pronouns policy. (I can't see the point in doing that.  The answer is No. But its a free world :-) )

Comment: @StephenC, I assume that people chose their words thoughtfully, with purpose and intent. To assume otherwise would be ungenerous, don't you think?

Comment: Lets be realistic.  Some people do, some people don't. And some people use words differently to others.  But that's beside the point.  The real point is that Makoto is a better judge of what he means than you are ... unless >>you<< are being ungenerous about his motivations.   And to me "orthogonal" and "off-topic" are saying the same thing in this context.