# Why does the community mourn for ex-moderators instead of forging a new community?

Tags: discussion, community, user-retention

*First off, the title itself might look a bit disrespectful or cheeky - that by no means is my intention.*

I'd like to know why some members of this community, clearly unhappy about the recent affairs / events still stick with this place, instead of working together on something new.

I've spent a good few hours reading through recent stepping-down letters by now ex-moderators as well as commemoration posts for their service by the community. From all these amazing comments I've read, just a tiny, very tiny fraction mentioned the idea of leaving the site.

That leads me to ask: Why would anyone, who is unhappy about something, stay in a place that makes him/her go through all these negative emotions / experiences?

Comment: Who said this is "instead"? Codidact is one such attempt to forge a new community.

Comment: @DavyM I'm saying instead and I'm as well aware of Codidact. Didn't want to mention in the post for ethical reasons (direct concurency) in the first way.

Comment: Last summer I asked something that I think is similar to what you're asking about here. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386639/why-do-you-stay A lot of stuff has happened since then, and maybe some people's answers have changed.

Comment: Also highly related is [this MSO post about why it affects the community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392914)

Comment: I guess people have to decide where to go before going. Taking part in Q&A and programming and running your own Q&A platform are different things but it probably comes down to that in the end.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Emotional links are strong. I'm sad Madara stepped down, among other incredible moderators, but I love this community. It's comparable (almost, don't read too deep into the comparison) to a marriage, you don't just give up, you try and try and try and make it work. Eventually, breaking points are (and have been) hit. So while I'm unhappy with many things, I still love helping people too much to renounce the community for decisions not made by them.

To give you some context, I've given 8-9 or so years of my life to this community. That's not something I can just up and walk away from easily. I think also the "bad" recently has heavily overshadowed the good. We still help people code, learn, and talk about really cool ideas and innovations. This brings me joy.

Comment: You mean "Stack Overflow was a dream come true for many of us. Something we felt a part of, something we felt proud to participate in. Now that it's turning around and not being exactly that anymore, it's sometimes hard to detach yourself. You *want it to succeed* so bad you'll stay, you'll roll with the punches when they come, still trying to emulate that dream".  It's.... it's time to wake up, unfortunately :(

Comment: "It's comparable to a marriage" I always knew you loved me, Sterling

Comment: Unfortunately, sticking around because you '`try and try and try to make it work`', and sticking around because of the sunk cost fallacy "`I've given 8-9 or so years of my life to the this community. That's not something I can just up and walk away from easily`" are too hard to tell apart.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I tried to give reasoning to avoid that specific fallacy, such as the breaking points, or the pros vs cons part. Of course if it's more harm than good for you (the average SO user), back away. :)

Comment: Indeed, it is very comparable to a marriage or any other sort of relationship. I've sunk a *lot*, emotionally speaking, into Stack Overflow over the years, and it is very difficult to just throw that away. George is also, of course, correct that it is seriously bordering on the sunk cost fallacy at this point. I struggle with that all the time.

Answer (score 10):

> ... instead of working together on something new.

First of all, plenty of people **are** working on something new already: [Codidact](https://codidact.org/).

But more importantly: there is no real *together* here. There is no organized "union" of users. You see, there are many many different communities on the overall network, and **millions** of users on Stack Overflow. Only a very small fraction of that large group even *noticed* the ongoing storms.

You see, part two: even the very small group of *moderators* doesn't form a true community; see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339475/is-there-an-organized-community-of-moderators). Yes, even the 500+ moderators on the network aren't organized in a way that would allow them to *act* in a uniform way.

In other words: there is nobody around who could make a convincing call that gets "all" of "us" to greener grasses.

Or who could tell the SO moderators to all suspend their activity, or the 150 top SO contributors to totally stop contributing for a month?!

Answer (score 6):

"working together on something new"

Together with whom? The perceived problem is the high handed actions of the Stack Overflow staff.

I don't really see any problems between moderators themselves. There have been disagreements but the discussions are generally polite and civilised.

Answer (score 1):

There are askers and answerers. (And one person can be both.)

### Askers

For askers, there is no where else on the internet where you can get answers as fast, as cheap and as accurate. Especially if you know how to ask a question correctly.

### Answerers

I am an asker.  So I don't really know about this one.  My guess is that those that were here for the community interaction aspect have already (or are soon to have) left.  Those who do it for the enjoyment of sharing knowledge and helping out someone in need don't *need* community interactions to pull that off (though it helps).

But that is just a guess.  As I said, I am an asker, and until a competitor comes along, I will be going to Stack Overflow.  (Though I have noticed that more of my questions go unanswered of late.)

Comment: "*Especially if you know how to ask a question correctly.*" and unfortunately, often even if you do it incorrectly. Way too many "give me the code" questions are answered within 1-2 minutes, if all it takes is yet another basic iteration of a well known answer. Even duplicate closing something ultimately answers the question. Especially sad when I've found the dupe by literally just googling the question's title and landed on a post from 10 years ago with over 1000 upvotes.

Comment: @VLAZ Search for questions including IndexOutOfBoundException in the title and you'll get thousands (!) of results on Stack overflow with only hundreds closed as duplicates, already more than 10 new ones this year. People don't google anymore, I guess.