# Why not just make another Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I'm not very active on Meta. But from a distance I can tell there's quite a bit of angst among the most active community members. Lots of people leaving and whatnot.

So why don't you just create a SO clone and run it your own way?

Couldn't you just:

1. Find/create a different Q&A site software
2. Do a one-time scrape of all the CC-licensed material using APIs and dump it (with [appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/api-terms-of-use) [attributions](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public)) into said software
3. Pass the word that on X day of Y month everyone will stop using SO and switch to new site; and edit, post, and feature content here pointing everyone there

What am I missing?

Edit: this isn't a joke. I'm asking because that's what I do with software when the system stops working: I just switch to (or make) something that does work. I don't understand what's at play here that's preventing everyone who's upset from doing that.

Comment: The goal of SO, and many other community sites, is very different. I do belong to a different site, but the goals there aren't the same. Also, why create a new one, when you're going to need a huge development team to even be able to compete? If those that are fed up don't want to use the site, they will migrate to a different one that already exists.

Comment: What makes SO so attractive is the users, without the users there is no SO. The content is entirely user-generated and created. Making a new site is fine but without that engine to produce content, there's really no point.

Comment: Efforts to create something new are under way.

Comment: @Matthew But if all the moderators begin editing everything to say "switch to the new site Z" then won't the users follow? Nice name by the way :)

Comment: No they would not follow, as the if any moderator did that they would quickly find themselves no longer being a moderator, and their changes would rapidly be reverted.

Comment: *"But if all the moderators begin editing everything to say "switch to the new site Z""* If the moderators start doing that, they are terrible moderators.

Comment: @MattThomas I think you're making a joke, but just in case you're not, the moderators are the very people elected to keep vandalism off the site, it's absurd to think they'd do something like that. Also, any changes can be easily rolled back, especially if they're all under just a few UIDs then a script could be written to roll back any such changes pretty easily.

Comment: @DavyM Not a joke. Edited to clarify that

Comment: Question is: When we decide to move somewhere else, who will pay? Developers need salaries, servers need to be maintained, ...

Comment: @BDL I imagine the cost of writing software would be small to a large community of software developers. And servers are cheap. If my understanding is correct ads alone kept SO alive for a long time

Comment: The main problem are *the people* aka the community. We would all have to switch to another site.

Comment: @MattThomas you willing to provide money for these servers? Yeah they are cheap... but... how many total questions on Stack? Memory is cheap. It's still money. Without a company.... how do we get money? How do we get ads started if volume is going *here*? It seems like very idealistic to just say "well.... go". There's a **lot** involved here. Stack wasn't built in a day. Its replacement won't either

Comment: @JonasWilms I'm imagining a tipping point: so many moderators have moved to the new site preemptively that the remaining moderators are pressured into moving there, too (queues are getting too long, disgruntlement that the garden is no longer growing, etc). Then question/answer quality declines because of lack of moderation. Then users begin to notice SO has turned into just another Yah00 Answers and stop visiting. Meanwhile the new site Z is growing in popularity and climbs the Google search results ranking. There will be a couple of painful years before the transition is complete

Comment: *cough* https://topanswers.xyz *cough* https://codidact.org/ - this is already happening

Comment: @Patrice I get the feeling that something besides the cost of hosting content is what's keeping people here. Yeah a better plan than my oversimplified 1. 2. 3. would be needed, but it really isn't expensive to have a single database and web app. Maybe it would even fit in AWS's free tier or something. It wouldn't even need to scale until the volume of visitors hit, and that's precisely when the funding from ads would scale too. I think paying for it is an easy problem to solve

Comment: "one of the 90%" - can you clarify what do you mean? You seem to have way to much reputation for someone who never post any content on SO - which is what 90% often refers to - "90% (or other kind of *a lot* value) users only read SO content found via search engines"... And being "top 13%" really don't qualify you for 90% of users who post on SO either...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't actively participate on Meta very much. Edited to clarify

Comment: "I'm going to create my own Stack Overflow, with blackjack and... blackjack." - Bender (circa 1999) (redacted)

Comment: I'm gathering from this that the community is split on this issue, and thus my idea wouldn't work. If only 5 of 29 people (vote count as of now) think this is a good idea then there wouldn't be enough momentum behind step #3. I also discovered this isn't a new question around here--I just wasn't searching for the correct words. This idea has popped up [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/392910/3063273), [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393474/3063273), and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/392920/3063273)

Answer (score 9):

Simply cloning the concept of SO would also clone many of the problems.

Instead people are working on sites that do things better than SO, on Q&A sites that are developed with the needs of the community in mind. In particular two projects come to mind:

- https://topanswers.xyz
- https://codidact.org

Answer (score 3):

You're asking the question from the wrong angle. Cloning the software clones the problems of the software.

What you need are users. Not just any user, but *good* users. In the case of Stack Overflow, you need experts for answers. Answers can only be given to questions, so people that know how to ask well written questions are also valuable, to a point.

A fool can ask more questions than a wise man can answer. So, what kind of users would a brand new site attract? How would you attract the best users?

These are the tough questions that Stack Overflow still deals with today. I doubt anyone could make a new site and not deal with those same issues.

Comment: I was trying to ask the question from the perspective of "angst among the most active community members" because they feel it's being run incorrectly. If the angst is caused by technical issues (like not having good moderation tools available) then you have a fair point

Comment: @MattThomas Management issues are unfortunately opaque and subject to change without changing the software. Any site can wind up in the same situation as Stack Overflow when management changes. I am not sure there is a good way to solve that.

Comment: That's true. But I don't view that as a reason to avoid changing the system when problems do arise. When my car breaks down beyond repair I'll switch to a different one even though everyone knows that all cars eventually break down beyond repair. Although I would hesitate switching to a car that was likely to have the same problems soon

Comment: All that said, your answer does help give me some perspective: perception of management isn't the _only_ difficulty that SO is currently working through, and any clone would largely clone those other difficulties. Thank you!