# My flags on rude comments were marked "helpful", but the user seems to have gotten away with it

Tags: discussion, comments, rude-or-abusive

Last night I was offended by another user (they wrote a very rude and insulting comment) which  I flagged twice.

Both flags *"helpful"* but user was not punished. Is it the new policy of keeping as many new users as possible?

At the moment I feel this way: mods told me exactly the same as this user by their lack of action. I hope this is not a new policy. I feel demotivated and humiliated.

If it is, I will obey it, and bar myself from answering the questions in the future.

Comment: Was the comment left posted? If a mod handled the flag it should have been deleted

Comment: Has the comment been deleted? Would be strange if a moderator marked as helpful but didn't delete the comment.

Comment: Posts were deleted but I feel ignoread as nothing else happened

Comment: I'm afraid that this calls for patience and to let a moderator do the part of applying the punishment they see fit.

Comment: Also relevant is that the [moderator resignations from a few months ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392914/how-do-the-moderator-resignations-affect-me-and-the-community) makes it less likely that sanctions are applied in a timely manner. Imagine you were the poor fellow in [this story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396581/1233251).

Comment: I'm still unsure if all actions a moderator took needs to be visible to you. A private message to the user and an annotation might well be their "punishment" for now. You'll never get a public record of that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No moderator has seen those flags yet, therefore you cannot draw any such conclusions.

Because the comments you flagged contained an expletive, they were *automatically* deleted by the system, immediately after you flagged them. No moderator intervention was required. They were automatically marked as "helpful".

Because a significant number of that user's recent comments were flagged as rude, a separate moderator flag has since been raised (also automatic), but no moderator has had a chance to process it yet. I've only seen the flag because of this question, which made me go looking for it.

So, no, there have been no policy changes allowing users to use expletives or otherwise be rude, regardless of how "new" they are. This is still a violation of our [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), which applies to all users equally, regardless of reputation.

There is no cause for alarm. Please do not read subtle messages into flags.

(For what it's worth, the situation has now been handled. We currently have 820 pending moderator flags on Stack Overflow. Almost 300 of those are flags on comments, including both "no longer needed" and "unfriendly/unkind". We promise to get to them all eventually, and we appreciate your patience in the meantime.)

Answer (score 7):

When you flag a comment containing certain rude words the flag is automatically accepted as helpful and the offending comment is deleted. No moderators are involved.

If you're experiencing a pattern of abuse flag a post with a custom moderator flag. Flag one of the offending users posts if they have one or if not you can even flag one of your own posts. Explain the problem clearly so that moderators can take action.