# Should we flag comments made from the Low Quality Posts queue that are plain wrong?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, comments, low-quality-posts

While working the [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) review queue, I've been seeing quite a few comments (and deletion recommendations) that are *simply wrong*. Take this for example:

> [image]

I literally skipped through the LQP queue for ~2 minutes to find that. These aren't uncommon, and there are even worse cases out there. **This is *not* the poster child of answers** (it should probably have some explanation), but it certainly shouldn't be deleted. It might even be incorrect, but at least it *attempts* to answer the question.

I'd like to know what the procedure is for when I stumble across a case like this. Do we flag the comment? The post? Ignore it?

Comment: Might be worth looking at the user's review history to see if they're regularly reviewing incorrectly or if this was just an unusual mistake from an otherwise respectable history of reviews.  Also, through their history you can find the review page for this post, which should tell you if it has been removed from review by other users (as is correct) or if it looks like it's about to be deleted incorrectly.

Comment: I do that, @Servy. I've found some, for lack of a better term, large piles of crap. But it still leaves the question of what to do with the comments themselves, which likely mislead other, newer, users.

Comment: If the *only* problem is a comment that's wrong, and there's no regular review abuse nor is the answer being incorrectly deleted, then I don't see it as any different than any other incorrect comment.  Reply with an explanation of why it's wrong if you want.  If you did flag I'd expect it to be in response to invalid review behavior (in effect inappropriate votes to delete) rather than the comment itself.

Comment: And the example answer is gone.

Comment: Updated with a better example @gunr2171

Comment: I leave a comment explaining why it's wrong and hope that it stops other wrongful delete votes.

Comment: I've seen review audits like that answer, where the correct action would have been "Recommend Deletion".

Comment: Remember, it's *possible* that the original answer should have been flagged, got placed in a review queue, was accurately reviewed, and was updated in response to the review comment within the 5 minute window. In that case, it would look like a mistaken comment, even though it was appropriate at the time it was written.  Not saying that happened here, but it *can* happen.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I'd say flag misplaced comments left via review. If the comments are not at all relevant to the answer ("This does not provide an answer" to a full answer, etc.), they are noise and should be removed.

Moderators currently get flags for contentious reviews, and so far the only useful thing I've been able to do with those is to go back to the reviewed answer and clean up mistaken comments left from review. These misplaced comments often confuse answerers unfamiliar with the review system, and sometimes they offend and even drive off answerers.

Sometimes people see a hypothetical question asked in the first line of a legitimate answer, stop reading at that point, and leave a comment telling people not to ask questions in answers. Sometimes [they vote to delete every short but correct answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256361/should-i-be-concerned-about-delete-reviews-on-reasonable-but-brief-answers). Sometimes I want to punch reviewers through the Internet.

I'm not saying that all comments left from review are bad (many have been very instructive to new answerers leaving questions or comments in answers), but some fraction of them are. I'd prefer to have those flagged for cleanup if you come across blatantly off-point ones.

Comment: As someone who started reviewing relatively recently...  it very quickly skews your perspective.  The overwhelming majority of what you review is crap, and while reviewing I have a tendency to assume it's crap and then start looking for the reason it's crap.  It's not an easy urge to fight.  I don't have a good fix for the problem, but it often feels like the review process is design to make the reviewers jaded.  I know it's not, but it might explain why you want to punch the reviewers :)

Comment: @SomeGuy, just you wait till you get access to the Suggested Edit queue...

Comment: It is odd to read "you would like to punch" people who do not agree with you, especially when it means many.

Comment: @FinalContest - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16496/is-humor-allowed-in-answers

Comment: @BradLarson: well, I also have a [link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254760/are-jokes-that-center-around-code-on-topic/261851#261851) for you, but either way: could you please then make it a proper humor with smiley or just reword it? I am not a native speaker, but it reads verbally abusive and unreasonable to me.

Comment: I quite appreciate your point, @FinalContest. I can tell you it is not so strange for American English.  It does assume a sense of familiarity with the listener that maybe not every reader would share.  On the other hand, I think the fact it is inherently impossible does makes it softer.

Comment: If the technology existed to email someone a punch, I think we'd all have bruised faces. I did have the idea for a foam-rubber head that you could attach to your monitor and connect via USB which the user could slap, poke, stab, or choke. Doing so would cause minor damage to data on the hard drive. I'd buy one.

Comment: @FinalContest: I agree with you. He should not be saying he will punch anyone figuratively or literally. It sounds very unprofessional.

Comment: For the folks too young to remember it: http://bash.org/?4281

Comment: Some detail about which flag reason to choose would improve this answer. I have been using "not constructive" myself.