# Were these LQP auto-comments, in fact, wrong/not constructive, or am I over-defending dubious answers?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, declined-flags, not-constructive

Since starting LQP reviews, I've run across a number of auto-comments along with votes to recommend deletion that seemed careless and inapplicable. Then I read a [screed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) that recommended flagging these sorts of incorrect auto-comments as Not Constructive, per [Brad Larson ♦'s answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265287). Great! I immediately began doing exactly that; running into two such flatly-wrong comments, I flagged them both and hit <kbd>Looks OK</kbd> on the answers. A couple days later… I have two shiny new declined comment flags. This decline rate is unprecedented for me; I hardly ever get two declined per *week*, much less in one day and for the same exact reason. Never mind that those are the only two comments I've flagged that way!

Isn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324819/formulas-for-heights-of-nodes-that-change-after-tree-rotation/29324843#29324843) actually an answer, however wrong it might be, and however plausible the (assumed) reason for the error as given in another comment? And how about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868562/professinal-charting-tool-winforms-wpf/29342162#29342162) (10k only), given that it gives not merely a link to a tool (already definitely *not* NAA) but some further details about its use?

A third flag since then, on an even more blatant case ([code-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29419617) with link-only auto-comment on it) got a helpful marking. Hurray! The comment has not (yet?) been deleted, though. So… I'm getting a distinctly negative vibe here: 0 for 3 on actually getting wrong comments removed.

Comment: @Roombatron5000 that's enough to cause much confusion. No matter how much devs like to tell us to ignore declined flags. Especially since then they shove them in our faces for a week.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Not sure anyone says to *ignore* declined flags, just not to worry about one or two isolated declines. (Paradoxically, the best way to avoid getting declines shoved in your face is probably to flag in fairly high volume, as long as you're reasonably accurate, to make sure that you get at least, I dunno, 20 or so helpful per week, such that one or two declines will never trigger the percentage thresholds.)

Answer (score 5):

One thing to remember is that even canned comments have a time and place.  In the latter case, that canned comment was left on March 30th, 3 days ago now.  There's no way to know if the OP has seen it, let alone decided to ignore it.

I'm not a fan of canned comments, but I understand their usage.  When you're flagging these sorts of comments, you won't go wrong by flagging older comments (obsolete, especially if they've had months to act on it).  If you flag very recent comments, you always run the risk that a moderator will say, "No, this isn't 'Not constructive'" or "No, this isn't obsolete because the user may not have even seen it yet."

I'm not so sure I feel about 'Not Constructive' as a reason to flag these comments: If they leave actionable information for the OP and they do so in a respectful manner, what about them is 'Not Constructive'?

I didn't handle any of these flags; but If I had, it's a coin-toss as to whether or not I would have dismissed (declined) the flag or whether I would have deleted the comment.

It's a coin-toss because if I see a lot of comment flags where someone went through someone else's profile to flag all their canned comments, it gets... annoying. We don't want people to go through other people's profiles to find things to close or flag; so when we see it en masse it starts to warrant declinations after a while.

Comment: Well, I was flagging them as not constructive not because they were *canned*, but because they were *wrong*.

Comment: @NathanTuggy It isn't immediately apparent to me that it *is* an answer, so that's another reason why I wouldn't have deleted the comment.   If there's room for doubt, we'll probably keep it around, all else being equal.

Comment: That seems unfortunate, if the precise circumstances that usually lead to these mistaken comments (accidentally trips some mental heuristic) would also lead to declining flags to correct them.

Comment: @NathanTuggy No doubt. We're not perfect.  That's why there are a lot of moderators and thousands more in the community that can look at this stuff. What we get wrong individually we should get right in the aggregate.

Comment: So, should I just keep trying on those I'm certain of until the flag sticks, or what?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Move on; no need to get stuck on one particular issue.