# Neutralizing the propaganda effects of terrible, inaccurate comments on wrongly deleted answers in FP/LA audits

Tags: discussion, comments, review-audits, deleted-answers, automatic-comments

First Posts and Late Answers audits draw chiefly from posts that have been downvoted and deleted (with various exceptions for corner cases). All that such audits *expect* are simple downvotes, and a reasonable case can be made that almost all answers that have been *deleted* do deserve a downvote, whether or not their deletion is warranted.

Unfortunately, almost every one of these answers has a comment, often an auto-comment from Low Quality Posts, explaining the reason someone thought the answer should be deleted. And quite frequently this is badly wrong, flagrantly violating [Your Answer Is In Another Castle guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) by deleting an answer in review that should *only* have been downvoted, or deleted by 20k users, not 2k users.

This wouldn't be so much of a problem except for one crucial thing: these audits are being deliberately presented, misleading comments and all, as the very models of proper moderation, the things FP/LA reviewers are being tested to try to live up to. So we are training junior site members that it's OK to routinely flag and delete answers because they are very terse ([with](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/16404133) or even [without](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/16426984) that [fatal link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/16386066)). And when they hit 2k, they happily go and Recommend Deletion on all kinds of answers, completely unaware that they're violating *official* site policy, because they're instead following "official" site policy as expressed by "obviously correct" comments on actually deleted posts that the site software really did choose as audits.

How can we avoid spreading misinformation this way? Should we stop showing comments *after* FP/LA audits are revealed to match the way we hide them *before*? Should we add a special heuristic to audit selection to try to filter out the specific very common case of a link-*based* answer that's mistaken for link-*only*?

Comment: Would these comments be flaggable in the meantime? The ones that simply suggest that  the answer be improved almost certainly aren't but the auto-comments all explicitly state that the answer isn't an answer. Could they be considered un-constructive?

Comment: @BSMP: I've [tried that in the past and got nowhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289254/were-these-lqp-auto-comments-in-fact-wrong-not-constructive-or-am-i-over-defe).

Comment: _flagrantly violating_ "Does that mean these answers should forever hang around the site? No, not necessarily - if it turns out they're just not that useful, they should probably still be removed"

Comment: @NathanTuggy - I'd say that just because you had two flags declined on comments two years ago, I wouldn't use that as an indication that none of these should be flagged. I still stand by [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265287/19679) from before that, and if these comments are completely out of place and people flag them, I delete them. I know that other moderators feel the same way. I can't speak for the moderator who handled those, but maybe they didn't think it was worth the effort to remove them.

Comment: Recommended read [A minor change to the description of the "not an answer" flag: "the question" → "a question"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286229)

Answer (score 16):

> So we are training junior site members that it's OK to routinely flag and delete answers because they are very terse ([with](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/16404133) or even [without](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/16426984) that [fatal link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/16386066)). And when they hit 2k, they happily go and Recommend Deletion on all kinds of answers, completely unaware that they're violating *official* site policy, because they're instead following "official" site policy as expressed by "obviously correct" comments on actually deleted posts that the site software really did choose as audits.

Bollocks, I say.

Presumably, these are the best examples that you could cherry-pick in support of your argument, yet it is quite clear to me that the first two are non-answers in need of deletion, completely consistent with our official policies.

[This isn't just a link-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/16404133), it's a link to another question on Stack Overflow, which suggests that the question itself is a duplicate and should be closed. The answer should never have been posted. It should have been a comment or flag on the question, with a link to the proposed duplicate. If two questions have exactly the same answer, to the extent that no additional explanation is needed, then those questions are duplicates.

But even if you disagree with that, I don't see anything here that redeems this from being a useless, link-only answer in flagrant violation of the ["Apples" guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Verdict: [image: NOT Answer]

Furthermore, the phrase that constitutes the bulk of that "answer":

> You could either modify the image pixel by pixel and it's a quick fix.

is utterly nonsensical. It starts out by saying "either", but there's never a second choice presented, so there isn't an "either"-"or" situation at all.

Besides, the question asks why the code they have isn't working to change the background. "Modify the image pixel by pixel" is not an answer to that question; it's an answer to a *different* question, one that was never asked.

Similarly, [this isn't an answer to *any* of the questions that were asked](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/16426984). It might be tangentially relevant, or even helpful information, but it is not an answer and should therefore have been posted as a comment. Whatever you feel about it, it doesn't belong in the answer box. Not because it fails to meet some arbitrary length threshold, but because it is completely at odds with the question.

Verdict: [image: NOT answer]

[This answer is the only one that might possibly be construed as an answer to the question being asked](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/16386066), but honestly, I don't have any problem with training users to delete garbage like this.

Comment: While I have some sympathy with the idea that answers that are clearly on the wrong question should be deleted in review, that's not official guidance, contradicts current mod behavior, and — in these two cases — is definitely rather arguable, since I actually *did* think that, at the very least, an answer about creating multidimensional matrices on a question whose first line talks about creating multidimensional matrices was a plausible attempt.

Comment: "that's not the official guidance" I very much disagree with that. But everyone interprets that "apples" advice differently, which is what makes it so laughably worthless. "contradicts current mod behavior" Also disagree. I've flagged a lot of answers like this and had mods delete them with >98% success. I also see a lot of these such answers that have been deleted, either by the community or by moderators. (And preemptively: if the community is doing this, but moderators aren't, perhaps it's time for *community* moderators to get on board with what the community wants.)

Comment: Also, don't think it's arguable in this case. You have to read past the question's first line. Specifically, you have to look at what *questions* the *question* is actually asking. That "answer" doesn't answer *any* of them. This business about "a plausible attempt" is errant nonsense, and I've talked about that at length before. We don't judge *attempts* here, we judge *content*. Is it an answer? If so, good. If not, delete. It doesn't matter what my *intent* was or that my heart was in the right place when I posted it.

Comment: I don't have time to dig up the guidance I was talking about right now, but this debate has been a problem for a while now. (And, of course, *obviously* you see a lot of answers-to-the-wrong-question deleted by community, since /review will happily do so whenever its technical competence overlaps well enough to be able to give authoritative downvotes in LQP.)

Comment: Good, then the system is working correctly. Knowledgeable users are removing non-answers. If that's *"obvious"*, I couldn't be happier. I'm not sure why you are unhappy.

Comment: Because /review isn't supposed to be about highly-knowledgeable users applying specialized topic expertise to posts, which is guaranteed to (and *does*) produce uneven and unpredictable results. It's for *highly-experienced moderators* (diamond and otherwise) to apply *specialized SO rules* to posts.

Comment: This kind of flies in the face of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: @NathanOliver Which is a good thing because "answers that are merely wrong don't necessarily deserve deletion" is taken as "all attempts to answer *a* (not *the*) question is OK even if the given answer is complete bullshit" - we need to somehow fix that misunderstanding.

Comment: @CodyGray `Good, then the system is working correctly. Knowledgeable users are removing non-answers`  But they're *not* "non-answers".  They're *actual answers* that you don't think are *good* answers.  That you don't like something that *is* an answer doesn't make it not an answer.

Comment: @servy That is absolutely a mischaracterization of everything I said in this answer.

Comment: @CodyGray How so?

Comment: I'm not going to re-explain it. I already took the time to write out why I don't think these are answers to the questions that were asked, other than the fact that they managed to get posted in a box labeled "answer".

Comment: @CodyGray Why are you not replying to people when responding to their comments?  Anyway, you've [said in comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350908/neutralizing-the-propaganda-effects-of-terrible-inaccurate-comments-on-wrongly#comment483364_350924) that you think it's appropriate to delete answers just because you think they're bad answers, so I don't see how I'm mischaractarizing you at all.  Additionally in your answer you explain how their answer *fails* to properly answer the question.  That doesn't make it not an answer, it makes it an *incorrect* answer.

Comment: It's interesting to me that no one ever seems to try to defend answers like these except by resort to "the rules". Not for any actual value they hold.

Comment: I said "cleaning up the site by removing stuff that shouldn't be here". So yes, that's still a mischaracterization. I don't bother to use @ replies much anymore. My inbox has overflowed to hundreds (and more) of items, and I just don't have the time to go through all of those, especially since the UI is so broken that clicking on it once clears all unviewed responses. If you want to follow the discussion, you'll look at the discussion. That's what I do. Sorry if that inconveniences you.

Comment: And seriously, I just lose all respect for people who make this argument: "their answer fails to properly answer the question. That doesn't make it not an answer, it makes it an incorrect answer." I mean, I don't even know what to say to that. With that logic, everything you could post would be an answer. `43` would be an answer. Should we not delete that because it is merely an *incorrect* answer? That's just too stupid for words. The answers discussed are not answering the question that is asked. They are answering something completely different. They are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @CodyGray So by your logic, it's entirely acceptable for me to flag your answer as NAA and vote to delete it from the queue just because I think that it's wrong, and I'm doing nothing wrong at all in doing so, even though your answer is an answer?  Why even have downvotes in the first place if everyone is supposed to *actually* try to delete every answer that they think it's a good answer?  Heck, why even have rules at all if you're advocating flagrantly disregarding them and knowingly violating them just because you want to?

Comment: @CodyGray But anyway, it's a super tiring argument to constantly see people comparing answers honestly attempting to answer the question, and simply failing, to obvious troll answers that are making no honest attempt at answering the question.  People aren't stupid, they can tell the difference between an obvious troll answer like `43` and an answer that's wrong but ernest.  This is a non-issue.  Such troll answers don't even need flags like NAA, they're simply abusive, as is apparent on their face, and nobody is arguing that they stick around.

Comment: No, @Servy. You *disagree* with my answer and think it's wrong. That's very different from the answer having nothing to do with the question and/or responding to a different question than the one that was asked. *"Heck, why even have rules at all if you're advocating flagrantly disregarding them and knowingly violating them just because you want to?"* Absurdist, straw-man arguments like this makes me think that engaging in discussion with you is a waste of time. You're either a fool, or you're playing like one, and neither is worth my time.

Comment: As for the "43" example, I used it because of limited space. Consider instead a question tagged [windows] where an answer is provided about how to do something in Linux. Let's even be charitable and assume it is the same "something". That's…an "attempt" to answer, as you construe it, but this is not an answer by any reasonable definition of the concept because it doesn't respond to the question that is being asked. Now, reviewers still have to use their brains. If the answer leads with, "This can't be done on Windows natively. You need to install a Linux emulator and do…" then it's an answer.

Comment: @CodyGray So you're saying that if *I* think that an answer is wrong, I should just suck it up and leave it there, but if *you* think an answer is wrong you should delete it because it shouldn't be allowed to even be considered by anyone else.  Glad we've sorted that out.  You can only accuse people of making straw man arguments *when you haven't said the things that they claim you say*.  You're constantly saying that you don't care about the rules and advocating ignoring them when they don't suit you, so no, it's *not* absurd to accuse you of saying the things that you've actually said.

Comment: Oh boy. You must have reading comprehension problems. I'm finished with this; my words are having no useful results.

Comment: @CodyGray Having an answer that's *wrong* isn't "not an attempt to answer".  That's...now how that works.  For it to even *be* wrong it needs to actually be an answer (just not a correct one), which that example *would* be.  Claiming that it's not an answer, just because it's wrong, is *not appropriate*.  It *is* an answer.

Comment: You say "wrong" where I say "it doesn't respond to the question that is being asked", and then you act like I'm the one making no sense. Well, I said I was finished. I should probably stick by that promise.

Comment: @CodyGray "wrong" is a superset of "it dosen't respond to the question being asked".  Not properly answering the question asked *makes it wrong*, among other things that can make an answer wrong.  Considering that you're continuing to assert that you haven't said things that you've said, and claiming that you're above the rules, you *are* the one making no sense.

Comment: Wrong cannot be a subset of irrelevant to the question because if the answer is irrelevant to the question, we cannot yet assess its correctness. If you ask me, "What color is the sky?", and I say "apples", then that answer is not wrong. It is [not even wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong), mainly because it is unfalsifiable. It is responding to a question that was not asked. On the contrary, if I said "red", or "there is no sky", or "the sky has no color", then those answers could be deemed wrong because they are actually responsive to the question. Basic epistemology.

Comment: @Servy I think the point Cody's trying to make: I think you should teach your child when to say they are uncomfortable with something. This is an important thing for them to learn. It means that they can decide for themselves in borderline cases when you have already decided they can watch, but they are not enjoying it. I have the same experience with my son who likes watching animated movies, but will tell me if he's feeling uncomfortable.

Comment: @CodyGray Such an answer *can* be tested, because the questions themselves to have verifiably correct answers, and you can demonstrate that those answers *don't meet those criteria*.  You need to have a *question* with no criteria for a correct answer (such as, "What is the sky's gender") for an answer to not even be able to be "wrong", because there is no way to assert whether or not it successfully answers the question.  For your question you can know what the color of the sky is, know if it *is* in fact "apples", and therefore determine if the answer is wrong.

Comment: @Braiam But these cases aren't even borderline.  These queues don't exist for people to determine if they *like* the answers, or whether they think they're good or bad answers.  They're there to determine if they *aren't even an answer at all*, which these posts *are*.  If someone comes across a post that *is an answer*, but makes them uncomfortable for some other reason, they *can* go to the post and take an action that's appropriate based on the problem(s) with the post (perhaps downvoting it, or flagging it for some reason other than what the queue is there to handle, like spam).

Comment: @Braiam It's *not* appropriate for someone to read an answer, think that there's *something* wrong with it (if that something isn't that the post isn't an answer), and therefore vote to delete it by claiming that it's not an answer.

Comment: @Servy aslkfjklsdjlkfj is an answer, because, hey, I'm attempting of answering your argument since english isn't working. An answer that doesn't answer the question, is not an answer to the question asked, therefore it **should be deleted**. It's even in the help center: Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are: [...]  not even a partial answer **to the actual question**

Comment: @Braiam An extremely poor example which I've already explained the numerous flaws with a few comments up.  That's a comment that's simply abusive, and should be treated as such.  There's no need to even *consider* whether or not it's an answer as it's problems are much deeper than that.

Comment: @Braiam By your own argument this answer here merits deletion, because it doesn't answer the actual question asked of "how do we stop the spread of misinformation from incorrect comments on audits" by instead posting an answer saying, "We should encourage the spread of this misinformation because I disagree with that rule", which of course isn't actually answer *the actual question*.

Comment: @Servy Try to argue that with the help center. The help center says very clearly "not even a partial answer to the actual question" => deletion. Or, what do you propose for such answers?

Comment: @Braiam So you feel that this answer should be deleted, because it's not actually answering the question asked?  As for what I'm indicating is appropriate, an answer attempting to answer the question, even if it doesn't *succeed* in answering the question, should be downvoted.  That's the appropriate tool to indicate that you don't think an answer is a useful answer.  Deleting *an answer* as a non-answer, just because  you don't think it's a *good* answer, is not appropriate.

Comment: @Servy any answer that doesn't answer even partially answers the question, should be deleted, that's the only way to keep quality up.

Comment: @Braiam So then you've cast a NAA flag on this answer?

Comment: @Servy why do you believe I should cast a NAA flag? I'm saying it should be deleted, not a flag.

Comment: @Braiam The whole question is about deleting posts as Not An Answer through the relevant review queue.  The question isn't talking about 20k users using delete votes.

Comment: @Servy the whole post is about deleted answers. Those answers should be deleted, however the mechanism is necessary to achieve that goal, **is irrelevant**. Just delete that crap that doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @Braiam No, the question is *specifically* referring to the review queue, and has *specifically* indicated as not referring to 20k delete votes, as they're a different mechanism entirely with entirely different rules and guidelines.  That said, since you apparently think that this answer should be deleted (but for some reason seem opposed to using flags on it even though you think it should be deleted for not being an answer) what actions *have* you taken to delete the answer, since, as per your statements, you feel it should be deleted, even though you don't think it should be flagged.

Comment: @Servy "review queue" which, if you know? The frigging First Post and Late Answers one. The foremost queues. If these guys do not do everything in their power to keep quality up, we have lost! SO has an attention span of just couple hours, anything that didn't get proper moderation handling there, is very likely that they will never get it. Nothing about NAA's there.

Comment: @Braiam And so you're suggesting is that they should break the rules and flag actual answers as non-answers?  By all means, use all of the **appropriate** moderation tools at your disposal to improve the quality of the site, but don't **intentionally abuse the system** in an attempt to delete answers that don't merit deletion just because you don't like them.  Anyway, you didn't answer my earlier questions of what you've done to delete this answer (since you feel it merits deletion, but don't feel it merits flagging).  What actions *have* you taken to delete this answer?

Comment: @Servy when I mentioned flags? **WHEN**!? You have demonstrated that you don't know how to read plain simple english, and a massive waste of time on this subject. You apparently don't want to read what the other want to say without twisting it beyond recognition to be able to run your argument. I frigging give up. I won't continue arguing with you, I have better things to do, like fomenting ways to keep the quality of the site.

Comment: @Braiam [Right here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350908/neutralizing-the-propaganda-effects-of-terrible-inaccurate-comments-on-wrongly/350917?noredirect=1#comment483856_350917).   You have demonstrated that you don't know how to read plain simple english, and a massive waste of time on the subject.  You apparently don't want to read what the other want to say without twisting it beyond recognition to be able to run your argument.  Well anyway, I wish you the worst of luck intentionally abusing the site to delete content that you know full well doesn't merit deletion.

Answer (score 12):

I cannot agree more with Cody Gray's examination, but I want to add this:

The purpose of the "castle guidance" is to warn against becoming a thoughtless reviewing robot who runs a mental regex and votes to delete anything that has a link, without considering the other content.

It's **not** a stone tablet encouraging conversion into another kind of braindead rule follower, who insists that anything in an answer box that has more than just a link should *ipso facto* be preserved.

Junk posts are, and should remain, subject to removal at any time.

This is pretty clearly stated:

> Does that mean these answers should forever hang around the site? No, not necessarily - if it turns out they're just not that useful, they should probably still be removed...

As for the "downvote, don't delete" dichotomy:
Downvotes are for "not useful" posts.
Posts that aren't useful get in the way when searching for solutions.
Removing these un-useful posts (in favor of useful ones) [makes the internet a better place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124706/159251).
QED.

Comment: This, this is what I was saying. Crap answers (even if they are answers) should be deleted. That's how you maintain quality: removing anything that doesn't meet the quality standards.

Comment: This is simply wrong, and is attributing something to Shog's post that is has never said.  If you think a post *isn't useful* then you downvote it.  If you think a post *isn't even trying to answer the question* then it merits deletion.  Deleting posts that *answer the question* that you simply think aren't useful *do not merit deletion*, and you're fragrently violating SE's rulse to claim that a post that is an answer "isn't an answer" just to delete it.

Comment: @Servy https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350908/neutralizing-the-propaganda-effects-of-terrible-inaccurate-comments-on-wrongly#comment483256_350908

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's simply saying that these posts may possibly merit deletion for some *other* reason, through some *other* mechanism, that isn't "not an answer", but claiming that they're Not An Answer is still wrong.

Comment: I was careful to refer to deletion *through review* in opposition to deletion by 20k users. Or is there no distinction in your mind?

Comment: Why should there be a difference? This is the whole reason we have review queues: so the community can take out the trash. The system already handles whatever difference there should be: it takes twice as many (I think?) "recommend deletion" votes through review to actually delete something than it does delete votes by 20k+ users.

Comment: @CodyGray Why should there be any difference between two entirely different mechanisms designed to do two entirely different things?  Deleting things for being Not An Answer should be done when things are Not An Answer.  20k user delete votes aren't (just) for deleting posts for being Not An Answer.  As a 20k user you're given the privilege of voting to delete an answer that *is an answer* that you feel is so egregiously bad that it needs to be removed from the site because it's actively harmful.  Users without 20k *don't have that privilege*.

Comment: @NathanTuggy My reply would just echo Cody's comment above. I don't see why the rules should be different in review vs. for 20kers.

Comment: The point is that making these kind of semantic distinctions just seems like a navel-gazing waste of time. Why do we need to indoctrinate users into the "rules" of Stack Overflow when they already understand the larger picture: cleaning up the site by removing stuff that shouldn't be here. We have *guidelines* for the types of answers that should be removed, but these aren't an exhaustive list, and that is by design. Honestly, I don't understand why Servy et al. think we *don't* give <20k users the privilege to vote to delete garbage. It certainly seems like we do, and if we don't, we should.

Comment: @CodyGray So you're not saying that these actions are appropriate under the rules, you're saying that *you know that they aren't and don't care*.  If that's the case, then *propose a change* rather than falsely claiming that a given action is actually appropriate, when you know that it's not.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. I'm saying I'm not familiar with the "rules" that you and Nathan seem to be referencing. I haven't found such "rules", and the ones you've pointed me to so far, I interpret quite differently.

Comment: @CodyGray You're saying that people should delete answers that are answer using the "not an answer" reason because that's the only option for deletion avaliable for them, since they don't have access to any means of deleting answers that are actually answers.  If you want <20k users to have a means of deleting answers that *are* answers, then by all means, write a proposal for such a feature, rather than telling people to delete answers that they think are wrong, brief, or otherwise not *good* answers using a "not an answer" reason that doesn't apply.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Maybe your concern is that reviewers are not using the technical expertise that we expect of 20kers? That could be something we need training on: "if you're not _able_ to judge whether or not this is good, then please hit 'Skip'".

Comment: Honestly, I can't remember what it says in the queue for <20k users because I haven't been one of those in a while, and I don't have a sock puppet account that I can use to check it out. But I was pretty sure all you see is "Recommend Deletion", nothing about "not an answer" except for the guidance of what types of posts you might want to "recommend deletion" for. But like I said, maybe I'm wrong here. But I'm getting a little bit pissed off that my argument keeps getting mischaracterized as acknowledging that these *are* answers, but should be deleted anyway. I said quite the opposite.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Well, expecting /review to delete any answer a 20ker might **means** expecting every bit of the technical expertise and moderation ability from 2kers that 20kers are supposed to have. They're two quite different rep/privilege levels, and maybe, just maybe, there's a *reason* for that.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Your argument, then, is that users with ~2k rep can't be expected to know how moderation works...which leaves me wondering why you think I should give a tinker's cuss what you, a ~2k user, have to say about how moderation works. I'm not going down that road; instead I'll reply. Yes, the privileges are different; the 2k one is substantially weaker. It takes a flag to even get the post into review, and then six votes to delete. Why that should not be considered training wheels for the 20k privilege is entirely lost on me.

Comment: @JoshCaswell ...you could also add that post deleted by 2Kers from review can be unilaterally undeleted by author (and yes this regularly happens). Wish that all who pretend LQ queue deletions are same as those by diamonds / 20Kers knew how much a difference this makes

Comment: @JoshCaswell The argument is that 2k users can't be expected to know how moderation works *for privileges that they haven't earned yet*, yes.  It expects them to know how to use the privileges that they *have* earned, which are different, and simpler by design.  They're expected to be able to judge if an answer *is an answer* without being trusted to delete answers that *are* answers, but have other problems with them that make them worthy of deletion.

Comment: @Servy per my observations author undeletion happens frequently, I guess they somehow find out (for example tracking rep changes or comments notifications one can easily get to their deleted post and find prominently bold-and-red link "undelete")

Comment: @gnat since you don't really want to use anecdotal data, here's the breackdown for 2016 in flag types [2016: a year in moderation](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340865), you are looking for disputed auto flags.