# Should this answer have been deleted via the LQP Queue?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, deleted-answers, specific-answer

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10215027/4875631) was recently deleted via the [LQP Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18702546).

For the <10k users:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Should this post have been deleted? I feel while it was wrong that the LQP queue should have deleted this answer (It did attempt to answer the question), it should have been *downvoted* instead of deleted.

My main issues for bringing this to the mod attention:

- This is a low quality answer, that would likely draw 3 20k voters attention, and would likely be deleted anyway (Or by the OP himself).
- This was replied to by the question owner saying that the issue was different.

Additionally, should I raise mod attention? I feel like while the question quality was low, and would have been most likely deleted anyway, I should flag it for the simple fact that the LQP reviewers should not have been the ones to delete this answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what response you're expecting.  You've already answered all of the questions that you've asked.

Comment: What I feel may not be correct, nor the right thing to do.

Comment: It may not have been completely _correct_ to delete it (in LQP review)... but then again I see no harm done in it being deleted.

Comment: If you feel something is not correct it's *always* okay to flag the post.  It's up to the moderator to evaluate your flag and determine if it actually merits action.  The worst thing that could possibly happen is that you're wrong and so the moderator explains why this isn't a problem when declining your flag, which...isn't really a problem at all, you've learned what to do in the future.

Comment: @yivi So would this be something the mods would want to bring to the attention of the users in the queue, that it was *incorrect* to delete that via the queue?

Comment: I don't know. Personally, I would prefer the mods focus on actions where the outcome is undesirable, not on on low impact things like these where we'd all can live with the post being deleted anyway. IMO, the robo-approvers are doing more harm than something like deleting actual low quality stuff, even if the process is not completely kosher.

Comment: If you like to flag reviewers you need more then just one example, you need to find 2-3 example (a pattern) that reviewer is messing up.

Comment: Why does it matter that it was deleted by the queue? If that was bad, *you wouldn't be able to cast a delete vote.* SO is community moderated, and when the community has deemed something not to be of value (via downvotes), they can vote to delete it (rules permitting).

Comment: Further to Will's comment, see the two answers at: [Neutralizing the propaganda effects of terrible, inaccurate comments on wrongly deleted answers in FP/LA audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350908/neutralizing-the-propaganda-effects-of-terrible-inaccurate-comments-on-wrongly)