# Question about a deleted answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I'm wondering why my answer to this question was deleted:
[Repository Pattern - Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442102/repository-pattern-caching)

Apparently it happened a long time ago and I only just noticed it.  The accepted answer for this question is IMO not the best approach to the OP's request, as it conflates two concerns in the repository (data access, caching).  The better approach is to put the caching logic into a separate class, but the details of this approach are non-trivial and had been previously described in detail elsewhere, hence my answer referencing these other resources.

Was the issue that there wasn't enough information provided directly in the answer (in which I did answer the question - only the implementation details of my recommended approach were in the cited links).  If this was the issue, wouldn't a comment or edit have made more sense, and in any case shouldn't there have been a notification (and perhaps there was and I missed it) of the deletion sent to me?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Please add a picture of the deleted answer (sry, not question). Otherwise, I can only point you to the help-center.

Comment: I would explicitely state that you're linking to your own blog and ask your self if the answer is useful without the link to your blog. If the answer is *no* you need to improve the excerpt until it does.

Comment: You can easily let [others promote your blog](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fstevesmithblog.com), even Oded has [one answer linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462719/svn-marking-file-production-ready/2462820#2462820) to it ;) And when eventually you do link, [make the affiliation clear](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: Thanks brasofilo, that helps. I'll strive to make it clear in the future if I refer to one of my own articles as a resource for a particular user's question.

Answer (score 4):

It was flagged as spam and deleted less than an hour after being posted, by a moderator.

As for why it was flagged as spam - possibly due to the self promotional nature of the links.

Comment: If I want this answer to be available (with or without links to my blog, just so the correct information is available), would my best path forward at this point be to request it be undeleted and then edit it to make it better, or to submit another answer?  Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like I should request undelete per this answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251724/is-it-ok-to-repost-deleted-answers-as-new-answers?rq=1

Comment: @ssmith - you **could**, but frankly, I don't see any moderator undeleting it, not as it stands. It is not a great answer, by our current standards. If it were expanded and the essential information presented without the need to follow through to your blog, then perhaps. Suggested reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers

Comment: Sure, I meant coordinated with me improving the answer.  I see that I can edit the deleted answer, so assuming I edit it to improve it according to the guidelines you've provided, and then request undelete, that's the way to go?

Comment: @ssmith - absolutely the way to go. Looking forward to those edits :)

Comment: I've edited it. Do you think it would be a good answer now? Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442102/repository-pattern-caching/7805942#7805942

Comment: I've undeleted the answer, @ssmith - not sure how the community will react to the links. We have a bunch of people who are vehemently against any kind of self promotion :(

Comment: Thanks, Oded.  I understand - it's a tough balance to strike.  We'll see.