# "Are you sure you want to add another answer?" when my old answer was deleted

Tags: bug, answers, warning-message

Today on a whim I decided to scroll through answers of my own that were deleted, to see (among other things) what sort of awful nonsense I was getting up to back in 2010.

I found that my answer for [Choose list variable given probability of each variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437250) had been deleted. I agree with the deletion, but when I saw the question I also realized that the standard library had been upgraded since the question was asked, and there is now a better way to solve the problem.

When I clicked to add another answer, I got the confirmation dialog described in the title:

[image]

Isn't that, at least a bit heavy-handed, if not outright inappropriate? Since my old answer was deleted, I hardly see how it causes a problem to try again. While I can see the old answer due to my reputation, and I apparently even have access to an Edit link still, it's not as though this actually makes the content visible to the general public.

(Actually, I see someone commented about the new functionality before me, but still.)

Comment: It is not an option to edit your answer and get it undeleted? To me it looks more like the most intuitive option.

Comment: Could you clarify what the issue is? Is it about "old answer", or "deleted answer", or both "old and deleted answer", or just... "answer"? It's because the confirmation dialog should at least help to prevent new users from posting multiple answers (or even multiple NAA!) as replies (forum vs Q&A).

Comment: @Tom my old answer is bad. It is effectively a link-only answer, and linking to a Google search at that. I was already old enough to know better, too.

Comment: @AndrewT. I consider it an issue because the answer is deleted, and not because it is old. The dialog specifically suggests a course of action that isn't available to me because of the deletion.

Comment: I know what your answer currently is, but that doesn't explain why you can't fix that post.

Comment: If you know your answer is bad, why don't you just fix that answer, and request it be undeleted?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Is it OK to repost deleted answers as new answers when errors have been corrected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297104/4108803)

Comment: "*While I can see the old answer due to my reputation*", I can also see my deleted Answers with only 0.6k-Rep... ([Link to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-answers/523612)) // Ugly Typo in the Title...: "*an another*"...

Comment: I believe users can always view and edit *their own* deleted content. Not posting as an answer, because I'm not entirely sure what the exact flow is for *undeleting* the answer if it was deleted by someone else, but "answer -> self-delete -> edit -> undelete" is a perfectly reasonable flow in some circumstances, and preferable to having lots of deleted versions of the same answer visible to high-rep users.

Comment: @SecurityHound because the answer I would give today is totally unrelated to the one I gave then.

Comment: I don't really see why showing this to you and having you confirm that you want to post a new answer is a problem. You're the human. You get to make the choice. The system just detects that you already have an answer and is asking you about it. How complicated should the check be for if that popup should be shown or not? What criteria exists in the current situation which *guarantees* that that popup isn't needed? In other words, from a programming POV, what are you saying should be included in the check which has a *very* high likelihood of indicating the popup isn't needed 100% of the time?

Comment: I just found it irritating, but I see the room to disagree with that.

Comment: Note that *just* the fact that your answer is deleted isn't sufficient, as there are times, probably even most times, that popup should be shown when a user is wanting to post a new answer, but already has a deleted answer. Your answer was deleted by a moderator and converted to a comment. I'm not sure if that would tend to indicate that the popup is needed *more*, or less often. Yes, in this instance, you didn't need that popup, but how could the system actually know that it shouldn't show that popup?

Comment: I'm not trying to be derogatory or saying that nothing should be changed. At a minimum, the text in the popup could certainly use some work. It's just that nothing *can be* changed with respect to not showing the popup, unless the criteria which should prevent that popup being shown can be determined (i.e. that information is *needed* in order to make any change).

Comment: *"Isn't that, at least a bit heavy-handed, if not outright inappropriate?"* - you are reasoning this from your own singular perspective. Reason from the big picture which includes millions of people who are doing as they damn well please rather than what either the rules or social standards dictate they should do. IMO the message is uncharacteristically tame.

Answer (score 3):

I would not call it a bug but I agree it is undesirable:

Technically, we should be allowing multiple answers on a post that may showcase different solutions and can be voted on independently.

In practice, this message is extremely loud in suggesting users *shouldn't* post multiple answers.

I get the premise - newer users may post again instead of editing. However, at some point some basic familiarity with the site should be assumed. There should be a way to opt out of these messages. Perhaps with enough reputation and/or another measure of site familiarity. It may even be a toggle option in the profile.

Comment: It's not even the message generally that bothers me (although I think your point is well taken about familiarity), it's the fact that a *deleted* question can still trigger the check.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I also understand the sentiment there. You *can* edit your answer and undelete it. But I also disagree with it being *generally* applicable. Surely experienced users would know when to undeleted and when to post a different answer. Or post multiple answers.

Comment: As you can add multiple answers to a question, it is preferred to edit your existing answer, the message helps greatly when the  a so many answer, that you missed yours altogether

Comment: One of the things I often will point out, on those communities I can see delete answers on, is that reposting the same answer after a near identical answer was deleted is often an undesirable outcome.  As the author of a deleted answer you should be reviewing and editing that original answer, getting that undeleted, before you submit any additional answers to the question.  The first thing I will do as a reviewer is compare it to existing answers, and will point out the fact, any answer that had been deleted that looks similar. Submitting multiple unique answers to the same question is fine.